# Golf you a quine for great good!

Tags: code-golf, quine

Using your language of choice, golf a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29).

> A **quine** is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output.

No cheating -- that means that you can't just read the source file and print it. Also, in many languages, an empty file is also a quine: that isn't considered a legit quine either.

No error quines -- there is already a [separate challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36260/make-an-error-quine) for error quines.

Points for:

- Smallest code (in bytes)
- Most obfuscated/obscure solution
- Using esoteric/obscure languages
- Successfully using languages that are difficult to golf in

The following Stack Snippet can be used to get a quick view of the current score in each language, and thus to know which languages have existing answers and what sort of target you have to beat:

```js
var QUESTION_ID=69;
var OVERRIDE_USER=98;

var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";var COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";var answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(index){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+index+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}
function commentUrl(index,answers){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+answers.join(';')+"/comments?page="+index+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}
function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(data){answers.push.apply(answers,data.items);answers_hash=[];answer_ids=[];data.items.forEach(function(a){a.comments=[];var id=+a.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(id);answers_hash[id]=a});if(!data.has_more)more_answers=!1;comment_page=1;getComments()}})}
function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(data){data.items.forEach(function(c){if(c.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER)
answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c)});if(data.has_more)getComments();else if(more_answers)getAnswers();else process()}})}
getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=(function(){var headerTag=String.raw `h\d`
var score=String.raw `\-?\d+\.?\d*`
var normalText=String.raw `[^\n<>]*`
var strikethrough=String.raw `<s>${normalText}</s>|<strike>${normalText}</strike>|<del>${normalText}</del>`
var noDigitText=String.raw `[^\n\d<>]*`
var htmlTag=String.raw `<[^\n<>]+>`
return new RegExp(String.raw `<${headerTag}>`+String.raw `\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw `(${score})`+String.raw `(?=`+String.raw `${noDigitText}`+String.raw `(?:(?:${strikethrough}|${htmlTag})${noDigitText})*`+String.raw `</${headerTag}>`+String.raw `)`)})();var OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(a){return a.owner.display_name}
function process(){var valid=[];answers.forEach(function(a){var body=a.body;a.comments.forEach(function(c){if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
body='<h1>'+c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,'')+'</h1>'});var match=body.match(SCORE_REG);if(match)
valid.push({user:getAuthorName(a),size:+match[2],language:match[1],link:a.share_link,})});valid.sort(function(a,b){var aB=a.size,bB=b.size;return aB-bB});var languages={};var place=1;var lastSize=null;var lastPlace=1;valid.forEach(function(a){if(a.size!=lastSize)
lastPlace=place;lastSize=a.size;++place;var answer=jQuery("#answer-template").html();answer=answer.replace("{{PLACE}}",lastPlace+".").replace("{{NAME}}",a.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",a.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",a.size).replace("{{LINK}}",a.link);answer=jQuery(answer);jQuery("#answers").append(answer);var lang=a.language;lang=jQuery('<i>'+a.language+'</i>').text().toLowerCase();languages[lang]=languages[lang]||{lang:a.language,user:a.user,size:a.size,link:a.link,uniq:lang}});var langs=[];for(var lang in languages)
if(languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
langs.push(languages[lang]);langs.sort(function(a,b){if(a.uniq>b.uniq)return 1;if(a.uniq<b.uniq)return-1;return 0});for(var i=0;i<langs.length;++i)
{var language=jQuery("#language-template").html();var lang=langs[i];language=language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",lang.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",lang.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",lang.size).replace("{{LINK}}",lang.link);language=jQuery(language);jQuery("#languages").append(language)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Do you not mean, *"Golf you a quine for greater good!"?*

Comment: @muntoo it's a play on "Learn you a Haskell for Great Good".

Comment: Did anybody notice that this is question 69?

Answer (score 134):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), side-length <s>17</s> 16, <s>816</s> 705 bytes

```
180963109168843880558244491673953327577233938129339173058720504081484022549811402058271303887670710274969455065557883702369807148960608553223879503892017157337685576056512546932243594316638247597075423507937943819812664454190530214807032600083287129465751195839469777849740055584043374711363571711078781297231590606019313065042667406784753422844".".>.@.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.>.(...........................<.".......".".>./.4.Q.;.+.<.#.>...........................<.".....".".>.#.#.>.N.2.'.\.>.............=.=......._.<.".....".".>.>.;.'.=.:.\.>.......................<."...".".>.\.'.%.'.<.#.>..............._.....<."...".".>.#.#.>.<.#.>...............=.=.<.".".".>.#.\.'.R./.>.................<.".!.........../.>.
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=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-LiMuIy4-Lk4uMi4nLlwuPi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi49Lj0uLi4uLi4uXy48LiIuLi4uLiIuIi4-Lj4uOy4nLj0uOi5cLj4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLjwuIi4uLiIuIi4-LlwuJy4lLicuPC4jLj4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi5fLi4uLi48LiIuLi4iLiIuPi4jLiMuPi48LiMuPi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLj0uPS48LiIuIi4iLj4uIy5cLicuUi4vLj4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLjwuIi4hLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4vLj4u&input=)

This is what it looks like unfolded:

```
                1 8 0 9 6 3 1 0 9 1 6 8 8 4 3 8
               8 0 5 5 8 2 4 4 4 9 1 6 7 3 9 5 3
              3 2 7 5 7 7 2 3 3 9 3 8 1 2 9 3 3 9
             1 7 3 0 5 8 7 2 0 5 0 4 0 8 1 4 8 4 0
            2 2 5 4 9 8 1 1 4 0 2 0 5 8 2 7 1 3 0 3
           8 8 7 6 7 0 7 1 0 2 7 4 9 6 9 4 5 5 0 6 5
          5 5 7 8 8 3 7 0 2 3 6 9 8 0 7 1 4 8 9 6 0 6
         0 8 5 5 3 2 2 3 8 7 9 5 0 3 8 9 2 0 1 7 1 5 7
        3 3 7 6 8 5 5 7 6 0 5 6 5 1 2 5 4 6 9 3 2 2 4 3
       5 9 4 3 1 6 6 3 8 2 4 7 5 9 7 0 7 5 4 2 3 5 0 7 9
      3 7 9 4 3 8 1 9 8 1 2 6 6 4 4 5 4 1 9 0 5 3 0 2 1 4
     8 0 7 0 3 2 6 0 0 0 8 3 2 8 7 1 2 9 4 6 5 7 5 1 1 9 5
    8 3 9 4 6 9 7 7 7 8 4 9 7 4 0 0 5 5 5 8 4 0 4 3 3 7 4 7
   1 1 3 6 3 5 7 1 7 1 1 0 7 8 7 8 1 2 9 7 2 3 1 5 9 0 6 0 6
  0 1 9 3 1 3 0 6 5 0 4 2 6 6 7 4 0 6 7 8 4 7 5 3 4 2 2 8 4 4
 " . " . > . @ . # . # . # . # . # . # . # . > . ( . . . . . .
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . < . " . . . . . .
   . " . " . > . / . 4 . Q . ; . + . < . # . > . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . < . " . . . . .
     " . " . > . # . # . > . N . 2 . ' . \ . > . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . = . = . . . . . . . _ . < . " . . . .
       . " . " . > . > . ; . ' . = . : . \ . > . . . . .
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . < . " . . .
         " . " . > . \ . ' . % . ' . < . # . > . . . .
          . . . . . . . . . . . _ . . . . . < . " . .
           . " . " . > . # . # . > . < . # . > . . .
            . . . . . . . . . . . . = . = . < . " .
             " . " . > . # . \ . ' . R . / . > . .
              . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . < . "
               . ! . . . . . . . . . . . / . > .
                . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Ah well, this was quite the emotional rollercoaster... I stopped counting the number of times I switched between "haha, this is madness" and "wait, if I do *this* it should actually be fairly doable". The constraints imposed on the code by Hexagony's layout rules were... severe.

It might be possible to reduce the side-length by 1 or 2 without changing the general approach, but it's going to be tough (only the cells with `#` are currently unused *and* available for the decoder). At the moment I also have absolutely no ideas left for how a more efficient approach, but I'm sure one exists. I'll give this some thought over the next few days and maybe try to golf off one side-length, before I add an explanation and everything.

Well at least, I've proven it's possible...

Some CJam scripts for my own future reference:

- [Encoder](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qS-N-Y%2514f-W%2582b)
- [Literal-shortcut finder](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='%5B%2C_el%5EA%2Cm*%7B_N%2B%5CAb256%2546%3D*%7D%2F)

Comment: Dear pete what is this.

Comment: How long did it take to make this?

Comment: @AandN I've been playing around with concepts for a general "template" since yesterday now and then (that didn't involve any actual testing... just typing up some stuff on a 7x7 grid and seeing if it might work... I discarded probably half a dozen approaches already there). The actual coding then took this evening... maybe 3 hours, I'd say.

Comment: Well, my guess of 23 was a bit off... :P

Comment: @RikerW Hey, I'm not done yet! (That said, yes it was.)

Comment: Are you done yet?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Ummm, not quite... I've got a couple of ideas, but I haven't found the motivation yet to sit down for another 3-hour Hexagony session to try them out. :P

Comment: Words can't explain how astonished I am when seeing this in action with Esoteric IDE step by step... 

To whom may want to understand this, this Hexagon encodes the "decoder" part into an integer which is printed with `!` and then with a mirror `/` on the 2nd last line it enters the decoder to print the decoder code to complete the quine.

This has a miraculous use of `<` and `>` which reads the multiline very big integer and built the area for storing the decoder.

I'd really love to know what "dozens of approaches" are being considered?

Comment: Explanation? ---

Comment: I suggest you check "Biggest Irreducbile Hello World" and its Python answer - puts 10^10^97! to shame.

Comment: Could you explain this please?

Answer (score 92):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), side length 11, 314 bytes

```
164248894991581511673077637999211259627125600306858995725520485910920851569759793601722945695269172442124287874075294735023125483.....!/:;.........)%'=a':\....................\...................\..................\.................\................\...............\..............\..$@.........\$><>'?2='%.<\:;_;4Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYy7CsJQEAW/RUgINnF37z7z0l@wvyApRCtt9evjtRAbUadZZg7s@XibT9fLfVlQmdg9OALFURDVEphpsoggRJJQsnIUIIG6eIQYiRCwSyAEgQuKhklYJAU0ouAShDSKMBMSk5sbg0nZLAlQKj/ZU/tkten69sW6bsa56XL7gfxfy79L/u5Fq93bqmmYmi2NTd0OuesPPe@X5QE)

---

<sup>Note: Currently [the shortest program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/193220#193220) is only **261** bytes long, using a similar technique.</sup>

Older version:

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), side length 11, 330 bytes

```
362003511553420961423766261426252539048636523959468260999944549820033581478284471415809677091006384959302453627348235790194699306179..../:{;+'=1P'%'a{:..\.....................\...................\..................\.................\................\...............\..............\.............\!$><........\..@>{?2'%<......:;;4Q/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY29CsJAEISfRVBSCHH/bzfR6CNof00K0UpbJQ8fL2ChIOpUO98yM@fjrT9dL/dxZCMAVkRVFoIwFOJkRtNhpKQcIG5sShwaYk4GUSSiEj6lWR0lOblIQkH1UpMSBAIYu5QUA4mWqcTixJoCsDRF4YYp6qJVM7TLaoP7alH1Q1PXuf6k/B/Lv0n@7t9tns279ctr1w1bqhZP1LStHFbj@AA)

Encoder: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHNTsMwEITvfoohApoQ6v4hIdKmIMGFG6hHysEkTmyRJpVj0Up9@LJxCuKEnMiyvfPtatarRPspq@p41JttYyyehBX8UQnDmKyzJpdIEqys0XWJ4RLPtZWlND9aa5GiwDkKXVlpENaN5bpdbUUmI1IZdkoayYgJAvRfinF3Dwd8kHTLRq6GxdUU8cRJmQJcnAG6wHiR5rrUFpeXcIfFh2ipKKySNUKXiy6EuNcjuk9JlxXFpDENOQu6pkTWuQwQx3jL1Hu3B9AtyDa@RKXzIKI057mvRNZsc2oaYWNyZCrCEE1RtNIythG6JkYT0RWnl2hVs@Phej9chvtrVLIurTqFsY8i3r8cY85virtb1tei82x2PHLOyQHHCAkOmFNHA1ImeKH9gpagaEI6xxpEcs9/7Yr6kv6gN@eLeVJ@kBeDMxrPEov/EHd/IOqAe0zdKBz/h/hNS2hqc9zgFaNv)

The program is roughly equivalent to this Python code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDbbsMgDIbv8xSWpimJJrWAzWnS9i5JR9RITakCVZW@fGbSXuzABdgf/u0fLks@xjOu6zDHCdKSYJwucc6Q8le85qqawgQfgEYJgVpKrZGU8EaSQmuMKoFRWmn0gpxBoxV67ck4ZYTnRaTJu6JG7SRZpxyRlSS14zbWCi@FMOiIVSgUaR5lkZxCbb2Q3MkzN9L6qnp42t3mMYcm5blhc21b3Y7jKUAx@gnivQLo2LHis@ez4FfoOBsHBs8KgF@96t2ubjf8eG7Z9/tNBXCI5zyer4GTcErhIe//VvVdCszi/NXUXd3CC3i7XSxMe7ZQCjYQhyGFXD4Vt/zO4QJvT/7f3OE4N/f2p72@jC391vUb)

Unfolded code:

```
           3 6 2 0 0 3 5 1 1 5 5
          3 4 2 0 9 6 1 4 2 3 7 6
         6 2 6 1 4 2 6 2 5 2 5 3 9
        0 4 8 6 3 6 5 2 3 9 5 9 4 6
       8 2 6 0 9 9 9 9 4 4 5 4 9 8 2
      0 0 3 3 5 8 1 4 7 8 2 8 4 4 7 1
     4 1 5 8 0 9 6 7 7 0 9 1 0 0 6 3 8
    4 9 5 9 3 0 2 4 5 3 6 2 7 3 4 8 2 3
   5 7 9 0 1 9 4 6 9 9 3 0 6 1 7 9 . . .
  . / : { ; + ' = 1 P ' % ' a { : . . \ .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \ 
   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \  
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \   
     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \    
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \     
       . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \      
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . \       
         ! $ > < . . . . . . . . \        
          . . @ > { ? 2 ' % < . .         
           . . . . : ; ; 4 Q / .
```

Two `.`s takes 1 bit. Any other characters take 1 bit and a base-97 digit.

## Explanation

Click at the images for larger size. Each explanation part has corresponding Python code to help understanding.

#### Data part

Instead of the complex structure used in some other answers (with `<`, `"` and some other things), I just let the IP pass through the lower half.

[image: Data]

First, the IP runs through a lot of numbers and no-op's (`.`) and mirrors (`\`). Each digit appends to the number in the memory, so in the end the memory value is equal to the number at the start of the program.

```python
mem = 362003511...99306179
```

`!` prints it,

```python
stdout.write(str(mem))
```

and `$` jumps through the next `>`.

Starting from the `<`. If the memory value `mem` is falsy (`<= 0`, i.e., the condition `mem > 0` is not satisfied), we have done printing the program, and should exit. The IP would follow the upper path.

[image: Exit]

(let the IP runs <s>around the world</s> for about 33 commands before hitting the `@` (which terminates the program) because putting it anywhere else incurs some additional bytes)

If it's true, we follow the lower path, get redirected a few times and execute some more commands before hitting another conditional.

[image]

```python
# Python                    # Hexagony
# go to memory cell (a)     # {
a = 2                       # ?2
# go to memory cell (b)     # '
b = mem % a                 # %
```

Now the memory looks like this:

[image: Mem1]

If the value is truthy:

```python
if b > 0:
```

the following code is executed:

[image]

```python
# Python                    # Hexagony
b = ord('Q')                # Q
b = b*10+4                  # 4
# Note: now b == ord('.')+256*3
stdout.write(chr(b%256))    # ;
stdout.write(chr(b%256))    # ;
```

See detailed explanation of the `Q4` at [MartinEnder's HelloWorld Hexagony answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57600/69850). In short, this code prints `.` twice.

Originally I planned for this to print `.` once. When I came up with this (print `.` twice) and implement it, about 10 digits were saved.

Then,

```python
b = mem // a                # :
```

Here is a important fact I realized that saved me about 14 digits: You don't need to be at where you started.

---

To understand what I'm saying, let's have a BF analogy. (skip this if you already understood)

Given the code

```python
while a != 0:
    b, a = a * 2, 0
    a, b = b, 0
    print(a)
```

Assuming we let `a` be the value of the current cell and `b` be the value of the right cell, a straightforward translation of this to BF is:

```python
[             # while a != 0:
    [->++<]       # b, a = a * 2, 0
    >[-<+>]       # a, b = b, 0
    <.            # print(a)
]
```

However, note that we don't need to be at the same position all the time during the program. We can let the value of `a` be whatever we are at the start of each iteration, then we have this code:

```python
[             # while a != 0:
    [->++<]       # b, a = a * 2, 0
                  # implicitly let (a) be at the position of (b) now
    .             # print(a)
]
```

which is several bytes shorter.

---

Also, the corner wrapping behavior also saves me from having a `\` mirror there - without it I would not be able to fit the digits (+2 digits for the `\` itself and +2 digits for an unpaired `.` to the right of it, not to mention the flags)

(details:

- The IP enters the lower-left corner, heading left
- It get warped to the right corner, still heads left
- It encounters a `\` which reflects it, now it heads right-up
- It goes into the corner and get warped again to the lower-left corner

)

---

If the value (of the mod 2 operation above) is falsy (zero), then we follow this path:

[image]

```python
# Python                 # Hexagony   # Memory visualization after execution
b = mem // a             # :          # click here
base = ord('a') # 97     # a
y = b % base             # '%
offset = 33              # P1
z = y + offset           # ='+
stdout.write(chr(z))     # ;          # click here
mem = b // base          # {:         # click here
```

I won't explain too detailed here, but the offset is actually not exactly `33`, but is congruent to `33` mod `256`. And `chr` has an implicit `% 256`.

Comment: Man, that is a *lot* of no-ops

Comment: I laughed at "To understand what I'm saying, let's have a [BrainFuck] analogy." Only on PPCG... :)

Comment: I scrolled like 3 times to the top of the answer to upvote it, only to find out that I did it already...

Comment: Just had another look at this: have you tried avoiding `{` so you can lower the base from `a` down to `A` (naively by doing `='=` but some restructuring might be able to save on some `=` there)? That could shorten the data part significantly.

Comment: @MartinEnder [Failed? :(](https://tio.run/##jdG7TkMxDADQvV9hJKoOSCV@27c8/wD2LgwVTLDC1198A5QuiChKbEfHXvxyeH96fnv9mGdEaqFhHs1bI3VjNBQS1irS2UQD0aIRa4ioiDAmmyW2aMlYhWONEXLTlERlMcnCnJmK4ZLcUFWZSFFcjSijEsfln0N9tV0BbOESJriGTd0dXPSI8FBx3fP7eifYrwqOnX0fOiSh6KDsdEx@0SH5TUfkDx2QR/q//KVwBudwA1d/yhPa/@9Kb@AWqC9vvXSeiGP7VFvdgcDjsul5/gQ) (originally the number is 132 digits long, when base is changed to `A` and the code is unchanged it's 124 bytes long, but each extra character or unpaired `.` adds 2 digits, so the added amount must be < 4 bytes to be useful)

Comment: @user202729 Can't you move the code on the last line one cell right to avoid two unpaired `.`?

Comment: @MartinEnder I overlooked that. / On another note, combining that idea with changing the offset to 1 gives [this](https://tio.run/##jdG7TgMxEAXQfr/iIoFWNIk9bye8foE@TQoEFbTk6zfDAmERirCvZMvW8W3m5el9//z2epgmZQoqhZqGtEJshag2reFGEmFSuEqoUvPKwRzNXRpXdUrqRUreTdlMjJXFS23ZyJZJSy0NqbqIkLM6VzJjJo@oOqxOawBWWGODbZ6/c40rjLjFPvcNdsMfcC67ubRLImmnnGmf/KRd8ov2yG/aIU/0f/lDcYFL3OHmrFzQ@f0h9Yh7UA5pzGHlz4VYFHxMdwvBI9bTdAQ), which saves 7 digits in the data part.

Comment: [Decoder in side length 10 hexagon](https://tio.run/##jZBfT4MwFMXf@ymORAeIY39iYmQwTfTFR7NH50OFQhsZLKVx@/Z4C3OLJoo00PaeXy@nR/LmXZRl26rNttYGj9zw8EFyzZio0joTiCKsjFZVgfEST5URhdBfWmOQIMc5clUaoeFVtQlVs9ryVPikMuyk0IIR4zjonwRTu/fc0I3sa/yuh8HlHMGsk1IJdHUGqBzTOMlUoQxGI3SL@I031BRGigpedxa2hKDXfdrPSRcl1YTWNTlz7KV4al06CAK8pPLVzg5UA7KND16qzPHpWOe570TWTH24NLxaZ0iljzHqPG@EYWzDVUWMIsI2pyQaWe9Cb70fL739FUpRFUYeytj7ftgnx1jnN8HtDet70XrWtkCICSIsaD4NHxdwCeD0jbBm38TfBmH/pIYhwGLDVI8NUgdsyNZfyBHAGaW7RPzjJye9K9wT4uIOc0rRpTTjk3w8ZFNf4BrPmHwC). Unfortunately the data is 9 digits longer than the maximum possible.

Comment: Are you sure the bottom branch of that decoder works?

Comment: @MartinEnder not really, but fixing it will make the data longer, not shorter...

Comment: @MartinEnder I saved 10 bytes with the no-{ idea anyway.

Comment: [310 bytes](https://tio.run/##jYw7CgJBEETPIiiLydg9/a31ewXzSUREI0319OsGJoKoFdV7FHU53Q/n2/UxDMww8XQBQOwJDYgqpzpUKRBVRUhMiZIlyLiSBbhykFdhjEsXDWFysKGOH5ThZnCkpCUHLC0iGa6UNFqBogpZnUw33bauu00pfbc@dn3bldL6ZZsutXxI@8@136Z953dss9WrzGertl8MwxM) by taking advantage of the new space from shortening the number

Comment: [308 bytes](https://tio.run/##jYw7DgIxDETPgrSriGaJHX/i/cEV6N2AhKCCFk4fstQrYBrPPM34dnmero/7qxTABMZKQoJoHJlQgSRrMjMW04hEIAAZjQgpZuBlgyLVJxMljUQZWVBAGLF6IGBcKAtglFTrIPWL5KwYTRk41h1tmjnscQrtOLdh2p5D793B@8GbgY67bkX@H/PfxL9nX0ufM3opbw) by taking out even more space

Answer (score 91):

## MySQL, 167 characters

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(@v:='SELECT REPLACE(@v:=\'2\',1+1,REPLACE(REPLACE(@v,\'\\\\\',\'\\\\\\\\\'),\'\\\'\',\'\\\\\\\'\'));',1+1,REPLACE(REPLACE(@v,'\\','\\\\'),'\'','\\\''));
```

That's right. :-)

I really did write this one myself.  It was originally [posted at my site](https://joshduff.com/2008-11-29-my-accomplishment-for-the-day-a-mysql-quine.html).

Answer (score 84):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>9.8e580</s> <s>1.3e562</s> <s>9.3e516</s> <s>12818</s> <s>11024</s> <s>4452</s> <s>4332</s> <s>4240</s> <s>4200</s> <s>4180</s> <s>3852</s> <s>3656</s> <s>3616</s> <s>3540</s> 2485 + 3 = 2488 bytes

*Now fits in the observable universe!*

```
(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(())(())(()())(()()()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(()())(()()())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(())(()()())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(())(()()())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(()())(()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()())(())(()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(())(()()()())(()()()())(()())([[]]){({}()<(([{}]())<{({}())<>(((((()()()()()){}){}){}())[()])<>{({}())<>{}({}(((()()()){}())){}{})<>{({}())<>({}(((()()()()()){})){}{}())<>{{}<>({}(((()()()()){}){}){})(<>)}}<>(({})[()()])<>}}{}<>({}(<()>)<><{({}<>)<>}<>>){({}<>)<>}{}(<>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}(((((((()()()()()){}){}){}))()))>){({}()<((({}[()])()))>)}{}<>{({}<>)<>}{}>)}{}<>{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#zVVBEoMgDLz3JcmhP2CY6TsYXsLwdhpIEaoE0KrTKgjrmmRhtQEAkVo8EErrzfPB4zXSY69b6949mQunjYzzfnO38ca1ztTSXo85bM9ovr9@3@r5lTnxdO/3FG390os662U5i@Tlnp@liO2q73Do2H8z@zTymlRlb9XPft/mdO39xoz2QVZ4TOteXVfp7Lv/376vv6iXn2u/B2f/e0nxjbEWHTgPqACM85ZQxQAqDelXojrPJw0NoCXGQqULnZnNHOqJXpFqSg6YSBzC@TVlyYigNPp4nwgxOaf3Pj@jADUBqXYVR9RrLLNI0Z9aFgQkgRgnqMvS0DUpZjhlrSNtIKUfIYTn6w0)

---

### Explanation

This Quine works like most Quines in esoteric languages; it has two parts an encoder and a decoder.  The encoder is all of the parentheses at the beginning and the decoder is the more complex part at the very end.

A naive way of encoding the program would be to put the ASCII value of every character in the decoder to the stack.  This is not a very good idea because Brain-Flak only uses 8 characters (`()<>[]{}`) so you end up paying quite a few bytes to encode very little information.  A smarter idea, and the one used up until now is to assign each of the 8 braces to an much smaller number (1-8) and convert these to the ASCII values with our decoder.  This is nice because it costs no more than 18 bytes to encode a character as opposed to the prior 252.

However this program does neither.  It relies on the fact that Brain-Flak programs are all balanced to encode the 8 braces with the numbers up to 5.  It encodes them as follows.

```
(       -> 2
<       -> 3
[       -> 4
{       -> 5
),>,],} -> 1
```

All the close braces are assigned 1 because we can use context to determine which of them we need to use in a particular scenario.  This may sound like a daunting task for a Brain-Flak program, but it really is not.  Take for example the following encodings with the open braces decoded and the close braces replaced with a `.`:

```
(.
((..
<([.{...
```

Hopefully you can see that the algorithm is pretty simple, we read left to right, each time we encounter a open brace we push its close brace to an imaginary stack and when we encounter a `.` we pop the top value and put it in place of the `.`. This new encoding saves us an enormous number of bytes in the encoder while only losing us a handful of bytes on the decoder.

#### Low level explanation

*Work in progress*

Comment: I think you win for longest solution to a code-golf challenge...

Comment: *Just made the largest single golf in the history of PPCG* [Nope.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37797/the-bowlers-golfers-fraction-war/37812#comment86551_37812) **9.8e580** is still impressive though.

Comment: +1 for fitting into the observable universe. Also, with TIO Nexus, the permalink should fit in the answer. https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@q@hoakJxPSB9LMJ0K4Z5TAIwmD4OvCwGxCSncN4EsLZWREMLtse2DIQ/DSCCpTa/rQFLL217fNXfsfidpyzLcZ7IK@mt51H0HYWy1P7fUcNPmvz0x3axs@MKt1XFCPtq3OLRyB6PHNsNe@MakZLwsgZDzFtbCqynkM3oAWLx0rT3NEQSMN@gyeQDy7BJdz2HEF1exPsV7BfgXSR7re7QcznQRzz@fH@ViAqwG8hXaTbMyrAZuOl4bT3OgG6@6@NwFK0QfSyaqecX5RejZIbbayKRyqWZ@cllzQVOW@kiYlNjJUXksYsXoVMLrPaO58zdyRbSCfqpe3e@/t6ucZGdeM1MRBCuN0f

Comment: ... very big golf ...

Comment: I think you win for most bytes cut off

Comment: @Dennis isn't [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37797/the-bowlers-golfers-fraction-war/37812#comment86459_37802) a larger golf? or is it invalid

Comment: @ASCII-only That's only **2.1 × 10^7417**. The other one is **10^(5.2 × 10^152)**.

Comment: @Dennis Ah. the complexity of the expression was confusing me >_>

Comment: From 9.8 * 10 ^ 580 to 2000. Wow

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress on the low level explanation?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 I was writing a memory visualizer for this but kind of got bored of it.  At this point I only have a hazy recollection of how this even works.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 77):

### GolfScript, 2 bytes

```
1
```

(note trailing newline) This pushes the number 1 onto the stack. At the end of the program, GolfScript prints out all items in the stack (with no spaces in between), then prints a newline.

This is a true quine (as listed in the question), because it actually executes the code; it doesn't just "read the source file and print it" (unlike the PHP submission).

---

For another example, here's a GolfScript program to print `12345678`:

```
9,(;
```

1. `9`: push 9 to the stack
2. [`,`](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html#%2C): consume the 9 as an argument, push the array `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` to the stack
3. [`(`](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html#%28): consume the array as an argument, push the array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` and the item `0` to the stack
4. [`;`](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html#%3B): discard the top item of the stack

The stack now contains the array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`. This gets written to standard output with no spaces between the elements, followed by a newline.

Comment: Or PowerShell, or PHP :-)

Comment: You didn't go back in time and give the inventor the idea to invent GolfScript, did you?

Comment: Technically, `1` is not a quine in GolfScript: it outputs `1\n`, where `\n` denotes a newline.  However, the two-char program `1\n` _is_ a quine.

Comment: The one-char program `\n` probably also is?

Comment: No, Ilmari, even that is not a quine. A quine is not just a program which prints its own source, it has to have a specific structure to be a quine.

Comment: @Pseudonym a quine is literally a program which prints its own source. I don't think there are any arbitrary restrictions on "structure".

Comment: @Rokk When Hofstader coined the term, he was specifically thinking of Quine's paradox. "Self-replicating program" or "self-copying program" is the more general term.

Comment: @Pseudonym I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Pseudonym This program doesn't just print its own source. I've expanded with an explanation.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I don't dispute that it's a real, non-cheating self-replicating program. I'm just saying it's not a quine, which is a certain kind of self-replicating program.

Comment: I doubt this is allowed, because on what counts as a valid quine, it says one part of the script has to encode another.

Comment: This program is self-referencing because the program directly says that the exact source string should be printed to the console. The content of the reference is identical to the complete source code before it gets printed out. Therefore this program is a cheating quine.

Answer (score 73):

## [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), <s>5157</s> <s>4514</s> <s>2348</s> <s>1761</s> <s>1537</s> <s>664</s> <s>569</s> <s>535</s> <s>423</s> <s>241</s> <s>214</s> <s>184</s> <s>178</s> <s>175</s> <s>169</s> <s>148</s> <s>142</s> <s>136</s> 133 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 3 bytes.*

<s>This is rather long...</s> (okay, it's still long ... at least it's beating the shortest <s>known Brainfuck</s> C# quine on this challenge now) *but* it's the first quine I discovered myself (my Lua and Julia submissions are really just translations of standard quine techniques into other languages) *and* as far as I'm aware no one has written a quine in Prelude so far, so I'm actually quite proud of this. :)

```
7( -^^^2+8+2-!( 6+ !
  ((#^#(1- )#)8(1-)8)#)4337435843475142584337433447514237963742423434123534455634423547524558455296969647344257)
```

That large number of digits is just an encoding of the core code, which is why the quine is so long.

The digits encoding the quine have been generated with [this CJam script](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qW%25%7Bi2%2BAb%7D%2F&input=7(%20-%5E%5E%5E2%2B8%2B2-!(%206%2B%20!%0A%20%20((%23%5E%23(1-%20)%23)8(1-)8)%23)).

This requires a standard-compliant interpreter, which prints characters (using the values as character codes). So if you're using [the Python interpreter](http://web.archive.org/web/20060504072747/http://z3.ca/~lament/prelude.py) you'll need to set `NUMERIC_OUTPUT = False`.

### Explanation

First, a few words about Prelude: each line in Prelude is a separate "voice" which manipulates its own stack. These stacks are initialised to an infinite number of 0s. The program is executed column by column, where all commands in the column are executed "simultaneously" based on the previous stack states. Digits are pushed onto the stack individually, so `42` will push a `4`, then a `2`. There's no way to push larger numbers directly, you'll have to add them up. Values can be copied from adjacent stacks with `v` and `^`. Brainfuck-style loops can be introduced with parentheses. See the link in the headline for more information.

Here is the basic idea of the quine: first we push loads of digits onto the stack which encode the core of the quine. Said core then takes those digits,decodes them to print itself and then prints the digits as they appear in the code (and the trailing `)`).

This is slightly complicated by the fact that I had to split the core over multiple lines. Originally I had the encoding at the start, but then needed to pad the other lines with the same number of spaces. This is why the initial scores were all so large. Now I've put the encoding at the end, but this means that I first need to skip the core, then push the digits, and jump back to the start and do the printing.

#### The Encoding

Since the code only has two voices, and and adjacency is cyclic, `^` and `v` are synonymous. That's good because `v` has by far the largest character code, so avoiding it by always using `^` makes encoding simpler. Now all character codes are in the range 10 to 94, inclusive. This means I can encode each character with exactly two decimal digits. There is one problem though: some characters, notably the linefeed, have a zero in their decimal representation. That's a problem because zeroes aren't easily distinguishable from the bottom of the stack. Luckily there's a simple fix to that: we offset the character codes by `2`, so we have a range from 12 to 96, inclusive, that still comfortably fits in two decimal digits. Now of all the characters that can appear in the Prelude program, only `0` has a 0 in its representation (50), but we really don't need `0` at all. So that's the encoding I'm using, pushing each digit individually.

However, since we're working with a stack, the representations are pushed in reverse. So if you look at the end of the encoding:

```
...9647344257
```

Split into pairs and reverse, then subtract two, and then look up the character codes:

```
57 42 34 47 96
55 40 32 45 94
 7  (     -  ^
```

where `32` is corresponds to spaces. The core does exactly this transformation, and then prints the characters.

#### The Core

So let's look at how these numbers are actually processed. First, it's important to note that matching parentheses don't have to be on the same line in Prelude. There can only be one parenthesis per column, so there is no ambiguity in which parentheses belong together. In particular, the vertical position of the closing parenthesis is always irrelevant - the stack which is checked to determine whether the loop terminates (or is skipped entirely) will always be the one which has the `(`.

We want to run the code exactly twice - the first time, we skip the core and push all the numbers at the end, the second time we run the core. In fact, after we've run the core, we'll push all those numbers again, but since the loop terminates afterwards, this is irrelevant. This gives the following skeleton:

```
7(
  (                   )43... encoding ...57)
```

First, we push a `7` onto the first voice - if we don't do this, we'd never enter the loop (for the skeleton it's only important that this is non-zero... why it's specifically `7` we'll see later). Then we enter the main loop. Now, the second voice contains another loop. On the first pass, this loop will be skipped because the second stack is empty/contains only 0s. So we jump straight to the encoding and push all those digits onto the stack. The `7` we pushed onto the first stack is still there, so the loop repeats.

This time, there is also a `7` on the second stack, so we do enter loop on the second voice. The loop on the second voice is designed such that the stack is empty again at the end, so it only runs once. It will *also* deplete the first stack... So when we leave the loop on the second voice, we push all the digits again, but now the `7` on the first stack has been discarded, so the main loop ends and the program terminates.

Next, let's look at the first loop in the actual core. Doing things simultaneously with a `(` or `)` is quite interesting. I've marked the loop body here with `=`:

```
-^^^2+8+2-!
(#^#(1- )#)
 ==========
```

That means the column containing `(` is not considered part of the loop (the characters there are only executed once, and even if the loop is skipped). But the column containing the `)` *is* part of the loop and is ran once on each iteration.

So we start with a single `-`, which turns the `7` on the first stack into a `-7`... again, more on that later. As for the actual loop...

The loop continues while the stack of digits hasn't been emptied. It processes two digits at a time,. The purpose of this loop is to decode the encoding, print the character, and at the same time shift the stack of digits to the first voice. So this part first:

```
^^^
#^#
```

The first column moves the 1-digit over to the first voice. The second column copies the 10-digit to the first voice while also copying the 1-digit back to the second voice. The third column moves that copy back to the first voice. That means the first voice now has the 1-digit twice and the 10-digit in between. The second voice has only another copy of the 10-digit. That means we can work with the values on the tops of the stacks and be sure there's two copies left on the first stack for later.

Now we recover the character code from the two digits:

```
2+8+2-!
(1- )#
```

The bottom is a small loop that just decrements the 10-digit to zero. For each iteration we want to add 10 to the top. Remember that the first `2` is not part of the loop, so the loop body is actually `+8+2` which adds 10 (using the `2` pushed previously) and the pushes another 2. So when we're done with the loop, the first stack actually has the base-10 value and another 2. We subtract that 2 with `-` to account for the offset in the encoding and print the character with `!`. The `#` just discards the zero at the end of the bottom loop.

Once this loop completes, the second stack is empty and the first stack holds all the digits in reverse order (and a `-7` at the bottom). The rest is fairly simple:

```
( 6+ !
8(1-)8)#
```

This is the second loop of the core, which now prints back all the digits. To do so we need to 48 to each digit to get its correct character code. We do this with a simple loop that runs `8` times and adds `6` each time. The result is printed with `!` and the `8` at the end is for the next iteration.

So what about the `-7`? Yeah, `48 - 7 = 41` which is the character code of `)`. Magic!

Finally, when we're done with that loop we discard the `8` we just pushed with `#` in order to ensure that we leave the outer loop on the second voice. We push all the digits again and the program terminates.

Comment: [Listening to Hello World in Fugue right now](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/fugue/src/hworld.mid)... pretty catchy.

Comment: Martin, you gotta stop somewhere.

Comment: I love that this has over 5000 bytes golfed overall, plus an acknowledgement to Sp3000 for saving 3 of them.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Those were the last 3 bytes though, so it's quite a big deal. ;)

Answer (score 55):

## Javascript ES6 - 21 bytes

```
$=_=>`$=${$};$()`;$()
```

I call this quine "The Bling Quine."

Sometimes, you gotta golf in style.

Comment: Does `!$=_=>\`!$=${$}()\`()` save you 2 bytes?

Comment: `Invalid assignment left hand side`. Wish it worked :(

Comment: Does `!_=>\`!$=${$}()\`()` work ?

Comment: Declaration of quine is missing. Nope.

Comment: ``$=_=>eval(`$=${$};$()`);$()`` is a rather amusing quine to crash your browser.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `$=_=>eval\`$=${$};$()\`;$()` Two bytes off

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg that won't work

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg eliminating parentheses around template literals only works on native prototype functions, like `Array.prototype.join`.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll TIL

Comment: I love this one so much. I don't think it's quite correct, though - the REPL environments I run it in all enclose the output in quotes, and evaluating it with node.js doesn't output anything.  Needs a `console.log` somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I wrote this over a year ago (it was considered valid then), and I haven't been following quine rule changes too closely. However, adding `alert` or `console.log` after the arrow function and wrapping the template string in parentheses would work.

Comment: Also if You run this in the concole, it overwrites $ ( jQuery function ) on this site, and the upvote function won't work anymore. :)

Comment: If this is a quine, `0` is too.

Answer (score 52):

## Vim, 11 bytes

```
q"iq"qP<Esc>hqP
```

- `iq"qP<Esc>`: Manually insert a duplicate of the text that *has to be* outside the recording.
- `q"` and `hqP`: Record the inside directly into the unnamed `""` register, so it can be pasted in the middle. The `h` is the only repositioning required; if you put it inside the macro, it will be pasted into the result.

**Edit**

A note about recording with `q"`: The unnamed register `""` is a funny thing. It's not really a true register like the others, since text isn't stored there. It's actually a pointer to some other register (usually `"-` for deletes with no newline, `"0` for yanks, or `"1` for deletes with a newline). `q"` breaks the rules; it actually writes to `"0`. If your `""` was already pointing to some register other than `"0`, `q"` will overwrite `"0` but leave `""` unchanged. When you start a fresh Vim, `""` automatically points to `"0`, so you're fine in that case.

Basically, Vim is weird and buggy.

Comment: wait why doesn't this work for me

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Can't say for sure, but one explanation is most likely. Probably should have had it in the write-up before, since it can throw people off. Read the edit.

Comment: you should probably put something about how pressing `y` or something before running can help

Comment: Why don't you use `␛` to show pressing the <Esc> key? Part of this [Unicode Block “Control Pictures”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2400)

Comment: @mbomb007 The `<Esc>` notation is standard in Vim mappings (`:help <>`) and that's what vimgolf.com uses. Any experienced vimgolfer will be used to reading it. As for the unicode, I have to squint to read the little letters, and they obscure the method of typing them and searching the help file.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I already had something on the clipboard -- the final `P` pastes what was originally on the clipboard.

Answer (score 48):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), side length <s>15 14 13</s> 12, <s>616 533 456</s> 383 bytes

After several days of careful golfing, rearranging loops and starting over, I've *finally* managed to get it down to a side 12 hexagon.

```
1845711724004994017660745324800783542810548755533855003470320302321248615173041097895645488030498537186418612923408209003405383437728326777573965676397524751468186829816614632962096935858"">./<$;-<.....>,.........==.........<"......."">'....>+'\.>.........==........<"......"">:>)<$=<..>..............$..<"...."">\'Q4;="/@>...............<"....."">P='%<.>.............<"..!'<.\=6,'/>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxNSsRAEAXgsxhGGnFM6r@qne7gEXSfjQvRlW719LEyGIXBBw3V1Ffv7eXz@fXj/WtdMUQd0UkApFYBdDNwUSYJAA9WoUBQCVdV5lAFYHFgAgZiwoSGis4gCNWjqknyyLXUUHYMk3xIlVggCOrWAMrBwu4UTObu6lxNzY2rK4krikXeBdVAs/wxVctrq6yhMQzzOLXD6a6NW@bjuKf337ENP0Pqcma3ZRnnf@guE97PN@3Qs/bPnXPYVZqlPMmpD9PDhdl7kjz2ct0uOrbtVWnj0u1YpnldvwE)

Unfolded:

```
            1 8 4 5 7 1 1 7 2 4 0 0
           4 9 9 4 0 1 7 6 6 0 7 4 5
          3 2 4 8 0 0 7 8 3 5 4 2 8 1
         0 5 4 8 7 5 5 5 3 3 8 5 5 0 0
        3 4 7 0 3 2 0 3 0 2 3 2 1 2 4 8
       6 1 5 1 7 3 0 4 1 0 9 7 8 9 5 6 4
      5 4 8 8 0 3 0 4 9 8 5 3 7 1 8 6 4 1
     8 6 1 2 9 2 3 4 0 8 2 0 9 0 0 3 4 0 5
    3 8 3 4 3 7 7 2 8 3 2 6 7 7 7 5 7 3 9 6
   5 6 7 6 3 9 7 5 2 4 7 5 1 4 6 8 1 8 6 8 2
  9 8 1 6 6 1 4 6 3 2 9 6 2 0 9 6 9 3 5 8 5 8
 " " > . / < $ ; - < . . . . . > , . . . . . .
  . . . = = . . . . . . . . . < " . . . . . .
   . " " > ' . . . . > + ' \ . > . . . . . .
    . . . = = . . . . . . . . < " . . . . .
     . " " > : > ) < $ = < . . > . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . $ . . < " . . . .
       " " > \ ' Q 4 ; = " / @ > . . . .
        . . . . . . . . . . . < " . . .
         . . " " > P = ' % < . > . . .
          . . . . . . . . . . < " . .
           ! ' < . \ = 6 , ' / > . .
            . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

While it doesn't look like the most golfed of Hexagony code, the type of encoding I used is optimised for longer runs of no-ops, which is something you would otherwise avoid.

#### Explanation

This beats the [previous Hexagony answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74294/76162) by encoding the no-ops (`.`) in a different way. While that answer saves space by making every other character a `.`, mine encodes the *number* of no-ops. It also means the source doesn't have to be so restricted.

Here I use a base 80 encoding, where numbers below 16 indicate runs of no-ops, and numbers between 16 and 79 represent the range 32 (`!`) to 95 (`_`) (I'm just now realising I golfed all the `_`s out of my code lol). Some Pythonic pseudocode:

```
i = absurdly long number
print(i)
base = 80
n = i%base
while n:
    if n < 16:
        print("."*(16-n))
    else:
        print(ASCII(n+16))
    i = i//base
    n = i%base
```

The number is encoded in the first half of the hexagon, with all the

```
" " > 
 " " > 
  ... etc
```

on the left side and the

```
 > ,
< "
 >
< "
... etc
```

on the right side redirecting the pointer to encode the number into one cell. This is taken from [Martin Ender's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74294/76162) (thanks), because I couldn't figure out a more efficient way.

It then enters the bottom section through the `->`:

```
       " " > \ ' Q 4 ; = " / @ > . . . .
        . . . . . . . . . . . < " . . .
         . . " " > P = ' % < . > . . .
          . . . . . . . . . . < " . .
     ->    ! ' < . \ = 6 , ' / > . .
```

`!` prints the number and `'` navigates to the right memory cell before starting the loop. `P='%` mods the current number by 80. If the result is 0, go up to the terminating `@`, else go down and create a cell next to the mod result with the value `-16`.

```
   . " " > ' . . . . > + ' \ . > . . . . . .
    . . . = = . . . . . . . . < " . . . . .
     . " " > : > ) < $ = < . . > . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . $ . . < " . . . .
       " " > \ ' Q 4 ; = " / @ > . . . .
                      /
                     /
```

Set the cell to (mod value + -16). If that value is negative, go up at the branching `>+'\`, otherwise go down.

If the value is positive:

```
 " " > . / < $ ; - < . . . . . > , . . . . . .
  . . . = = . . . . . . . . . < " . . . . . .
   . " " > ' . . . . > + ' \ . > . . . . . .
```

The pointer ends up at the `;-<` which sets the cell to (mod value - -16) and print it.

The the value is negative:

```
   . " " > ' . . . . > + ' \ . > . . . . . .
    . . . = = . . . . . . . . < " . . . . .
     . " " > : > ) < $ = < . . > . . . . .
```

Go down to the `> ) <` section which starts the loop. Here it is isolated:

```
     . . > ) < $ = < . .
      . . . . . . . . .
       \ ' Q 4 ; = " /
```

Which executes the code `'Q4;="=` which prints a `.` (thanks again to Martin Ender, who wrote a [program](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%3AC%3B%27%5B%2C_el%5EA%2Cm*%7B_Ab256%25c%5C%2B%7D%25%7B0%3DC%26%7D%2C1f%3EN*&input=.) to find the letter-number combinations for characters) and moves back to the starting cell. It then increments (`)`) the mod value cell and loops again, until the mod value is positive.

When that is done, it moves up and joins with the other section at:

```
 " " > . / < $ ; - < . . .
            \
             \
```

The pointer then travels back to the start of the larger loop again

```
 " " > . / <--
  . . . = =
   . " " > ' 
    . . . = = 
     . " " > :
      . . . . .
       " " > \ ' . .
        . . . . . . .
         . . " " > P = ' % < . > . . .
```

This executes `='=:'` which divides the current number by 80 and navigates to the correct cell.

#### Old version (Side length 13)

```
343492224739614249922260393321622160373961419962223434213460086222642247615159528192623434203460066247203920342162343419346017616112622045226041621962343418346002622192616220391962343417346001406218603959366061583947623434"">/':=<$;'<.....>(......................<"......"">....'...>=\..>.....................<"....."">....>)<.-...>...........==......<"...."">.."...'.../>.................<"..."">\Q4;3=/.@.>...............<".."".>c)='%<..>..!'<.\1*='/.\""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NSgUxDIWfxaKMV7DT/DS38bbFV3A/GxHRlW716cekM4jixUJ/wvnOSfr6/PH48v72ua7ExIqIfCQVYGT1ShIpEYKg7USbBqpWozsQiCWl4rWwuwUyZM1YQFE2Jg1GxFR7q9ee6Bqoa2AuATAeE2fvyqaD7kwZflc902exlG/1OFTgZI7i82YlkWRzFFKbZ1Ah9Hm6a/XyNNXoq1/Hs6uG7TaDX5OjbbHjP3qH@6HG2/ibbe0nOcCw5879fJ5BywOfqM3x/k9fJ0KI/enQpqs6el3Ylxa4adMclxDW9Qs)

<s>I can most definitely golf another side length off this, but I'll have to leave it til' tomorrow because it's getting late.</s> Turns out I'm impatient and can't wait until tomorrow. <s>Maybe another side can be golfed?</s> <s>:(</s>   *ahhhhhhhhh* i did it!

I even golfed off a [couple of extra digits](https://tio.run/##fZPLTsMwEEX3@YoBFUUIMH7FcWhr8QMs2GfTBYIVbOHrw52x86S0o4ztyfHN9ST9ePs@vX99/gwDLX4tBfJkKCJbcpjxqq0WSAeoQbYYc@ZVoLiAAmpWqg0i4vKICEE9Ux7lFtnhCqQF1zJqChNmWBpiBtHgjhE5hwqHqyZXTopaJFtgTrZ68YfDFFBjO1e1uNbyaGa0PMbw/kw68efLITLgC@ow56N3gjZYtaVXnWSuWLEThDRsilkrXbHiIjc5Yh1xO8rRcj@zsBbRWI6bpceus7Sao0KqEYke6UA72tMDxhlIdL/Gy@yIUH/iAKU1Xab14kaiO6x6mW3gC@Ir6dzn0fkTrltxfyze0xY943W3lR2/hyzaI7@id3uIXqM5z7Po9IGpszFJzt@rmry@QK6mG/GZttglueX/6AolFughFvCCavhLW@gfd2oYfgE) with a base 77 encoding, but it doesn't really matter, since it has the same bytecount.

Comment: This is amazing. The idea for this hybrid run-length encoding is really neat. :) Remind me to give you a bounty if I forget.

Answer (score 46):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 20 bytes

```
3434Qu$v@!<"OOw\o;/"
```

*Almost got the* `\o/`...

**Net**:

```
    3 4
    3 4
Q u $ v @ ! < "
O O w \ o ; / "
    . .
    . .
```

## Try it online

Try it [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=MzQzNFF1JC9AITwiT093XG87LyI=)!

## Additional notes

### Background story

After being impressed by reading [this great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103532/63774) by @ais523, I started thinking about further golfing the quine. After all, there were quite a few no-ops in there, and that didn't feel very compressed. However, as the technique his answer (and mine as well) uses, requires the code to span full lines, a saving of at least 12 bytes was needed. There was one remark in his explanation that really got me thinking:

> On the subject of golfing down this quine further, [...] it'd need [...] some other way to represent the top face of the cube [...]

Then, suddenly, as I stood up and walked away to get something to drink, it struck me: What if the program didn't use character codes, but rather numbers to represent the top face? This is especially short if the number we're printing has 2 digits. Cubix has 3 one-byte instructions for pushing double-digit numbers: `N`, `S` and `Q`, which push `10`, `32` and `34` respectively, so this should be pretty golfy, I thought.

The first complication with this idea is that the top face is now filled with useless numbers, so we can't use that anymore. The second complication is that the top face has a size which is the cube size squared, and it needed to have an even size, otherwise one number would also end up on the starting position of the instruction pointer, leading to a polluted stack. Because of these complications, my code needed to fit on a cube of size 2 (which can contain 'only' 24 bytes, so I had to golf off at least 21 bytes). Also, because the top and bottom faces are unusable, I only had 16 effective bytes.

So I started by choosing the number that would become half of the top face. I started out with `N` (10), but that didn't quite work out because of the approach I was taking to print everything. Either way, I started anew and used `S` (32) for some reason. That did result in a proper quine, or so I thought. It all worked very well, but the quotes were missing. Then, it occured to me that the `Q` (34) would be really useful. After all, 34 is the character code of the double quote, which enables us to keep it on the stack, saving (2, in the layout I used then) precious bytes. After I changed the IP route a bit, all that was left was an excercise to fill in the blanks.

### How it works

The code can be split up into 5 parts. I'll go over them one by one. Note that we are encoding the middle faces in reverse order because the stack model is first-in-last-out.

#### Step 1: Printing the top face

The irrelevant instructions have been replaced by no-ops (`.`). The IP starts the the third line, on the very left, pointing east. The stack is (obviously) empty.

```
    . .
    . .
Q u . . . . . .
O O . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

The IP ends at the leftmost position on the fourth line, pointing west, about to wrap around to the rightmost position on that same line. The instructions executed are (without the control flow character):

```
QOO
Q   # Push 34 (double quotes) to the stack
 OO # Output twice as number (the top face)
```

The stack contains just 34, representlng the last character of the source.

#### Step 2: Encode the fourth line

This bit pretty much does what you expect it to do: encode the fourth line. The IP starts on the double quote at the end of that line, and goes west while pushing the character codes of every character it lands on until it finds a matching double quote. This matching double quote is also the last character on the fourth line, because the IP wraps again when it reaches the left edge.

Effectively, the IP has moved one position to the left, and the stack now contains the representation of the fourth line in character codes and reverse order.

#### Step 3: Push another quote

We need to push another quote, and what better way than to recycle the `Q` at the start of the program by approaching it from the right? This has the added bonus that the IP directly runs into the quote that encodes the third line.

Here's the net version for this step. Irrelevant intructions have been replaced by no-ops again, the no-ops that are executed have been replaced by hashtags (`#`) for illustration purposes and the IP starts at the last character on the fourth line.

```
    . .
    . .
Q u $ . . . . .
. . w \ . . / .
    . #
    . #
```

The IP ends on the third line at the first instruction, about to wrap to the end of that line because it's pointing west. The following instructions (excluding control flow) are excecuted:

```
$uQ
$u  # Don't do anthing
  Q # Push the double quote
```

This double quote represents the one at the end of the third line.

#### Step 4: Encoding the third line

This works exactly the same as step 2, so please look there for an explanation.

#### Step 5: Print the stack

The stack now contains the fourth and third lines, in reverse order, so all we need to do now, it print it. The IP starts at the penultimate instruction on the third line, moving west. Here's the relevant part of the cube (again, irrelevant parts have been replaced by no-ops).

```
    . .
    . .
. . . v @ ! < .
. . . \ o ; / .
    . .
    . .
```

This is a loop, as you might have seen/expected. The main body is:

```
o;
o  # Print top of stack as character
 ; # Delete top of stack
```

The loop ends if the top item is 0, which only happens when the stack is empty. If the loop ends, the `@` is executed, ending the program.

Comment: wish I could upvote this more

Comment: Bounties are always welcome ;-)

Answer (score 44):

### Brainf*ck (755 characters)

This is based off of a technique developed by Erik Bosman (ejbosman at cs.vu.nl).  Note that the "ESultanik's Quine!" text is actually necessary for it to be a quine!

```
->++>+++>+>+>++>>+>+>+++>>+>+>++>+++>+++>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>++>>>+++>>>>>+++>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+++>>>>>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>+++>+>++>+++>>>+>+>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>>>>>+>+>>>+>+>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>+++>+>+++>+>++>+++>++>>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>+++>+>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>+++>+>>+++>>+++>>>+++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++>++++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++++>+++>+++>++++>++++++++++++++>+++>++++++++++>++++>++++++>++>+++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++>++++>++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++>>++++>++++++++++++++>+++>+++>++++>++++++>+++>+++++++++>++++>+>++++>++++++++++>++++>++++++++>++>++++++++++>+>+++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++
ESultanik's Quine!
+[[>>+[>]+>+[<]<-]>>[>]<+<+++[<]<<+]>>+[>]+++[++++++++++>++[-<++++++++++++++++>]<.<-<]
```

Comment: That's a clever way to do it.

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @proudhaskeller IIRC, the part before `ESultanik's Quine!` sets up the memory as a stack encoding `ESultanik's Quine!` and onward, with two bytes of memory for each character (ASCII value offsets from 0x1F). The final bit of code loops through the memory, first programmatically reproducing the `++>+++…` codes for each character, then actually printing the characters.

Comment: Can be golfed by removing unnecessary chars like newlines, 'E"s, and other insignificant characters.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy They are required for it to be a quine! While it is true that they could be removed, one would also have to change the preceding code to maintain the quine property.

Comment: That's true. Also the newlines are necessary.

Comment: To make this even better, Mr. Bosman created a brainf*ck quine that is 410 characters long and some Mr. Christofani modified it, so it uses only 392 characters.
This is how it looks like:
    ->++>+++>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>++>+++>++>>+++>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>>+++>>+++>>>>>+++>+>>>>>>>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>++>+++>>>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>>>>>+>+>>>+>+>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>++>+++>++>>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>>>+++>+>>>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>+++>+>>+++>>+++>>++[[>>+[>]++>++[<]<-]>+[>]<+<+++[<]<+]>+[>]++++>++[[<++++++++++++++++>-]<+++++++++.<]

Comment: The fact that this includes non-Brainfuck characters make be doubt whether it is a serious contender for the winning criteria of the challenge.

Answer (score 39):

## Vim, <s>17</s>, 14 keystrokes

Someone randomly upvoted this, so I remembered that it exists. When I re-read it, I thought "Hey, I can do better than that!", so I golfed two bytes off. It's still not the shortest, but at least it's an improvement.

---

For a long time, I've been wondering if a vim quine is possible. On one hand, it must be possible, since vim is turing complete. But after looking for a vim quine for a really long time, I was unable to find one. I *did* find [this PPCG challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2985/compose-a-vim-quine), but it's closed and not exactly about literal quines. So I decided to make one, since I couldn't find one.

I'm really proud of this answer, because of two *firsts*:

1. This is the first quine I have ever made, and
2. As far as I know, this is the worlds first *vim-quine* to ever be published! I could be wrong about this, so if you know of one, please let me know.

So, after that long introduction, here it is:

```
qqX"qpAq@q<esc>q@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@19YGKFUWOBY6FAoDcT//wMA)

Note that when you type this out, it will display the `<esc>` keystroke as `^[`. This is still accurate, since `^[` represents `0x1B`, which is escape [in ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), and the way vim internally represents the `<esc>` key.

*Also* note, that testing this might fail if you load an existing vim session. I wrote a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) answer explaining that [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74663/31716), if you want more information, but basically you need to launch vim with

```
vim -u NONE -N -i NONE
```

*or* type `qqq` before running this.

Explanation:

```
qq                  " Start recording into register 'q'
  X                 " Delete one character before the cursor (Once we play this back, it will delete the '@')
   "qp              " Paste register 'q'
      Aq@q<esc>     " Append 'q@q' to this line
               q    " Stop recording
                @q  " Playback register 'q'
```

On a side note, this answer is probably a world record for most 'q's in a PPCG answer, or something.

Comment: `2i2i<esc>` is so close. I feel like there must be something I can do to make this work.

Comment: @zwei I know, it's close it hurts! Actually, `<Esc>` is implicit in V,  so [that works](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MmkyaQ&input=). Unfortunately it also adds a newline, which is why I haven't posted it yet.

Comment: `q"iq"qbP<Esc>qbP` is 11. After you put this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/56kg5d/a_sequence_of_vim_keystrokes_that_creates_the/d8k6z8o), I investigated the vimgolfing here and decided to make an account. This is the answer I posted there.

Comment: @udioica Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 36):

## PostScript, 20 chars

Short and legit. 20 chars including trailing newline.

```
(dup == =)
dup == =
```

Answer (score 35):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 45 bytes

```
.....>...R$R....W..^".<R.!'.\)!'"R@>>o;?/o'u"
```

You can test this code [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Li4uLi4+Li4uUiRSLi4uLlcuLl4iLjxSLiEnLlwpISciUkA+Pm87Py9vJ3Ui&input=&speed=20).

This program is fairly hard to follow, but to have any chance to do so, we need to start by expanding it into a cube, like the Cubix interpreter does:

```
      . . .
      . . >
      . . .
R $ R . . . . W . . ^ "
. < R . ! ' . \ ) ! ' "
R @ > > o ; ? / o ' u "
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

This is a Befunge-style quine, which works via exploiting wrapping to make string literals "wrap around" executable code (with only one `"` mark, the code is both inside and outside the quote at the same time, something that becomes possible when you have programs that are nonlinear and nonplanar). Note that this fits our definition of a proper quine, because two of the double quotes don't encode themselves, but rather are calculated later via use of arithmetic.

Unlike Befunge, though, we're using four strings here, rather than one. Here's how they get pushed onto the stack;

1. The program starts at the top of the left edge, going rightwards; it turns right twice (`R`), making it go leftwards along the third and last of the lines that wrap around the whole cube. The double quote matches itself, so we push the entire third line onto the stack backwards. Then execution continues after the double quote.
2. The `u` command does a U-turn to the right, so the next thing we're running is from `'"` onwards on the middle line. That pushes a `"` onto the stack. Continuing to wrap around, we hit the `<` near the left hand side of the cube and bounce back. When approaching from this direction, we see a plain `"` command, not `'"`, so the entire second line is pushed onto the stack backwards above the third line and the double quote.
3. We start by pushing a `!` onto the stack (`'!`) and incrementing it (`)`); this produces a double quote without needing a double quote in our source code (which would terminate the string). A mirror (`\`) reflects the execution direction up northwards; then the `W` command sidesteps to the left. This leaves us going upwards on the seventh column, which because this is a cube, wraps to leftwards on the third row, then downwards on the third column. We hit an `R`, to turn right and go leftwards along the top row; then the `$` skips the `R` via which we entered the program, so execution wraps round to the `"` at the end of the line, and we capture the first line in a string the same way that we did for the second and third.
4. The `^` command sends us northwards up the eleventh column, which is (allowing for cube wrapping) southwards on the fifth. The only thing we encounter there is `!` (skip if nonzero; the top of the stack is indeed nonzero), which skips over the `o` command, effectively making the fifth column entirely empty. So we wrap back to the `u` command, which once again U-turns, but this time we're left on the final column southwards, which wraps to the fourth column northwards. We hit a double quote during the U-turn, though, so we capture the entire fourth column in a string, from bottom to top. Unlike most double quotes in the program, this one doesn't close itself; rather, it's closed by the `"` in the top-right corner, meaning that we capture the nine-character string `...>.....`.

So the stack layout is now, from top to bottom: fourth column; top row; `"`; middle row; `"`; bottom row. Each of these are represented on the stack with the first character nearest the top of the stack (Cubix pushes strings in the reverse of this order, like Befunge does, but each time the IP was moving in the opposite direction to the natural reading direction, so it effectively got reversed twice). It can be noted that the stack contents are almost identical to the original program (because the fourth column, and the north/top face of the cube, contain the same characters in the same order; obviously, it was designed like that intentionally).

The next step is to print the contents of the stack. After all the pushes, the IP is going northwards on the fourth column, so it hits the `>` there and enters a tight loop `>>o;?` (i.e. "turn east, turn east, output as character, pop, turn right if positive"). Because the seventh line is full of NOPs, the `?` is going to wrap back to the first `>`, so this effectively pushes the entire contents of the stack (`?` is a no-op on an empty stack). We almost printed the entire program! Unfortunately, it's not quite done yet; we're missing the double-quote at the end.

Once the loop ends, we reflect onto the central line, moving west, via a pair of mirrors. (We used the "other side" of the `\` mirror earlier; now we're using the southwest side. The `/` mirror hasn't been used before.) We encounter `'!`, so we push an exclamation mark (i.e. 33; we're using ASCII and Cubix doesn't distinguish between integers and characters) onto the stack. (Conveniently, this is the same `!` which was used to skip over the `o` command earlier.) We encounter a pair of `R` commands and use them to make a "manual" U-turn (the second `R` command here was used earlier in order to reach the first row, so it seemed most natural to fit another `R` command alongside it.) The execution continues along a series of NOPs until it reaches the `W` command, to sidestep to the left. The sidestep crashes right into the `>` command on the second line, bouncing execution back exactly where it was. So we sidestep to the left again, but this time we're going southwards, so the next command to execute is the `)` (incrementing the exclamation mark into a double quote), followed by an `o` (to output it). Finally, execution wraps along the eighth line to the second column, where it finds a `@` to exit the program.

I apologise for the stray apostrophe on the third line. It doesn't do anything in this version of the program; it was part of an earlier idea I had but which turned out not to be necessary. However, once I'd got a working quine, I just wanted to submit it rather than mess around with it further, especially as removing it wouldn't change the byte count. On the subject of golfing down this quine further, it wouldn't surprise me if this were possible at 3×3 by only using the first five lines, but I can't see an obvious way to do that, and it'd need even tighter packing of all the control flow together with some other way to represent the top face of the cube (or else modifying the algorithm so that it can continue to use the fourth column even though it'd now be ten or eleven characters long).

Comment: Nice work, this is a really impressive score. I love how you encoded the top face. :)

Comment: This is just incredible! If it would help any, another way to push `"` is `Q`.

Comment: Wow! I never though I'd see a cubix quine!

Comment: I didn't have time to read the explanation yesterday, but now that I have... Just... WOW. I can't believe how many characters are used for two or even three completely different purposes. This is probably the coolest Cubix program I've ever seen.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 34):

## Python 2, 30 bytes

```python
_='_=%r;print _%%_';print _%_
```

[Taken from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130701215340/http://en.literateprograms.org/Quine_(Python))

Comment: +1, you beat my similar solution so I deleted it. It should be noted that this only works in Python 2.

Comment: It looks weird with the variable name as `_`, but reads better if you assign it to any letter, i.e. s: `s='s=%r;print s%%s';print s%s`

Comment: If this solution is not your own creation, you should make it Community Wiki. Also, the link is dead.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but can someone explain how this works?

Comment: @MadTux `%` is the string formatting operator; in this case, `x % y` replaces all instances of `%r` in `x` with ` y` formatted as a string. The `%` must be escaped with a second `%`.

Comment: This requires a trailing linefeed to be valid. As it is, the source code doesn't match the output.

Answer (score 31):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 261 bytes, side length 10

```
113009344778658560261693601386118648881408495353228771273368412312382314076924170567897137624629445942109467..../....%'=g':..\..................\.................\................\...............\..............\.............\............\!$/'?))='%<\..>:;/$;4Q/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYk7DsIwEETPgpTISmPvz7vrhMAZ6N1QoFBBC6c3pkbAaPSkN3O9PM7b/fZsDZEBCouYuWbPCqSohRWQXRFdxd1RwKVkzkzkZkjGrC5I3OudAqaFBA2ymhdDNiVRKiK5CCEUUYs96Y0xrFuYY6zxI/X/Un97/W51N6RwnKY1jPt@HOYlDYucUmsv)

Uses the same encoding [user202729's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156271/76162), but terminates in a divide by zero error.

Formatted, this looks like:

```
          1 1 3 0 0 9 3 4 4 7
         7 8 6 5 8 5 6 0 2 6 1
        6 9 3 6 0 1 3 8 6 1 1 8
       6 4 8 8 8 1 4 0 8 4 9 5 3
      5 3 2 2 8 7 7 1 2 7 3 3 6 8
     4 1 2 3 1 2 3 8 2 3 1 4 0 7 6
    9 2 4 1 7 0 5 6 7 8 9 7 1 3 7 6
   2 4 6 2 9 4 4 5 9 4 2 1 0 9 4 6 7
  . . . . / . . . . % ' = g ' : . . \
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \
   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \  
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \   
     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \    
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . \
       . . . . . . . . . . . . \
        ! $ / ' ? ) ) = ' % < \
         . . > : ; / $ ; 4 Q /
          . . . . . . . . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZC9DsIwDIT3PsUhtapY6F@atEDhGdi7MKAywQpPH84mBAbU9iTbtb@cnFwvj/N0vz29R/wqqkFJ9cyGckkcOnSwaBlb5hI1YxXHVo9IXyyEFLMuiWPDpqhiVTIbHmjRBIAVDWv2HVWxcuyIYbAw2mxC7EItVg5WkZ49oRx7sqHs26tZ82EEsIy93q3VXBMotbJ6201QEasMOQZMjFv9H5M4mtP4YzZPLUOAXnGRemOLVMCW1ppDIoAVUj5WjiPW1MAqw/5nrviBb7cjljIanFB8x//svX8B)

Some python-like psuedo-code to explain:

```
n = ridiculously long number
base = 103
print(n)
while n > 0:
    b = 2
    if n%b == 1:
        c = '.'
        print(c)
    else:
        n = n//b
        b = base
        c = chr(n%b + 1)
    print(c)
    n = n//b
```

I'm using base 103 rather than the optimal base 97 just to make sure the number fully fits the top half of the hexagon and doesn't leave an extra `.` to encode.

Here's a [link](https://tio.run/##jZJPU4MwEMXv@RRPploilv7RE5Z60ItHp0frIUIgGSl0Qsb22@MmYMdTMZmE7L5fdl52UKL9klXVdXp/aIzFi7AiflbCMCbrrMklkgRba3RdYrbBa21lKc2v1lqkKDBBoSsrDcK6sbFutweRSU4qw1FJIxkxQYB@pFi4OJzG08Qty30Ni9sVoqWXMgX4PAN0gcU6zXWpLW5u4A/rT9FSUVgla4T@LlwKUa9zileky4py0piGnAXuUSJzLgNEEd4z9eG@AXQLso1vUek84HTNe@4rkTXbDI9G2JgcmeKYoSmKVlrG9kLXxGgiXHHqRKuaYxzuTrNNeLpDJevSqiGNE@dx3znGvN8Uy8U964u5oOuAeJjz8@kaUxJL2hMf79hZujQJ@yc1DgEOG6d6bJQasDFbl5AzgCtq75ya8wQO9y9NqWHrP7rHN9S7R8ImtD/gDfMf) to user202729's encoder that I used to get the large number and check that the number actually fit in the hexagon.

Comment: What a shame [this](https://tio.run/##jZLNTsMwEITvfoohKk1CaPojJERoygEuHFGPlINJnNgijSvHon37sHZaxKklVmzvzufVeGXJuy/RNH2vtjttLF645emz5IYx0Ra6FMgyrK1RbY3JCq@tFbUwJ62zyFFhhEo1VhhErbap6tY7XoiYVIa9FEYwYoIAw5dj5uIoTMPM/Tb2NSxuFkjmXiok4PMMUBVmy7xUtbIYj@E3y0/eUVFYKVpE/ixcCsmgxxQvSBcN5YQxmpwF7lK8cC4DJAneC/nh1gCqA9nGN29UGcR0zHseKpE1q4@XRqRNiULGmEBXVScsY1uuWmIUEa44daKTep9Gm8NkFR1u0Yi2tvKYxiGO06FzjHm/OR7u2VCL9vO@B6ZI/TitKa4Rkshpzny8Yb/SuUHYP6nLEOCwy9SAXaSO2CVb55BfAFfU3Sk15wkx3FMKqWHLP7rHV9S7R8JGNN/h7Qc) doesn't fit in 108 digits.

Comment: Another disappointing almost golf is [this](https://tio.run/##jVLLTsMwELz7K4aoNAmh6UNIiNCWA1w4oh4pB5M4sUUaV45F@/dh7bQHEFLjldf2zng0Xlny9kvUddep3V4bixduefosuWFMNLkuBLIMG2tUU2GyxmtjRSXMGWstVigxQqlqKwyiRttUtZs9z0VMKMNBCiMYcYIA/Vhh5s5RmIaZmzb2GhY3CyRzD@US8HUGqBKz5apQlbIYj@E3y0/ekiisFA0ifxeuhKTHYzovCBc11YQxmpwF7lE8dy4DJAnec/nh1gCqBdnGN69VEcR0zXvulcia1adHI9KmQC5jTKDLshWWsR1XDXEUMZw4daKV@pBG2@NkHR1vUYumsvJUxjGO075zjHm/Kzzcs16L9vOuw6VxhRE5TCmmPp/jGiEpcMoZtq7CfsH/xYk2kDWMNIgzhDKAcZlAPQrxhBjui4XUo@UfHGtq1yPRRpTv8IbpDw) for 107 digits needing 106

Comment: [259](https://tio.run/##dYo7DsIwEEQlxEWQErmz97/ehMBF0lAgqKCF0xvXiZhq5s173j@3x/v1bY3YWCiUDaEqGlWt6EDuSAEVVI2gEqM7QLABhbhUc0ZhDRNXYa4ehEEgpBhijm4R0l0EZFcIQDkNOZfcM6aF45qmNe@yQcOObMBeWP@ffZR0yHlJ47n3yzSXYbZjae0H) bytes, packs `?))` into chr(2), which grants enough space to expand the modulo and use a smaller mod (93), saving a couple bytes in the encoding

Answer (score 30):

## C, <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
main(s){printf(s="main(s){printf(s=%c%s%1$c,34,s);}",34,s);}
```

This may segfault on 64-bit systems with some compilers, such as newest Clang, due to the type of `s` being interpreted as 32-bit `int` instead of a pointer.

So far, this is the shortest known C quine. There's an [extended bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12581/61563) if you find a shorter one.

This works in [GCC](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPo1izuqAoM68kTaPYVglDRDVZtVjVUCVZx9hEp1jTulYJxvj/HwA), [Clang](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM0@jWLO6oCgzryRNo9hWCUNENVm1WNVQJVnH2ESnWNO6VgnG@P8fAA), and [TCC](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z83MTNPo1izuqAoM68kTaPYVglDRDVZtVjVUCVZx9hEp1jTulYJxvj/HwA) in a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) environment. It invokes an excessive amount of undefined behavior with all of them.

Just for fun, here's a [repo](https://github.com/aaronryank/quines/tree/master/c) that contains all the C quines I know of. Feel free to fork/PR if you find or write a different one that adds something new and creative over the existing ones.

Note that it only works in an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) environment. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/MESjTMQt) works for [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), but still requires [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). Good luck finding a POSIX/EBCDIC environment anyway :P

---

How it works:

1. `main(s)` abuses `main`'s arguments, declaring a virtually untyped variable `s`. (Note that `s` is not actually untyped, but since listed compilers auto-cast it as necessary, it might as well be*.)
2. `printf(s="..."` sets `s` to the provided string and passes the first argument to `printf`.
3. `s` is set to `main(s){printf(s=%c%s%1$c,34,s);}`.
4. The `%c` is set to ASCII `34`, `"`. This makes the quine possible. Now `s` looks like this:
   `main(s){printf(s="%s%1$c,34,s);}`.
5. The `%s` is set to `s` itself, which is possible due to #2. Now `s` looks like this:
   `main(s){printf(s="main(s){printf(s=%c%s%1$c,34,s);}%1$c,34,s);}`.
6. The `%1$c` is set to ASCII 34 `"`, `printf`'s first** argument. Now `s` looks like this:
   `main(s){printf(s="main(s){printf(s=%c%s%1$c,34,s);}",34,s);}`
   ... which just so happens to be the original source code.

<sup>* [Example](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw46LKzOvRCE3MTNPoyw/M0WTq5pLAQhAghkKtgpKHqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpikrWYMmC0pJijQxNa67a//8B) thanks to @Pavel</sup>
<sup>** first argument after the format specifier - in this case, `s`. It's impossible to reference the format specifier.</sup>

---

I think it's impossible that this will get any shorter with the same approach. If `printf`'s format specifier was accessible via `$`, this would work for 52 bytes:

```
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%0$s%1$c,34);}",34);}
```

---

Also here's a longer 64-byte version that will work on all combinations of compilers and ASCII environments that support the POSIX printf `$` extension:

```
*s;main(){printf(s="*s;main(){printf(s=%c%s%1$c,34,s);}",34,s);}
```

Comment: Although it certainly shouldn't count as competing, the winner of "Worst abuse of the rules" from the 1994 International Obfuscated C Code Contest, [1994_smr.c](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1994_smr), is definitely shorter.

Comment: @Ray It's not allowed. It's not a proper quine by any definition. The quien rules were changed because of that program :P

Comment: I agree entirely, but it's an interesting enough hack that it's worth mentioning any time someone mentions a smallest known quine, if only for historical reasons.

Comment: @Ray Well... smallest known *valid* quine, anyway.

Comment: `s` is of type `int`, not an "untyped variable".

Comment: These compilers all apparently allow implicit conversion of a pointer to an int. `s=3` obviously wouldn't work because you need to pass the string twice to `printf`.

Comment: @jxh I added everything from the nyx.net list, and I'll add Adam's. Thanks!

Comment: @jxh I wouldn't consider an EBCDIC-only solution worthy of the bounty for beating this quine, but I'd add one to the repo with a note.

Comment: @jxh Well, this quine (the 60-byter) is ASCII/EBCDIC-independent, so I think it's safe. For the repo, I'll clarify that.

Comment: @jxh Additionally, I've [clarified the bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12581/61563).

Comment: @jxh Oh, I do use ASCII codes! I completely forgot... sorry about that. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 29):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), <s>120 116 98 96 76 70</s> 66 bytes

Edit: yay, under 100

Edit: Saved a bunch o' bytes by switching to all `/`s on the bottom line

```
:2+52*95*2+>::1?:[:[[[[@^%?>([ "
////////////////////////////////
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/38pI29RIy9JUy0jbzsrK0N4q2ioaCBziVO3tNKIVlLj0CQCu////6zoCAA) + [verification it's deterministic for all possible states](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/38pI29RIy9JUy0jbzsrK0N4q2ioaCBziVO3tNKIVlLj0CQCu////6zoGAgA)

Lost is a 2D language in which the starting position and direction are completely random. This means there has to be a lot of error-checking at every stage to make sure you've got the correct instruction pointer, and it isn't one that has just wandered in randomly.

#### Explanation:

All the `/`s on the bottom line are there to make sure that all the pointers that spawn in a vertical direction or on the bottom line get funneled in the right direction. From there, they end up at several different places, but all of them end up going right into the

```
 ^%?>
 ////
```

Which clears out all the non-zero numbers in the stack. The `([` after that clears out any extra 0s as well.

In the middle of the clear, it hits the `%`, which turns the 'safety' off, which allows the program to end when it hits the `@` (without this, the program could end immediately if a pointer started at the `@`).

From there it does a pretty simple 2D language quine, by wrapping a string literal (`"`) around the first line, pushing a `"` character by duping a space (`:2+`) and then a newline (`52*`). For the second line, it creates a `/` character (`95*2+`) and duplicates it a bunch (`>::1?:[:[[[[`), before finally ending at the `@` and printing the stack implicitly. The `?1` is to stop the process from creating too many 0s if the pointer enters early, saving on having to clear them later.

I saved 20 bytes here by making the last line all the same character, meaning I could go straight from the duping process into the ending `@`.

#### Explanation about the duping process:

`[` is a character known as a 'Door'. If the pointer hits the flat side of a `[` or a `]` , it reflects, else it passes through it. Each time the pointer interacts with a Door, it switches to the opposite type. Using this knowledge we can construct a simple formula for how many times an instruction will execute in a `>:[` block.

Add the initial amount of instructions. For each `[`, add 2 times the amount of instructions to the left of it. For the example `>::::[:[[[`, we start with 5 as the initial amount. The first Door has 4 dupe instructions, so we add 4*2=8 to 5 to get 13. The other three Doors have 5 dupes to their left, so we add 3*(5*2)=30 to 13 to get 43 dupe instructions executed, and have 44 `>`s on the stack. The same process can be applied to other instructions, such as `(` to push a large amount of items from the stack to the scope, or as used here, to clear items from the stack.

A trick I've used here to avoid duping too many 0s is the `1?`. If the character is 0, the `?` doesn't skip the 1, which means it duplicates 1 for the remainder of the dupe. This makes it *much* easier to clear the stack later on.

Answer (score 27):

## [Chicken](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Chicken), 7

```
chicken
```

No, this is not directly echoed :)

Comment: Damnit, you beat me to it :)

Comment: It's not echoed, it's the string `chicken`!

Comment: No code/data separation, and therefore invalid.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Did you read the rules?

Comment: By the [current quine definition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#4878) this is not valid, as it should be possible to `identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program`. `chicken` appears to encode only `chicken` and nothing else.

Comment: @JoKing I don't think this is invalid, because the rules of the challenge only prohibit zero-length and cheating (reading your own source file) quines. The only thing that prohibits improper quines is [a standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10033/46076) -- except standard loopholes aren't generally considered to apply to answers that predate them.

Answer (score 26):

### Cross-browser JavaScript (41 characters)

It works in the top 5 web browsers (IE >= 8, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, Opera). Enter it into the developer's console in any one of those:

```
eval(I="'eval(I='+JSON.stringify(I)+')'")
```

It's not "cheating" — unlike Chris Jester-Young's single-byte quine, as it could easily be modified to use the `alert()` function (costing 14 characters):

```
alert(eval(I="'alert(eval(I='+JSON.stringify(I)+'))'"))
```

Or converted to a bookmarklet (costing 22 characters):

```
javascript:eval(I="'javascript:eval(I='+JSON.stringify(I)+')'")
```

Answer (score 26):

## [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission), 6 bytes

It appears this is now the shortest "proper" quine among these answers.

```
'!+OR"
```

### Explanation

Control flow starts at `R` with a single right-going `(1,0)` atom. It hits `"` toggling print mode and then wraps around the line, printing `'!+OR` before hitting the same `"` again and exiting print mode.

That leaves the `"` itself to be printed. The shortest way is `'"O` (where `'"` sets the atom's mass to the character code of `"` and `O` prints the character and destroys the atom), but if we did this the `"` would interfere with print mode. So instead we set the atom's value to `'!` (one less than `"`), then increment with `+` and *then* print the result with `O`.

### Alternatives

Here are a couple of alternatives, which are longer, but maybe their techniques inspire someone to find a shorter version using them (or maybe they'll be more useful in certain generalised quines).

#### 8 bytes using `J`ump

```
' |R@JO"
```

Again, the code starts at `R`. The `@` swaps mass and energy to give `(0,1)`. Therefore the `J` makes the atom jump over the `O` straight onto the `"`. Then, as before, all but the `"` are printed in string mode. Afterwards, the atom hits `|` to reverse its direction, and then passes through `'"O` printing `"`. The space is a bit annoying, but it seems necessary, because otherwise the `'` would make the atom treat the `|` as a character instead of a mirror.

#### 8 bytes using two atoms

```
"'L;R@JO
```

This has two atoms, starting left-going from `L` and right-going from `R`. The left-going atom gets its value set by `'"` which is then immediately printed with `O` (and the atom destroyed). For the right-going atom, we swap mass and energy again, jump over the `O` to print the rest of the code in print mode. Afterwards its value is set by `'L` but that doesn't matter because the atom is then discarded with `;`.

Comment: Technically invalid due to lack of code/data separation in the source.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline `'!+` encodes `"`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fission, but would `|R@JO"'` work, or would you still need that space after the `'`?

Comment: @MistahFiggins I think so, but more importantly you'd print the `'` first.

Answer (score 25):

### Java, 528 bytes:

A Java solution with an original approach:

```
import java.math.*;class a{public static void main(String[]a){BigInteger b=new BigInteger("90ygts9hiey66o0uh2kqadro71r14x0ucr5v33k1pe27jqk7mywnd5m54uypfrnt6r8aks1g5e080mua80mgw3bybkp904cxfcf4whcz9ckkecz8kr3huuui5gbr27vpsw9vc0m36tadcg7uxsl8p9hfnphqgksttq1wlolm2c3he9fdd25v0gsqfcx9vl4002dil6a00bh7kqn0301cvq3ghdu7fhwf231r43aes2a6018svioyy0lz1gpm3ma5yrspbh2j85dhwdn5sem4d9nyswvx4wmx25ulwnd3drwatvbn6a4jb000gbh8e2lshp",36);int i=0;for(byte c:b.toByteArray()){if(++i==92)System.out.print(b.toString(36));System.out.print((char)c);}}}
```

in readable form:

```
import java.math.*;
class a
{
    public static void main (String [] a)
    {
        BigInteger b=new BigInteger ("90ygts9hiey66o0uh2kqadro71r14x0ucr5v33k1pe27jqk7mywnd5m54uypfrnt6r8aks1g5e080mua80mgw3bybkp904cxfcf4whcz9ckkecz8kr3huuui5gbr27vpsw9vc0m36tadcg7uxsl8p9hfnphqgksttq1wlolm2c3he9fdd25v0gsqfcx9vl4002dil6a00bh7kqn0301cvq3ghdu7fhwf231r43aes2a6018svioyy0lz1gpm3ma5yrspbh2j85dhwdn5sem4d9nyswvx4wmx25ulwnd3drwatvbn6a4jb000gbh8e2lshp", 36); 
        int i=0; 
        for (byte c:b.toByteArray ())
        {
            if (++i==92) 
                System.out.print (b.toString (36)); 
            System.out.print ((char) c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @Loovjo: Similar as other solutions which cut the code in two parts and inserts the whole String which reprensents the code inside again, but the whole code is not just a String but encoded as the long number in base 36 (26 alphabetical characters + 10 digits).

Comment: This could be shortened if you put `if(++i==92)`,

Comment: @tuskiomi: Thanks, shortened for two characters

Comment: I see one can save another character by (String a*) instead of (String []a), but then I would have to recompute the magic number, so I guess you get the point. :)

Comment: @userunknown Actually, `a*` as array doesn't exit in Java, that's C. Some other parts to golf: `import java.math.*;class a{public static void main(String[]a){BigInteger b=new BigInteger("abc",36);int i=0;for(int c:b.toByteArray())System.out.printf("%s%c",++i==92?b.toString(36):"",c);}}`, where `abc` would be the newly computed magic number String. In java 8+ it's also possible to change `class a{public static void main` to `interface a{static void main`, and in Java 10+ it's also possible to change `import java.math.*;` and `BigInteger b=new BigInteger(` to `var b=new java.math.BigInteger(`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yes, it was a... which is even longer, wasn't it? The suggestions: if you like to do it, go for it. With Java9, there is the JShell, which allows to run fragments of code - no classes/interfaces, no main, so thereby bigger savings are possible.

Answer (score 24):

These are the two shortest **Ruby** quines [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474861/shortest-ruby-quine/2475931#2475931):

```
_="_=%p;puts _%%_";puts _%_
```

and

```
puts <<2*2,2
puts <<2*2,2
2
```

Don't ask me how the second works...

Comment: The second one uses heredoc, `<<2` starts a string on the next line, and `*2` repeats the string

Comment: Why do you need the 2?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline It's the terminator of the heredoc string (which has to appear on its own line). It doesn't actually have to be a 2 though: https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFjBxsZAy0jHgAuFY8D1/z8A

Answer (score 23):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>20</s> <s>14</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Before we get started, I'd like to mention the trivial solution of a file which contains a single `0`. In that case Retina will try to count the `0`s in the empty input, the result of which is also `0`. I wouldn't consider that a proper quine though.

So here is a proper one:

```
>\`
>\`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3y4mgQuI//8HAA)

Alternatively, we could use `;` instead of `>`.

#### Explanation

The program consists of a single replacement which we print twice.

In the first line, the `` ` `` separates the configuration from the regex, so the regex is empty. Therefore the empty string (i.e. the non-existent input) is replaced with the second line, verbatim.

To print the result twice, we wrap it in two output stages. The inner one, `\` prints the result with a trailing linefeed, and the outer one, `>`, prints it without one.

If you're a bit familiar with Retina, you might be wondering what happened to Retina's implicit output. Retina's implicit output works by wrapping the final stage of a program in an output stage. However, Retina doesn't do this, if the final stage is already an output stage. The reason for that is that in a normal program it's more useful to be able to replace the implicit output stage with special one like `\` or `;` for a single byte (instead of having to get rid of the implicit one with the `.` flag as well). Unfortunately, this behaviour ends up costing us two bytes for the quine.

Answer (score 22):

### GolfScript, 8 bytes

I always thought the shortest (true) GolfScript quine was 9 bytes:

```
{'.~'}.~
```

Where the trailing linefeed is necessary because GolfScript prints a trailing linefeed by default.

But I just found an 8-byte quine, which works exactly around that linefeed restriction:

```
":n`":n`
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IjpuYCI6bmA&input=)

So the catch is that GolfScript doesn't print a trailing linefeed, but it prints the contents of `n` at the end of the program. It's just that `n` contains a linefeed to begin with. So the idea is to replace that with the string `` ":n`" ``, and then stringifying it, such that the copy on the stack prints with quotes and copy stored in `n` prints without.

As pointed out by Thomas Kwa, the 7-byte CJam quine can also be adapted to an 8-byte solution:

```
".p"
.p
```

Again, we need the trailing linefeed.

Comment: Golfscript is weird.

Answer (score 22):

## [Fueue](https://github.com/TryItOnline/fueue), 423 bytes

Fueue is a queue-based esolang in which the running program *is* the queue.

```
)$$4255%%1(~):[)$$24%%0:<[~:)~)]~[$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]](H-):~:[)[):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]~:](106328966328112328136317639696111819119696281563139628116326221310190661962811611211962861109696289611619628116111612896281115421063633063961111116163963011632811111819159628151213262722151522061361613096119619190661966311961128966130281807072220060611612811961019070723232022060611
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9bjsQgDLtMKzVTVRvzSAH1AHsHxOfsDeY3V@8mzKy0VFAnJrb5eT1fz/umZUkh53XFptS6lSGtK7erayOloX0BlPTqfV/ScaRa9sfR9AATtUGXjk5EOq4xtu@DmppIt18nbapbb0qPWS/Y9lSGwX2YgJIpqI6vsbdsStrGBpYYShU/geBnlIhTYpUqAAoq4NiYbEycCHZfQkAEo7IIPl2TwMSG@D3lKv94297zCjkF95cY2f0wl8Bx5OlRZssz5HcC03fn07wzcggsltdmIvu87fqXx7J6Pd2ct@nCJ9tkYBaWd5J5x9/gTLSPXdPZ@/4F)

## How it works

This explanation <s>may or may not have</s> got way out of hand. On the other hand I don't know how to explain it *much* shorter in a way I hope people can follow.

### Fueue cheat sheet

See [esolang wiki article](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fueue) for details, including the few features not used in this program.

- The initial program is the initial state of the queue, which can contain the following elements:

  - Integer literals (only non-negative in the source, but negative ones can be calculated), executing them prints a character.
  - Square-bracket delimited nested blocks, inert (preserved intact unless some function acts upon them).
  - Functions, their arguments are the elements following them immediately in the queue:

    - `+*/-%`: integer arithmetic (`-` is unary, `%` logical negation). Inert if not given number arguments.
    - `()<`: put element in brackets, remove brackets from block, add final element to block. The latter two are inert unless followed by a block.
    - `~:`: swap, duplicate.
    - `$`: copy (takes number + element). Inert before non-number.
    - `H`: halt program.

  Note that while `[]` nest, `()` don't - the latter are simply separate functions.

### Execution trace syntax

Whitespace is optional in Fueue, except between numerals. In the following execution traces it will be used to suggest program structure, in particular:

- When a function executes, it and its arguments will be set off from the surrounding elements with spaces. If some of the arguments are complicated, there may be a space between them as well.
- Many execution traces are divided into a "delay blob" on the left, separated from a part to the right that does the substantial data manipulation. See next section.

Curly brackets `{}` (not used in Fueue) are used in the traces to represent the integer result of mathematical expressions. This includes negative numbers, as Fueue has only non-negative literals – `-` is the negation function.

Various metavariable names and `...` are used to denote values and abbreviations.

### Delaying tactics

Intuitively, execution cycles around the queue, partially modifying what it passes through. The results of a function cannot be acted on again until the next cycle. Different parts of the program effectively evolve in parallel as long as they don't interact.

As a result, a lot of the code is devoted to synchronization, in particular to delaying execution of parts of the program until the right time. There are a lot of options for golfing this, which tends to turn those parts into unreadable blobs that can only be understood by tracing their execution cycle by cycle.

These tactics won't always be individually mentioned in the below:

- `)[A]` delays `A` for a cycle. (Probably the easiest and most readable method.)
- `~ef` swaps the elements `e` and `f` which also delays their execution. (Probably the least readable, but often shortest for minor delays.)
- `$1e` delays a single element `e`.
- `-` and `%` are useful for delaying numbers (the latter for `0` and `1`.)
- When delaying several equal elements in a row, `:` or `$` can be used to create them from a single one.
- `(n` wraps `n` in brackets, which may later be removed at convenience. This is particularly vital for numeric calculations, since numbers are too unstable to even be copied without first putting them in a block.

### Overall structure

The rest of the explanation is divided into seven parts, each for a section of the running program. The larger cycles after which most of them repeat themselves will be called "iterations" to distinguish them from the "cycles" of single passes through the entire queue.

Here is how the initial program is divided between them:

```
A:  )$$4255%%1(~
B:  ):[)$$24%%0:<[~:)~)]~[$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]
C:  
D:  (H-
E:  
F:  
G:  ):~:[)[):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]~:](106328966328112328136317639696111819119696281563139628116326221310190661962811611211962861109696289611619628116111612896281115421063633063961111116163963011632811111819159628151213262722151522061361613096119619190661966311961128966130281807072220060611612811961019070723232022060611
```

The big numeral at the end of the program encodes the rest in reverse, two digits per character, with 30 subtracted from each ASCII value (so e.g. `10` encodes a `(`.)

On a higher level you can think of the data in this program (starting with the bignum) as flowing from right to left, but control flowing from left to right. However, at a lower level Fueue muddles the distinction between code and data all the time.

- Section G decodes the bignum into ASCII digits (e.g. digit `0` as the integer `48`), splitting off the least significant digits first. It produces one digit every 15 cycles.
- Section F contains the produced digit ASCII values (each inside a block) until section E can consume them.
- Section E handles the produced digits two at a time, pairing them up into blocks of the form `[x[y]]`, also printing the encoded character of each pair.
- Section D consists of a deeply nested block gradually constructed from the `[x[y]]` blocks in such a way that once it contains all digits, it can be run to print all of them, then halt the entire program.
- Section C handles the construction of section D, and also recreates section E.
- Section B recreates section C as well as itself every 30 cycles.
- Section A counts down cycles until the last iteration of the other sections. Then it aborts section B and runs section D.

### Section A

Section A handles scheduling the end of the program.
It takes 4258 cycles to reduce to a single swap function `~`, which then makes an adjustment to section B that stops its main loop and starts running section D instead.

```
)$ $4255% %1 (~
)$%%%...%% %0 [~]
)$%%%...% %1 [~]
⋮
)$ %0 [~]
) $1[~]
)[~]
~
```

- A `$` function creates 4255 copies of the following `%` while the `(` wraps the `~` in brackets.
- Each cycle the last `%` is used up to toggle the following number between `0` and `1`.
- When all `%`s are used up, the `$1` creates 1 copy of the `[~]` (effectively a NOP), and on the next cycle the `)` removes the brackets.

### Section B

Section B handles regenerating itself as well as a new iteration of section C every 30 cycles.

```
) : [)$$24%%0:<[~:)~)]~[$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]
) [)$$24%%0:<[~:)~)]~[$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]            [BkB]
)$ $24%     %0  :<  [~:)~)]    ~ [$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<] [BkB]
)$ %...%%% %1   < < [~:)~)] [BkB]   [$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]
)$ %...%% %0      < [~:)~)[BkB]] [$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]
)$ %...% %1         [~:)~)[BkB][$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]
⋮
) $1 [~:)~)[BkB][$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]
) [~:)~)[BkB][$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]                    (1)
~:) ~)[BkB]                 [$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]
) : [BkB]                 ) [$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]      (2)
) [BkB] [BkB]               $11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<
```

- A `:` duplicates the big block following (one copy abbreviated as `[BkB]`), then `)` removes the brackets from the first copy.
- `$$24%%0` sets up a countdown similar to the one in section A.
- While this counts down, `:<` turns into `<<`, and a `~` swaps two of the blocks, placing the code for a new section C last.
- The two `<` functions pack the two final blocks into the first one - this is redundant in normal iterations, but will allow the `~` from section A to do its job at the end.
- (1) When the countdown is finished, the `)` removes the outer brackets. Next `~:)` turns into `):` and `~)` swaps a `)` to the beginning of the section C code.
- (2) Section B is now back at its initial cycle, while a `)` is just about to remove the brackets to start running a new iteration of section C.

In the final iteration, the `~` from section A appears at point (1) above:

```
~ ) [~:)~)[BkB][$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]                  (1)
[~:)~)[BkB][$11~)~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~][)))~]<]]              )
```

The `~` swaps the `)` across the block and into section C, preventing section B from being run again.

### Section C

Section C handles merging new digit character pairs into section D's block, and also creating new iterations of section E.

The below shows a typical iteration with `x` and `y` representing the digits' ASCII codes. In the very first iteration, the incoming "D" and "E" elements are the initial `[H]` and `-` instead, as no previous section E has run to produce any digit character pairs.

```
C                                               D             E
$11~ )  ~<[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~]  [)))~]  < [)))~[...]]   [x[y]]
~~~ ~~~ ~~~ ~~) [[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~]  < [)))~] [)))~[...][x[y]]]
~~~ ~~~     )  ~ [[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~] [)))~[)))~[...][x[y]]]]
~~~       ~ )   [)))~[....]]                                  [[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~]
                                              ~~[)))~[....]] )[[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~]
                                                [)))~[....]]  ~[+$4--498+*-:~-10)):])<~
```

- This uses a different method of synchronization which I discovered for this answer. When you have several swap functions `~` in a row, the row will shrink to approximately 2/3 each cycle (because one `~` swaps two following), but occasionally with a remainder of `~`s that <s>wreaks havoc on</s> carefully manipulates what follows.
- `$11~` produces such a row. The next `~` swaps a `<` across the following block. Another `<` at the end appends a new digit pair block (digits x and y as ASCII codes) into the section D block.
- Next cycle, the `~` row has a `~~` remainder, which swaps a `~` over the following `)`. The other `<` appends section D to a `[)))~]` block.
- Next the swapped `~` itself swaps the following block with new section E code across the section D block. Then a new leftover `~` swaps a `)` across, and finally the last `~~` in the `~` row swap one of them across to section E just as the `)` has removed its brackets.

In the final iteration, section A's `~` has swapped a `)` across section B and into section C. However, section C is so short-lived that it already has disappeared, and the `)` ends up at the beginning of section D.

### Section D

Section D handles printing the final big numeral and halting the program. During most of the program run, it is an inert block that sections B–G cooperate on building.

```
    (H -
    [H]-
    ⋮
    [)))~[H-]]                  After one iteration of section C
    ⋮
    [)))~[)))~[H-][49[49]]]]    Second iteration, after E has also run
    ⋮
)   [)))~[...]]     [49[48]]    Final printing starts as ) is swapped in
    ))) ~[...][49[48]]
    )) )[49[48]] [...]
    )) 49 [48][...]             Print first 1
    ) )[48] [...]
    ) 48 [...]                  Print 0
    )[...]                      Recurse to inner block
    ...
    ⋮
    )[H-]                       Innermost block reached
    H -                         Program halts
```

- In the first cycle of the program, a `(` wraps the halting function `H` in brackets. A `-` follows, it will be used as a dummy element for the first iteration instead of a digit pair.
- The first real digit pair incorporated is `[49[49]]`, corresponding to the final `11` in the numeral.
- The very last digit pair `[49[48]]` (corresponding to the `10` at the beginning of the numeral) is not actually incorporated into the block, but this makes no difference as `)[A[B]]` and `)[A][B]` are equivalent, both turning into `A[B]`.

After the final iteration, the `)` swapped rightwards from section B arrives and the section D block is deblocked.  The `)))~` at the beginning of each sub-block makes sure that all parts are executed in the right order. Finally the innermost block contains an `H` halting the program.

### Section E

Section E handles combining pairs of ASCII digits produced by section G, and both prints the corresponding encoded character and sends a block with the combined pair leftwards to sections C and D.

Again the below shows a typical iteration with `x` and `y` representing the digits' ASCII codes.

```
E                                                   F
~ [+$4--498+*-:~-10)):] )              <  ~         [y] [x]
) [+$4--498+*-:~-10)):]                   < [x] [y]
+ $4-  - 498  +*- :~ -10 ) )              : [x[y]]
+---  -{-498} +*- ~~{-10} )       ) [x[y]]  [x[y]]
+--    - 498  +*   -{-10}       ~ ) x  [y]  [x[y]]
+-    -{-498} +               * 10 x  )[y]  [x[y]]
+      - 498                    + {10*x} y  [x[y]]
                         + {-498} {10*x+y}  [x[y]]
{10*x+y-498}  [x[y]]
[x[y]]
```

- The incoming digit blocks are swapped, then the y block is appended to the x block, and the whole pair block is copied. One copy will be left until the end for sections C and D.
- The other copy is deblocked again, then a sequence of arithmetic functions are applied to calculate `10*x+y-498`, the ASCII value of the encoded character. `498 = 10*48+48-30`, the `48`s undo the ASCII encoding of `x` and `y` while the `30` shifts the encoding from `00–99` to `30–129`, which includes all printable ASCII.
- The resulting number is then left to execute, which prints its character.

### Section F

Section F consists of inert blocks containing ASCII codes of digits. For most of the program run there will be at most two here, since section E consumes them at the same speed that G produces them with. However, in the final printing phase some redundant `0` digits will collect here.

```
[y] [x] ...
```

### Section G

Section G handles splitting up the big number at the end of the program, least significant digits first, and sending blocks with their ASCII codes leftward to the other sections.

As it has no halting check, it will actually continue producing `0` digits when the number has whittled down to 0, until section D halts the entire program with the `H` function.

`[BkG]` abbreviates a copy of the big starting code block, which is used for self-replication to start new iterations.

Initialization in the first cycles:

```
) :~  : [)[):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]~:]  ( 106328966328112328136317639696111819119696281563139628116326221310190661962811611211962861109696289611619628116111612896281115421063633063961111116163963011632811111819159628151213262722151522061361613096119619190661966311961128966130281807072220060611612811961019070723232022060611
)  ~ ~ [)[):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]~:]  [BkG] [10...11]
) [)[):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]~:]     ~ [BkG] [10...11]
) [):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]       ~ : [10...11]  [BkG]
```

Typical iteration, `N` denotes the number to split:

```
) [):~[)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+:5):]        ~ : [N]  [BkG]
) :~ [)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]+ :5 )         : [N]  : [BkG]
)  ~ ~ [)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]  +5 5     ) [N]  [N] [BkG] [BkG]
) [)~:~~([:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]/]               ~ 10 N  [N] [BkG] [BkG]
) ~:~  ~ ( [:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]               / N 10  [N] [BkG] [BkG]
)  ~ : [:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]                 ( {N/10}  [N] [BkG] [BkG]
) [:~)*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]-:~~)10)~~]                    : [{N/10}]  [N] [BkG] [BkG]
:~ )*[):~[$1(+48]):~+]- :~ ~)10 )           ~ ~ [{N/10}]  [{N/10}] [N] [BkG] [BkG]
~~) *[):~[$1(+48]):~+]- ~~10 )             ) [{N/10}]  ~ [{N/10}] [N]  [BkG] [BkG]
)  ~ * [):~[$1(+48]):~+]  -10            ~ ) {N/10}  [N] [{N/10}] [BkG] [BkG]
) [):~[$1(+48]):~+]               * {-10} {N/10}  ) [N]  [{N/10}] [BkG] [BkG]
) :~ [$1(+48]) :~                 + {-10*(N/10)} N  [{N/10}] [BkG] [BkG]
)  ~ ~ [$1(+48]  )                 ~ ~ {N%10}  [{N/10}] [BkG] [BkG]
) [$1(+48]                 ~ ) {N%10}  ~ [{N/10}] [BkG]  [BkG]
$1(                     + 48 {N%10}    ) [BkG]  [{N/10}] [BkG]
                        ( {48+N%10}   BkG [{N/10}] [BkG]            New iteration starts
                        [{48+N%10}]   ....
```

- The delay blob here is particularly hairy. However, the only new delaying trick is to use `+:5` instead of `--10` to delay a `10` two cycles. Alas only one of the `10`s in the program was helped by this.
- The `[N]` and `[BkG]` blocks are duplicated, then one copy of `N` is divided by `10`.
- `[{N/10}]` is duplicated, then more arithmetic functions are used to calculate the  ASCII code of the last digit of `N` as `48+((-10)*(N/10)+N)`. The block with this ASCII code is left for section F.
- The other copy of `[{N/10}]` gets swapped between the `[BkG]` blocks to set up the start of a new iteration.

## Bonus quine (540 bytes)

```
)$$3371%%1[~!~~!)!]):[)$$20%%0[):]~)~~[)$$12%%0[<$$7%~~0):~[+----48+*-~~10))]<]<~!:~)~~[40~[:~))~:~[)~(~~/[+--48):]~10]+30])):]]][)[H]](11(06(06(21(21(25(19(07(07(19(61(96(03(96(96(03(11(03(63(11(28(61(11(06(06(20(18(07(07(18(61(11(28(63(96(11(96(96(61(11(06(06(19(20(07(07(18(61(30(06(06(25(07(96(96(18(11(28(96(61(13(15(15(15(15(22(26(13(12(15(96(96(19(18(11(11(63(30(63(30(96(03(28(96(11(96(96(61(22(18(96(61(28(96(11(11(96(28(96(61(11(96(10(96(96(17(61(13(15(15(22(26(11(28(63(96(19(18(63(13(21(18(63(11(11(28(63(63(63(61(11(61(42(63(63
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBbjsMwCDxLpESCjaoFO2/lAL2D5c/2Bv3l6lnwo/FaIwsPzIB5f16f13Vh33u/8jBwkE6kwy7iEZR1NAwU8IiCIkawM@Ls@3UQITwkjA890zb@PESYEOMZT@mOJJhIgkYoWocCIr9WPm1myBRHTxE1jjFgeMYIzECLwXHCDLwDrQYNFoZds97uHFi9hyUFbrOC24GAt6qtKatJcuZi0kq0hapaiafqNhuZJZrKVkWu3ecbzoFbEunsWSR7USl0ALXNd/5FtmpHUhOu/t9sLrj7pidTbbH@G6aM0X45zWC78rbbEjdrKchDMkwuM9f1Bw)

Since I wasn't sure which method would be shortest, I first tried encoding characters as two-digit numbers separated by `(`s. The core code is a bit shorter, but the 50% larger data representation makes up for it. Not as golfed as the other one, as I stopped when I realized it wouldn't beat it. It has one advantage: It doesn't require an implementation with bignum support.

Its overall structure is somewhat similar to the main one. Section G is missing since the data representation fills in section F directly. However, section E must do a similar divmod calculation to reconstruct the digits of the two-digit numbers.

Comment: You should golf the explanation XD

Comment: `)$n[)](` is a byte shorter for the delay counter.

Answer (score 22):

## [Amazon Alexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa), 31 words

```
Alexa, Simon Says Alexa, Simon Says
Alexa, Repeat That
Alexa, Simon Says Alexa, Repeat That Alexa, Simon Says, Alexa, Repeat That Alexa, Simon Says
Alexa, Repeat That
Alexa, Simon Says quiet
```

(each command is on a newline)

When said out loud to a device with the Amazon Alexa digital assistant enabled (I've only tested this on the Echo Dot though), it should say the same words back to you. There will be some different lengths of pauses between words, as you wait for Alexa to reply, and it says everything without breaks, but the sequence of words are the same.

#### Explanation:

Each line is a new Alexa command, one of either:

- `Alexa, Simon Says ...`, which will prompt Alexa to say everything afterward the command
- `Alexa, Repeat That`, which repeats the last thing Alexa said

(neither of these appear on most lists of Alexa commands, so I hope someone has actually learned something from this)

We can simplify this to the commands `S` and `R` respectively, separated by spaces. For example, `SR` will represent `Alexa, Simon Says Alexa, Repeat That`. The translation of our program would be:

```
SS R SRSRS R SQ
```

Where `Q` is `quiet` (but can be anything. I chose `quiet` because that's what Alexa produced when I tried to give it `quine`, and it fit, so I kept it). Step by step, we can map each command to the output of each command:

```
Commands: SS
Output:   S
Commands: SS R
Output:   S  S
Commands: SS R SRSRS
Output:   S  S RSRS
Commands: SS R SRSRS R
Output:   S  S RSRS  RSRS
Commands: SS R SRSRS R    SQ
Output:   S  S RSRS  RSRS Q
Total Commands: SSRSRSRSRSQ
Total Output:   SSRSRSRSRSQ
```

The general approach for this was to get the output *ahead* of the input commands. This happens on the second to last command, which gets an extra `S` command. First we have to get behind on output though. The first two commands `SS R` only produce `SS`, leaving us to make up the `R`. However, this allows us to start a `S` command with an `R`, which means we can repeat a section (`RSRS`) multiple times, which allows us to get the spare `S` leftover. After that, all we had to do was use it to say whatever we wanted.

Comment: Can Alexa do addition and primality checks? If so, then Alexa is a programming language according to PPCG

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Yes, Alexa can do both those things, but I still hesitate to call it a programming language since those are both "built-ins", and Alexa is incapable of basic data storage and input.

Comment: This is really a nice idea, but i don't think that it would be a valid quine if it is a valid programming language. In a valid quine, the spaces (or pauses) must also be the same, so if you had a second Alexa which only hears the output of the first Alexa, it should say the same as the first Alexa for a valid quine.

The different pauses lead to different commands. You enter `S("S"); R(); S("RSRS"); R(); S();` and you get `S(); S(); R("SRS"); R("SRS");`

Comment: I disagree. Each line of a quine isn't required to output itself. In an arbitrary scripting language, `A\nB\n` would be a valid quine even if `A` output nothing then `B` output `A\nB\n`. *most* multi-instruction quines don't output anything until the last line [of each loop].

Answer (score 21):

### Javascript (36 char)

```
(function a(){alert("("+a+")()")})()
```

This is, AFAICT, the shortest javascript quine posted so far.

Comment: That... is impressive.  You should explain how it works for me 8-|

Comment: @TehShrike Hint: you can view the contents a function by coercing it to a string. For example, if you have a function `a`, you can access its contents by calling `a.toString`.

Comment: To be pedantic, though, this is only a quine if your JavaScript implementation stringifies the function `a` exactly the same way as it's been written above.  However, the _output_ of this code is likely to be a quine on any JavaScript implementation.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen not exactly. If an other implementation chooses to add a space between the arguments and the body, the output is not a quine in an implementation that doesn't add a space between the arguments and body.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: I meant that, for any given JavaScript implementation, the output of running the above code on that implementation is likely to be a quine on that implementation. Sorry for the imprecise language.

Comment: Ok, "However, the output of this code is likely to be a quine on that JavaScript implementation."

Comment: Here is the same quine, 1 byte shorter: `!function a(){alert("!"+a+"()")}()`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry to interrupt, but this is a way to read your own source code!

Comment: Same, but output to console: `(function a(){return "("+a+")()"})()`

Comment: With lambda `(a=()=>alert('('+a+')'))();`

Comment: `(a=()=>alert(`(${a})`))()`

Comment: @DennisC `()` could be replaced with `k` to save another byte

Comment: @Max Do you mean  `(a=k=>alert(\`(a=${a})()\`))()`

Comment: @DennisC precicely

Answer (score 21):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), <s>124</s> <s>110</s> 53 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for golfing off 9 bytes, which allowed me to golf off another 7.*

```
44660535853919556129637653276602333!
1
:_98
/8 %
@9_.
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=NDQ2NjA1MzU4NTM5MTk1NTYxMjk2Mzc2NTMyNzY2MDIzMzMhCjEKOl85OAovOCAlCkA5Xy4&input=)

### Explanation

Labyrinth 101:

- Labyrinth is a stack-based 2D language. The stack is bottomless and filled with zeroes, so popping from an empty stack is not an error.
- Execution starts from the first valid character (here the top left). At each junction, where there are two or more possible paths for the instruction pointer (IP) to take, the top of the stack is checked to determine where to go next. Negative is turn left, zero is go forward and positive is turn right.
- Digits in the source code don't push the corresponding number – instead, they pop the top of the stack and push `n*10 + <digit>`. This allows the easy building up of large numbers. To start a new number, use `_`, which pushes zero.
- `"` are no-ops.

First, I'll explain a slightly simpler version that is a byte longer, but a bit less magical:

```
395852936437949826992796242020587432!
"
:_96
/6 %
@9_.
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=Mzk1ODUyOTM2NDM3OTQ5ODI2OTkyNzk2MjQyMDIwNTg3NDMyIQoiCjpfOTYKLzYgJQpAOV8u&input=)

The main idea is to encode the main body of the source in a single number, using some large base. That number can then itself easily be printed back before it's decoded to print the remainder of the source code. The decoding is simply the repeated application of `divmod base`, where print the `mod` and continue working with the `div` until its zero.

By avoiding `{}`, the highest character code we'll need is `_` (95) such that base 96 is sufficient (by keeping the base low, the number at the beginning is shorter). So what we want to encode is this:

```
!
"
:_96
/6 %
@9_.
```

Turning those characters into their code points and treating the result as a base-96 number (with the least-significant digit corresponding to `!` and the most-significant one to `.`, because that's the order in which we'll disassemble the number), we get

```
234785020242697299628949734639258593
```

Now the code starts with a pretty cool trick (if I may say so) that allows us to print back the encoding and keep another copy for decoding with very little overhead: we put the number into the code in reverse. I computed the result [with this CJam script](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qW%2596bsW%25&input=!%0A%22%0A%3A_96%0A%2F6%20%25%0A%409_.) So let's move on to the actual code. Here's the start:

```
395852936437949826992796242020587432!
"
```

The IP starts in the top left corner, going east. While it runs over those digits, it simply builds up that number on top of the stack. The number itself is entirely meaningless, because it's the reverse of what we want. When the IP hits the `!`, that pops this number from the stack and prints it. That's all there is to reproducing the encoding in the output.

But now the IP has hit a dead end. That means it turns around and now moves back west (without executing `!` again). This time, conveniently, the IP reads the number from back to front, so that now the number on top of the stack *does* encode the remainder of the source.

When the IP now hits the top left corner again, this is not a dead end because the IP can take a left turn, so it does and now moves south. The `"` is a no-op, that we need here to separate the number from the code's main loop. Speaking of which:

```
...
"
:_96
/6 %
@9_.
```

As long as the top of the stack is not zero yet, the IP will run through this rather dense code in the following loop:

```
"
>>>v
^< v
 ^<<
```

Or laid out linearly:

```
:_96%._96/
```

The reason it takes those turns is because of Labyrinth's control flow semantics. When there are at least three neighbours to the current cell, the IP will turn left on a negative stack value, go ahead on a zero and turn right on a positive stack value. If the chosen direction is not possible because there's a wall, the IP will take the opposite direction instead (which is why there are two left turns in the code although the top of the stack is never negative).

The loop code itself is actually pretty straightforward (compressing it this tightly wasn't and is where Sp3000's main contribution is):

```
:    # Duplicate the remaining encoding number N.
_96  # Push 96, the base.
%.   # Take modulo and print as a character.
_96  # Push 96 again.
/    # Divide N by 96 to move to the next digit.
```

Once `N` hits zero, control flow changes. Now the IP would like to move straight ahead after the `/` (i.e. west), but there's a wall there. So instead if turns around (east), executes the `6` again. That makes the top of the stack positive, so the IP turns right (south) and executes the `9`. The top of the stack is now `69`, but all we care about is that it's positive. The IP takes another right turn (west) and moves onto the `@` which terminates the code.

All in all, pretty simple actually.

Okay, now how do we shave off that additional byte. Clearly, that no-op seems wasteful, but we need that additional row: if the loop was adjacent to the number, the IP would already move there immediately instead of traversing the entire number. So can we do something useful with that no-op.

Well, in principle we can use that to add the last digit onto the encoding. The encoding doesn't really need to be all on the first line... the `!` just ensures that whatever *is* there also gets printed there.

There is a catch though, we can't just do this:

```
95852936437949826992796242020587432!
3
:_96
/6 %
@9_.
```

The problem is that now we've changed the `"` to a `3`, which also changes the actual number we want to have. And sure enough that number doesn't end in `3`. Since the number is completely determined by the code starting from `!` we can't do a lot about that.

*But* maybe we can choose another digit? We don't really care whether there's a `3` in that spot as long as we end up with a number that correctly encodes the source. Well, unfortunately, none of the 10 digits yields an encoding whose least-significant digit matches the chosen one. Luckily, there's some leeway in the remainder of the code such that we can try a few more encodings without increasing the byte count. I've found three options:

1. We can change `@` to `/`. In that case we can use any digit from `1357` and get a matching encoding. However, this would mean that the program then terminates with an error, which is allowed but doesn't seem very clean.
2. Spaces aren't the only "wall" characters. Every unused character is, notably all letters. If we use an upper case letter, then we don't even need to increase the base to accommodate it (since those code points are below `_`). 26 choices gives plenty of possibilities. E.g. for `A` any odd digit works. This is a bit nicer, but it still doesn't seem all that elegant, since you'd never use a letter there in real code.
3. We can use a greater base. As long as we don't increase the base significantly, the number of decimal digits in the encoding will remain the same (specifically, any base up to 104 is fine, although bases beyond 99 would actually require additional characters in the code itself). Luckily, base 98 gives a single matching solution: when we use the digit `1`, the encoding also ends in `1`. This is the only solution among bases 96, 97, 98, 99, so this is indeed very lucky. And that's how we end up with the code at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 21):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), <s>293</s> <s>262</s> 249 bytes

```
>:2+52*:6*:(84*+75*):>:::::[[[[[[[:[(52*)>::::[[[[[[:[84*+@>%?!<((((((((((([[[[[[[[[[[[[[ "
\#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/387KSNvUSMvKTMtKw8JES9vcVEvTys4KBKIhwCpaA6hA0w4hZBUNUulgp2qvaKOBANEoQEGJK0bZhlaAi0L9MVz////XdQQA)

### Explanation

This entire project has been an up and down.  I kept thinking it was impossible and then coming up with a crazy idea that just might work.

Why is a Lost Quine so hard?

As you may know Lost is a 2D programming language where the start location and direction are entirely random.  This makes writing any lost program about as difficult as writing radiation hardened code.  You have to consider every possible location and direction.

That being said there are some standard ways to do things.  For example here is the standard way of printing a string.

```
>%?"Stringv"(@
^<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

This has a collection stream at the bottom that grabs the most of the ips and pulls them to the start location.  Once they reach are start location (upper left) we sanitize them with a loop getting rid of all the values on the stack then turn the safety of push the string and exit.  (safety is a concept unique to Lost every program must hit a `%` before exiting, this prevents the possibility of the program terminating upon start).  Now my idea would be to extend this form into a full fledged quine.

The first thing that had to be done was to rework the loop a bit, the existing loop was specific to the String format.

```
>%?!<"Stringv"(@
^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

We need to add a second stream to avoid the possibility of the `!` jumping over the stream and creating a loop.

Now we want to mix this with the standard Quine format.  Since Lost is based very much on Klein I've <s>basically stolen</s> borrowed the Klien Quine for [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender).

```
:2+@>%?!< "
<<<<^<<<<<<
<<<<^<<<<<<
```

This quite conveniently prints the first line of the quine.  Now all we need to do is hard-code the streams.  Well this is easier said than done.  I tried approximately four different methods of doing this.  I'll just describe the one that worked.

The idea here is to use doors to get the desired number of arrows.  A Door is a special type of mirror that changes every time it is hit.  `[` reflects ips coming from the left and `]` from the right.  When they are hit by an ip from either of these sides the switch orientation.  We can make a line of these doors and a static reflector to repeatedly perform an operation.

```
>:[[[
```

Will perform `:` three times.  This way if we push a `<` to the stack before hand we can make a lot of them with less bytes.  We make 2 of these, one for each line, and in between them we lay down a newline, however the second one needs only go until it covers the `!` we added it for, anything else can be left empty saving us a few bytes. Ok now we need to add the vertical arrows to our streams.  This is where the key optimization comes in.  Instead of redirecting all the ips to the "start" of the program directly we will instead redirect them to the far left, because we already know that the ips starting in far left *must* work (or at least will work in the final version) we can also just redirect the other ips.  This not only makes it cheaper in bytes, I think this optimization is what makes the quine possible.

However there are still some problems, the most important one being ips starting after the `>` has been pushed but before we start making copies of it.  Such ips will enter the copier and make a bunch of copies of 0.  This is bad because our stack clearing mechanism uses zeros to determine the bottom of the stack, leaving a whole bunch of zeros at the bottom.  We need to add a stronger stack sanitation method.  Since there is no real way of telling if the stack is empty, we will simply have to attempt to destroy as many items on the stack as possible.  Here we will once again use the door method described earlier.  We will add `((((((((((([[[[[[[[[[[[[[` to the end of the first line right after the sanitizor to get rid of the zeros.

Now there is one more problem, since we redirected our streams to the upper left ips starting at the `%` and moving down will already have turned the safety off and will exit prematurely.  So we need to turn the safety off.  We do this by adding a `#` to the stream, that way ips flowing through the stream will be turned off but ips that have already been sanitized will not.  The `#` must also be hard coded into the first line as well.

That's it, hopefully you understand how this works now.

Comment: :/ so many typos and missing links

Answer (score 18):

### [Yup](http://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/yup), <s>1165</s> <s>879</s> <s>606</s> <s>561</s> <s>540</s> <s>522</s> 498 + 7 = 505 bytes

Requires the `-cheat` flag to allow the definition of aliases.

```
022222120211111102222122021121202222212021112202222110222212202112110222221202122212022222102222212021222120222221022222102222210222221202222110222211022222210222221022222210222212202222221022221102211110222221022221220222212202112120221111022212202211210222212022222102211120222122022111202222120212212021221202222221022111102221210222122022222102222120212212022221102211110222122022221102222120212212022112120221111022212202112120222212=%;0e-=<;0<-=>;:0~--=1;1>=2;0%{{>0<~{~>~<<}>>>]}>]}${<#}%{@}
```

[Try it online!](http://yup.tryitonline.net/#code=MDIyMjIyMTIwMjExMTExMTAyMjIyMTIyMDIxMTIxMjAyMjIyMjEyMDIxMTEyMjAyMjIyMTEwMjIyMjEyMjAyMTEyMTEwMjIyMjIxMjAyMTIyMjEyMDIyMjIyMTAyMjIyMjEyMDIxMjIyMTIwMjIyMjIxMDIyMjIyMTAyMjIyMjEwMjIyMjIxMjAyMjIyMTEwMjIyMjExMDIyMjIyMjEwMjIyMjIxMDIyMjIyMjEwMjIyMjEyMjAyMjIyMjIxMDIyMjIxMTAyMjExMTEwMjIyMjIxMDIyMjIxMjIwMjIyMjEyMjAyMTEyMTIwMjIxMTExMDIyMjEyMjAyMjExMjEwMjIyMjEyMDIyMjIyMTAyMjExMTIwMjIyMTIyMDIyMTExMjAyMjIyMTIwMjEyMjEyMDIxMjIxMjAyMjIyMjIxMDIyMTExMTAyMjIxMjEwMjIyMTIyMDIyMjIyMTAyMjIyMTIwMjEyMjEyMDIyMjIxMTAyMjExMTEwMjIyMTIyMDIyMjIxMTAyMjIyMTIwMjEyMjEyMDIyMTEyMTIwMjIxMTExMDIyMjEyMjAyMTEyMTIwMjIyMjEyPSU7MGUtPTw7MDwtPT47OjB-LS09MTsxPj0yOzAle3s-MDx-e34-fjw8fT4-Pl19Pl19JHs8I30le0B9&input=&args=LWNoZWF0)

#### Explanation

There are two parts to this (as with most quines). The data:

```
022222120211111102222122021121202222212021112202222110222212202112110222221202122212022222102222212021222120222221022222102222210222221202222110222211022222210222221022222210222212202222221022221102211110222221022221220222212202112120221111022212202211210222212022222102211120222122022111202222120212212021221202222221022111102221210222122022222102222120212212022221102211110222122022221102222120212212022112120221111022212202112120222212
```

And the decoder:

```
=%;0e-=<;0<-=>;:0~--=1;1>=2;0%{{>0<~{~>~<<}>>>]}>]}${<#}%{@}
```

The data is merely a binary encoding of the decoder (or rather its reverse). Each `0` starts a new character and the `1`s and `2`s are the `0`- and `1`-bits, respectively.

Note that `0` is a standard Yup command which pushes a zero, while `1` and `2` are not defined at this point. However, we assign the entire data part to the command `%` so that the `1` and `2` can remain undefined until `%` is actually used.

Next, we define some more commands:

```
0e-=<;
0<-=>;
:0~--=1;
1>=2;
```

`<` decrements the top of the stack, `>` increments it. `1` (somewhat unintuitively) doubles the top of the stack. `2` doubles it and then increments it. Thanks to these definitions, something like `0221111` will actually leave a 48 (110000 in binary) on the stack.

The remaining 32 bytes do the actual decoding in two parts. First we need to reconstruct the data string.

```
0%                ` Push a zero and then the data.
{                 ` For each value...
  {               `   Until that value is zero...
    >0<~{~>~<<}>  `   divmod 2. The div is the input to the next iteration,
                  `   the mod gives us the next bit.
    >>]           `   Increment twice (gives 2 or 3) and put at the bottom
                  `   of the stack.
  }
  >]              ` Increment the 0 and put it at the bottom as well.
}
$                 ` Reverse the entire stack.
{<#}              ` Decrement and print each number.
```

And finally, we push the data again and print each value as a character:

```
%{@}
```

For future reference, [here is a CJam script](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cXtpMmI6KTBcK30lVyU&input=PSU7MGUtPTw7MDwtPT47OjB-LS09MTsxPj0yOzAle3s-MDx-e34-fjw8fT4-Pl19Pl19JHs8I30le0B9) to encode the data.

Answer (score 17):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), ~6.1*10^4391 bytes

```
000000000...(more 0s than fits in the observable universe)...000
```

For reasons that may be somewhat obvious, you can't try this one online.

### What the hell is Unary?

Unary is a joke(?) esolang with a pretty basic premise: the only valid symbol is the number 0. To interpret Unary, the 0s are first counted, then that number is converted into binary, then *that* number is converted into brainfuck (000 corresponds to +, 001 corresponds to -, and so on), then the brainfuck is run.

It's worth noting that you can't distinguish between the numbers 000001 and 001 even though they represent different brainfuck, so in all cases, Unary requires us to include an extra 1 bit at the top of the binary representation: we instead write the binary numbers 1000001 or 1001, which are distinguishable.

### Basic overview/comments

Whew, this was a huge pain. As a forewarning, I'm almost certain it's not optimal (there are quite a few structures that are pretty space-inefficient used in the brainfuck) but I'm also almost certain there's no way this is ever fitting on any real computer, so I don't feel too bad about it.

The basic idea for this is probably about what you expect: there's a big array that represents the rest of the code (with a cell set to negative one at the start for navigation), and there's a bunch of code which takes an array and prints out unary code representing the code initializing the array (and the negative one flag), then the code represented by the array.

Obviously it's impossible to test this thing, but I tested the actual quining part on the smallest possible array input ("->+>>" representing "-++"), and it correctly output exactly 19,407,936 0s (corresponding to "->+>>-++"), which is good enough for me.

Finally, I'd like to point out that this is technically a Unary/Lenguage polyglot quine (as all Unary code is also valid lenguage with the same function), though a proper Lenguage golf adapted from this one would probably be a couple hundred orders of magnitude smaller.

### Detailed overview

The core idea of this code is to use our array as a base-8 "number", with each entry being another base-8 "digit". We can cascade this downwards (subtract 1 from an entry and add 8 to the one directly after it), and then print a 0 for every entry in the last array entry.
Doing this process on the original array prints Unary code for whatever brainfuck the array represented (the representation is as you might expect: every entry is a different symbol, and every entry contains a number 0-7, one corresponding to each brainfuck command).

You'll note that technically, we're doing this "backwards": printing all the 0s for the code before we print the 0s for the array. I'm not certain that this is *necessary*, but it does enable us to use some clever constructions later on to save quite a bit of work.

This process, incidentally, will destroy whatever array it's run on. Thus, before we do that, we need to copy the array (actually quite an obnoxious task given that the arrray is variable-length).

Thus after we print the code itself, we have data looking like this:

```
-1 flag | [original array] | -2 flag | [empty array with the same length] | -3 flag
```

This means we only need to print the Unary for the array itself, the -1 flag at the start of the array, and the 1 bit at the top of the binary representation which Unary requires.

Fortunately, we can actually use similar code to do this! In order to encode further data, we need to print out 0s in chunks of some very large power of 8: ie, if our code so far was 50 characters long, in order to encode a "-" before the code, we would have to print 8^50 0s.

The power of 8 we have to use is *exactly the length of that big empty array*. This means that if we put a 1 in the top register of that array, it will increment the last symbol encoded by 1, and if we put an 8 in the top register it will encode a new symbol (specifically a minus).

Furthermore if we move the flag at the end of the array to the right by 1 it'll print out 8 times as many 0s, and thus start editing the symbol before the last symbol encoded!

Since a plus is just "000", we can just move the flag to the right by the value of the last position in the array. This adds as many "000"s to our binary output as there were plusses in the original array representation. When more stuff is added to our array and cascaded down, this will correctly encode the plusses.

We then move the flag at the *start* of the empty array to the *left* by 1: this means we start editing the symbol before the plusses we just added. Conveniently, the space it moves into will have been emptied by the operation that moved the end of the array just before now.

All this means that if we put a 2 in the top register of the empty array and then cascade it'll actually print a right carat, and the blank spaces left from moving b will interpret to an appropriate amount of plusses.

We can then repeat this for *every single entry* in the filled array, thus encoding all of the array representation.

Memory now looks like this

```
-1 flag|-2 flag| [huge empty array, 2 times as long as the original array]| -3 flag
```

We now need to add one last minus (to initialize the -1 flag we just got to). All we need to do this is change the minus 2 to a plus 1, then cascade. This both performs the appropriate multiplication by 8, and encodes a -.

Finally, we just need to encode the 1 at the top of the binary representation. To do this, we move b over by 1 one last time and add a 1 at the top, then cascade.

And there it is! We've now printed out 0s representing every part of our original code.

Thank you, and I'm sorry.

### Source code

The brainfuck is a little bit long when fully commented (~200 lines), so I'm not certain if I should post it, but I figure y'all can at least have the un-pretty source:

```
->++>+>+>++>++>+>+>++++++>+>+++>>+++++++>+>++>++++++>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>>>++++++>+>+++>>+++++++>+>++>+++++++>>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>++>+>+>++++++>+>+++>>+++++++>+>++>+>+>+>+>++>>>++++++>+>+>+++>++>++++++>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>++>+++++++>>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>++>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>+++++++>++>+>+>+>+>++>>>+++++++>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+++>+>+>++++++>+>+++>>+++++++>+>++>++>+>+>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>++>++>+>+>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>++>++++++>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>++>+++++++>+>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>+++++++>++>+>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>++>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>++>++>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+++>++++++>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>++>+++++++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>+++++++>++>+>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>++>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>+++++++>++>+>+>+>+>+>+>++>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>+++++++>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>++++++>>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>+++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++++++>++>++>++++++>>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>++>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>++>+++++++>>>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>++>++>++>+>+>+>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>++>+>+>+>+>+>++>++>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>++++++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+>++>+++++++>>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>+++++++>++>+>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>>+++++++>++>+>+>+>+>+>++>++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>+++>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>>>+++++++>>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>++++++>>>++++++>+>+>+>+++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+>+++>+++++++>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>++>++>>>>>>>++++++>+>+++>>>>>>>>>++>+++++++>+++>++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>+++>+++>++++++>+>++>++>++++>+++>+++>+++++++>>>>++++++>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>++++++>+>++>++>++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>+++>+++>+++>+++++++>>++++++>+>++++++>++>+>++>+++++++>+++>>+++++++>+++>+>++>>>>>>>>>+++>>>>+++++++>+>+>++>+>+>+>+>++++++>+>+>+>+>++>>>>>+++++++>>>>>>++++++>+>+>+>+>+>+++>>>>>>+++++++>>>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>+++>>++++++>+>++++++>>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>++>++++++>+>++>>+++>+++++++>+++>>>>++>+>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>+++>+++++++>++>>>+++>+>+>++>>>>>>++++++>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>++++++>+>++>++>++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>+++>+++>+++>+++++++>>++++++>+>++++++>++>+>++>+++++++>+++>>+++++++>+++>+>++>>>>>>>>>+++>>>>+++++++>+>+>++>+>+>+>+>+>+>++++++>+>+>+++>>>+++++++>+>+>+++>>+++++++>+>++>>>>>>++++++>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>++++++>+>++>++>++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>+++>+++>+++>+++++++>>>++++++>+>+>++++++>++>+>+>++>+++++++>+++>>>+++++++>+++>+>++>>>>>>>>>+++>>>+++++++>+>++>+>+>+>+>+>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>++>++++++>+>++>>+++>+++++++>+++>>>>++>+>+>++++++>+>+++>>+++++++>+>++>>>>++++++>>++++++>+>+>+>++>>>>+++++++>+>+>+>+++>+++>++++++>+>++>++>++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>++++>+++>+++>+++>+++++++>>>++++++>+>+>++++++>++>+>+>++>+++++++>+++>>>+++++++>+++>+>++>>>>>>>>>+++>>>+++++++

>-->>--[-<+]->[++[--->+++]---<++[-<+]->]+++[--->+++]>--[-<+]->---->++[--<>[++[--->+++]---<+++++[----<++++]---->]+++[--->+++]>+[----<++++]>---->++]--<+++++++[--->+++]<--[-<+]->>--[--->+++]--->>--[--<++]-->[++++[-----<+++++]-----<+++++[---->++++]----<+++[--<++]-->]-[-----<+++++]>-[---->++++]>++[------<++++++]------>>+++[---<[++++[-----<+++++]-----<+++++[---->++++]----<+++++++[------<++++++]------>]+++++[-----<+++++]>-[---->++++]>++[------<++++++]>------>>+++]---<<+++++++++++++[-------<+++++++]+[--->+++]---<[+[--<++]--<+++++[---->++++]----<++++[---<+++]---<]>>[+[--<++]-->++++[--->+++]--->]++[--<++]-->>>---[--->+++]--->----->>++++[----<[+++++[------<++++++]------<++++++[----->+++++]----->]++++++[------<++++++]>-[----->+++++]>----->>++++]----<<++++++++++++++[---------<+++++++++]+[---->++++]----<[++[---<+++]---<+++++[---->++++]----<]+++[---<+++]--->>++++++[-<++++++++>]<>-----<<<[->>.<<]+++[[--->+++]---<<[->>>........<<<]+[-[>->]<+]<->++++++++<+++]-->----[---->++++]+++++[-----<+++++]++[--<++]--<+[-[++[--->+++]--->[->+<]<+++>-[--<++]--<]>++<-->+++++[[--->+++]---<<[->>>........<<<]+[-[>->]<+]<->++++++++<+++]-->------[--<++]--<+]->+++++[+[--->+++]---<<[->>>........<<<]++[--[>-->]<++]<->++++++++<++]->-----[--->+++]--->[->+<]<+++>--[-<+]->+++[+[--->+++]---<<[->>>........<<<]++[--[>-->]<++]<->++++++++<++]
```

The exact number of 0s used is

```
616143364761046940121393482224894339867345380201767130133313486919095927124457356445367231747521140266173370022946551757495986436536081196868045297628272330390384059772395971191779286883783813697712702083311380720802629542181528279259974270122382291334259076670078283456907144090063837123521728109038972289254725923131778417128787123839239037575809566518515144698909511013229597825122095407702198996899541417882553289474401282217717777845438435506256387112472797473268235689408744655098869728879606757978358505806156421963379547318142883884528468751816610374042589741195416986282360597637951748580316227437951083206547340002950237138353873683827224872420688269051148041914106540181545636126975204020515616888610209347943212212684032994981872040279134760921950441974664462626740824769006477972532358261625821022468550562561067773665916456352101740599621566669636512759138416019741339956533219082231457782020998061560188458949523569043543472825311694153186492127832152368263433627346401816742081184272285138868588737702544161051266511345401776302508848404989044851701234612868569930533447734786659774504348270829815069786996595352931052563253833910670459061338664835111006064026972821593395459376847379338727645638102959876509529598180508190944759740278032543135323831096032264282759700516599819159593380726609694016158768372040897232130064627016970719454234890810133557942103242082428193652525717784679766009840567745646644331050845934041815088097332504352438215802005681361724732417128846494405432135929762912067831306775322080038483165731774473085357566563624402414177907348890170209026776293825006497117681077216606902562225184543780956129658804093641090955334441702108200564658744439989789201224157261892503165643308457788492416371138829568712401818445624554600923862455172225972137155277042400428634635794267865563766239731245919228046855426376607293646700303578427596008362291239931429658436763436719678326692915408656227680419507941034924280704994802195387552837470839012206296262948274121554534825929221937317579576287409893717258523001476821273741591905466514991100795003027995820718624627560000685829593037893516218245771605918736777569490302646860116831211143429524438818972119953427472167111184521816913965170021208796837058611193110390517567196364486837447552746813630060986477162908564149642028449379763465797559696051374230746360712939114777230926431439196151657705180265020483638629061181115856223950249806419818375856529987900246040227082601855626646444080216637310658434683889414278770982063250184353729183793452944251724697854181617951614799763586644028479802980036647045105801552589931160634006431597294780772117688186110086846079813170103829768160563126247208942693587842950980471492950218296552846456932278774596999132699204842933464261728949352373762279520360130690593476460298502885309846199176184758132580237138986886575217114963071503275472309839043003811612480724199448586309349213643468070828586583244591263370384564485550086863984151080517206405235910197380819828141069270492593578986828345436437174028486982241355518138451897126139232242703752607826960024771549490116659322453183855123857138475614101348080310760135256588738232612996648332732281155595814319181966181574401320500067489163573212418944844484950259082074896272135947770797061836016279282123019467117684670513267319113631747092736545960755034809236690912731932588771491682676453979945982754468716932978590114642741630083944274379070387978397185461190324579966999262505612480431374579002240579057976399577489156724969889391725011201833796208889208642431523656036515892951544697280547449403879151875515288785339517008449261777065296448378328263083714549226346273500515673503831635754141766922846713000935292132391822069931132294405910519960461798776924488932623464859144582786720457864275598371518594949910770504649195142874620028228890448589489597208338562687621880437805894822197524541279873734273522403771848708628352939445662430217734644866430785751657273790572085485900108956813143322699032604055731135389248624818347278303261582515845621280853277496120155330289546717304073439125810011869192307295393119864362022104242206053603655047887527558361040028989920694801323274066616457054148538214643602629113440692125709885109559566032777838457552957583786148605526507117591555800832794105245862353696525934364943795116979478987279494334241959368528163214344004159915398916504737171079910682142420502023
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Unary is more often called *Lenguage* here, but all the same.

Comment: Lenguage and Unary have different encodings (`+-` and `><` are swapped, no extra leading `1` in Lenguage), so they're not quite the same

Answer (score 16):

### **Fob (135)**

In [Fob](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fob), a language of my own creation from some time ago, I present a rather interesting 135-byte quine:

```
$$#<&$::#<&$:#<&#<&$:#<=#<&$&//%<//<.&%<<%.%<&>/////%<<%.<&.%<.%/////<&.%<<&/.%%<&>%</%<////<&.%<<%/<&.%%<&>/%//<&.%<</&.%%%<&>>/>>#<=
```

Comment: "If Fob, a lan"

Answer (score 16):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <strike>30</strike> 28 bytes

```perl
printf+(q(printf+(q(%s))x2))x2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1bo1ADwVIt1tSsMALh//8B)

I first posted this one years ago to the Fun With Perl mailing list, and I've been quite fond of it ever since.

You can save two characters if you use `qw` instead of `q`:

```perl
printf+qw(printf+qw(%s)x2)x2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE27sFwDwVIt1qwwAqL//wE)

Comment: This is the shortest Perl quine I'm aware of (which doesn't read `$0`, that is).

Comment: For [pl](https://perl1liner.sourceforge.io/), the Perl One-Liner Magic Wand wrapper, I have stolen your idea.  Because that has 1-char aliases to its functions, it's [6 bytes shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213629/98751).  (Could be 18 chars if `f` didn't have a prototype.)  Thanks for the inspiration! ★★★★★

Comment: [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/211216#211216) is a 21-byte perl quine, and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/219316#219316) a 24-byte one without any options

Answer (score 16):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$q++show q;q="main=putStr$q++show q;q="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIpVBbuzgjv1yh0LrQVgmnxP//AA)

Answer (score 16):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 16 bytes

```
[91PP6120568P]dx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z/a0jAgwMzQyMDUzCIgNqXi/38A)

Comment: There's this for 10: `6581840dnP`

Comment: I knew you could print a character based on an `ASCII code directly` or a `number % 256`, but not a string using the coefficients of a base 256 polynomial as individual characters. Awesome!

Comment: Same length: `[91PP93P[dx]p]dx` (taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/e6i2s/quine_in_dc1/))

Comment: @seshoumara it's just a base-256 number whose digits are 1-byte characters; it could be used to represent the coefficients of a polynomial, but there's no such interpretation implied. It's just `('d'*256+'n')*256+'P'==6581840`

Answer (score 16):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
”ṘṘ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCd4bmY4bmY&input=)

#### Verification

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US
$ xxd -g 1 quine.jelly
0000000: ff cc cc                                         ...
$ ./jelly f quine.jelly | xxd -g 1
0000000: ff cc cc                                         ...
```

#### How it works

```
”ṘṘ    Main link. No input.

”Ṙ     Set the return value to the character 'Ṙ'.
  Ṙ    Print a string representation of the return value.
       This prints: ”Ṙ
       (implicit) Print the return value.
       This prints: Ṙ
```

Comment: Which version of the interpreter does this use? When I test it, it outputs in UTF-8 even though the input is in Jelly's codepage (and the change in encoding would make it not-a-quine).

Comment: The output's encoding depends on your terminal's settings: if it's set to UTF-x, it uses that; if it's set to anything else, it uses Jelly's code page. On Linux, `LANG=en_US` achieves just that. https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@@/j6Odum5oXHxrMVVGRoqBbpKBbUKxgY2OjkJaWDAQKdgqFpZl5qXpZqTk5lRA16QqGKIL6@QUl@mAmhFRIQ5ZWqFGA6fr/HwA

Answer (score 16):

## Shakespeare Programming Language, 6060001 bytes

Disclaimer: I do not take credit for this, the generator was made by Florian Pommerening and Thomas Mayer.

```
An Epic Never-Ending Saga.

Paris, a stacky person.
Pinch, impersonates Paris.
Venus, the opposite of Paris and Pinch.
Puck, continuously speaking.
Ajax, constantly complaining.
Page, perpetually blabbing.
Ford, incessantly talking.
Viola, ceaselessly communicating.


            Act I: Prelude.

        Scene I: Best things last.

[Enter Venus and Paris]

Paris:
    Let us proceed to act V.



            Act II: Remembrance.

        Scene I: Forgetful Venus.

Paris:
    Remember nothing.
    [...]
```

[Generator Link](https://github.com/FlorianPommerening/spl-quine)

[Generated SPL Code](https://github.com/FlorianPommerening/spl-quine/blob/master/compiled/v1.4/splquine.spl)

[Translated C Code](https://github.com/FlorianPommerening/spl-quine/blob/master/compiled/v1.4/splquine.c) (requires `spl.h` and `libspl.a` from a [bugfixed SPL version](https://github.com/FlorianPommerening/spl-fixes) to compile)

[Compiled binary](https://github.com/FlorianPommerening/spl-quine/blob/master/compiled/v1.4/splquine)

Comment: This answer should be marked as community wiki, perhaps?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Done. Thank you.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 [Community wiki is not a rep waiver.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9692/12012)

Comment: Holy crap. ----

Comment: also this is hardly golfed

Comment: @user202729 Not according to the meta post I linked to.

Comment: This was beaten.

Answer (score 16):

## [7](http://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 1⅝ bytes

7 is an Underload derivative that I've been working on over the past few days. Being an Underload derivative, it's particularly good at quines, so I thought I'd come to this challenge first. (Unlike Underload, though, it has support for input. Like Underload, it's Turing-complete, thus meaning it can handle all the tasks required to be an actual programming language.)

The program itself can be expressed either in octal encoding (there are only 8 commands, named `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, and `7`, that can appear in a 7 source file):

```
23723
```

or packed into bytes (the language sees them as raw octets; I've expressed them as codepage 437 here):

```
Oº
```

(The interpreter ignores trailing 1 bits, so arguably this program can be golfed down to only 13 bits = 1⅝ bytes long via removing the language's equivalent of "trailing whitespace". Languages like this are a little hard to count.)

Here's how the program works. `2` encodes "duplicate", `3` encodes "output and pop twice", thus the combination `23` means "output and pop". The program will thus start by pushing two `23` units on the stack (these are initially inert, but become active as they're pushed). Because the end of the program was reached, it's replaced by the top stack element, without disturbing the stack; thus the text of the second `23` gets output and popped. (As it's active rather than inert, what actually gets output is a string representation, `723`, but the first `7` is interpreted as a formatting code that specifies "the output should be in the same encoding as the program itself", meaning that the quine works in both encodings.) Then the same thing happens for the first `23`; this time, the whole `723` gets output, leading to an output of `23723` (or `Oº`).

This is a true quine via all the definitions we commonly use on SE. For example, the first `23` encodes the second `23` and vice versa, meaning that part of the program encodes a different part of the output. Likewise, this quine could handle a payload just fine. If you didn't require a true quine, you could use the following ⅜-byte program:

```
3
```

which is a proper quine by some definitions, but not others. (The stack starts with two bars on it, meaning that the extra pop that occurs after the output is printed is harmless.)

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55943/42545 I should've implemented it sooner ;-)

Comment: Not really a big deal to have two languages with the same name. [It's happened before.](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clue)

Answer (score 15):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) - 8 chars

Prints itself but throws an error

```
"r0:g>o<
```

13 For no error (old Fish)

```
"r0:g!;>?o?|;
```

15 if you think `g` is cheating

```
"r1b3*+!;>?o?|;
```

Comment: Last two ones don't work for me. They output `rg>?` and `r3!?|`, respectively. They seem to skip two characters every time...

Comment: @tomsmeding I think the interpreter changed some point after this answer, hence the (old fish) in parentheses. Though I honestly can't remember it was 2 years ago. I know they worked when i posted my answer.

Comment: In old fish the `?` command did not pop the stack, new fish does

Comment: I would suggest, for new ><>, `"r0:g>o_!~l?!;!_|`, or `"r13b*+>o_!~l?!;!_|` for no  `g` version (which I don't view as cheating anyway...). But then you're not better off from `"r00g!;oooooooo|` (16)

Comment: I've been looking at this for a little bit (longer than I should have!) and I've come up with this quine which errors but doesn't use g; #o<}-1:" respectively; #.09;!?lo}-1:" for the non error one. being 8 bytes and 14 bytes.

Comment: @Tealpelican brilliant! I never even thought about ' # ' - 1 being ' " '

Answer (score 15):

### Bash, <s>35</s> <s>28</s> 20 bytes

```
trap -- 'trap' EXIT
```

@Dennis pointed out that even the `-p` flag is not necessary, and trap will print the trap strings unqualified, which helped save another 8 bytes, and brought about another quine:

### Zsh, 18 bytes

```
trap -- trap EXIT
```

Zsh `trap` does not print the single quotes, which makes it incompatible with the bash version, but also allows you to save another 2 bytes for the zsh-only version. Again, though, bash does not show this behavior and `trap` does not print anything.

### Bash, 19 bytes

Another, just barely shorter, and much less interesting bash quine:

```
echo $BASH_COMMAND
```

Thankfully the lack of single quotes mean that in zsh, `trap` is still shorter, which is important because the `$BASH_COMMAND` variable does not exist. Additionally, I'd be tempted to count this as 'reading the source' but that might be because I like the `trap` one so much.

### Bash 28 byte submission

```
trap -- 'trap -p EXIT' EXIT
```

Just realized that the echo statement could be cut out entirely, `trap -p` simply prints the trap statement in this format (saved another 7 bytes).

**Compatibility**: This must be in a script file, trap does not work as expected on the command line, and its bash-only: bourne shell/ash/dash does not support the `-p` flag to trap (obviously instrumental to the quine).

## Original 35 byte submission:

```
trap -- 'echo `trap -p EXIT`' EXIT
```

A much farther golf of @ormaaj's `trap`-based solution. Shaves off 1 byte by switching to backticks, 2 more because the quotes around the echo body are not necessary, and 9 bytes by switching to `echo`. The real magic though, is switching from a DEBUG trap to `EXIT`. This saves 2 bytes just because `EXIT` is shorter, and 3 more because you do not need to call : or print it (and it drastically simplified the escaping needed for echo).

I'm not 100% sure whether this counts as 34 or 35 bytes, as echo prints a trailing newline and I'm not sure whether its a true quine if I don't include a trailing newline in the source. I called it 35 bytes to be more safe/truthful, but I'd love to know what a real ruling on this is.

[Link to @ormaaj's original solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/4837#48372) (If I had enough reputation to post these golfs as a comment on the original post, I would have. My apologies if any of this breaks convention.)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, and congrats on a really neat quine! **1.** `trap -- 'trap' EXIT` should work as well. **2.** The trailing newline has to be counted, since the program wouldn't be a quine without it. **3.** Your solution is different enough to be posted in a separate answer. No worries.

Comment: What was the original answer?

Comment: My original answer is the 35 byte one at the end of this post, with trap and echo. As I edited it and golfed my solution down farther, I added new solutions and comments to the top of the post.

Answer (score 15):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>10</s> 4 bytes

```
..SS
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=..SS&a=1)

I have long believed that the 10-byte quine cannot be any shorter until I happen to come across this one while doing another challenge. This one is not extensible while the 10-byte one is.

### Explanation

```
..SS
..S     The string ".S"
   S    Powerset, in dictionary order if the original string is ordered
        In this case, generates [".",".S","S"]
        Implicit flatten and output
```

### Old version, 10 bytes

```
"34bL"34bL
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%2234bL%2234bL&i=&a=1)

Added for completeness. I thought this is the shortest proper quine in Stax, but the idea is not that exciting and has been extensively used. <s>I tried to come up with a more interesting (but longer) solution but so far to no avail</s> Now there is one, it's even shorter than this.

I would also be happy to offer a bounty to a proper quine in Stax in the packed form.

### Explanation

```
"34bL"        Push that string
      34      Push the quotation mark
        b     Duplicate both elements on stack
         L    Pack all elements to an array
              Implicit output
```

Finally, an improper quine:

```
|?            Source of the program
```

or just

```
0             Implicitly prints the 0 on the top of stack
```

Comment: Quine(s) in packed form: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212323

Answer (score 15):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/),  <s>44</s>  41 bytes

EDIT:

- -3 bytes due to H.PWiz

GHC 8.4.1 is out, which implements the second phase of the [Semigroup Monoid Proposal](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid).

As a result, the `<>` operator is now available without an import, which allows a 9 bytes shorter quine than the previous record, the nearly six year old [answer by AardvarkSoup](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5263/).

```
main=putStr<>print$"main=putStr<>print$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfmVuQX1Si4JJYkqjnm5@Xn5mioKFhY6ep@T83MTPPtqC0JLikyMauoCgzr0RFCZsY1///AA) (This cheats and has an import in the header because TIO hasn't upgraded to GHC 8.4 yet.)

## How it works

- `<>` is `Semigroup` multiplication, defined differently for each type it supports.

  - For functions, it returns a new function that takes an argument, passes it to the two multiplied functions, and then applies `<>` for the *result type* to the results.
  - For `IO` actions, it returns a new `IO` action that runs the two multiplied actions, and then applies `<>` to their result values to get the result value of the combination.
- Thus `putStr<>print$q = do x <- putStr q; y <- print q; pure (x<>y)`, which first outputs the string `q`, then outputs its string literal version with a newline appended. (The result values are both `()`, so the final one is also `()`, although this doesn't affect output.)

Comment: I don't fully understand new stuff. would [this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmvYWOnaZubWFCQmpfyPzcxM8@2oLQkuKTIxq6gKDOvREUJmxjX//8A) be valid?

Comment: I figured that if Semigroup was a suprclass of Monoid, then `IO ()` would have to become a Semigroup and `<>` would work

Comment: Oh I completely misread what you were asking. I didn't know `IO ()` was a `Semigroup`.

Comment: I don't think it is at the  moment, so I would have to install the latest version to really check

Comment: Oh right. It's only a `Monoid` in TIO's version.

Comment: I just installed it, my link is valid for 41 bytes :)

Answer (score 14):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 392 bytes

Like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2875/42643) 755B answer, this quine is accompanied by an additional character, which appears in both source and output. I tested this using [BFO](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BFO) in the windows terminal emulator ConEMU.

```
->++>+++>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>++>+++>++>>+++>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>>+++>>+++>>>>>+++>+>>>>>>>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>++>+++>>>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>>>>>+>+>>>+>+>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>++>+++>++>>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>>>+++>+>>>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>+++>+>>+++>>+++>>++[[>>+[>]++>++[<]<-]>+[>]<+<+++[<]<+]>+[>]++++>++[[<++++++++++++++++>-]<+++++++++.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9vCoAgDMXv0RWGnWDsImMfKggi6EPQ@c02TY2s4R98/vZ8jvuwbPMxrd47AggjTLL9pezKqAAY/VfKQOJVqfpuwwymHClI@S4VRtG8ztWy0QQNo5zoy@bxEwDmsDKJNjAKOtEzAoIJIBEwhC@9KnKStR6l8/4E)

The source and output have no linebreaks. The last character is a `\x1a` (SUB ctrl code).

Invented by [Daniel B Cristofani](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/).
(That's an overstatement; I'd say Erik Bosman invented it and I just polished it a bit. His version was 410 bytes.)

---

**How it works**

Like many other brainfuck quines, this code first inputs a list of values that are later used to recreate the actual code, then it builds up a list that contains the "+" and ">" symbols needed for the input and then all characters are printed out.

Each character of the actual code (starting with `+[`) is stored in two cells. Let's call them x and y. The formula to calculate the current character is `(x+2)*16 + (y+2) + 9`, so the characters are encoded like this:

```
char ascii minus9 outX outY inX inY
+    43    34     2    2    0   0
-    45    36     2    4    0   2
.    46    37     2    5    0   3
<    60    51     3    3    1   1
>    62    53     3    5    1   3
[    91    82     5    2    3   0
]    93    84     5    4    3   2
```

All values are stored in reversed order. For example the starting `->++>+++>+>+>+++>>` (2 3, 1 1, 3 0) encodes the `.<]` at the end of the code.

```
[tape: End Marker/EM(-1), [in values], Between Lists Marker(0), [out values]]

-                       set EM

                        read list of in values
[>++>+++>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>>>>.... ] 

                    build out values to generate list
+[                      while input (for each gt)

                    append pluses to out vals / always runs one extra time
  [                     while value gt 0 (for each plus)
    >>+                 copy in value to out value
    [>]++>++            append out values 2 2 (plus)
    [<]<-               decrement in value
  ]

  >+                    new out value 1 (for adding 2 to each in value / one by the extra loop and one by this)
  [>]<+<+++             add 3 and 1 to last out values (change plus to gt)
  [<]                   go to old in value
  <+                    repeat if not on EM
]

>+[>]++++>++            append out value 4 2 (minus)
                      >[instead of ">+", we could also use ">>", 
                        but a ">" is encoded as "+++>+>", while a "+" is encoded ">>", 
                        so it saves four bytes, when using "+>".]<

                    printing loop
[
  [<++++++++++++++++>-] add 16 times out value(X) to next out value(Y)
  <+++++++++            add constant 9
  .                     print char
  <                     go to next out value
]
```

The `` in the end appears, because the copy routine leaves the extra values 1, 1 at the end of the list, which will be encoded 16+1+9 = 25. If we wanted to avoid that, we had to replace the `>+` by the code `>>->`. The input code of that section would change from `>>+++>+>` to `+++>+>++>>+++>+>+++>+>`, so the code would be 15 bytes longer.

Comment: The output is ASCII-only and has 392 bytes. The last byte, `\x1a`, is rendered as a right arrow in code page 437; it's not the same as the unicode right arrow `\u2192`.

Comment: (Put another way, the 394-byte program ending with `\xe2\x86\x92` is not a quine, but it prints the 392-byte quine ending with `\x1a`.)

Comment: If you haven't written this yourself, I think it should be community wiki.

Answer (score 14):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), <del>191143</del> <del>136577</del> <del>91163</del> <del>79824</del> <del>32301</del> 23782 bytes

bzip2 base64:

```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=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vxdb6pAEH33V4ymV6RkA6vIQ2taHvQmN9H@giaNH5iSGLUFkt5afrvddqVY@1KsLlLOPigsc86ss7O7wywyGgb36/CR2ITOtNu5Rlf@fBmF1On0brprY7cMmr1G1Vr1u33NaLfbLWaJ4jJxZFhJcd16PGCtnXLOG47Jja/Vgu7aWZ1zLkmbb3wJmyuUbBTIU1nLUl2JoGu0WFJly49Ns7avfGL7oEiubyneohbcbKdmW12Keru8kU2x7JOmxGIJb9oQifhogOAX0ra101y339X6msl5HFedlWGn5dpambbBuXsXC4M2HGFPYWtXiDJbj2PGIQ95yGcoezIeriGZmL4nvFfjDm9aW0VHKCDMtWXqRkiRkNlx6sbEiYNyMmVBHAVuApCC1SADSd7r8mkEXeoWCuCAA@6HuP3UHOFW6GATmoJfBDcCDjhMcyVP4iie2HP8@WrWFKTXipxeQzYJmZ2ypk4Kk2jEIEVP/LJhBFC@gwcg@BRGNLaBckoPot/LEy3DLnnbBc9knMZqh/kZIGQzcEOGngAIIwbLGkDY9gEIvguPQsYOSxpGOKwP50BEDRDCcEypWJsQdMHdMD/jKSWAAMLWGkJ4gBBlYR8VIESrSAygy7Cz/wuiPDgaggWAShQEH4XwmH9Iz115oV9ikLkUpQXleYnG9@RjXV/3broVc7EMzXE08sfD2ex/ekTTiOQr0a8WUSi@K974fkFsTrW//syjwH/2Lqh2SUE4DImN6U8g5SsTfzqlTuPpaSIr9M2JpNGpXqd3qtq/kB4if@4F1Vpl9Owvm9SRGl9Gw8Bz7PUr)

At least it is obviously possible. Didn't try v1.3 yet.

The official interpreter seemed to be lying about that it supports SBCS. But I managed to get it working in Unicode mode.

#### Generator in CJam

```
{
e#"«»"[129 130]er
"«»"'Â1$f+ers
}:U;
{
N-U:i_0=\2ewWf%::-+
{
_g:M;
[z
[[36 5]
[29 4]
[25 2]
[23 1]
[21 3]]
{~@@md\@s*\}/
_11>{3 21@-])\s_M" +-"=\+e&\0s*_M" -+"=\+e&+}{0s*]s_M" +-"=\+e&}?
'@
}%s
}:F;

[
""
"M2E
(
!0{LDL'"

"}))"F

"&}
M-"

""
"*1(6/1+"

""

"*1
!0{?6{*11LDL'"

"
?0{/4+11@_}
!0{(6*11+33@/11-4)}
}-1
!6{+":QN-F

"LD'L'/11}}
!6{+"

]_sN-

U,24md23\-'+*@0@t4 2$)"3"*t6@)"3"*t
sN-

_U{i32-"4"*QN-}/"}))"
```

#### Pseudocode

```
Loop i in {1,2,3}
    If i = 3, output "}))" and exit
    n = -1 - length before the first +1+1+1+1+...
    Loop while n != 0:
        n += 1 + length before the first +1+1+1+1+...
        If i = 2, output the code corresponding to the following pseudocode:
            "
                    If i = 1, output n as a character
                    If i = 2, output "+1" n times
                n--

                If n = 0:
                    n =
            "

        If n = 0:
            n = +1+1+1+1+... (the first character)
            If i = 1, output n as a character
            If i = 2, output "+1" n times
        n--

        If n = 0:
            n = +1+1+1+1+... (the second character)
            If i = 1, output n as a character
            If i = 2, output "+1" n times
        n--

        ...
```

`n` is stored in the register called "notepad". `i` is stored as cube positions.

The first version has used a `1` in one face to print numbers. The latest version simply add whatever number in one face and divides by it.

There are two ways of printing a string preserving the register. One way is to multiply by 16 or 32 two times, the other is to shift left by a small number. The cube position had to be chosen carefully to get a small enough number in the first version to prevent overflow. But after it is golfed it almost always works.

Comment: So... how many chars are there in the program?

Comment: Somewhat similar to the Mini-flak quine.

Comment: `The official interpreter seemed to be lying about that it supports SBCS.` shhhhh :P but congrats on winning the bounty!

Comment: Yeah, it was lying. I'm too lazy to go fix the repo so I'll delete the meta post until it's fixed.

Comment: @jimmy23013 I'll give you a +100 bounty on another post in honor of this one. (Dennis has said this is allowed.)

Answer (score 12):

### Python 3, 54

I have never seen this one before, so here's my fair creation. It is longer than the classical one but it is a single expression.

```python
print(str.format(*['print(str.format(*[{!r}]*2))']*2))
```

Comment: btw, this is 2 bytes shorter in Python 2, where you don't need the parentheses after `print`.

Answer (score 12):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos),  <sub><sup><s>1743</s> <s>1722</s> <s>1380</s> <s>1360</s> <s>1340</s> <s>1155</s> <s>1120</s> <s>1105</s> <s>1095</s> <s>1075</s></sup></sub> 985 bytes

```
	o	d
	o	e	d
o
	a	3	p
	o	>	>
p
	u	=
	u	=
	=
	=	>
u
	
	
	
	
	
e
	*	*	-	=
	e	>
a
	dot
>
	dab
b
	b	dip
=
	a	b	m
m
	a	>
	a
i
	a	+	=
	>
*
	=	b
	
+
	dip	=	b
	
-
	i	i	+
.
	i	-
2
	i	i	i	i	.
3
	i	2
5
	i	3
d
	*	*	3	-	*	*	2	-	*	+	*	*	3	-	*	*	2	.	*	*	2	-	*	+	3	-	*	+	*	*	2	*	*	*	-	3	*	*	3	.	*	+	*	*	3	-	*	*	.	3	*	*	.	3	*	+	3	.	*	+	*	*	3	3	*	*	.	2	*	+	*	*	3	3	*	*	.	2	*	+	*	*	.	2	*	+	*	*	.	2	*	*	.	3	*	+	3	3	*	+	*	*	*	+	*	*	*	+	*	*	*	+	*	*	*	+	*	*	*	+	2	.	*	+	*	*	-	*	*	*	-	*	*	*	-	-	*	*	.	2	*	+	*	*	2	.	*	*	.	3	*	+	2	*	*	+	*	*	2	-	3	-	3	2	*	+	.	3	*	+	*	*	2	-	2	*	2	+	*	+	2	+	*	+	*	*	2	+	*	*	2	-	2	2	3	.	*	+	.	2	*	+	*	*	2	*	*	*	2	+	*	*	3	+	*	+	3	+	*	+	*	*	2	*	*	*	.	3	*	+	*	*	2	*	*	+	2	2	*	+	*	*	2	*	*	*	-	+	*	*	.	2	*	+	*	*	.	3	*	+	-	*	*	+	*	*	.	2	*	*	2	+	*	+	*	*	*	+	-	+	*	+	*	*	2	-	2	2	3	.	*	*	.	2	*	*	2	+	*	+	*	*	*	+	-	-	*	+	*	*	2	2	*	*	2	2	*	*	-	+	*	+	-	.	*	+	*	*	2	2	*	*	-	-	*	+	-	2	*	+	*	*	2	2	*	*	2	2	*	*	2	2	*	*	2	2	*	*	-	.	*	+	-	3	*	+	*	*	2	2	*	*	-	2	*	+	.	*	*	+	*	*	2	2	*	*	-	3	*	+	2	-	*	+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLLjsMwCDzDp8SyD1h7bA77J4mcQw6tI7X9/WbBjxQn2apy68EeGMAkxBDv6woRAvI2MUSEATwscu6hRzaecCmb/PjuibCtCaHjZYWbmBsQQnxgzzCMOCKMEOYFLyI7whWvYjA74CyWkbgeOxFmZzQo7uVgEWZeBp0YFimfZTn0ciD8EfAYchmeCxGkhGZ35xrOKx9Ku7ThS4w7xLvCZTQ7n8rRx7ujrfX8xn2DpPLbrf6K9pCv9l/zkdKj1Ln8s79TtQhHCU2JM4rTPrS9SZu3a3x9ifeNTtfU9r4zSfc4p7P3zLFW9VXfWNecfcyuv1r7pxj9vVCDVc@qmbw5Wzj6N/6o50qMP9GrM@pOuDrblHNdX3F5zPF2X@3vHw)

Comment: Why did you use tabs instead of spaces in the last line?

Comment: It's easier to print here, because I have a function `-` that prepends **9** to the argument vector.

Comment: And now it's all tabs, because encoding the encoded data is shorter than printing it directly.

Answer (score 12):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>327718</s> 292629 bytes

That's about 286 KiB, not 3 MiB.

Because the source code itself is too big, run this Bash program to generate the quine in `quine.spl` file. Expect `.input.tio` file to be the input in the TIO link.

```bash
cat << 'eof' > convert.ijs
9!:37 (0 _ _ _)

f =: (('the sum ofa cat ' #~ 2&|) , 'twice ' , [: f <.@%&2) ` ('zero'"_) @. (=&0)
g =: ([: toupper 'remember ' , f , '!'"_)"0

inp =: stdin''
inp =: toupper inp rplc LF;' ';'!';'.'
out =: 'LET USSCENE D.' ,~ ; <@g 0, |. -&31 a. i. inp
NB. echo # out
echo out

exit ''
eof

cp .input.tio quine.spl
/opt/j/bin/jconsole convert.ijs < .input.tio | tr -d '\n' >> quine.spl
wc -c quine.spl

/opt/spl/spl2c < quine.spl > quine.spl.c 2> /dev/null
gcc -c -I /opt/spl -o quine.spl.o quine.spl.c
gcc -lm -o quine quine.spl.o /opt/spl/libspl.a

./quine < /dev/null > quine.spl.out

wc -c quine.spl.out

diff quine.spl quine.spl.out
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVdbU9pAFH7fX3HUqQszsFh86DSiNYTVbgtEIXip7VgMQeMAoRC003H863Q3F9gkIEEdBmYv5/Kd852zu9y0x3fTqdl2oVQCbDldDAdgOoMHa@QS@36MPm8ou58gswPX4pNFqAv7CmQy2L2zYDzpg9Ntg9DHsPUMxe2nLOQAu4@2afGlHFwp0IUSOfywXczCb8jgf9bIwZvXWTgkkNnf3smiW88iF3SdyXBojQCPrL7VvxEjbqErDG4Ilc0dhOzBUIiP3Y49wDichppiOhr2TKge7WHAe1xvDxOMnIkrxHCVGtBqNjVap1Ah3Poz7EHp8BZ2cvBEIL@9@xHaBGwiLKF6mYBl3jmwBdwA8oZigKy/Ng8YI54vhMwhEC49cYlrO/BnYg8sMh72UMEZuoX7wo09KNzzjI6dniVnFkqy2hO4I8h3AP8ccAYOJDOPJuRNae7b5SPxLZrczGwPJD1iQvEACh3roTCY9Hro1vTs5BmE@pCX0BJ5bPrSvf5MJCI4A9Czb8RKGyFS8MVKc48RMF7WYpH4ix2725UiiOxOpwZRv6kXOXKiHtMcUTUDmEJ8@vjgitYN2gAhAmq9AkLql5gpMs@MBRoVxbOjNGiN1spCEU7YcbCpKZ4rvqmp1WpMkPl7ZQqXegvqTONrP2hD/8KOoK4bsrcaESJc0vhKodmqgX7kuZHm3G@ZL8S/mmoI86R5QtXvXPySyHa1AGdtFoSHM4B0rjeadAapqUfiv/DRJ3B5o9OW2qDhJIAbR6XOfyV0i@3FTMzVxa7WKtP49ksW1RUJWqEg0r6WQgoPy8IISF0jRYGzNRR9rhq6boiVc16GnoF4NEujWFp3kqhfM2dBlaWp@GR5nbZ0g/He5HPjnNI6k2Kc9ZRAyOVZYHwWzgIPVT@AJdg9oKF3z4qUtvk8kjzGWzqZ7ZhylF@2Hj0sMCereXmaTyPAk/zylZOGXmlpRqRwhAJLV9bv0DCrIKfyFicl1gQsZQv4@UycQ@8CcaWXNxVYDGJQ1YqENVbTkY5a7jKJOEWZvvr4iVAWuTzY6ozGqRClpqY/oVcVV6LX5Hs8EGWRC/UsoOFiCQ0LqVhyCkuXQppUJBISdkGqDngz80HSYUbEa/oh@uYJXxrKotN4Rf2@y3sjWs3SeZb@8Au9L0jV667SlPwli0oo@sGkeh8tBbnW2b/WgynlQ@lldtagN1qyL9K7DjMLKzHNPbboDJB@o@rBURT@Gwn@aPwH)

---

The content of the `.input.tio` file should be:

```bash
T.AJAX,.PAGE,.ACT I:.SCENE I:.[ENTER AJAX AND PAGE]AJAX:LET USSCENE II.SCENE D:.PAGE:REMEMBER A PIG.SCENE C:.AJAX:RECALL.PAGE:REMEMBER I.AJAX:BE YOU NICER ZERO?IF NOTLET USSCENE M.YOU BE THE SUM OFA PIG THE SUM OF A BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.LET USSCENE C.SCENE M:.PAGE:RECALL.BE YOU WORSE ZERO?IF SOLET USSCENE IX.AJAX:YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SQUARE OFTHE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG CAT A CAT A CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA BIG BIG CAT A CAT THE CUBE OFA BIG BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG PIG YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE CUBE OFA BIG BIG CAT A BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA CAT YOU A BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SQUARE ROOT OFTWICE YOU THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE A BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.SCENE V:.PAGE:BE YOU NICER ZERO?IF NOTLET USSCENE X.AJAX:YOU BE THE QUOTIENT BETWEENI A BIG CAT.REMEMBER YOU.BE I NICER TWICE YOU?IF NOTLET USSCENE L.YOU BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT.PAGE:YOU BE TWICE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SQUARE ROOT OFI I.SPEAK THY.YOU BE TWICE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG CAT I.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SQUARE ROOT OFI TWICE I.SPEAK THY.AJAX:SPEAK THY.PAGE:YOU BE THE SQUARE ROOT OFTHE PRODUCT OFTHE SUM OFYOU I YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG PIG YOU.SPEAK THY.AJAX:SPEAK THY.PAGE:YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE TWICE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA CAT I A BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE I A CAT.SPEAK THY.AJAX:SPEAK THY.PAGE:YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE I A CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE TWICE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SQUARE ROOT OFI I.SPEAK THY.AJAX:SPEAK THY.SCENE L:.PAGE:YOU BIG BIG BIG CAT.AJAX:YOU BE TWICE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SUM OFTWICE I A CAT I.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA CAT YOU A BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA CAT I THE SQUARE OFI.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SUM OFA BIG PIG A PIG YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE TWICE TWICE I.SPEAK THY.RECALL.PAGE:YOU BE I.LET USSCENE V.SCENE X:.PAGE:YOU BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT.AJAX:YOU BE THE SQUARE ROOT OFTWICE THE CUBE OFI.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE TWICE THE SUM OFA CAT I A CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SUM OFTWICE I A CAT I.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA PIG YOU A BIG PIG.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE I A CAT.SPEAK THY.LET USSCENE M.SCENE IX:.PAGE:YOU BE TWICE TWICE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG CAT A CAT A CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA CAT YOU A BIG BIG BIG PIG.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT THE SUM OFA PIG YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE A BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SUM OFTWICE THE SQUARE ROOT OFYOU YOU A CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG PIG YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG BIG BIG BIG PIG YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA CAT YOU A BIG BIG BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE THE SUM OFTHE SUM OFA PIG YOU A BIG BIG BIG PIG.SPEAK THY.YOU BE A BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG CAT.SPEAK THY.YOU BE TWICE THE SUM OFA BIG CAT YOU.SPEAK THY.YOU BE TWICE THE SQUARE ROOT OFTWICE TWICE TWICE YOU.SPEAK THY.RECALL.SCENE II:.AJAX:
```

which is also the first part of the quine program. The second part is the first part converted through the `convert.ijs` J script written above.

---

The constant generation part needs **a lot** more work.

---

Each byte in the source code is encoded by:

```bash
REMEMBER <repr(value - 31)>.
```

where:

```bash
repr(0) = 'ZERO'
repr(2 * x + 1) = 'THE SUM OFA CAT ' + repr(2 * x)
repr(2 * x) = 'TWICE ' + repr(x)
```

with integral `x`.

Comment: For the record this one is about 5% of the previous quine (6MiB) (although the other one is not really a serious contender)

Comment: Some quick golfing to get to 264827 bytes. [Pastebin link to TIO link because it doesn't fit in a comment](https://pastebin.com/4gbeNDdz)

Answer (score 12):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 105 Bytes

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 0000 00ff ff00 0000 ffff 0000 00ff ff00  ................
00000010: 1400 ebff 0000 00ff ff00 0000 ffff 0000  ................
00000020: 00ff ff00 1400 ebff 4288 21c4 0000 1400  ........B.!.....
00000030: ebff 4288 21c4 0000 1400 ebff 4288 21c4  ..B.!.......B.!.
00000040: 0000 1400 ebff 4288 21c4 0000 1400 ebff  ......B.!.......
00000050: 0000 00ff ff00 0000 ffff 0000 00ff ff03  ................
00000060: 1300 0000 0313 0000 00                   .........
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBCoAgEETvfcX2A6GuhXTsU4y2Sx37fts0rQyjOSzCOI9h7GbtMs3b6pw41cNx@RABkX/xIVZuQJOpCgTJDKn5w2TfoYxWYijfI4YumlbGgJKjDnFvJMbQ1HcGMqMYygy40uF1MnTc47uCN@DZIvVof2@KxT26Y1OMSYESYxLeSmHndg)

(You might want to verify it offline - since the input is hexdump and the output is raw.)

---

This relies on the fact that Bubbleugum [tries to DEFLATE decode its input first](https://github.com/TryItOnline/bubblegum/blob/67a2ae40075a063b084e3ada06324f42d898a148/bubblegum#L24):

```python
...
o = zlib.decompress(code, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
...
```

So if we can find a fixpoint in [DEFLATE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951#page-6) compression, such that `x = zlib.decompress(x, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)`, we are done. But how to do this?

#### Part I: Generic Compression Quine

Say we have a compression programming 'language' that has two operations:

- `Pn`: Print the following `n` tokens as literals, and skip interpreting them
- `Rn`: Print the last `n` tokens printed

Let's write some simple programs in this to understand how it works.

```
Input   | Output
P1 P0   | P0
```

```
Input   | Output
P1 P0   | P0
P1 P1   | P1
```

```
Input   | Output
P1 P0   | P0
R1      | P0
```

```
Input          | Output
P4 P0 P0 P0 P0 | P0 P0 P0 P0
R4             | P0 P0 P0 P0
```

Now the question is: Just with these two instructions, can we create a quine? The answer is yes, thanks to [Russ Cox](https://research.swtch.com/zip):

```
Input          | Output
P0             | 
P0             |
P0             |
P4 P0 P0 P0 P4 | P0 P0 P0 P4
R4             | P0 P0 P0 P4
P4 R4 P4 R4 P4 | R4 P4 R4 P4
R4             | R4 P4 R4 P4
P4 P0 P0 P0 P0 | P0 P0 P0 P0
```

(The tokens are not on the same line, but you can check they're the same).

This gives us hope we might be able to write a DEFLATE quine. But we're not close to done yet, since we have to deal with actual file formats and not made up tokens. Read on!

#### Part II: Zlib and DEFLATE

Zlib usually appends a 2 byte header and a 4 byte checksum to everything it compresses. The 4 byte checksum would make the creation of a quine much more difficult. But luckily, Bubblegum is designed using to utilize the `-zlib.MAX_WBITS` flag, which skips the header and the checksum! So we just have a raw DEFLATE stream. How does DEFLATE work? The full thing can be a bit complicated, but luckily we only need to pull out the bits that allow us to have our `Pn` and `Rn` building blocks.

#### Part III: The `Pn` building block

A deflate stream is made up of a series of *blocks*. Each block starts with the following:

- `BFINAL`: 1 bit, set to 1 if it's the last block.
- `BTYPE`: 2 bits. All we need to know is that it's `00` for 'no compression' (ie `Pn`) and `01` for 'fixed compression' (which turns out to map to `Rn`).

If we have a 'no compression' block, the rest of the bits in the current byte are set to zero and the next bytes look like:

```
+---+---+---+---+================================+
|  LEN  | NLEN  |... LEN bytes of literal data...|
+---+---+---+---+================================+
```

Where `LEN` is a 2-byte little endian unsigned number of bytes in the literal data, `NLEN`  is the complement of LEN (also unsigned little endian) and we then have `N` literal bytes. Keeping in mind the first byte is packed from LSB to MSB, this means we can encode the following:

```
P0 = 00 00 00 ff ff
00000 00 0 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 11111111 | 11111111
^     ^  ^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|     |  |   LEN = 0x0000          NLEN = ~LEN = 0xFFFF
|     |  |
|     |  \- BFINAL = 0 (not final block)
|     \---- BTYPE = 00 (no compression)
\---------- 5 bits padding in block
```

```
P4 = 00 14 00 eb ff
00000 00 0 | 00010100 | 00000000 | 11101011 | 11111111
^     ^  ^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|     |  |   LEN = 0x0014          NLEN = ~LEN = 0xFFEB
|     |  |
|     |  \- BFINAL = 0 (not final block)
|     \---- BTYPE = 00 (no compression)
\---------- 5 bits padding in block
```

Why is `P4` printing `0x14 = 20` bytes, you ask, instead of 4? Well, the previous token 'quine' had the units of 1 byte ~ 1 token, but we don't have that luxury. So instead, we have a fixed length of 5 bytes per token, since this is the minimum size of a print token. So 4 tokens is 20 bytes.

#### Part IV: The `Rn` building block

The `BTYPE = 01` allows us to make queries of the form `REPEAT(n, q)`:

> Starting from `q` bytes away in the output, print `n` bytes.

It shouldn't be hard to see that `REPEAT(n, n)` gives us `Rn`. But there's a problem, since it turns out that `R4 = REPEAT(20, 20)` only takes up 3 bytes instead of 5! Since we are assuming all our tokens take up 5 bytes for our quine to work, this is no good. However, we can introduce some redundancy - it turns out if we define `R4 = REPEAT(10, 20), REPEAT(10, 20)`, then we do the same thing but now the instruction takes up 5 bytes total!

The way these blocks are actually encoded as bytes is a little complex. I'll annotate the block, and to fill in the gaps read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951). For compressed blocks, the data is turned from bits into bytes *LSB to MSB* with a couple of exceptions.

```
P4 = 42 88 21 c4 00
01000 01 0 | 1 00010 00 | 001000 01 | 11 00010 0 | 0000000 0
^     ^  ^   ^  ^    ^    ^      ^    ^   ^    ^   ^       ^
|     |  |  [5] |    |    |      |    [8] |    |   padding [8]
[3]   |  \- [1] [4] [3]  [6]    [5]      [7]  [6]
      \---- [2]

[1]: BFINAL: 0 (not end block)
[2]: BTYPE: 01 (fixed compression) 
[3]: Literal code 264 (print 10 bytes...)
[4]: Distance code 8 (starting from 17 + ... )
[5]: Extra distance code bits ( ... 3 bytes back) (= 20 total)
[6]: Literal code 264 (print 10 bytes...)
[7]: Distance code 8 (starting from 17 + ... )
[8]: Extra distance code bits ( ... 3 bytes back) (= 20 total)
```

So we've got all our building blocks! `P0`, `P4`, `R4` right? Are we done?

#### Part V: The final tweak

Well, not so fast. Remember we had a bit saying which block was the end block? It turns out, for Python at least, that we need to include this on the last block, else it messes up our program. And unfortunately, if we let `P*0` be a `P0` end block token, the following is NOT a quine:

```
Input           | Output
P0              | 
P0              |
P0              | 
P4 P0 P0 P0 P4  | P0 P0 P0 P4
R4              | P0 P0 P0 P4
P4 R4 P4 R4 P4  | R4 P4 R4 P4
R4              | R4 P4 R4 P4 <-\
P*4 P0 P0 P0 P0 | P0 P0 P0 P0   |
^                               |
\--------------+----------------+
               |
          Not the same!
```

However, if we introduce an `R*1`, we can fix this quite easily:

```
Input            | Output
P0               | 
P0               |
P0               | 
P4 P0 P0 P0 P4   | P0 P0 P0 P4
R4               | P0 P0 P0 P4
P4 R4 P4 R4 P4   | R4 P4 R4 P4
R4               | R4 P4 R4 P4
P4 P0 P0 P0 R*1  | P0 P0 P0 R*1
R*1              | R*1
```

It turns out we can encode `R*1 = 03 13 00 00 00`, so we are done. Use the following Python program to assemble and verify our DEFLATE quine:

```python
import zlib

P0 = b'\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff'
P4 = b'\x00\x14\x00\xeb\xff'
R4 = b'B\x88!\xc4\x00'
R1_F = b'\x03\x13\x00\x00\x00'

comp = b''
comp += P0
comp += P0
comp += P0
comp += P4 + P0 + P0 + P0 + P4
comp += R4
comp += P4 + R4 + P4 + R4 + P4
comp += R4
comp += P4 + P0 + P0 + P0 + R1_F
comp += R1_F

print(zlib.decompress(comp, -zlib.MAX_WBITS) == comp)
```

Well done! You are now a certified deflate quine expert™.

Answer (score 11):

## A Classic - Lisp - 78

```
((lambda (x) (list x (list 'quote x))) '(lambda (x) (list x (list 'quote x))))
```

A beautiful snippet, but [give credit where credit is due.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130619151711/http://en.literateprograms.org/Quine_%28Lisp%29)

Comment: Actually this code *returns* itself instead of *printing* itself. Running it in an interpreter with read-eval-print loop will of course print the returned list, but the printing is not part of the code itself. The C equivalent of this would be a C code which outputs its executable instead of its source code. Which would certainly also be a quite interesting problem, although heavily system-dependent.

Comment: that would make it not different from one of those function quines

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: The link is indeed dead. The suggested edit adds a link that doesn't help, though.

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript, 31 characters

```
function f(){alert(f+"f()")}f()
```

Is this seriously the shortest JavaScript quine here?

Comment: 75, without recursion: `!function (x){alert('!'+x+'('+x+')')}(function (x){alert('!'+x+'('+x+')')})`

Answer (score 11):

## Ceylon <s>1647</s> <s>1165</s> <s>885</s> <s>739</s> <s>672</s> <s>566</s> <s>388</s> <s>187</s> 178 bytes

Late, and won't win anything ... but I'm trying out how Ceylon works.

An one-liner now:

```ceylon
shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t="""shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t=""";value b=""";print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+b);}""";print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+b);}`
```

The ungolfed original (1647 bytes):

```ceylon
shared void quine69() {
    void printQuoted(String line) => print("        \"" + line + "\"");
    void printQuotedWithComma(String* seq) {
        for (line in seq) {
            print("        \"" + line.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"".string, "\\\"") + "\",");
        }
    }
    void printLines(String* seq) {
        for (line in seq) {
            print(line);
        }
    }
    value top = [
        "shared void quine69() {",
        "    void printQuoted(String line) => print(\"        \\\"\" + line + \"\\\"\");",
        "    void printQuotedWithComma(String* seq) {",
        "        for (line in seq) {",
        "            print(\"        \\\"\" + line.replace(\"\\\\\", \"\\\\\\\\\").replace(\"\\\"\".string, \"\\\\\\\"\") + \"\\\",\");",
        "        }",
        "    }",
        "    void printLines(String* seq) {",
        "        for (line in seq) {",
        "            print(line);",
        "        }",
        "    }",
        "    value top = ["
    ];
    value bottom = [
        "    ];",
        "    printLines(*top);",
        "    printQuotedWithComma(*top.exceptLast);",
        "    printQuoted(top.last);",
        "    print(\"    ];\");",
        "    print(\"    value bottom = [\");",
        "    printQuotedWithComma(*bottom.exceptLast);",
        "    printQuoted(bottom.last);",
        "    printLines(*bottom);",
        "}"
    ];
    printLines(*top);
    printQuotedWithComma(*top.exceptLast);
    printQuoted(top.last);
    print("    ];");
    print("    value bottom = [");
    printQuotedWithComma(*bottom.exceptLast);
    printQuoted(bottom.last);
    printLines(*bottom);
}
```

The second try, mainly with shorter names, and extract the quote function (to 1165 bytes):

```ceylon
shared void q() {
    String q1(String l) => "        \"" + l.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"".string, "\\\"") + "\"";
    void pQ(String l) => print(q1(l));
    void pQC(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(q1(l) + ","); } }
    void pL(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(l); } }
    value t = [
        "shared void q() {",
        "    String q1(String l) => \"        \\\"\" + l.replace(\"\\\\\", \"\\\\\\\\\").replace(\"\\\"\".string, \"\\\\\\\"\") + \"\\\"\";",
        "    void pQ(String l) => print(q1(l));",
        "    void pQC(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(q1(l) + \",\"); } }",
        "    void pL(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(l); } }",
        "    value t = ["
    ];
    value b = [
        "    ];",
        "    pL(*t);",
        "    pQC(*t.exceptLast);",
        "    pQ(t.last);",
        "    print(\"    ];\");",
        "    print(\"    value b = [\");",
        "    pQC(*b.exceptLast);",
        "    pQ(b.last);",
        "    pL(*b);",
        "}"
    ];
    pL(*t);
    pQC(*t.exceptLast);
    pQ(t.last);
    print("    ];");
    print("    value b = [");
    pQC(*b.exceptLast);
    pQ(b.last);
    pL(*b);
}
```

The third try omits the indentation (I had to change my IDE settings to turn auto-formatting off). This gets us to 885 bytes:

```ceylon
shared void i() {
String q1(String l) => "\"" + l.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"".string, "\\\"") + "\"";
void pQ(String l) => print(q1(l));
void pQC(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(q1(l) + ","); } }
void pL(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(l); } }
value t = [
"shared void i() {",
"String q1(String l) => \"\\\"\" + l.replace(\"\\\\\", \"\\\\\\\\\").replace(\"\\\"\".string, \"\\\\\\\"\") + \"\\\"\";",
"void pQ(String l) => print(q1(l));",
"void pQC(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(q1(l) + \",\"); } }",
"void pL(String* seq) { for (l in seq) { print(l); } }",
"value t = ["
];
value b = [
"];",
"pL(*t);",
"pQC(*t.exceptLast);",
"pQ(t.last);",
"print(\"];\");",
"print(\"value b = [\");",
"pQC(*b.exceptLast);",
"pQ(b.last);",
"pL(*b);",
"}"
];
pL(*t);
pQC(*t.exceptLast);
pQ(t.last);
print("];");
print("value b = [");
pQC(*b.exceptLast);
pQ(b.last);
pL(*b);
}
```

The fourth version has also the internal spaces, and some line breaks removed, comes down to 739 bytes:

```ceylon
shared void n(){
String q1(String l)=>"\""+l.replace("\\","\\\\").replace("\"","\\\"")+"\"";
void pQ(String l)=>print(q1(l));
void pQC(String*s){for(l in s){print(q1(l)+",");}}
void pL(String*s){for(l in s){print(l);}}
value t=[
"shared void n(){",
"String q1(String l)=>\"\\\"\"+l.replace(\"\\\\\",\"\\\\\\\\\").replace(\"\\\"\",\"\\\\\\\"\")+\"\\\"\";",
"void pQ(String l)=>print(q1(l));",
"void pQC(String*s){for(l in s){print(q1(l)+\",\");}}",
"void pL(String*s){for(l in s){print(l);}}",
"value t=["
];value b=[
"];",
"pL(*t);pQC(*t.exceptLast);pQ(t.last);",
"print(\"];value b=[\");",
"pQC(*b.exceptLast);pQ(b.last);pL(*b);",
"}"
];
pL(*t);pQC(*t.exceptLast);pQ(t.last);
print("];value b=[");
pQC(*b.exceptLast);pQ(b.last);pL(*b);
}
```

For the next version I tried a different approach, to avoid all this escaping. Ceylon has (like Python) a "long string literal" format – everything between `"""` and `"""` is part of a string, with no escapes. ... But the indentation is removed, and because the `"""` itself is already 3 chars long, we also need at least those the spaces of indentation. For printing this string literal we also need to add those indentation back, and we need to handle the first and last line specially (the first needs to have `"""` in front, the last one is better omitted, otherwise we get one line more in the output than we already had. This (and replacing some identifiers by one-letter ones) gets us down to 672 bytes:

```ceylon
shared void e(){
value _="   ";value q="\"\"\"";
void r(String? l)=>print(q+(l else""));
void s(String l)=>print(_+q+l);
void c(String*s){for(l in s){print(_+l);}}
value t=

"""shared void e(){
   value _="   ";value q="\"\"\"";
   void r(String? l)=>print(q+(l else""));
   void s(String l)=>print(_+q+l);
   void c(String*s){for(l in s){print(_+l);}}
   value t=
   """;value b=
"""print(t);r(t.lines.first);c(*t.lines.rest.exceptLast);
   s(";value b=");
   r(b.lines.first);c(*b.lines.rest.exceptLast);s(";");print(b);
   }
   """;
print(t);r(t.lines.first);c(*t.lines.rest.exceptLast);
s(";value b=");
r(b.lines.first);c(*b.lines.rest.exceptLast);s(";");print(b);
}
```

(This has an empty trailing line, which Stack Exchange doesn't show. Same for the next ones.)

By inlining the two short functions `r` and `s` (their savings are less than the function definition), and extracting the long `.lines.rest.exceptLast` expression into the c function, we get down to 566 bytes:

```ceylon
shared void e(){
value _="   ";value q="\"\"\"";
void c(String s){for(l in s.lines.rest.exceptLast){print(_+l);}}
value t=

"""shared void e(){
   value _="   ";value q="\"\"\"";
   void c(String s){for(l in s.lines.rest.exceptLast){print(_+l);}}
   value t=
   """;value b=
"""print(t);print(q+(t.lines.first else""));c(t);
   print(_+q+";value b=");
   print(q+(b.lines.first else""));c(b);print(_+q+";");print(b);
   }
   """;
print(t);print(q+(t.lines.first else""));c(t);
print(_+q+";value b=");
print(q+(b.lines.first else""));c(b);print(_+q+";");print(b);
}
```

Another, now "obvious" optimization would be to remove the line breaks (and most of the indentation) inside our long string literals here. By that, we actually only the first and last line of each to handle (first is to be printed with `"""`, and the empty last one we print manually with the stuff behind it), and can get rid of the long `c` function which looped over everything but first and last line. This gets us down to 388:

```ceylon
shared void e(){value _="   ";value q="\"\"\"";value t=

"""shared void e(){value _="   ";value q="\"\"\"";value t=
   """;value b=
"""print(t);print(q+(t.lines.first else""));print(_+q+";value b=");print(q+(b.lines.first else""));print(_+q+";");print(b);}
   """;
print(t);print(q+(t.lines.first else""));print(_+q+";value b=");print(q+(b.lines.first else""));print(_+q+";");print(b);}
```

Now we can ask: why do we have many print statements, instead of using just one and some string concatenation? This gets rid of the remaining line breaks (and also the trailing empty line), and gets us down to 185 bytes (including the new line character at the end):

```ceylon
shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t="""shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t=""";value b="""print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+";"+b);}""";print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+";"+b);}
```

Here slightly easier to read (but without syntax highlighting):

`shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t="""shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t=""";value b="""print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+";"+b);}""";print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+";"+b);}`

We can actually remove another 9 characters by putting this single `;` inside the `b` string:

`shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t="""shared void e(){value q="\"\"\"";value t=""";value b=""";print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+b);}""";print(t+q+t+q+";value b="+q+b+q+b);}`

I don't see how this could be shrunk further anymore ... maybe with a totally different approach.

(I did put a [commented version of this](https://github.com/ePaul/ceylon-codegolf/blob/master/source/codegolf/quine69/commentedQuine.ceylon) into my new Github repository).

As a bonus, an "ungolfed version" of the last one (463 chars):

```ceylon
shared void quine(){
    value quote = "\"\"\"";
    value top = """shared void quine(){#    value quote = "\"\"\"";#    value top = """;
    value bottom = """    print(top.replace("#","\n") + quote + top + quote + ";\n    value bottom = " + quote + bottom + quote + ";\n" + bottom.replace("$"+"$","\n"));$$}""";
    print(top.replace("#","\n") + quote + top + quote + ";\n    value bottom = " + quote + bottom + quote + ";\n" + bottom.replace("$"+"$","\n"));
}
```

This needed some additional tricks to encode the line breaks in each of the string literals, because once they should be printed directly, once not. In `top`, I use `#` as a replacement. In bottom, where I replace the `#` in `top` by a newline, we need to use a different replacement string. I chose the two letter-string `$$`, because that can be escaped by string concatenation.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6 REPL), 22 bytes

```
f=_=>"f="+f+";f()";f()
```

Idea stolen from Kendall Frey but in less bytes.

Since I cannot comment on his answer because I don't have rep I decided to make a new answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Save a byte with template literals: `f=_=>'f=${f};f()';f()` (replace single quotes with backticks).

Comment: `(f=_=>*(f=${f})()*)()` to save one byte (swap `*` with "`")

Answer (score 11):

## [Threead](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Threead), 85 bytes

```
>93>60>111>99>91>60>93>62>111>100>111>99>50>54>105>91>62>93>60>91[<]>[i62codo>]<[co<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#@29naWxnZmBnaGhoZ2lpZ2kI4oCEjMBChgZwKVMDO1MToIApWJERVJ@lYbRNrF10pplRcn5Kvl2sTXRyvk3s//8A)

```
>93>60>...60>91      # Encodes the second part backwards
[<]>                 # Go back to the begining
    [        ]       # for every number
     i               # insert an extra cell
      62co           # print a '>' 
          d          # delete the cell
           o         # print the original number in this cell
            >        # go to the next cell
              <[  <] # for every cell in reverse order
                co   # print the character that it represents
```

Comment: That's, actually much more simple than the solution I had planned.

Answer (score 11):

## [Forte](https://github.com/judofyr/forter), 66 bytes

*Updated for the new Interpreter*

```
2PUT34:LET1=3
4PUT34:END
1PRINT
"2PUT34:LET1=3
4PUT34:END
1PRINT
"
```

Which, in order is:

```
1: Print the first half of the code.
2: Print a ", then set line 3 to be line 1.
3: Print the second half of the code again.
4: Print another ", then end the program.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/forte#@28UEBpibGLl4xpiaGvMZQLhufq5cBkGBHn6hXApEVTw/z8A)

Comment: I remember when you and me were trying to do this. I am still impressed

Comment: Why the bounty?

Comment: @MDXF Bounty was for writing a Forte quine, which at the time, hadn't been done.

Comment: @ATaco Ah, got it. Cheers

Answer (score 11):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 18337

```
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................,94942339352462393733242422402282678746947594827594678246942219941994753536322424463225469422223987242539322425469475943836248282228238392446947594383433242467274646946730621520949494282828<>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH33pp)95*P973**(:(dUi@p]pd]pUd@p(%p%p]562**@2+@p((9i*+92*+@p]p86*dd(d89*@p]p843**U-@@pU0P!&ppp...HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH``
```

Since this contains un-printables here's a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tXkjNK7c). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7dBNS8NAEIDhP@LFQyVuVNKZ/RSRHD32kmOhhUAJiCxFf3@ctei9Nw/vE5JlZ3Zmh3yel@PH6ev9eF7XJwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAf/VQfPGiWjSIj2JrUhVvj/hBJEtMOflYfArFZ2lfi0iLiGxL8e1NQYNGlVbn2xouebF@OVk0WN@WDb@dNGsU65el3WG70ir/cv4yQ0xid7d4TDpE2QYZ2rzWu5Xml9ebt6uo1npfgtuVpM51z908LWPd13lfp3ms3aZu6j5EcW6U3vZdWVxfxPXtUI5unrs5F/ez89ZhehzHOg2727taq/3N66Y5HNb1Gw)

### Explanation

Here is the relevant portion of the code with a line breaks where they would be inserted:

```
  ,94942339352462393733242422402282678746947594827594678246942219941994753536322424463225469422223987242539322425469475943836248282228238392446947594383433242467274646946730621520949494282828<
 >HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH33pp)95*P973**(:(dUi@p]pd]pUd@p(%p%p]562**@2+@p((9i*+92*+@p]p86*dd(d89*@p]p843**U-@@pU0P!&ppp...HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH`
`
```

The `H`s are there because they are easier to print than `.`, but they have the same function, so I'll replace them and all the other noops with `.`:

```
  ,94942339352462393733242422402282678746947594827594678246942219941994753536322424463225469422223987242539322425469475943836248282228238392446947594383433242467274646946730621520949494282828<
 >................................................33pp)95*P973**(:(dUi@p]pd]pUd@p(%p%p]562**@2+@p((9i*+92*+@p]p86*dd(d89*@p]p843**U-@@pU0P!&ppp.................................................`
`
```

Like most quines this comes in two parts, an encoder and a decoder.  The encoder is the line full of numbers and the decoder is the line full of symbols.  Each pair of numbers in the encoder represents a single character in the decoder.  Once we have encoded we get pushed down to the decoder.

The first thing in the encoder (besides `33pp` which is just there for spacing) is `)`.  This tells triangular to jump back to the start of the most recent loop.  However since we have not opened a loop there is nothing to go back to so it does nothing.  This will be used later to yoyo the ip when we don't want it to run the decoder.

We then store `-` to the register with `95*P`, this will be used to create both `,` and `.`.  We then push 189 which is the number of blank lines before the code starts.  We use this and a loop to generate all the empty lines before the code starts.

```
(:(dUi@p]pd]
```

Once our loop is done we add the `,` with `pUd@p`.  Now we are ready to decode the encoder, this is done with the simple loop:

```
(%p%p]
```

Each `%p` prints one of the numbers off the top of the stack.  We have two of them because some of the numbers have zero as their second digit, meaning in order to get the loop to go through all the encoder we need to print them two at a time.

Once the encoder has been printed we print `<>` which makes up the two redirects that are needed.

```
562**@2+@p
```

Now we need to fetch another copy of the encoder.  To start we open a loop with `(` this will be closed by the `)` we encountered earlier allowing us to spring back to where we were first.

But first we have to run through the decoding section once.  The decoding section combines the two numbers as a double digit number in base 10 and adds 18 to the result, since our stack is currently empty this will decode to 18 directly.  Thats what accounts for the unprintable in the quine.  Once we have "decoded" a character we run through the bit of the program that creates the padding, we make half the padding and leave the other half to be made later.  Next up we is the code that makes the backticks.  Since we absolutely cannot have any of these just lying around we subtract the register from the result to makes some significantly less harmful `3`s.  Lastly we use the check the contents of the register, exiting on zero.  Since we don't have anything we continue on for later.  In order to make sure the next run does terminate we put a `0` in the register.

The ip runs through the encoder again and gets yoyo'd back to our decoder again.

Now we are ready to decode everything.  The first loop

```
(9i*+92*+@p]p
```

Converts to base 10 adds 18 and outputs, it does this until we have emptied the stack.

Next up we create the padding.  We already created half the padding the first run through so we only have half left.

```
86*dd(d89*@p]p
```

Once again we pad with `H` because its cheaper to make than `.` in this situation.

Now we make the backticks.  We make them using `843**` and subtract the contents of the register using `U-`, since we previously set the register to zero we output backtick this time.

Now we exit by checking the contents of the register:

```
U0P!&
```

(there are also 3 `p`s at the end of the code, I don't know why they need to be there but they do, a bunch of weird characters end up in the output otherwise)

Answer (score 10):

### PHP - 54 characters (no cheating)

```
<?printf($p='<?printf($p=%c%s%c,39,$p,39);',39,$p,39);
```

(finally even shorter)

Answer (score 10):

**C, 77 chars**

Maybe the easiest one in C.

```
main(){char*c="main(){char*c=%c%s%c;printf(c,34,c,34);}";printf(c,34,c,34);}
```

34 is the ASCII decimal for `"`.

Comment: I count 76 bytes.

Comment: @Lynn He must have used `wc` and forgot to exclude the trailing newline :P

Answer (score 10):

## HTML + CSS <del>118</del> <del>78</del> <del>77</del> <del>75</del> <del>53</del>  <del>51</del> 50 characters

```
<style>*{display:flex}html:before{content:'<style>
```

This language isn't good for quining, but it works. Invalid HTML and CSS, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: } isn't required

Comment: @xem: Removed `'}`. This abuses CSS error handling rules, but considering it's code golf, it's fine.

Comment: What browser did this work in? Running in Chrome 59 and this outputs `*{display:inline;font-family:monospace}style:before{content:'<style>`

Comment: Why does it need to be monospaced? And if it does, using `<pre>` is faster.

Comment: `<style>*{display:inline}style:before{content:'<style>` works for less bytes.

Comment: @Riker Not sure how I missed that. Fixed.

Comment: `display:flex` seems to work as well.

Comment: Cheat a bit,   a blank file will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 10):

### TI-BASIC

```
i
```

Where `i` is the imaginary number

Comment: -1. That doesn't actually **print** `2i` outside of an interactive console, does it?

Comment: @nyuszika7h **Yes it does.** `2i` works as a program that, when run, prints `2i` (because the last line that sets `Ans` is automatically printed).

Comment: @nyuszika7h Please test or research before downvoting.

Comment: Well, now I can't undo my vote unless this answer is edited. But then couldn't you just use `2` for a 1-byte solution?

Comment: @nyuszika7h Yes, but that isn't interesting/obfuscated...

Comment: @Timtech The goal is to write the *shortest* quine.

Comment: @mbomb007 True, updated.

Answer (score 10):

## Mini-Flak, 6900 bytes

Mini-flak is a Turing complete subset of [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/).  It works exactly like Brain-Flak except the `[]`, `<>` and `<...>` operations are banned from use.  Programming in Min-Flak is thus much more difficult than traditional Brain-Flak.

The main difficulty with Mini-Flak is the lack of random access.  While Mini-flak is Turing complete, location of access (relative to the top of the stack) must be determined at compile time rather than run time.

---

The following is the quine.  Unfortunately this quine has an order notation of `O(7**n)` (where n is its own length) and thus cannot be run to completion in the lifetime of the universe.  I will hopefully convince you that it does work but for now you will have to trust me a bit.  If you want a version that can be run in the lifetime of the universe (or an afternoon) you can scroll down a bit to my faster version.

```
(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()())(()())(())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()())(())(()())(()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(({}({}))[({}[{}])]){((((((({}({}))[({}[{}])])){})){}{}{}{}({}))[({}[{}])])}{}(({})[({(({}[(((()()()){}()))]{})([((({}({}))[({}[{}])]))]{})){({}[()((({}()[({})])){{}([(({}({}[(({}[()]))]{})))]{})}{})]{})}(({}{}[({})]{}({}))[({}[{}])(({}[()(((((()()()()()){}){}){}))]{}){([(({}[()(({}()))]{}){([(({}[()((({}){}((()()())){}{}))]{}){([(({}[()(({}()()))]{}){([(({}[()(({}(((()()()()())){}{}){}))]{}){([({}({}()()))]{})}{})]{})}{})]{})}{})]{})}{})]{})}{})]{})}{})]{}){(({}[(((()()()){}()))]{})([((({}({}))[({}[{}])]))]{})){({}[()((({}()[({})])){{}([(({}({}[(({}[()]))]{})))]{})}{})]{})}(({}{}[({})]{}({}))[({}[{}])(({}[(((((()()()()()){}){}){}()))]{}){({}[()((((((()()()()()){}){}){}())[()]))]{})}{}((((()()()()()){}){}){}))]{})}{}
```

---

### Explanation

Like my previous [Brain-Flak quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/95296#95296) This program has two parts.  The first part pushes numbers between 1 and 6 to the stack representing the second part of the program using the following key.

```
1 -> (
2 -> )
3 -> [
4 -> ]
5 -> {
6 -> }
```

(Since there is no `<>` in Mini-Flak those characters are left unencoded).  It does this in a deterministic fashion so that this section can be reversed by the next section.

The second section is a decoder.  It takes the output from the first section and turns it into the code that generates that list and the code represented by that list (this section's source).  However this is easier said than done.  Because of Mini-Flak's lack of random access we are going to need to abandon Brain-Flak's traditional techniques in favor of some more bizarre methods.  This program starts by compressing the entire stack into one base 7 number where each digit is one number in the list.  It does that with the following code:

```
(({}({}))[({}[{}])]){(({}({}))[({}[{}])])((((({})){})){}{}{}{})(({}({}))[({}[{}])])}{}
```

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KCh7fSh7fSkpWyh7fVt7fV0pXSl7KCh7fSh7fSkpWyh7fVt7fV0pXSkoKCgoKHt9KSl7fSkpe317fXt9e30pKCh7fSh7fSkpWyh7fVt7fV0pXSl9e30&input=)

This is a pretty straightforward (as far as Mini-Flak goes) program and I won't get into how it works unless any one is interested. (It is a neat little program but to save space I will leave it out).

We now have one single number representing the entire program.  I will push a copy to "temporary memory" (the scope) like follows:

```
(({})[(...)]{})
```

And decompose the original copy via repeated devision.  Each time I remove a digit from the number I will convert it to the code that generates it.

Once I am done with that, the program will put the copy stored in temporary memory back down and begin a second decomposition.  This time it will map each digit to the ASCII value of its corresponding brace as it is decomposed from the total.

Once that is done the program has constructed it's source so it simply terminates.

---

### Verification

You might be suspicious of my program.  How can we know that it actually works if it won't terminate in the lifetime of the universe?

So I have set up a "toy version" of the original quine to demonstrate that all of the parts are working.

[Try it Online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=MSAyIDMgNCA1IDY&args=LUE)

This version has the first part removed.  You can pass the list of numbers that would be generated by the first part as command line arguments.  It will construct code that pushes them and the code they represent.  I provided a simple test case but I encourage you to try it out with your own!  You will notice even with only six characters the run times are starting to become noticeably long.  This is because the division I use is `O(n)`.  Slow division has always been a reality in Brain-Flak and it carries over into Mini-Flak.

If you have any questions or confusions comment them and I will be happy to address them.

---

## 106656 bytes

Now for my fast version.

This version takes about half an hour (175300470 Brain-Flak cycles) to run on my machine using the ruby interpreter.  But for the best performance I suggest you use [Crain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/CraneFlak) the C interpreter which is much faster but lacks some of the polish of the ruby interpreter.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#7d1ZkpswEAbg95xEOhPFSVw@u4MWY8DYqVkqBulzZjIuQatptfT3ooVbGEIcQ4whxPIvXsLlOoSQ/49jnL7GfMclTPderpdrHKffOH2ZSzJxnMu/Tvsb9L9Rw8/q@D7tJyiP0mqfkv6T/fV87XU@HZ21b5wdy37O/VNo2DcKt9Dr@m4Bfeiz6ANDPMWRngIlSpQoUaI8SlyOa5tcRZ8k6C@HDrdxhaDtSNDjXIVcCcsDydkP9qNP@9GC5iGEdStsM664sgsk4NP03G7iYFYaV0jHxrE2@m6b7cbSsiC4wjkSsDW9zBCz1PIHNEzDNEzDNHxOi9jf@jo9S4ZBvC7mEe3SPM2z1OwWrtALetG8PLNYkeVk/Vh6eM/S2@1rvxlKFoTdYrfYLXZLxAWVIYKzvp1R7M0nMn7efAKVvfnEWwvko4w7npQ3n8AQnjTJoT68@v/Sy4SeNfKXMennzb69ZZZkho6sWXpFaW7NOguZc1kM/V42mh1kQXFluVguHptspJwYzwQuQJTz99aeuGpjEeH5Y0meMwnErXqNVURo0dqFARmtk3KeE4/b6Z5OeGd/7CjpJa@GUnbXekHZEDk02asz7eETw5iTkqWFNW1HhfxHeb9W@qMTE6xxNUb4ta3lD6ARNDI72ua5m@aTYQrf6PwWj1dlLgjamwOAntYloMS1VStmlooEPFWaNx8kR8OPkz2DoayndZTWNrH/7CmrCFXZYhKIxdtrN/GoNbvefW4Wlk/JjzWTxXvhPZNAXoQ9cfIgSwxTvSsBPtpr0/bJa3xnKCkjKd8sPuDlskAsEAm8t8p7q8y08e70ZHsA7G/E1a5KfikJ9F377My1oGRjWXY2lU2VK7Zz0Qo9Nt8KPVEOW8yb0G7mGswk2bkoYrdzkR/LIyGBDI1ew0LYo4cWLVq0aNGiRYsWbftxYO9xpJxz@5lYe3msmuktNyYri6u8N2yADU5e6v0t5/ZxQOWWZzPFKPYXGHc8qfNlV2AIT7o3T1q7OY1G1IGrHJ@IjgRyEnISvJxznwdkBwd8gk/wCT6JIkVWIisS8JdonsfH4@Px8fj4JFARKkJFqCiaxZWVdFqOyJ2vxdeyVs0aS1GZfXbqEL@0/j6Gvv0m2Zme33zc42kv/DZnIxktzkayZxAi0R5PgObksXA9st8kJ8IesSdm8VhjuWhRhDPwnIEHlZ2BJ5shp8KXdAYeDOFJH0nvZsbtCMCV5y8fIxssq6LnruvIX5YV3S/uVVUKSm2vPw8uqZr8sywvRYlNrn3vyvR3SAXlgfZqzF/TDe@vv6cf0/VUx4u/uaGGNZflM245rK@NW9In0YfX1xLdSlcbdf9bS@nu/JvKU9GQah2HWkuim7pM4T@sVJcVdn/G8jNumnG@FlKtoSgr1ZzqTSX5vntx@iwavnxJj7X4FGHqo5Wa7lqYxR/CfoPl2rLYmVuqudQ/Lh@jNEcscqeb85ipRbVlE0GVIj95ua0MrpB5lNL1g2z7VWEW5xvLAy01P5bKysW5SRb9OtSnrt3gPuDyDWvdzNXEuOx8ubhKdb973Ghko@Q91cWijjdD7Lk53sm6N4ZfyvrUY6qYX/qMBUzSaL6EWHtJ7VE/H2GP4fQC@dYdu0izLdoAyKzGZ9oX1DsDs96Wn@/B9Zo@u7iQr4fntsqMkvBx22rDXEtpmW@2YWa/h3a1munrn9vtLw)

### Explanation

The reason that Miniflak quines are destined to be slow is Miniflak's lack of random access.  In the short but slow version (short is a bit of an exaggeration and slow an understatement) I get around this by pushing all the numbers and then packaging them up into one number and unrolling it piece by piece.  However this version does it quite differently.  I create a block of code that takes in a number and returns a datum.  Each datum represents a single character like before and the main code simply queries this block for each one at a time.  This essentially works as a block of random access memory.

---

To construct this block I actually reused a method from my proof that Miniflak is Turing complete.  For each datum there is a block of code that looks like this:

```
(({}[()])[(())]()){(([({}{})]{}))}{}{(([({}{}(%s))]{}))}{}
```

This subtracts one from the number on top of the stack and if zero pushes `%s` the datum beneath it.  Since each piece decrements the size by one if you start with n on the stack you will get back the nth datum.

This is nice and modular, so it can be written by a program easily.

---

Next we have to set up the machine that actually translates this memory into the source.  This consists of 5 parts as such:

```
([()]())(()()()())
{({}[(
   -
 )]{})
 1. (({}[()])[((()))]{}){(([({}{})]{}))}{}{([({}{}{}{}
     (((((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()()()){}){}){})((((()()()()){}){}())){}{})(((()()()()){}){}()){})[()()])[((((()()()()()){}){}){}()){}()])((((()()()()()){}){}){}()){}())[((((()()()()()){}){}){}()){}]))[()])())[()])())[()])())[()]))()))[()])((((()()()){}){}()){}){}())[((((()()()){}){}()){}){}])[()])((((()()()()){}){}())){}{})[((((()()()()){}){}())){}{}])
     (()()()())
    )]{})}{}
 2. (({}[()])[((()))]{}){(([({}{})]{}))}{}{([({}{}
     (({}(({}({}))[({}[{}])][(
     ({}[()(
      ([()](((()()[(((((((()()()){})())){}{}){}){})]((((()()()()())){}{}){})([{}]([()()](({})(([{}](()()([()()](((((({}){}){}())){}){}{}))))))))))))
     )]{})
     {({}[()(((({})())[()]))]{})}{}
     (([(((((()()()()){}){}()))){}{}([({})]((({})){}{}))]()()([()()]({}(({})([()]([({}())](({})([({}[()])]()(({})(([()](([({}()())]()({}([()](([((((((()()()())()){}){}){}()){})]({}()(([(((((({})){}){}())){}{})]({}([((((({}())){}){}){}()){}()](([()()])(()()({}(((((({}())())){}{}){}){}([((((({}))){}()){}){}]([((({}[()])){}{}){}]([()()](((((({}())){}{}){}){})(([{}](()()([()()](()()(((((()()()()()){}){}){}()){}()(([((((((()()()())){}){}())){}{})]({}([((((({})()){}){}){}()){}()](([()()])(()()({}(((((({}){}){}())){}){}{}(({})))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
     )]{})[()]))({()([({})]{})}{}()()()())
    )]{})}{}
 3. (({}[()])[((()))]{}){(([({}{})]{}))}{}{([({}{}
      (({}[(
      ({}[()(((((()()()()()){}){}){}))]{}){({}[()(({}()))]{}){({}[()(({}((((()()()){}){}){}()){}))]{}){({}[()(({}()()))]{}){({}[()(({}(((()()()()())){}{}){}))]{}){([(({}{}()))]{})}}}}}{}
      (({}({}))[({}[{}])])
     )]{}({})[()]))
      ({()([({}({}[({})]))]{})}{}()()()()[(({}({})))]{})
    )]{})}{}
 4. (({}[()])[((()))]{}){(([({}{})]{}))}{}{([({}{}(([{}]))(()()()()))]{})}{}
    ({}[()])
}{}
```

The machine consists of four parts that are run in reverse starting with 4 and ending with 1.  I have labeled them in the code above.  Each section also uses the same lookup table format I use for the encoding.  This is because the entire program is contained in a loop and we don't want to run every section every time we run through the loop so we put in the same RA structure and query the section we desire each time.

#### 4

Section 4 is a simple set up section.

The program tells first queries section 4 and datum 0. Datum 0 does not exist so instead of returning that value it simply decrements the query once for each datum.  This is useful because we can use the result to determine the number of data, which will become important in future sections.  Section 4 records the number of data by negativizing the result and queries Section 3 and the last datum.  The only problem is we cannot query section 3 directly.  Since there is another decrement left we need to  query a section 4.  In fact this will be the case every time we query a section within another section.  I will ignore this in my explanation however if you are looking a the code just remember 4 means go back a section and 5 means run the same section again.

#### 3

Section 3 decodes the data into the characters that make up the code after the data block.  Each time it expects the stack to appear as so:

```
Previous query
Result of query
Number of data
Junk we shouldn't touch...
```

It maps each possible result (a number from 1 to 6) to one of the six valid Miniflak characters (`(){}[]`) and places it below the number of data with the "Junk we shouldn't touch".  This gets us a stack like:

```
Previous query
Number of data
Junk we shouldn't touch...
```

From here we need to either query the next datum or if we have queried them all move to section 2.  Previous query is not actually the exact query sent out but rather the query minus the number of data in the block.  This is because each datum decrements the query by one so the query comes out quite mangled.  To generate the next query we add a copy of the number of data and subtract one.  Now our stack looks like:

```
Next query
Number of data
Junk we shouldn't touch...
```

If our next query is zero we have read all the memory needed in section 3 so we add the number of data to the query again and slap a 4 on top of the stack to move onto section 2.  If the next query is not zero we put a 5 on the stack to run section 3 again.

#### 2

Section 2 makes the block of data by querying our RAM just as section 3 does.

For the sake of brevity I will omit most of the details of how section 2 works.  It is almost identical to section 3 except instead of translating each datum into one character it translates each into a lengthy chunk of code representing its entry in the RAM.  When section 2 is done it calls on section 1.

#### 1

Section one is the most simple section.

It pushes the first bit of the quine `([()]())(()()()()){({}[(` and defers to section 5.

#### 5

There is no real section 5 instead a 5 will be decremented once by each section, entering none of them and the once more by the decrement hanging around at the end of the loop.  This will result in a zero and will exit the main loop terminating the program.

---

I hope this was clear.  Please comment if you are confused about anything.

Comment: Wait... so the quine of a subset is shorter than the quine of the original?

Comment: @ETHproductions No, the original was golfed down to 11k

Comment: @DJMcMayhem But isn't 6900 less than 11028?

Comment: ... Apparently I can't math...

Answer (score 10):

## [√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿](https://github.com/SatansSon/UnprintableName) , 9 (possibly 11) bytes

```
79 87  OW
```

Notice the double space between the `87` and the `OW`. This is necessary because of the way `√ å ı ¥ ® Ï Ø ¿` outputs.

The `O` command outputs the whole of the stack as numbers

The `W` command outputs the whole stack as Unicode interpretations of the numbers

#### The 11 byte solution

The above code will output

```
===== OUTPUT =====

79 87  OW

==================

-----Program Execution Information-----

Code        : 79 87  OW
Inputs      : []
Stack       : (79,87)
G-Variable  : None
Byte Length : 9
Exit Status : 0
Error       : None

---------------------------------------
```

This is obviously not the code inputted but is outputted automatically by the interpreter. If this is disallowed, there is an 11 byte solution that only outputs the required output:

```
ł 79 87  OW
```

This will only output

```
ł 79 87  OW
```

I'm not sure if the 9 byte answer is acceptable, could someone please tell me in the comments?

Comment: This is a much less trivial quine than usual - nice!

Comment: That looks valid (9 byte). I mean the other stuff is just interpreter items that are always there

Comment: this isn't non-competing because this is a catalogue and any language is fine

Comment: Gesundheit! Wait... that's a language name? You didn't just sneeze bytes? How do you say that language name in a conversation haha!

Answer (score 10):

## [Minecraft Java Edition](https://www.minecraft.net/), 241 bytes

This can be run as a function in a datapack, or by running each of the commands:

```
data modify storage z x set value ['["data modify storage z x set value ",{"nbt":"x","storage":"z"},"\\ntellraw @a {\\"storage\\":\\"z\\",\\"nbt\\":\\"x[0]\\",\\"interpret\\":true}"]']
tellraw @a {"storage":"z","nbt":"x[0]","interpret":true}
```

### Explanation

```
data modify storage z x set value ...   # set the variable x in the storage minecraft:z

['...']                                 # to a list containing a string (in JSON rich text format) of

"data modify storage z x set value "    # (a literal part of the source code),

{"nbt":"x","storage":"z"}               # this variable (this will only be evaluated 
                                        # during the tellraw command when it is interpreted), and

"\\ntellraw @a {\\"storage\\":\\"z\\",
  \\"nbt\\":\\"x[0]\\",                 # the rest of the source code
  \\"interpret\\":true}"                # (\ and " must be escaped because this is part of a string).

tellraw @a {"storage":"z","nbt":"x[0]", # then interpret the JSON string and print it to the chat
 "interpret":true}                      # (this will place the variable inside)
```

The list is necessary so that when it is printed, it will contain the quotes and double backslashes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 10):

## TypeScript Types, 149 bytes

```ts
//@ts-nocheck
type Q<A='`',B='$',C=Q<'${A}','${B}','${C}'>>=`//@ts-nocheck
type Q<A='${A}',B='${B}',C=Q<'${B}{A}','${B}{B}','${B}{C}'>>=${A}${C}${A}`
```

[Try it online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/PTACBcGcFoDsHsDGALApog1gKHATwA6oAEAigDwCCAvAOQAGNANAEK0AkTAwleTWwN4UAvkz79mIxmM4iAfLKp0QEGAhTpseQqUrtBk1mIlceZI0P2iBE8ZPP8ZNeVQHCBM10LpYcBYgH0iKlIAbiIQIgAJeAA3VAAnIn8fIA)

## TypeScript Types, <s>209</s> 197 bytes

Without `@ts-nocheck` to suppress compiler errors

```ts
type Q<X extends string[]=['`','$',Q<['${X[0]}','${X[1]}','${X[2]}']>]>=`type Q<X extends string[]=['${X[0]}','${X[1]}',Q<['${X[1]}{X[0]}','${X[1]}{X[1]}','${X[1]}{X[2]}']>]>=${X[0]}${X[2]}${X[0]}`
```

[Try it online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAigPADShAHsCA7AJgZyj4AJwEsMBzAbQF0BeCgcgAN6AaegElfgfYG8EKABioBfVh34UAjKPF8BAJllUAfKpqNQkWImRpMufEVKVaPScLFt502S24SBMkRbuPbLp25vPJSsarqNpY2-sGijADcAFDRWtAA+lA0sJFQAPTpUAASAPYAbhCEUIwJjEA)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript REPL, 21 bytes

```
(_=$=>`(_=${_})()`)()
```

It technically doesn't read its own file.

… kind of seems like `0` is also a quine for JavaScript the way this is evaluated, though.

Comment: It reads its own source, though.

Comment: ` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>` in Chrome

Comment: @Nakilon: Use Firefox.

Comment: +1 for the `+_+` in the shorter version

Comment: Umm... the first one is actually HTML5.

Comment: `0` is disallowed by our valid quine definition, which includes that some part of the program must encode a different part.

Answer (score 9):

**Shell echo-sed quine:**

```
echo sed -eh -es/[\\\(\\\\\\\\\\\)\\\&\\\|]/\\\\\\\\\\\&/g -es/^/echo\\ / -es/$/\\\|/ -eG|
sed -eh -es/[\(\\\\\)\&\|]/\\\\\&/g -es/^/echo\ / -es/$/\|/ -eG
```

I wanted to write a sed quine, but sed can only work on its input stream, not generate output spontaneously, so this is an echo-sed quine.
This 154-character quine uses command-line sed, which automatically makes it hard to read, and uses three different sed commands, as well as two sequences of eleven backslashes in a row.
This quine works in bash, ksh, and sh, but not csh or tcsh.

**EDIT:**

A blatant, and amusing, cheat: `echo $BASH_COMMAND`

Another, unreasonably silly, cheat: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $BASH_COMMAND';$PROMPT_COMMAND`

Answer (score 9):

### C, 78 chars

```
#define Q(S)char*q=#S;S
Q(main(){printf("#define Q(S)char*q=#S;S\nQ(%s)",q);})
```

This version is shorter than the familiar 79-character C quine and also doesn't assume ASCII. It does still assume that it's safe to not include stdio.h. (Adding an explicit declaration of printf() brings the length up to 103 chars.)

Answer (score 9):

## Java 6 - <s>138 110</s> 106

Since the question says "golf you a quine", I took Steve P's quine and golfed it:

```
enum Q{X;{String s="enum Q{X;{String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.printf(s,34,s);}}";System.out.printf(s,34,s);}}
```

With credits to Trixie Wolf and Volune.
Note: you need to ignore stderr (e.g. 2>/dev/null)

For great good (and justice)!

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Did you actually try to compile it?  I think you need a System.exit() gimmick or it will fail to run properly.  I'll add an answer here with my implementation later if I don't hear back from you soon.

Comment: Actually: given the "ignore stderr" comment obv. you did get it to work.  I'm very curious how, though.

Comment: @TrixieWolf It works fine here, there is absolutely no compile error. Did you think I would post it without trying it first? :p Anyway, you can only run it with java 6 (or 5), newer versions check for the main method first.

Comment: I'd like to suggest this improvement: ```enum Q{X;{String s="enum Q{X;{String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.printf(s,34,s);}}";System.out.printf(s,34,s);}}```

Comment: @aditsu  Ah, that makes perfect sense.  I'm busy today, but tomorrow I will check to see if mine still functions correctly (I tested it recently but I'll bet it was on J6).  It might still work due to the exit() trick.

Comment: @Volune  That's my quine, Volune.  :)  Well, the one I've been asking about anyway (I am not the original source; found it years ago and adapted it).

Answer (score 9):

## MUMPS, 9 bytes

```
R w $T(R)
```

This may fall afoul of the "you can't just read the source file and print it" restriction. Let me explain why I say *may*.

The line of code you see above constitutes a complete MUMPS "routine" (named `R`), which is sort of like a single source file in a conventional C-like language... but not *quite*.

The way MUMPS stores its routines is peculiar among programming languages. Routines are not files living in a regular filesystem. Instead, they are data structures internal to the database itself. The line of code I've supplied above is actually stored as part of the MUMPS global named `^ROUTINE` (globals are basically trees). The `"R"` subtree (in MUMPS parlance, "subscript") of that global would look something like this:

```
^ROUTINE("R",0)=1
^ROUTINE("R",1)="R w $T(R)"
```

The first entry is the number of lines of code in the routine. The subsequent entries are the lines of code in the routine itself.

Why do I bring this up? Well, this means that in MUMPS, the routines themselves are first-class entries in the database! One can edit routines by directly manipulating the contents of the `^ROUTINE` global, just as one can edit any other global. (Indeed, at the most basic level, if your MUMPS environment doesn't come with an editor, you must invent one for yourself that will edit the `^ROUTINE` global on your behalf.)

The ability to manipulate routines in MUMPS code is so important that the standard even defines a function whose explicit purpose is to tell you what code is found at a given line of a given routine. That function is named [`$T[EXT]`](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20082/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_ftext), and if you give it a pointer to a line of code, it will return the code present at that location.

And that's what we do here. We `w[rite]` the result of a call to `$TEXT(R)` - that is, the contents of the line at the first line of the routine `R` - to the output stream, and since `R` is only one line long, that makes the program a quine.

This program involves no file IO at all. The whole thing is internal to the MUMPS environment. I claim that this is interesting enough to count as a legitimate quine, despite the fact that this has a surface-level resemblance to a program that just reads and prints the source file.

Answer (score 9):

## Japt, 10 bytes

```
"iQ ²"iQ ²
```

Here's how this works:

```
"iQ ²"      // Take this string.        iQ ²
      iQ    // Insert a quote.          "iQ ²
         ²  // Double.                  "iQ ²"iQ ²
            // Implicitly output.
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=ImlRILIiaVEgsg==&input=)

Of course, any number literal is also a quine because of implicit output.

Comment: Does Japt add a newline at the end of implicit output?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Nope.

Answer (score 9):

## 05AB1E, 14 bytes

Shortest proper 05AB1E quine?

```
0"D34çý"D34çý
```

With  trailing newline.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MCJEMzTDp8O9IkQzNMOnw70K&input=)

Explanation:

```
0              # Push '0'
                   # Stack: ['0']
 "D34çý"       # Push 'D34çý'
                   # Stack: ['0', 'D34çý']
        D      # Duplicate
                   # Stack: ['0', 'D34çý', 'D34çý']
         34ç   # Push '"'
                   # Stack: ['0', 'D34çý', 'D34çý', '"']
            ý  # Join rest of the stack with '"'
                   # Stack: ['0"D34çý"D34çý']
               # Implicit print
```

Comment: Isn't `1` also a proper quine?

Comment: @ovs Not by [our standard definition](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4878/42545).

Answer (score 9):

## Befunge-93, <del>15</del> <del>14</del> 13 bytes

```
+9*5x:#,_:@#"
```

Works in [this interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html). `x`  is an unrecognized command which reflects the instruction pointer.

Thanks to Jo King for saving 1 byte.

This 14 byte version works in FBBI:

```
+9*5<>:#,_:@#"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNZNS0rK/P9f21LL1MbOSlkn3spBWen/fwA)

Comment: This almost works, but doesn't: `"gx:#,_:@#/3:` (also 13 bytes).

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
2096239D20BJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyMDSzMjY0sXIwMmL6/9/AA)

Beats all the string-based 05AB1E quines.

Explanation:

```
2096239            # integer literal
       D           # duplicate
        20B        # convert the copy to base 20, yielding "D20BJ"
           J       # join with the original
```

Alternative 13 byter:

```
11959189D₃BJ
```

Comment: [...except for this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226471/94066)

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

```ruby
printf x="printf x=%p,x",x
```

Not the shortest Ruby quine, but I think it's quite cute so I'm posting it.

#### Ruby, 27 bytes

```ruby
p S if$><<S="p S if$><<S="
```

#### Ruby, 28 bytes

```ruby
printf *["printf *[%p]*2"]*2
```

#### Ruby 2.7, 34 bytes

```ruby
".tap{puts p _1}"
.tap{puts p _1}
```

#### Ruby, 35 bytes

```ruby
END{p$0};$><<$0="END{p$0};$><<$0="
```

Answer (score 8):

### T-SQL 24

This statment reproduces itself in the `EVENTINFO` column of the output:

```
dbcc inputbuffer(@@spid)
```

Explanation:

- **dbcc inputbuffer()** - Displays the last statement sent from the client with the specified process id to the current instance of Microsoft SQL Server
- **@@spid** - Retrieves the current process id

*tested with SQL Server **2008 R2** and **2012**; probably working with other versions as well*

***Online demo:*** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2230

Answer (score 8):

## J (REPL) - 20 (16?) char

Seems we're missing a J entry. Trivially, any sentence that doesn't evaluate gets itself printed in the REPL, so `1` or `+` or `+/ % #` are all quines in that sense. A non-trivial quine would be one that produces specifically a string containing the source code.

```
',~@,~u:39',~@,~u:39
```

`u:39` is the ASCII character 39, i.e. the single quote, and `',~@,~u:39'` is a string. `,` is the append verb. The main verb `,~@,~` evaluates as follows:

```
x ,~@,~ y      
y ,~@, x       NB. x f~ y => y f x       "Passive"
,~ (y , x)     NB. x f@g y => f (x g y)  "At"
(y,x) , (y,x)  NB. f~ y => y f y         "Reflex"
```

So the result is `'string'string` when x is `string` and y is the single quote, and thus this is a quine when x is `,~@,~u:39`.

If we're allowed the [J standard library](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/library.htm) as well, then we can write the 16 character

```
(,quote)'(,quote)'
```

which appends the `quote` of the string `(,quote)` to itself.

Answer (score 8):

## QBasic, <s>76 (110)</s> 54 (72)

Tested with [QB64](http://qb64.net) on Windows 7, with auto-formatting turned off.

```
READ a$:?a$;:WRITE a$:DATA"READ a$:?a$;:WRITE a$:DATA"
```

`:` is a statement separator, and `?` is a shortcut for `PRINT`. The main trick here is using `DATA` and `READ` so we don't have to split the string up to add the quotes. **Edit:** I learned this week about the `WRITE` command, which outputs strings wrapped in double-quotes--a significant byte-saver here!

Since actual QBasic doesn't let you turn off auto-formatting, here's the same thing with proper formatting in 72 bytes:

```
READ x$: PRINT x$;: WRITE x$: DATA "READ x$: PRINT x$;: WRITE x$: DATA "
```

---

Original versions (76 bytes golfed, 110 formatted):

```
READ a$:q$=CHR$(34):?a$+q$+a$+q$:DATA"READ a$:q$=CHR$(34):?a$+q$+a$+q$:DATA"
```

or

```
READ a$: q$ = CHR$(34): PRINT a$ + q$ + a$ + q$: DATA "READ a$: q$ = CHR$(34): PRINT a$ + q$ + a$ + q$: DATA "
```

Comment: You can just load the non-formatted file directly though, right? This seems like a limitation of the editor rather than the language itself.

Answer (score 8):

## Lua, 44 bytes

```lua
s="s=%qprint(s:format(s))"print(s:format(s))
```

Some other comical answers in Lua:

```lua
print(arg[0])
```

...so long as the file is named `print(arg[0])`
And...

```lua
Lua: quine.lua:1: function arguments expected near '.'
```

...so long as the file is named `quine.lua`

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (Firefox), <s>44</s> 40 bytes

```js
eval(e="alert('eval(e='+uneval(e)+')')")
```

Not sure how I haven't thought of this before; it's basically exactly the same as the standard function quine `(f=_=>alert('f='+f+';f()'))()`, but with a string. Funnily enough, I only thought of this while attempting to demonstrate how similar string-based quines are to function-based quines...

A cross-browser version (avoiding `uneval`) is 72 bytes:

```js
Q='"';q="'";eval(e="alert('Q='+q+Q+q+';q='+Q+q+Q+';eval(e='+Q+e+Q+')')")
```

Or ES6, 50 bytes:

```js
Q='"';eval(e="alert(`Q='${Q}';eval(e=${Q+e+Q})`)")
```

#### Previous answer, 74 bytes

```js
".replace(/.+/,x=>alert(uneval(x)+x))".replace(/.+/,x=>alert(uneval(x)+x))
```

Simply takes the whole string and prepends its `uneval`uated form. Note: `uneval` may not work in all browsers. Here's a cross-browser version at 113 bytes:

```js
".replace(/.+/,x=>alert(q+x+q+x.replace(/\\d/g,q)),q='1')".replace(/.+/,x=>alert(q+x+q+x.replace(/\d/g,q)),q='"')
```

#### Original answer, 118 bytes

Now, this certainly isn't a winner, but AFAIK, this is the *first ever non-source-reading quine in JS!* :D

```js
alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))
```

How does it work, you ask? Well, if you look closely, you will see that it's really the same thing repeated twice:

```js
alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))
```

The logic here is to A) place a copy of the real code in a string, and B) orient this string so the program can be split into two identical halves. But how could we get those quotes in there? Well, we could either navigate an insanely difficult path of inserting backslashes before a quote, or use the (painfully long) workaround `String.fromCharCode(34)` to retrieve one. The latter method is what I chose.

So, this code puts three copies of the string

```js
,A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=
```

in an array, then joins them with quotes (using the mentioned workaround):

```js
,A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=
```

and finally, slices off the unnecessary characters from the beginning and end:

```js
,A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=
alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))alert([A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(49,-9))
```

This leaves us with the text of the original program, which is `alert`ed to the user.

If the alert is unnecessary, here's a 104-byte alternative:

```js
[A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(48,-3)[A=",A,A].join(String.fromCharCode(34)).slice(48,-3)
```

Answer (score 8):

### Julia, 37 bytes

```
x=:(print("x=:($x);eval(x)"));eval(x)
```

Now that I know a bit more Julia, I thought I'd revisit this... due to the way `printf` works in Julia, [my previous approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36908/8478) is clearly unsuitable. Instead we make use of (the tip of the iceberg of) Julia's homoiconic features. We define a symbol (that is, a representation of Julia code) which prints the framework of the code, as well as the contents of the variable `x` (via interpolation) and store that symbol in `x`. Then we `eval` that symbol. Much better. :)

Answer (score 8):

## APL, 22 bytes

```
1⌽22⍴11⍴'''1⌽22⍴11⍴'''
```

This is part of the [FinnAPL Idiom Library](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/FinnAPL_idiom_library).

```
        '''1⌽22⍴11⍴'''  ⍝ The string literal '1⌽22⍴11⍴' (quotes in string)
     11⍴                ⍝ Fill an 11-element array with these characters
                        ⍝ But the string has length 10, so we get '1⌽22⍴11⍴''
  22⍴                   ⍝ Do this again for 22 chars: '1⌽22⍴11⍴'''1⌽22⍴11⍴''
1⌽                      ⍝ Rotate left (puts quote at the back)
```

[Try it on ngn/apl](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=1%u233D22%u237411%u2374%27%27%271%u233D22%u237411%u2374%27%27%27)

Answer (score 8):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org) -  <del>74</del>  <s>69</s> 65 bytes

Works on the listener (REPL):

```
USE: formatting [ "USE: formatting %u dup call" printf ] dup call
```

This is my first ever quine, <s>I'm sure there must be a shorter one!</s> Already shorter. Now I'm no longer sure... <sub>(bad pun attempt)</sub>

What it does is:

- `USE: formatting` import the `formatting` vocabulary to use `printf`
- `[ "U... printf ]` create a quotation (or lambda, or block) on the top of the stack
- `dup call` duplicate it, and call it

The quotation takes the top of the stack and embeds it into the string as a literal.

Thanks, cat! -> shaved <s>2</s> 4 more bytes :D

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a really good answer; however most people replace their old code with the new code and use the [edit history](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/72040/revisions) to see the old code. You have, however, included a code breakdown and explanation, which not many people do on their first answer, so for that: +1.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks for the advice and up! Actually my 2nd answer, but first quine ever and first edit on PCG.

Comment: Well, if you ever need help, feel free to ping me.

Comment: I never realised a quine was so simple in Factor! Also, the bottom, shorter one can be a single line for 65 bytes, because you don't need the trailing newline: `USE: formatting [ "USE: formatting %u dup call" printf ] dup call`

Comment: Thanks, @cat Just assumed it expected EOL, but this makes more sense actually!

Comment: @fedes. No problem c: you don't need the `\n` at the end of the format string, also

Comment: @cat that happens when you try to read faster than you can think :/ added that. Too bad your trick of skipping ws after strings doesn't work here. pretty-printer adds the space by itself, so it's no longer a quine. (Same prob. with Smalltalk)

Comment: @fedes. Hm, interesting, I think this is as short as it can go

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426590/get-the-same-sha-224-sum-in-factor-as-coreutils-sha224sum

Answer (score 8):

## F#, 90 bytes

```
let q="let q=%A
printf(Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>q)q"
printf(Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>q)q
```

F#’s smart `printf` comes back to byte us! We can’t write `let q="...";;printf q q`, as the first parameter to `printf` [isn’t actually a `string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f21a2219-5d06-4211-82a3-c4538fc47f34):

```
printf : TextWriterFormat<'T> -> 'T
```

F# uses some compiler magic under the hood to guarantee type-safe `printf` calls. For example, `"yay %d wow!"` is a valid `TextWriterFormat<int -> unit>` literal, but not a valid `TextWriterFormat<double -> unit>` literal. But if we define the format string separately, the compiler will see it as a regular old `string` and complain. Instead, we have to convert `q` ourselves in the first argument.

> What about `let q:TextWriterFormat<_>="..."`? First of all, that’s two bytes longer. But second of all, the *second* argument to `printf` really needs to be a `string`, otherwise the typechecker will infer that we’re formatting a formatter, which in turn formats a formatter, which formats a…
>
> ```
> error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>     'a    
> but given a
>     Printf.TextWriterFormat<('a -> unit)>    
> The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and
>     'Printf.TextWriterFormat<('a -> unit)>'
> ```
>
> Yep, an infinite type. Oops.

Comment: +1 for emoticon in the code `<_>`

Answer (score 8):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 3 bytes

```
0
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@2/AZfD/PwA)

This exploits a potential flaw in our [definition of proper quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4878/12012):

> It must be possible to identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program. ("Different" meaning that the two parts appear in different positions.)
>
> Furthermore, a quine must not access its own source, directly or indirectly.

The stack of RProgN is printed backwards, so the first **0** encodes the *second* **0**, and vice versa.

This can be verified empirically; the program

```
1
2
```

prints

```
2
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@2/IZfT/PwA)

Comment: Oh my, it's actually getting usage.
I feel like a proud father.

Answer (score 8):

### [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), 11 + 6 = 17 bytes

3 additional bytes for the topology argument `001` and another 3 for ASCII output `-A`.

```
:?/:2+@> "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/klein#@29lr29lpO1gp6DE9f//fwMDw/@6jgA)

Let's start with the topology. The `1` at the end indicates that the north and south edges of the code are mapped to each other in reverse. So if the IP leaves the code through the south edge in the leftmost column, it will re-enter through the north edge in the rightmost column. We use this to skip to the end of the program.

```
:             Duplicate the top of the stack (implicitly zero).
?             Skip the next command if that value is non-zero (which it isn't).
/             Reflect the IP north.
              The IP leaves through the north edge in the third column from
              the left, so it will re-enter from the south edge in the third
              column from the right.
>             Move east.
":?/:2+@> "   Push the code points of the program, except for the quote itself
              to the stack.
:             Duplicate the top of the stack, now a 32 (the space).
?             Skip the next command (the /).
:             Duplicate the top of the stack again.
2+            Add 2, to turn the space into a quote.
@             Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>64</s> <s>31</s> 32 (because of newlines)

My first answer in charcoal ever!

Similar to /// and other languages, just straight up ascii would print itself. however that is not payload and also boring, so here is an actual quine.

taking a golfing tip from Ascii-only, and my realisation that the second looping is pointless, I have reduced by >50%

```
Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´αα´ＡＦα⁺´´ια
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z8JDW85tPLQFBMGc93uWQUQeNe6CCIPguZ0gQZAwUBFQybmNUOlzO89t5Pr/HwA)

## Explanation

(thanks to ascii-only for making most of this.)

```
Ａ                     α            Assign to a
 ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´α             "α´ＡＦα⁺´´ια", but with ´ escape character with each
                                    character
                                    these are the variable being assigned to, and the
                                    rest of the program that is not the string.

                        ´Ａ         Print Ａ to the grid. current grid: "Ａ"
                           Ｆα⁺´´ι  For each character in a, print ´ + character
                                    this results in the escaped version of the string
                                    which is the literal string that is assigned at the 
                                    start. current grid state: "Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´α"

                                  α Print a ("α´ＡＦα⁺´´ια"), which is the commands after
                                    the string assignment. final grid state vvv:
                                                 "Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´αα´ＡＦα⁺´´ια"

[implicitly print the grid: "Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´αα´ＡＦα⁺´´ια", the source, with a trailing newline]
```

Comment: Wish I was better at reading Charcoal. Looking forward to that explanation :)

Comment: I can hardly read this myself :P

Comment: You can leave off the final closing double angle bracket, saving 3 bytes: `Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´Ｌ´α´«´´´´´§´α´ι´»´Ｆ´Ｌ´α´«´§´α´ια´ＡＦＬα«´´§αι»ＦＬα«§αι`

Comment: Oh wait you can also iterate over the string directly. 37 bytes: `Ａ´α´´´Ａ´Ｆ´α´⁺´´´´´ι´Ｆ´α´ια´ＡＦα⁺´´ιＦαι`

Comment: @ASCII-only couldn't this be one byte? `f`

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@5/2/z8A

Comment: It is "A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output."

Comment: @Christopher ... That way It isn't payload-capable so it actually isn't a quine (You can't have commands in the payload)

Comment: @ASCII-only they defined their own quine definition so it does not need to be payload-capable.

Comment: @Christopher Well if it's valid feel free to post a solution

Comment: @Christopher That `f` suggestion seems to print an extra newline, so isn't a quine. But if it *didn't*, it would probably run afoul of the rule that there must be a part of the program that encodes a different part.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen well adding a newline to the code works. But if it is not "encoding" what about the quine in golfscript? (`1` and a newline)

Comment: @Christopher Oh, when I tried adding a newline it seemed to get stuck, I didn't try waiting until TIO timed out though. If I recall correctly the argument for golfscript is that the newline is not encoding itself.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen mine ran just fine.

Comment: [:( longer](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RHDXMrD20BMaZtd87PLShKLS5OTXk0f9m5jYaP5i8/tOXcxnMbgYrObSSo6v9/AA)

Answer (score 8):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 204 bytes

```
/<\>/<\\\\>\\\\\\//P1/<>/<<>\><>/<<>\<>\<>\<>\><>\<>\<>\<>\<>\<>\<>/<>/P<>1<>/P<>2<>/<>/P<<>\<>\><>\<>\<>2<>/P<>1<>/<>/<<>\><>/<<<>\<>\>><>\<>\<>/<>/<<>\<>\><>/<>/P<>1//P<\\>\\2/P1//<\>/<<\\>>\\//<\\>//P1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#XY7RDQAhCENHIvJNOoMDsP8aSFVOT4IBm9K8EHPky4LPEulNLDWDY8@vcX@q6e6GtoaW8Fzocf3Stw132rmt7KSyiajEW9AUQGAuxI4Y)

With some helpful whitespace inserted:

```
/<\>/<\\\\>\\\\\\/
/P1/
    <>/<<>\><>/<<>\<>\<>\<>\><>\<>\<>\<>\<>\<>\<>/<>/P<>1<>/P<>2<>/<>/P<<>\<>\><>\<>\<>2<>/P<>1<>/<>/<<>\><>/<<<>\<>\>><>\<>\<>/<>/<<>\<>\><>/<>/P<>1
/
/P<\\>\\2/P1/
/<\>/<<\\>>\\/
/<\\>//
P1
```

## How it works

- The long third line is the quining data. It is made from the entire rest of the program, with a `P2` in the spot where the data itself would fit, and then with the string `<>` inserted before each character from the set `\/12`.

  - It would be harmless to put `<>` before *all* characters in the data, but only these are necessary - `\/` because they need escaping to be copied, and `12` because it's vital to have a break inside `P1` and `P2` to prevent infinite loops when substituting them.
- The first substitution changes all the `<>` prefixes into `<\\>\\\`. The `\` in the source `<\>` is there to prevent its final printable form from being garbled by the other substitutions.
- The second substitution includes the quining data, copying them to the other `P1`s in the program. The `<\\>\\\` prefixes now become `<\>\` in both copies.
- The third substitution copies one of the quining data copies (in the substitution itself) into the middle of the other (at the end of the program), marked by the string `P<\>\2`. In the *inner* copy, the `<\>\` prefix now becomes `<>` again.
- The fourth substitution changes the inner copy's `<>` prefixes into `<<\>>\`. The change is needed to introduce the final backspace, protecting any following `\`s and `/`s that are to be printed. The inner `<\>` is necessary to prevent this substitution from infinitely looping – just a backslash here wouldn't do, as it would be garbled by the fifth substitution.
- The fifth substitution removes all instances of the string `<\>`, both those remaining in the outer copy of the quining data, and those produced by the fourth substitution.
- Finally, we reach the constructed copy of the program, with suitable backslashes prepended to some characters, ready for printing.

Answer (score 8):

## [Reflections](https://github.com/TheWastl/Reflections), 4222 bytes

Since wastl [out-golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164607/76162) me by about... [1.810<sup>371</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160196/76162) bytes through a vastly superior encoding system, I've decided to have another look at the problem. Since my program is still quite long, here's the main section (with SOHs replaced with spaces):

```
\0=0#_(4:(2(4(40\
      /# 0v\/(1v/
      \+#@~ > ~<
/#@#_#_#_1^1/
+
\#1)(2:2)4=/
```

[Try It Online!](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##XAoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKKwojCisKIworCiMKKwojCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCisKIworCiMKKwojCisKIworCiMKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojClwwPTAjXyg0OigyKDQoNDBcCgEBAQEBAS8jATB2XC8oMXYvCgEBAQEBAVwrI0B+AT4BfjwKLyNAI18jXyNfMV4xLworClwjMSkoMjoyKTQ9L/8x/zD/MP8=) (but have patience) (ASCII-only points out that [unchecking the time between steps](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##XAoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKKwojCisKIworCiMKKwojCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIworCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCisKIworCiMKKwojCisKIworCiMKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgorCiMKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCisKIwoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKKwojClwwPTAjXyg0OigyKDQoNDBcCgEBAQEBAS8jATB2XC8oMXYvCgEBAQEBAVwrI0B+AT4BfjwKLyNAI18jXyNfMV4xLworClwjMSkoMjoyKTQ9L/8w/zD/MP8=) will make it go faster, but beware of the javascript freezing up your browser)

This uses the same encoding as wastl's answer, where each character with byte value `n` is represented by `n` newlines followed by

```
+
#
```

and the first character of the code is `\` to change the pointer's direction down. Additionally, it also encodes the `\` as well as the `#`,`+` and newline in this process to save on doing them later

The main code is a more streamlined version of wastl's, where quite a few shortcuts have been made. I've also replaced all the spaces with SOHs (byte value 1) to save on bytes.

#### Detailed explanation

```
\0=0        Create a copy of the data in stack 0
    #_      Print the `\`
      (4:(2(4(4   Push the +, \n, # to stack 4, and a copy of the newline to stack 2
               0\ Switch back to the intact copy of the data

            /(1v/ Reverse the data
            > ~<
          ^1/


          v\
          ~   While the stack exists
          ^

          v\
              
           1  Move data to stack 1

         4=/  Copy #, \n, +
    (2:2)     Copy newline
\#1)          Get top of data

+
\#        Redefine origin and move up

/
+     Push -2

/#@   Print the newline the value of the top of data times
   #_#_#_   Print the +, \n, #
         1^ Switch back to the data and loop again


      /# 0v When the data stack is empty
      \+#@~
/#@#_#_#_1^

         0  Switch to the other copy of the data

      /#    Redefine the origin to push 1
      \+
        #@  Print the whole stack
          ~ >  And end
```

Comment: You should also say that unchecking the time between steps box shortens run time to like <5 seconds

Comment: @ASCII-only Ehh, depends on the computer I guess. Mine freezes up and finishes in about 40 seconds

Answer (score 8):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
".|>[show,print]".|>[show,print]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X0mvxi66OCO/XKegKDOvJBad//8/AA)

And here is a 35 byte quine that works in version 0.4 (And beats the [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92455/71256)):

```julia
x = "print(@show x)"
print(@show x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/79CwVZBqaAoM69Ew6E4I79coUJTiQuV//8/AA)

Comment: That, sir, is amazing!

Answer (score 8):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>72</s> 66 bytes

```rust
fn main(){print!("{}{0:?})}}","fn main(){print!(\"{}{0:?})}}\",")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDqbq22sDKvlaztlZJRwlDOgZJPgaoQLP2/38A)

Answer (score 8):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 338 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Dorian pointing out a mistake*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBbCoAwDPtOTtGriQj6Jyh4/En62tho1qTJxr7zeo/n3vZjDDODAQIVb6MA6FZirlBQwtQtQlBEx9Y4phs1snSGxZ7HRelHJN9ERiCR7iDX4hzloLY8WT2AJkyGwaLZuMrd6qgRnSg09hcw1TF@)

Not really much to see, but the code is there. This terminates with a 'Can't return from subroutine' error, which is only about 10 or so bytes extra to remove. Translated from whitespace, the tokens are:

```
push 213928514417226051472880134683878051755207959239232598316788086
push 2
call PRINT_SPACE
call PRINT_SPACE
call DIV_MOD_PRINT
push 1
add

label DIV_MOD_PRINT
    copy 2nd item in stack
    copy 2nd item in stack
    div
    jump if zero to POP_AND_PRINT_SPACE
    copy 2nd item in stack
    call DIV_MOD_PRINT
    mod
    dupe
    jump if zero to POP_AND_PRINT_SPACE
    push 8
    add
    print as character
    return

label POP_AND_PRINT_SPACE
    pop
    label PRINT_SPACE
        push 32
        print as character
        return
```

This starts off by pushing a rather large number in binary spaces and tabs. This number represents the rest of the program in trinary (since Whitespace has 3 valid characters), with space being 0, tab being 1 and newline as 2.

The main part of this code is the `DIV_MOD_PRINT` function, which assumes that the large number and the divisor is on top of the stack. This makes a copy of the two elements, then divides the number by the divisor and recursively calls the function again, returning once the result of the division is zero. On the tail call, this takes the two copied elements and gets the remainder after division. Then it maps it to the representation above.

This function is reused twice on the large number we pushed at the beginning, once with the divisor `2` to print the number itself in tabs and spaces, and again with `3` to print the rest of the program.

There are a couple of caveats; for example, we can't represent leading spaces with leading zeroes, so we with have to print those manually before we call the function the first time. This is partially mitigated by the fact that we stop the recursion by jumping to the `POP_AND_PRINT_SPACE` label, which means that we print a leading space anyway.

However, that causes one of the modulo pairs not to be evaluated, therefore the last character represented is not printed. This is actually a *good* thing, for a couple of reasons. First, since the binary number representation is terminated with a newline which would have had to have been printed (since we print a leading space), instead, if we ensure the last character of the binary number is a space, the newline is now the first character of the rest of the program. We can make the last character a space easily, since we aren't printing the last character of the program by adding a space or tab when encoding the number literal.

For reference, [my encoding program](https://tio.run/##bU5LDoIwEF13TjELTEENKiQuJHAOEzWm0CZ@ijQtGPTyOBghmrjpvHmfeTXK6nXXlQ/0WkxxE@98pxtrwqIqc3@xd4sgy8LKStzOVgFuJ/EhAXh7vXYa44zGJCLKif7EB3BE5HOvDXPhlB8FYW3Fzfl8ueKYZiQzHiTQdWAadyIvQyiE1vAPAA4mYPRqkSuiEWpxVceIjCR8Y3m@M0KyMQh4eVLoVx/OlpUkif34xu/QfSFlP4093@qC9Y0MhnJqsRXlRgK/o/02pqyqKfgC), my [commented program](https://tio.run/##bY5dDgIhDISf21PMGbyQwYVk0dUlLKuJl0d@CrhGHkpb5pvhNdtgNqcmEyMAQikkHYhKobqTURqi8iBC/N7NSxYNKlg3GZrqCKlDJuEtmepBz6UhEYOBEdjt21xIntSy8L@G0UScPRd1MWkNDupmzqdid@i1feYQvTswru8EHd@b7X3V@Q8HXf9O8lda59t5@wgT5UTiFp5S/Jq4vsA3mqdOeRMSGOMH), and I used [WhiteLips](https://vii5ard.github.io/whitespace/) to debug the program.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3, 34 Bytes

```
print((s:='print((s:=%r)%%s)')%s)
```

As far as I'm aware this is shorter than any other published Python 3 quine, mainly by virtue of having been written in the future with respect to most of them, so it can use `:=`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: There is `_='_=%r;print(_%%_)';print(_%_)` (32 bytes w/newline), basically the Python 2 quine ported to Python3

Answer (score 7):

## Befunge 98 - <s>17</s> 11 characters

```
<@,+1!',k9"
```

Or if using `g` is allowed:

## Befunge 98 - <s>12</s> 10

```
<@,g09,k8"
```

Comment: Explanation for why using `g` may not be allowed?

Comment: @MDXF `g` is arguably reading the source code. Befunge copies the code to the execution space and `g` reads the character at the `x, y` position in the execution space

Answer (score 7):

## TECO, 20 bytes

```
<Tab>V27:^TJDV<Esc>V27:^TJDV
```

The `<Esc>` should be replaced with ASCII 0x1B, and the `<Tab>` with 0x09.

- `<Tab>V27:^TJDV<Esc>` inserts the text `<Tab>V27:^TJDV`. This is *not* because there is a text insertion mode which TECO starts in by default. Instead, `<Tab>` *text* `<Esc>` is a special insertion command which inserts a tab, and then the text. A string whose own initial delimiter is part of the text -- very handy.
- `V` prints the current line.
- `27:^T` prints the character with ASCII code 27 without the usual conversion to a printable representation.
- `J` jumps to the beginning of the text.
- `D` deletes the first character (the tab).
- `V` prints the line again.

Comment: I gotta try this one out on TECOC :) https://github.com/blakemcbride/TECOC

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 31 bytes

```py
s="print's=%r;exec s'%s";exec s
```

It's 2 bytes longer than the [shortest Python quine on this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115/21487), but it's much more useful, since you don't need to write everything twice.

For example, to print a program's own source code in sorted order, we can just do:

```py
s="print''.join(sorted('s=%r;exec s'%s))";exec s
```

Another example by @feersum can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47198/21487).

### Notes

The reason the quine works is because of `%r`'s behaviour. With normal strings, `%r` puts single quotes around the string, e.g.

```py
>>> print "%r"%"abc"
'abc'
```

But if you have a single quotes inside the string, it uses double quotes instead:

```py
>>> print "%r"%"'abc'"
"'abc'"
```

This does, however, mean that the quine has a bit of a problem if you want to use both types of quotes in the string.

Comment: Python appends a leading newline to the output, so you will have to add a newline at the end of your program (making your program 32 bytes, not 31).

Answer (score 7):

## [ಠ_ಠ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7390/41247), 6 bytes

```
ಠಠ
```

This used to work back when the interpreter was still buggy but that's fixed now. However, you can try it in the [legacy version of the interpreter](http://codepen.io/molarmanful/debug/rxJmqx)!

Comment: It seems that `ಠ` also works in the interpreter provided. Also, ಠ is 3 bytes in UTF-8

Comment: Your link is dead, and can you upload the language source to GitHub so that it can be added to TIO?

Comment: http://codepen.io/molarmanful/pen/rxJmqx all the code happens to be there.

Answer (score 7):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 18 bytes

```
"34¤¤,,,,"34¤¤,,,,
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

First RETURN program on PPCG ever! RETURN is a language that tries to improve DUP by using nested stacks.

## Explanation

```
"34¤¤,,,,"         Push this string to the stack
          34       Push charcode of " to the stack
            ¤¤     Duplicate top 2 items
              ,,,, Output all 4 stack items from top to bottom
```

Answer (score 7):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 3057 bytes

```
A = 99
def S set 
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 76
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 65
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 57
A + 1
S A 57
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 72
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 56
A + 1
S A 51
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 100
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 102
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 104
A + 1
S A 97
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 72
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 76
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 83
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 57
A + 1
S A 57
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 66
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 103
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 108
A + 1
S A 98
A + 1
S A 108
A + 1
S A 68
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 43
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 49
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 104
A + 1
S A 97
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 72
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 65
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 73
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 66
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 76
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 65
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 43
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 49
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 66
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 103
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 102
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 66
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 68
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 70
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 57
A + 1
S A 57
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 69
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 103
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 70
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 108
A + 1
S A 98
A + 1
S A 108
A + 1
S A 71
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 70
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 43
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 49
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 112
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 110
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 67
A + 1
S A 104
A + 1
S A 97
A + 1
S A 114
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 69
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 69
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 61
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 103
A + 1
S A 101
A + 1
S A 116
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 70
A + 1
S A 10
A + 1
S A 105
A + 1
S A 102
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 69
A + 1
S A 32
A + 1
S A 71
A + 1
printLine A = 99
H = 83
print def 
printChar H
printLine  S 
C = 99
B = get C
lblD
C + 1
printChar H
print  A 
printInt B
printLine A + 1
B = get C
if B D
F = 99
E = get F
lblG
F + 1
printChar E
E = get F
if E G
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=)

I am ashamed to say this took me a while to write even though most of it was generated by another java program. Thanks to @MartinEnder for helping me out. This is the first quine I have ever written. **Credits go to Leaky Nun** for most of the code. I "borrowed his code" which was originally inspired by mine. My answer is similar to his, except it shows the "power" of the preprocessor. Hopefully this approach can be used to golf of bytes if done correctly. The goal was to prevent rewriting the word "set" 100's of times.

**Please check out his [much shorter answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91283/46918)**

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: It's borked from my understanding @LeakyNun but it essentially writes it source code to the memory buffer, and then prints out commands to write itself to the memory buffer, and then writes itself out

Comment: From my point of view this is not a quine?

Comment: @LeakyNun it's borked... let me fix... should I delete, fix and undelete?

Answer (score 7):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), <s>2642</s> 2593 bytes

**Credits to Rohan Jhunjhunwala for the algorithm.**

```
A = 99
set A 112
A + 1
set A 114
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 76
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 65
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 57
A + 1
set A 57
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 67
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 57
A + 1
set A 57
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 66
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 103
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 67
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 108
A + 1
set A 98
A + 1
set A 108
A + 1
set A 68
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 67
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 43
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 49
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 112
A + 1
set A 114
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 115
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 65
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 112
A + 1
set A 114
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 73
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 66
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 112
A + 1
set A 114
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 76
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 65
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 43
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 49
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 66
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 103
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 67
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 102
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 66
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 68
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 70
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 57
A + 1
set A 57
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 69
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 103
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 70
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 108
A + 1
set A 98
A + 1
set A 108
A + 1
set A 71
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 70
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 43
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 49
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 112
A + 1
set A 114
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 110
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 67
A + 1
set A 104
A + 1
set A 97
A + 1
set A 114
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 69
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 69
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 61
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 103
A + 1
set A 101
A + 1
set A 116
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 70
A + 1
set A 10
A + 1
set A 105
A + 1
set A 102
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 69
A + 1
set A 32
A + 1
set A 71
A + 1
printLine A = 99
C = 99
B = get C
lblD
C + 1
print set A 
printInt B
printLine A + 1
B = get C
if B D
F = 99
E = get F
lblG
F + 1
printChar E
E = get F
if E G
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=QSA9IDk5CnNldCBBIDExMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTQKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTA1CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDExMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNzYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTA1CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDExMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMDEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjUKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNTcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNTcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNTcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNTcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAzCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwMQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTA4CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDk4CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwOApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA2OApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA2NwpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA0MwpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA0OQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE0CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwNQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDExNQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMDEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDY1CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDExMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTQKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTA1CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDExMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNzMKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTEwCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDExNgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA2NgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE0CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwNQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDc2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwNQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAxCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDY1CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDQzCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDQ5CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDY2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDYxCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwMwpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMDEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDMyCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDY3CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwNQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMDIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjgKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNzAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNTcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNTcKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjkKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAzCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwMQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNzAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTA4CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDk4CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwOApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA3MQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA3MApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA0MwpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA0OQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE0CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwNQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTE2CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDY3CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwNApBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA5NwpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTQKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjkKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjkKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNjEKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAzCkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwMQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAxMTYKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMzIKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgNzAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTAKQSArIDEKc2V0IEEgMTA1CkEgKyAxCnNldCBBIDEwMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA2OQpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSAzMgpBICsgMQpzZXQgQSA3MQpBICsgMQpwcmludExpbmUgQSA9IDk5CkMgPSA5OQpCID0gZ2V0IEMKbGJsRApDICsgMQpwcmludCBzZXQgQSAKcHJpbnRJbnQgQgpwcmludExpbmUgQSArIDEKQiA9IGdldCBDCmlmIEIgRApGID0gOTkKRSA9IGdldCBGCmxibEcKRiArIDEKcHJpbnRDaGFyIEUKRSA9IGdldCBGCmlmIEUgRw&input=)

Comment: Good job! May I "borrow this post for my github repository?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Sure.

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
S+s"S+s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1i7WAmE//8HAA)

Husk is a new golfing functional language created by me and [Zgarb](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/136121). It is based on Haskell, but has an intelligent inferencer that can "guess" the intended meaning of functions used in a program based on their possible types.

#### Explanation

This is a quite simple program, composed by just three functions:

`S` is the S combinator from [SKI (typed) combinator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus): it takes two functions and a third value as arguments and applies the first function to the value and to the second function applied to that value (in code: `S f g x = f x (g x)`).

This gives us `+"S+s"(s"S+s")`. `s` stands for `show`, the Haskell function to convert something to a string: if show is applied to a string, special characters in the string are escaped and the whole string is wrapped in quotes.

We get then `+"S+s""\"S+s\""`. Here, `+` is string concatenation; it could also be numeric addition, but types wouldn't match so the other meaning is chosen by the inferencer.

Our result is then `"S+s\"S+s\""`, which is a string that gets printed simply as `S+s"S+s"`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 1805 bytes

```
(())(()()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()())(())(())(()()()())(())(()()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(()()()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()())(())(())(()()()())(())(()()())(()())(())(()()())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(())(())(())(()()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(())(()()())(()()())(()()()())(())(()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(())(())(()()())(()()()())(())(()())(())(()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(())(()()())(())(())(())(())(()()())(()()()())(()())(())(()())(()()())(())(()())(()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(())(())(())(()()()())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(()())(())(()()())(()())(())(())(())(()())(())(())(()()())(()())(()())(()()()()())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(()())(())(())(()()())(()())(()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()()()())(())(()())(())(()()())(()())(()())(()()()())(()())(())(())(()())(()()()()())(()()())(())(()())(()())(())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()()())(())(())(()()()())(())(()()())(()())(()()())(())(()()()())(())(())(()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()())(()())(()()())(()()()())(())(()())(())(())(())(()()())(()()()()())(()())(()())(())(()()()())(())(())(())(()())(()()()()())(())(())(()())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()()())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()())(())(()()()())(()()()){<>(((((()()()()()){}){}){}())[()])<>(([{}])()<{({}())<>((({}())[()]))<>}<>{({}<>)<>}{}>)((){[()](<(({}()<(((()()()()()){})(({})({}){})<((([(({})())]({}({}){}(<>)))()){}())>)>))((){()(<{}>)}{}<{({}()<{}>)}>{}({}<{{}}>{})<>)>)}{}){{}({}<>)<>{(<()>)}}<>{({}<>)<>}{}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVNJDsIwDLzzkvjQH0SReEfVQzkgIRAHrlbeHuwYVDWL4wrRhTrjZcYmubzW23O6PtZ7Ss4B0Cs3uO1trTXka9fZdea@yj7Gkq8x7xG9p3F/rajya1HSY2zV0CfaZhzXbk28RHpK@9pqT3um@r7S@u6zlPPZGFu4fZfbmMaTsFgjjZZuW5rqWYz/7X@eeG2nllqtvWtsx86QfnqsrEe7sa9/3VE95fmLPrh8bbIxykPm7GABjpgxLuTz6DKek7YIWkcf2OcD2xgDEyA7nZdIX5EwDk7Y2DsLAJRDCSKB6oGE00@gO9elCp45iOijSJYh53nEyCYpgRwDKDhrQ9LDaKGXjFNKaTq/AQ)

*-188 bytes by avoiding code duplication*

Like Wheat Wizard's answer, I encode every closing bracket as 1.  The assignment of numbers to the four opening brackets is chosen to minimize the total length of the quine:

```
2: ( - 63 instances
3: { - 41 instances
4: < - 24 instances
5: [ -  5 instances
```

The other major improvement over the old version is a shorter way to create the code points for the various bracket types.

The decoder builds the entire quine on the second stack, from the middle outward.  Closing brackets that have yet to be used are stored below a 0 on the second stack.  Here is a full explanation of an earlier version of the decoder:

```
# For each number n from the encoder:
{

 # Push () on second stack (with the opening bracket on top)
 <>(((((()()()()()){}){}){}())[()])<>

 # Store -n for later
 (([{}])

  # n times
  {<({}())

    # Replace ( with (()
    <>((({}())[()]))<>

  >}{}

  # Add 1 to -n
  ())

  # If n was not 1:
  ((){[()]<

     # Add 1 to 1-n
     (({}())<

       # Using existing 40, push 0, 91, 60, 123, and 40 in that order on first stack
       <>(({})<(([(({})())]((()()()()()){})({}{}({})(<>)))({})()()())>)

     # Push 2-n again
     >)

     # Pop n-2 entries from stack
     {({}()<{}>)}{}

     # Get opening bracket and clear remaining generated brackets
     (({}<{{}}>{})

      (<

        # Add 1 if n was 2; add 2 otherwise
        # This gives us the closing bracket
        ({}(){()(<{}>)}

         # Move second stack (down to the 0) to first stack temporarily and remove the zero
         <<>{({}<>)<>}{}>

        # Push closing bracket
        )

      # Push 0
      >)

     # Push opening bracket
     )

     # Move values back to second stack
     <>{({}<>)<>}

   # Else (i.e., if n = 1):
   >}{})

 {

  # Create temporary zero on first stack
  (<{}>)

  # Move second stack over
  <>{({}<>)<>}

  # Move 0 down one spot
  # If this would put 0 at the very bottom, just remove it
  {}({}{(<()>)})

  # Move second stack values back
  <>{({}<>)<>}}{}

}

# Move to second stack for output
<>
```

Comment: It looks like you have a stray newline at the end of your code. You can save a byte by removing it.

Comment: @0                            ' Since Brain-Flak prints with a trailing newline. It is necessary for it to be a quine

Answer (score 7):

### [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 48 bytes

```bash
Q=\';q='echo "Q=\\$Q;q=$Q$q$Q;eval \$q"';eval $q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9A2Rt260FY9NTkjX0EJyItRCQTyVQJVCoGM1LLEHIUYlUIldQhTpfD/fwA)

Comment: Hm the leaderboard gives a shorter one, although that one uses `sed` while you are only using builtins.

Comment: [After a search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+inquestion%3A69+%22bash%22), I think this is currently the shortest with only builtins and a "normal" quine construction.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @ØrjanJohansen! I'd like to differentiate this from the other solutions, but I don't know if I should change this title or the ones that use core utils... I'm happy with just coming up with the program to be honest! 

Comment: [Bash + coreutils](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=bash+coreutils+is%3Aa) seems to be fairly common, so I'd suggest to edit the header of the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Reflections](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/), 1.81x10<sup>375</sup> bytes

Or to be more accurate, `1807915590203341844429305353197790696509566500122529684898152779329215808774024592945687846574319976372141486620602238832625691964826524660034959965005782214063519831844201877682465421716887160572269094496883424760144353885803319534697097696032244637060648462957246689017512125938853808231760363803562240582599050626092031434403199296384297989898483105306069435021718135129945` bytes.

The relevant section of code is:

```
+#::(1   \/  \    /: 5;;\
          >v\>:\/:4#+     +\
     /+#   /   2 /4):_    ~/
     \ _   2:#_/ \  _(5#\ v#_\
         *(2 \;1^    ;;4) :54/
         \/ \    1^X    \_/
```

Where each line is preceeded by `451978897550835461107326338299447674127391625030632421224538194832303952193506148236421961643579994093035371655150559708156422991206631165008739991251445553515879957961050469420616355429221790143067273624220856190036088471450829883674274424008061159265162115739311672254378031484713452057940090950890560145649762656523007858600799824096074497474620776326517358755429533782443` spaces. The amount of spaces is a base 128 encoded version of the second part, with 0 printing all the spaces again.

Edit: H.PWiz points out that the interpreter probably doesn't support this large an integer, so this is all theoretical

#### How It Works:

```
+#::(1  Pushes the addition of the x,y coordinates (this is the extremely large number)
        Dupe the number a couple of times and push one of the copies to stack 1
            \
             >
                   Pushes a space to stack 2
            *(2
            \/


             /  \
             >v >:\
        /+#   /   2   Print space number times
        \ _   2:#_/


                #      Pop the extra 0
                \;1^   Switch to stack 1 and start the loop


                   /:4#+      +\
                    /4):_     ~/    Divide the current number by 128
                    \  _(5#\ v      Mod a copy by 128
                   ^      4) :
                           \_/


                             v#_\  If the number is not 0:
                   ^    ;;4) :54/  Print the number and re-enter the loop

                     /: 5;;\
             v\      4             If the number is 0:
                     4             Pop the excess 0
              :            \       And terminate if the divided number is 0
                                   Otherwise return to the space printing loop
              \     1^X
```

Conclusion: Can be golfed pretty easily, but maybe looking for a better encoding algorithm would be best. Unfortunately, there's basically no way to push an arbitrarily large number without going to that coordinate.

Comment: Does the interpreter support integers this large?

Comment: @H.PWiz, erm, probably not. The interpreter is written in JS, which has a max integer size of 2^53-1

Comment: Nevermind support for large integers. Where and how are you going to store the file? :P

Comment: Please let me verify the solution first. I promise I will be done until April 1st.

Comment: Okay, you get the rep in 23 hours (when I can award the bounty). But I think you got the byte count wrong, I get about 1.8 * 10<s>375</s> for 4 lines of spaces.

Comment: Arg, looks like I got the formatting a bit wrong. I mean, 1.8e375

Comment: Now I really want to prove that this answer is highly suboptimal, but first I have to learn the language...

Comment: @user202729 It's like ><>, but harder to work with. Read the wiki.

Comment: @wastl You should make [this page](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/field.html) easier to find on the wiki, or include it somewhere. Also, it'd be nice if you fully explained your programs' steps (all of them) on the wiki, because the language isn't as intuitive as ><>.

Comment: @mbomb007 Added the link to the footer. Do you mean explain the examples?

Comment: @wastl Yeah, like you made it sound like you were explaining the Fibonacci program, then didn't really explain much of it. And you didn't explain the simple programs, like the one that clears the stack (I think it needs one, because I can't figure it out.)

Comment: @mbomb007 [Done](https://github.com/TheWastl/Reflections/wiki)

Comment: @mbomb007 I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76946/reflections) for further discussion.

Comment: Since [V8 added support for BigInts](https://v8project.blogspot.com.ee/2018/05/bigint.html), the interpreter integer limit should no longer be a problem - provided you can find a computer that can handle it.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

[@ngn's updated version](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48380903#48380903) of the [classic APL quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70520/43319), using a modern operator to save four bytes.

```apl
1⌽,⍨9⍴'''1⌽,⍨9⍴'''
```

[Try APL!](https://tryapl.org/?a=1%u233D%2C%u23689%u2374%27%27%271%u233D%2C%u23689%u2374%27%27%27&run)

`'''1⌽,⍨9⍴'''` the characters `'1⌽,⍨9⍴'`

`9⍴` cyclically **r**eshape to shape 9; `'1⌽,⍨9⍴''`

`,⍨` concatenation selfie; `'1⌽,⍨9⍴'''1⌽,⍨9⍴''`

`1⌽` cyclically rotate one character to the left; `1⌽,⍨9⍴'''1⌽,⍨9⍴'''`

Answer (score 7):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), <s>720 657 637</s> 589 bytes

*-68 bytes thanks to Nitrodon!*

```
0n0n->1032277495984410008473317482709082716834303381684254553200866249636990941488983666019900274253616457803823281618684411320510311142825913359041514338427283749993903272329405501755383456706244811330910671378512874952277131061822871205085764018650085866697830216n4+Out_"0n0n->"+Out_n4+nn+n0n
4n0+4n0+n->Out_"n"
n+n+4n0+n0+n0+n0->Out_"+"
n+n+n+4n0+n0+n0->Out_n
4n+4n0+n0->Out_"4"
4n+n+4n0->Out_"\""
4n+n+n+n0+n0+n0->Out_"->"
4n+n+n+n+n0+n0->Out_"\n"
4n+4n+n0->Out_"Out_"
4n+4n+n->Out_"\\"
nn->4n0+4n0+nnn
n0+n4->n
nnn+4n+4n+n4->nn+n00
nnn+0n4->n+n40
n40+0n00+n4->n4+nn
n40+0n+n00->n4+n40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBZagMxEET/fYz5HQy9q/WTK@QChhCSQAyJHLBz/UxKM7KzwCzqV6Xukh7fnl5f3o/ny7JQo7a/Y1KRUqx6TTMmorSiysVSClXClyPVlFQTKxM3dxX4IsRqaNRK1dgya2pEEAOQFDg1OMxLkqaoYDtn9CmM/Y7JzGyS4pVVvZKxs2GMSZFUZKpVK/IVbK5G7sQFs5HGoxCmW6KVUmWKwlrSWbIfpZ@IFZRTQBjTKL2EEQI4ojvCRy2pJBzN5vvPy8O0Xci0FmCtzQA7azT3F9LqatMOwobGM5R5U35pm9B7DDacNnW0wkEO00Dtf1ckuil/hEObtsY/aP1c4dV2QCwUt3O0tus/299h0VZvt/e6t6IV0lqDojRCSWNLv5eBunkjRsvydfq4HE/tvOyfvwE)

Warning, takes far longer than the lifetime of the universe to execute, mostly cause we have to transfer that rather large number on the first line back and forth between multiple atoms repeatedly. [Here's a version](https://tio.run/##tZBbbsMgEEX/vQz/WpYGDLb5yRa6gUhV1VZqpJZUSrr9umBIGj/APMZSHjDD3Ln3vHy@frx/nS7XYQAJsj5QThkF3vWE8o42HaMtFS0XXADrW9J0hHNBiGgBeN8z4K0ggjdENE3fENXnAJQy0lDJqqef63NpdMvxompSVqpQMAmV/qrW@EqWhWqYkv3YTmU6Dz3T0Bq2Zl@yUpfGoq0cS1uSc1Xl6N6ZNI6yNML/pfHnVrw9Oypb6nLPIWWh/1h9UAc5vtXP9V1LwViE8a6q6spAXcGOaC62pB@bCoNBDwkwY@pIQI8UcDvpN/VBn5kRNc8nA48j06Hl2GxwOjofXhtfCMwlliLrMitCS6k1MZfcquCa5LqoW9YhvC7tEvfJOxe4VriX@Nd4FrlX@ZZtrfMu9K30L91eu7HYv3precj6TQNbFrZNhNkIMLJtJcRMqJ0gQyGWwkyF2wo0FmYt1FyMvWCDoRbDTcbZjDAabjXGbKzdKMMxluNMx9uONB5nPdZ8iv3oALER4kOkxUgIEh8lJUxqnKRAKZHSQqXHSgyWFi01XE685ICpEdND5sXMCJoeNSdsbtyswDmR80Lnx84Mnhc9NzxG/GwAuQjyIeBgQACRjwIDBhYOFCAYSHCg4GFBAoODBgsOJh40QFiI8CDhYkIEhYcKExY2LlRgmMhwoeFjQwaHiw4b3h740AFiI8SHuA/GHUDio9wD5h3n8Hv@vp7O8jLUb38) that outputs the first few lines in a reasonable amount of time.

[Here is the encoder](https://tio.run/##ZZHtboIwFIb/cxWkIwukgv3RLJlmhDvYBagxbrLEDQoBNSxEb52957SizgROe57z9ny0dd4UL8NQ/vpBWxya2n/zeZ17HljWwV8IIya@kGQUGU1mKcjGKe9Z8H7Yr9lbihWOP/HhrEvaqtmHfWzzJ59V@REG6@gUQdNuqEZSowl7Ik2T515oI0UXBlL6293R19FZjKCstgy0UYTCrIulDKKr8B5f5MbEKfXXh2fU5oIncUI1dECVqZHbBqdZN42S72pn3EUUmOVRUG7qsMcAX7um3WOqyewHgyVNfsybNp/bvBlmo3X2usiK1XwYjJZ8V8ootCXYATNGAng0Gf2uY1y@h4BF7nMRaSM3MRugHI45pRaEGDqC57PI/M@KjsbIXQCvbBNfEZsLvMiWaAvOOIcxHi06TrExrCU5@ZRKMVTsg8LVCq5yR@heHCKxJVr9AQ) that turns the program into the data section

Everything but the large number on the first line is encoded using these <s>8</s> 9 tokens:

```
0 n + -> " \n Out_ \ 4
```

That's why all the atom names are composed of just `n`,`0` and `4`.

As a bonus, this is now fully deterministic in what order the rules are executed.

#### Explanation:

```
Initialise the program
0n0n->        If no n0n atom (note we can't use _-> since _ isn't a token)
      n4+Out_"0n0n->"+Out_n4+nn4+n0n
      NUMn4           Create a really large number of n4 atoms  
      +Out_"0n0n->"   Print the leading "0n0n->"
      +Out_n4         Print the really large number
      +nn             Set the nn flag to start getting the next character
      +n0n            And prevent this rule from being called again


Divmod the number by 9 (nn and nnn flag)
nn->4n0+4n0+nnn          Convert the nn flag to 8 n0 atoms and the nnn flag
n0+n4->n                 Convert n4+n0 atoms to an n atom
nnn+4n+4n+n4->nn+n00     When we're out of n0 atoms, move back to the nn flag
                         And increment the number of n00 atoms
nnn+0n4->n+n40           When we're out of n4 atoms, add another n atom and set the n40 flag


Convert the 9 possible states of the n0 and n atoms to a token and output it (nn flag)
n+4n0+4n0->Out_"n"           1n+8n0 -> 'n'
n+n+4n0+n0+n0+n0->Out_"+"    2n+7n0 -> '+'
n+n+n+4n0+n0+n0->Out_n       3n+6n0 -> '0'
4n+4n0+n0->Out_"4"           4n+5n0 -> '4'
4n+n+4n0->Out_"\""           5n+4n0 -> '"'
4n+n+n+n0+n0+n0->Out_"->"    6n+3n0 -> '->'
4n+n+n+n+n0+n0->Out_"\n"     7n+2n0 -> '\n'
4n+4n+n0->Out_"Out_"         8n+1n0 -> 'Out_'
4n+4n+n->Out_"\\"            9n+0n0 -> '\'

Reset (n40 flag)
n40+0nn+n00->n4+n40    Convert all the n00 atoms back to n4 atoms
n40+0n00+n4->n4+nn     Once we're out of n00 atoms set the nn flag to start the divmod
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), <s>211 143 138 133 129 98 86</s> 84 bytes

```
?.21@@/BC1@c/@/C1112BC1BB/@c22B2%C@!{<?
!.>.._{<+>>-?>.---?+<+_{<-?>+<<-.+?ÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyrKTMzTTc4oTc7@/9@ekVHPyNDBQd/J2dChPlnfQd/Z0NDQCMhzctIHChgZORmp8jk71CsyV9vYcynq2enpxVfbaNvZ6drb6enq6tpr22gDBYA8bRsbXT1t@8P7//8HAA)

old version:

```
?{<^?_>{_;?_,<_-+_;._;}_^-_;{_^?_z<_>>_->_->_*}_-<_^._=+_->_->_->_-!_	?_;}_^_}<?
!.>.>.>.+>._<.}+>.>.>?<{?_{<-_}<.<+.<-?<{??`?=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxDsJADEPVEf6iKyH5gXOTPzkDXUBIDEgsRPftR3tC9uJn@/Z@XF@63j/rs/dI1KAnS/AMqrAYS2NVluRWfUF36vCpUcFqXORPds88xLhMExviOJsPiRthTUYKZDCh28IgBt1BXGLp/Qc)

New code. Now the data isn't split into nul separated chunks, but the nul will be pulled through the data.

```
Brian:
?                   start Chuck

.21@@/BC1@c/@/C1112BC1BB/@c22B2%C@!
                    data. This is basically the end of the Brian code and the Chuck code reversed 
                    and incremented by four. This must be done because the interpreter tries
                    to run the data, so it must not contain runnable characters

                    ASCII 3 for marking the end of the code section
{<?                 loop the current code portion of Chuck

Chuck:
code 1 (print start of Brian code)
.>..               print the first 3 characters of Brian

code 2 (print the data section)
{<+>>-              increment char left to null and decrement symbol right to null
                    for the first char, this increments the question mark and decrements the
                    ASCII 1. So the question mark can be reused in the end of the Chuck code
?>.                 if it became nul then print the next character
---?+<+             if the character is ASCII 3, then the data section is printed.
                    set it 1, and set the next char to the left 1, too

code 3 (extract code from data)
{<-                 decrement the symbol left to the nul
?>+<<-.             if it became nul then it is the new code section marker, so set the old one 1
                    and print the next character to the left
+?                  if all data was processed, then the pointer can't go further to the left
                    so the char 255 is printed. If you add 1, it will be null and the code ends.
ÿ                   ASCII 255 that is printed when the end of the data is reached
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), 330 bytes

```
"![	.;	=90*/[	.9(#;	=[>[.	>1#	98='9[	'7[.>;	[*;	)	=#0,*[	=.>9(.	=*(#(#([	.0#8;#(#;	[*9>[;	=> [*?	[9(;;"\
/																																																																																																														<
>:1+0\
 /:)$<
>\?\ /
?2 $
:9>(:\
(8\/?<
\+ <
 *
 >$1-+\
>/?:) /
 >+)$)$)\
/1$9<$)$<
\+:?\<
>?!\+@
\:)<<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vc5NbgMhDAXgtX0JSEAKAw0w3XT4GdOew952UbXK/XeEXKJ@qyc9ffLv3/fPY87rhSE2OEv2iUHF4sxqTKwi0K4MlOO8FYbbB0dqwF41UBuo0@Q3z3BGKm5N1emdWVlYNkczL4V9IV4YafYDuLjWroIJ/vU6Ut1DFtSpbnY1GaITjndtsRZyVdAdkkZHCbqj9qjJ7vcgSGnUbU01hc2urNd3W7p9KRLqkIWNi4RPlLr1jnPOPed5/3oC)

This works in all topologies, mostly by completely avoiding wrapping. The first list encodes the rest of the program offset by one, so newlines are the unprintable  (11).

Answer (score 7):

## [ed(1)](https://kidneybone.com/c2/wiki/EdIsTheStandardTextEditor), 45 bytes

We have quines for `TECO`, `Vim`, and `sed`, but not the almighty `ed`?! This travesty shall not stand. (NB: See also, this [error quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36286/15940) for `ed`)

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S035/z@RK5FLh0unxJBLRdekWF9HX0@fS6eAK5BLD4vg//8A)

```
a
a
,
,t1
$-4s/,/./
,p
Q
.
,t1
$-4s/,/./
,p
Q
```

Stolen from [here](https://github.com/tpenguinltg/ed1-quine/blob/master/quine.ed). It should be saved as a file `quine.ed` then run as follows: (TIO seems to work a bit differently)

```
$ ed < quine.ed
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 42 bytes

```
iIilWY!}I96PWwI10WwwwIkWwwwIhWq``
   k   h
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=iIilWY!%7DI96PWwI10WwwwIkWwwwIhWq%60%60%0A%20%20%20k%20%20%20h&inputs=)

It is very costly to output anything in Grok it seems.

Answer (score 7):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), <s>1128</s> <s>1116</s> <s>1069</s> <s>960</s> <s>877</s> <s>844</s> <s>540</s> <s>477</s> <s>407</s> <s>383</s> 33 bytes

**Edit**: Woah... -304 B with space

**Edit 2**: Bruh.

**Edit 3**: Thanks Jo King for the idea! I outgolfed ya!

A stack-based language(The first on TIO's list!)

It's a big pile of unprintables though

```
N0N  (!&+$*)^(!&@^)!
```

(Spaces are `NUL` bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P9f0s9ATFDCT1JKRJoByGAQ0FBUE9BW0dKMAzIc4jQV//8HAA)

Here's the code, but in Control Pictures form:

```
␙N0␖␑␘N␙␚␔␛␀␖␑␘␀␐(!&␐+$*)^(!&@^)!
```

### Explanation

```
␙N0␖␑␘N␙␚␔␛␀␖␑␘␀␐                 Data
                 (!&␐+$*)         Push the stack, reversed and +16 back on top
                         ^(!&@^)! Print everything reversed, including the length (Hence the final `!`)
```

It does error on overflow though...

Comment: Will it get to BF length? I wonder...

Comment: Almost there...

Comment: just as a note, i have posted a [quine in this language before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211199/76162), though don't let that stop you improving this further

Comment: SO messed up the unprintables

Answer (score 6):

## Clojure, 91 bytes

```lisp
((fn [x] (list x (list (quote quote) x))) (quote (fn [x] (list x (list (quote quote) x)))))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 68 bytes

```
Print[#<>ToString[#,InputForm]]&@"Print[#<>ToString[#,InputForm]]&@"
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

Run this code in Firefox 34+ (currently in Aurora)'s Web console

```
(f=x=>alert`(f=${f})()`)()
```

Comment: @rafe-ketler - I believe that this is the shortest ES6 version now :)

Comment: Hmm... doesn't work in the latest version of Firefox (it outputs `(f=,)()`), I believe you'd have to put the template in parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

## Commodore Basic, <s>54</s> 41 characters

```
1R─A$:?A$C|(34)A$:D♠"1R─A$:?A$C|(34)A$:D♠
```

Based on DLosc's QBasic quine, but modified to take advantage of Commodore Basic's shortcut forms.  In particular, the shorter version of `CHR$(34)` makes using it directly for quotation marks more efficient than defining it as a variable.

As usual, I've made substitutions for PETSCII characters that don't appear in Unicode: `♠` = `SHIFT+A`, `─` = `SHIFT+E`, `|` = `SHIFT+H`.

**Edit:** You know what?  If a string literal ends at the end of a line, the Commodore Basic interpreter will let you leave out the trailing quotation mark.  Golfed off 13 characters.

Alternatively, if you want to skirt the spirit of the rules,

```
1 LIST
```

`LIST` is an instruction that prints the current program's code.  It is intended for use in immediate mode, but like all immediate-mode commands, it can be used in a program (eg. `1 NEW` is a self-deleting program).  Nothing shorter is possible: dropped spaces or abbreviated forms get expanded by the interpreter and displayed at full length.

Comment: Its not opening the file and reading its input, but I do agree that this is a bit cheaty.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, is the new version better?

Comment: @Mark I can't read that, but it looks like a quine to me. ;)

Comment: @YoYoYonnY It reads its *source*, tho.

Comment: This is is no way cheating. Don't be confused by the fact that the statement is named READ; it's purely a way of initializing variables from values found elsewhere in the source code. No I/O is being performed; `READ A:DATA 1` is just a long way of writing `A=1` that lets the `A` and `1` not be next to each other.  It's mainly there because there's no composite literal syntax in the language.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 6 Bytes

This programming language was obviously made past the date of release for this question, but I thought I'd post an answer so I can a) get more used to it and b) figure out what else needed to be implemented.

```
'rd3*Z
```

The explanation is as follows:

```
'rd3*Z
'           Start recording as a string.

(wraps around once, capturing all the items)

'           Stop recording as a string. We now have everything recorded but the original ".
 r          Reverse the stack
  b3*       This equates the number 39 = 13*3 (in ASCII, ')
     Z      Output the entire stack.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [beeswax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax), <del>17</del> 13 bytes

According to the discussion on [Does using SMBF count as a cheating quine?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8503/39407) the original version at the bottom would count as a cheating quine, so I am wondering if a small change would make this a “proper” quine. The new version is 4 bytes smaller and does not modify its own source code:

```
`_4~++~+.}1fJ
```

Explanation:

```
                lstack     STDOUT

 _             α[0,0,0]•                 create bees α,β, moving right and left
               β[0,0,0]•

` 4            α[0,0,4]•                 push 4 on top of α lstack, switch β to print mode
β α            β[0,0,0]•                 switch β to character output mode

   ~           α[0,4,0]•                 flip α lstack top and 2nd
    +          α[0,4,4]•                 lstack top = top+2nd
     +         α[0,4,8]•                 lstack top = top+2nd
      ~        α[0,8,4]•                 flip lstack top and 2nd
       +       α[0,8,12]•                lstack top = top+2nd
        .      α[0,8,96]•                lstack top = top*2nd
         }     α[0,8,96]•    ` ASCII(96) output char(lstack top) to STDOUT
          1    α[0,8,1]•                 lstack top = 1
           F   α[1,1,1]•                 all lstack = top
            J  α[1,1,1]•                 jump to (x,y) = (lstack top, lstack 2nd)
`_4~++~+.}1FJ  α[1,1,1]•   _4~++~+.}1FJ  output characters to STDOUT
```

This version should qualify as proper quine if the Befunge-93 program on [Thompson’s Quine Page](http://www.nyx.net/%7Egthompso/quine.htm) is listed as proper quine.
The Befunge quine below does nothing else than read itself character by character, one character during each implicit loop, and output the character to STDOUT.

```
:0g,:93+`#@_1+
```

Correct me if I’m wrong.

---

**Old (cheating?) version.**

beeswax is a new 2D esolang on a hexagonal grid. It is inspired by bees, honeycombs and by the [Hive board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hive_%28game%29) (which uses hexagonal gaming pieces). beeswax programs are able to modify their own code.
Thanks to this ability it is not too hard to create a quine. But the program does not read its own source code, as my explanation shows.

The first beeswax quine in existence:

```
_4~++~+.@1~0@D@1J
```

Or equivalently:

```
*4~++~+.@1~0@D@1J
```

IPs are called bees, the program area is called honeycomb. Every bee owns a local stack called lstack, carrying 3 unsigned 64 bit integer values.

Explanation:

```
                                             lstack
                                     • marks top of stack

* or _  create bee(same result in this situation)[0,0,0]•
 4      1st lstack value=4                       [0,0,4]•
  ~        flip 1st/2nd lstack values            [0,4,0]•
   ++      1st=1st+2nd, twice                    [0,4,8]•
     ~                                           [0,8,4]•
      +                                          [0,8,12]•
       .         1st=1st*2nd                     [0,8,96]•
        @  flip 1st/3rd lstack values            [96,8,0]• 
         1     1st=1                             [96,8,1]•
          ~                                      [96,1,8]•
           0   1st=0                             [96,1,0]•
            @                                    [0,1,96]•
             D drop 1st at row=2nd,col.=3rd val. [0,1,96]•
       This drops ASCII(96)= ` beyond the left border.
```

Dropping a value at a coordinate outside the program—in this case at column 0—grows the honeycomb by 1 column to the left. The coordinate system gets reset, so this column becomes the new column 1. So, growing the honeycomb in ‘negative’ direction is only possible in steps of 1. The grown honeycomb is always a rectangle encompassing all code.

This modifies the program to:

```
`*4~++~+.@1~0@D@1J
```

continuing...

```
               @                                  [96,1,0]•
                1                                 [96,1,1]•
                 J jump to row=1st,column=2nd val.[96,1,1]•
`                  switch to character output mode.
 *4~++~+.@1~0@D@1J    the following characters are printed to STDOUT.
```

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl) of the Julia package of the beeswax interpreter.

Comment: You can generate 96 using `5~3(`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNLS5PrPj/P0E53rTOWKPWMM3r/38A "Beeswax – Try It Online") (TIO still has the bug with the endof vs lastindex)

Answer (score 6):

## Jolf, 4 bytes

```
Q«Q«
Q    double (string)
 «   begin matched string
  Q« capture that
```

This transpiles to `` square(`Q«`) `` (I accidentally did string doubling in the `square` function), which evaluates to `Q«Q«`. Note that `q` is the quining function in Jolf, *not* `Q` ;).

Answer (score 6):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 4 bytes

```
_UNK
```

I am not kidding.  Due to a suggestion by @ConorO'Brien, `K` prints `_UNK`.  The `_UN` does nothing really, but actually sets the temp var to `0`, pushes `0`, and pushes `None`.

The `K` prints "_UNK", and that is our quine.

Comment: I was bored today and decided to quine in FOG. Couldn't figure it out, this is very clever

Answer (score 6):

### Bash + coreutils, 18 bytes

```
sed p<<a
sed p<<a
```

It requires a trailing newline and generates a warning.

Posted the Zsh version in a separate answer to fix the leaderboard.

Comment: Interesting use of the here-document, but one has to end the text stream manually with Ctrl+D to make the script run, hence the warning. To have it run automatically, an extra line with just `a` on it is required, but that would break the quine.

Comment: @seshoumara Just put it in a script file and use `bash filename` to run.

Comment: Aah, you give an EOF this way, nice. Maybe add that to description. I run it with `bash script 2> /dev/null` to get rid of STDERR.

Comment: In dash and zsh, you don't need the trailing newline and it won't generate a warning.

Comment: @seshoumara Answers on this site should be functions or complete programs, and not code snippets in a REPL, by default.

Answer (score 6):

## C++, <s>286</s> <s>284</s> 236 bytes

Now with extra golf!

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){char a[]="#include<iostream>%sint main(){char a[]=%s%s%s,b[]=%s%s%s%s,c[]=%s%sn%s,d[]=%s%s%s%s;printf(a,c,b,a,b,b,d,b,b,b,d,b,b,d,d,b);}",b[]="\"",c[]="\n",d[]="\\";printf(a,c,b,a,b,b,d,b,b,b,d,b,b,d,d,b);}
```

I'm currently learning C++, and thought "Hey, I should make a quine in it to see how much I know!" 40 minutes later, I have this, a full <s>64</s> **114** bytes shorter than [the current one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/2431#2431). I compiled it as:

```
g++ quine.cpp
```

Output and running:

```
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming\cpp
λ g++ quine.cpp & a
#include<iostream>
int main(){char a[]="#include<iostream>%sint main(){char a[]=%s%s%s,b[]=%s%s%s%s,c[]=%s%sn%s,d[]=%s%s%s%s;printf(a,c,b,a,b,b,d,b,b,b,d,b,b,d,d,b);}",b[]="\"",c[]="\n",d[]="\\";printf(a,c,b,a,b,b,d,b,b,b,d,b,b,d,d,b);}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Cheddar](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar), 56 bytes

```
var a='var a=%s;print a%@"39+a+@"39';print a%@"39+a+@"39
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=dmFyIGE9J3ZhciBhPSVzO3ByaW50IGElQCIzOSthK0AiMzknO3ByaW50IGElQCIzOSthK0AiMzk&input=)

I felt like trying to make something in Cheddar today, and this is what appeared...

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

*Thanks to @Oliver for a correction (trailing newline)*

```
"D34ç.øsJ"D34ç.øsJ
```

There is a trailing newline.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IkQzNMOnLsO4c0oiRDM0w6cuw7hzSgo&input=)

```
"D34ç.øsJ"             Push this string
          D            Duplicate
           34          Push 34 (ASCII for double quote mark)
             ç         Convert to char
              .ø       Surround the string with quotes
                s      Swap
                 J     Join. Implicitly display
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fycXY5PByvcM7ir2Ks1E4//9Hqxur66ibqMcCAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161069/59376 - If you want to post this 22 byte answer on this question, you can :). Don't feel I deserve the credit.

Comment: Probably wasn't available in the old version of 05AB1E yet when you posted your answer, but you can golf 2 bytes by changing `sJ` (swap, join) to `ì` (prepend). [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fycXY5PByvcM7Dq9BYnL9/w8A)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I like to keep the language as it was before the challenge (even though that's not required anymore), so I'll leave it as it is

Comment: @LuisMendo Fine by me. There are already two shorter 05AB1E answers anyway. Was just stating it as a possibility. :)

Answer (score 6):

## 05AB1E, <s>16</s> 17 bytes

```
"34çs«DJ"34çs«DJ
```

With trailing newline.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IjM0w6dzwqtESiIzNMOnc8KrREoK&input=)

**Explanation:**

```
"34çs«DJ"        # push string
         34ç     # push "
            s«   # swap and concatenate
              DJ # duplicate and concatenate
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 26 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
"ạ~bAh34∧A~ạj"ạ~bAh34∧A~ạj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@6/0cNfCuiTHDGOTRx3LHeuAvCwsQv///48CAA)

A function that returns its own source code. (This can be made into a 28-byte full program by adding `w` after each occurrence of `j`.)

### Explanation

```
"ạ~bAh34∧A~ạj"ạ~bAh34∧A~ạj
"ạ~bAh34∧A~ạj"               String literal
              ạ              Convert to list of character codes
               ~b            Prepend an element
                  h34          so that the first element is 34
                 A   ∧A        but work with the entire list
                       ~ạ    Convert to string
                         j   Concatenate the string to itself
```

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>78</s> <s>70</s> <s>66</s> 62 bytes

Minus 4 bytes thanks to MD XF (reusing first argument of `printf`)!

There are a few unprintables in this answer, replaced with `?`.

```c
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@??');}",34,'@??');}
```

Here's an xxd:

```c
00000000: 6d61 696e 2829 7b70 7269 6e74 6628 226d  main(){printf("m
00000010: 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2825 6325  ain(){printf(%c%
00000020: 7325 3124 632c 3334 2c27 4005 9027 293b  s%1$c,34,'@..');
00000030: 7d22 2c33 342c 2740 0590 2729 3b7d       }",34,'@..');}
```

[Here's a bash script to generate and execute the program.](https://tio.run/##VdDBbsIwDAbge5/iF1oFSNCldmoThqZdtuuegaRl4wBDtAekiWfvki6HzQfHhz@fZPt9/zmOt1uL9RW73ev7G54xdP1QhcLk2kJaqSFOOtCGHNSrgZI4SKcWIrQBkbTAaX88L5bfl@vxPBwWs1M26mTUUz5FnXqoUfol1Yokt4FwbPhHlKHMBkVDU4BrsikawMwWFEhhjWngTJzIsQf6sn4IK7ar@UtVzZdP2eBktETxEzPYRoPUGpjGmTjF1dhrXGOq@@wPcC/iaYqPEPJxsP6apqJ6TM84/gA)

### 62 bytes, part 2

Here's a version that I have tested on my windows machine on gcc (ANSI encoded):

```c
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@@0');}",34,'@@0');}
```

Here's the output:

```c
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents
λ xxd test.c
00000000: 6d61 696e 2829 7b70 7269 6e74 6628 226d  main(){printf("m
00000010: 6169 6e28 297b 7072 696e 7466 2825 6325  ain(){printf(%c%
00000020: 7325 3124 632c 3334 2c27 4040 3027 293b  s%1$c,34,'@@0');
00000030: 7d22 2c33 342c 2740 4030 2729 3b7d       }",34,'@@0');}

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents
λ cat test.c
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@@0');}",34,'@@0');}
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents
λ wc test.c -c
62 test.c

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents
λ gcc test.c -o test
test.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@@0');}",34,'@@0');}
 ^
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:1:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@@0');}",34,'@@0');}
        ^
test.c:1:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
test.c:1:8: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
test.c:1:55: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
 main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@@0');}",34,'@@0');}
                                                       ^

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents
λ test
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,'@@0');}$c,34,'@@0');}
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents
λ
```

### 66 bytes

```c
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%1$c,34,4195728);}",34,4195728);}
```

I have no idea why this works, 100% honest here. But dang, is it short. Only 6 bytes longer than the current best.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQwmVq5qsWqxqqJKsY2yiY2JoaWpuZKFpXauEyv3/HwA)

### 70 bytes

```c
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%c,34,4195728,34);}",34,4195728,34);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQwmVq5qsWqyarGNsomNiaGlqbmQBZGpa1yphiPz/DwA)

### 78 bytes

```c
main(){printf("main(){printf(%c%s%c,34,%c%c+8,34,34,34);}",34,""+8,34,34,34);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQwmVq5qsWqyarGNsogNkJWtbgFhgpGldqwRiKSmhCv7/DwA)

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQwmVq5qsWqxqqJKsY2yiY2JoaWpuZKFpXauEyv3/HwA)

Comment: It works because `printf` is very weakly typed, so your integer constant gets interpreted as the actual pointer address of the format string constant. Very implementation-dependent, I tried it on a different Linux machine and even there I needed to adjust the numbers.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks, I figured it had _something_ to do with addressing.

Comment: Aha, you found out how to get it down to 62 non-locally!

Comment: @MDXF Yes I did :>

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Also, [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQwmVq5qsWqxqqJKsY2yio2qkkqJpXasEYpsYWpqaG1kAuf//AwA) without using wide-char magic

Answer (score 6):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>1144 1034</s> 970 bytes

```
"is waiting at Writer's Depot.34 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 r 3 l 2 l 3 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Charboil Grill.Go to Charboil Grill:e 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to KonKat's:n 3 r 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:s 1 l 2 r 1 l."is waiting at Writer's Depot.34 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 r 3 l 2 l 3 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Charboil Grill.Go to Charboil Grill:e 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to KonKat's:n 3 r 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:s 1 l 2 r 1 l.
```

*Please ignore the output to stderr. Who needs a job if you can quine anyway?*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VHBigIxDP2Vx168Dbh6musueBB0wIPnOtYxWJshjahfX7t2hB1Y1D3roYQkfe/lJWpOFOMHBRwNKfkGRrEUUiuDgG/bshajMfr9hRqpt@TWmB32Vthxcy4mDOU/W@URQwhGcPhML0cpKqp3hxYGrQnB@sYKGv5RSDRfWyMrJoeJkHMdd79Y2sTq7rJM2U@NDkKH79vKU/0Hf0tLnzzIYw/n2rG3t@FzlrDDvIe72IqDYr7ZUG2f/pd1flXK0GnJdVPvI7/AkWOMFw)

## How does this work?

**Short answer**

This quine starts with a string. If you replace the content of that string by `<string>`, the code looks like `"<string>"<string>`, which is `"<string>` twice. Because the string doesn't contain the double quote, we first get the double quote via its character code, concatenate it with the string, then copy the string and concatenate it with itself. Finally, we print the string.

**Long answer**

under construction

Answer (score 6):

## [Implicit](https://git.io/sS), 20 bytes

```
«@171%@187»@171%@187
```

This didn't work in older versions of Implicit.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///QagdDc0NVB0ML80O74cz//wE)

#### How it works

```
«@171%@187»           Push the string '@171%@187' on the stack. Let's call it s.
           @171       Print '«' (char code 171), without pushing it on the stack.
               %      Print s without popping it from the stack.
                @187  Print '»' (char code 171), without pushing it on the stack.
                      (implicit) Print the top of the stack: s.
```

---

## [Implicit](https://git.io/sS), 26 bytes

```
«:171,::187,"»:171,::187,"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///QaitDc0MdKytDC3MdpUO7kXn//wMA)

#### How it works

```
«:171,::187,"»              Push the string ':171,::187,"' on the stack.
                            Let's call it s.
              :171          Push 171 (code point of «).
                  ,         Swap s and 171.
                   :        Push a copy of s.
                    :187    Push 187 (code point of »).
                        ,   Swap the copy of s and ».
                         "  Combine the entire stack into a string.
```

Comment: +1, got the same solution not long after.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript, 49 bytes

A quine without any uses of `uneval` or `Function.prototype.toString`.

```js
eval(Q="q=Q.link()[8];alert(`eval(Q=${q+Q+q})`)")
```

Can avoid use of template strings for + 1 byte.

```js
eval(Q="q=Q.link()[8];alert('eval(Q='+q+Q+q+')')")
```

---

### JavaScript, 74 bytes

Another approach avoiding `uneval` and `Function.prototype.toString`:

```js
console.log(a="console.log(a=%s%s%s,q=a.link()[8],a,q)",q=a.link()[8],a,q)
```

Answer (score 6):

### Underload, 10 Bytes

```
(:aSS):aSS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fwyoxOFgTRPz/DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>31</s> 27 bytes

```perl6
<"<$_>~~.EVAL".say>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99GyUYl3q6uTs81zNFHSa84sRLG4fr/HwA)

No messing about with alternative `q` quotes or `.perl`, just `<>` and a good ol' EVAL quine.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
<                 >         # Create a list of 
 "<$_>~~.EVAL".say          # The string '"<$_>~~.EVAL".say'
                   ~~       # Smartmatch the list by setting $_ to it
                     .EVAL  # Evaluate the string as code
 "<$_>~~.EVAL"              # Interpolate the $_ list into the string
              .say          # And print it with a newline
```

Answer (score 6):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), <s>5424</s> <s>4978</s> <s>4808</s> <s>4112</s> <s>3962</s> 3748 bytes

```
11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+(|11+1<)\(1|1""+""*++"*;)($|1+11#(1)1""+""*+""*++;1#1+"//"\^\<11+*#()*+\)(%|()#(1)($)"1+1<#)\(&|()#11+"*"*"++;\"1+1<#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5Vhbb9pIFH73rzgx3cXGxmZIVu2S8NBUarVVhKJs@7AyLjL2UKz1bWeGXLT0t7NnbAwmXBIlYZd2cWTNnPnOd64zA8nuxDhN2rNZDcZCZLxj25nH/OhOeLc0ssQkHkbM8tPYzlIu7DevW29@eU1OjsmvdpgIyjJG8d0cpaxJmmHSzHI@Rakd2RPO7GGY2DS5hrm4BsSAih6O4bJcusztwidpGGz4SBmN5TQxod0iJ4i4CH2a@BRCDu/ewfkfzd/fwonVQvD7txdArGMcfeh9hg@XF9fHShhnKRPA77gyYmkMfhpF1BdhmnCYrwX0rwlVFG4CD6BbTDXdhL@/KUpAR5AmNIsmXOOI7UIPp3pHAfyEI0hS5GaimM9lEU00tGd57Ou1DkddaC@X5SdjGDyon7n3lXZABQNKtNNycaaCMwojCiKFIQV6S/2JoIGrrpBIFXobCo3oS9tJhg6mWcW@Q1wT6qy@BDHvBkEItRj1Am1F2/KjlNO5jEYc3SvgGGIuy1/j2IQrE4ZcmHBuQg/XHVemy1zmroV/ORh7AnxZYSRayZIP3S7Utfpqbs7B6AJZEaEdy8swqEDr6esM@hpD8z7DlSM5sjTTdFdWcGURic7hDFqrLJU6/RYPvcjDjgtgyDz/Tyr4kboGXtSjvcHHWh28JEA7OGl1MIEbAuotI89dOupWfXqUL/d9yF89E/xYNi6W5L2HNc2lN2PZYT0MXHYr1kZf2kplF6HI6bnVUGSrI1PnfvYkHGMk9Q7wMq5KUxattMQZVRwvqiK3QDHartfYpNd4WE9d0XOaxN2OtXMsS4Un6K4Y@v0qsLkD@SUH0lshrTtzZ83S6x2unFXdbsk8lzGfLUZyh8IO4zXkkLtzHJeW3a1Yq2rPG3IN@032xQCPhYnQ6gneAZR1cL/pO5JtVllSFlQZ/LGHLSsKEjzpdtB0kKbo@LnfW5Gn0iC2PRdBOhHWDQuxIJMk9MesbJIddhzULjbHJzahW2H3D6n8GBVJuUuwe0nnCneLa@GtKUJ5uWj1aV1fU0JK1MMzGZ0OHDlsufJEkqO2uwZfXDwL7DqlrO9Vdafmx/aWPeou4l2eBJWzR0HkYJB4MR0MJF4dDGIvTAYDtSAs/dFnM0KMyrMy@V6eF19@HuGjlP77RO0jyEPvBPI44SO75CVy9mCF/ic78tmEz2DbY9c8ubf2kfMnVOVp9sghNt0PZvhAb8oHduKeev/F07lp8v2fxPs7NTcCDuaL1@F@9/rhe@pFDpknSf6le3VPKT7QvaNNpeBM72tkSlTVUNWGYaiNU117NZXgmkb0Up6vnZIaMVTbVvtf@meo26hpesPo69pPU02XaO2VrkrKGnL@LGUIUhv4oG5/vjKz8v88WPh7/B8)

Comment: Congratulations! You beat me to the punch. Nice work!!

Answer (score 6):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 38 bytes

```
> "print('> %r\\n>> ⍎1'%a)"
>> ⍎1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkGpoCgzr0RD3U5BtSgmJs/OTuFRb5@humqiphIXlMP1/z8A)

Abuses the fact that there's an eval as Python command (`⍎`), which I can use to turn it into an arbitrary Python program. But of course, as a less cheaty feeling quine, there's:

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 270 bytes

```
> [62, 62, 32, 34, 49, 34, 10, 62, 32, 34, 62, 32, 34, 10, 62, 62, 32, 51, 43, 50, 10, 62, 62, 32, 69, 97, 99, 104, 32, 54, 32, 49, 10, 62, 62, 32, 39, 82, 10, 62, 62, 32, 79, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 32, 52, 32, 53]
>> "1"
> "> "
>> 3+2
>> Each 6 1
>> 'R
>> Output 4 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU67DsIwDNzzFVYXBjrUjyZkycaMxIoYEEIqW0Vb8fnBhkYqipS7s@9sK@/hOY2P10Q5J7h4asHABmlB4k@x@/e3dcmK16PusWpXZ17vxaCIlsm6sKrEeoHVO1DtB5vFYOSNaNt@j5bf8NWlBA02Tlmfdbwnk@PtPoAHtHp3Nj4t87jMINC7nD8)

Which encodes the ordinal values of the rest of the program on the first line, then prints the list then the list converted to characters.

Turns out I missed another way to make a slightly cheaty quine. In Whispers, the modulo command directly calls Python's `%`, which is overloaded with string formatting. This means you can forgo the eval command and do:

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 50 bytes

```
> '> %r\n>> 1%%1\n>> Output 2'
>> 1%1
>> Output 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkHdTkG1KCbPzk7BUFXVEMzwLy0pKC1RMFLnAosaciGJcf3/DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
p+N
"p+N
```

Saved one more byte by using the newline operator

(Also I made this ages ago but forgot to edit this so yeah)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v0Dbj0sJSPz/DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 54 bytes

```
'Z  u   u%+}12  !*]+|   |0]!&[&&Z'[
v
v&,~23
"+^,}
}1^"'\''[
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiJ1pcdHVcdHUlK30xMlx0ISpdK3xcdHwwXSEmWyYmWidbXG52XG52Jix+MjNcblwiK14sfVxufTFeXCInXFwnJ1siLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiIn0=)

As a bonus, I even managed to avoid using any unprintable characters, though there are a few tabs in there.

#### Explanation

Here's an image of how the code is interpreted (the gif version would take too long, since it takes approximately 23*26=598 steps):

[image: quine]

There are two starting conveyor belts here, indicated by the `[`s on the top and bottom lines. The one on the top line feeds the data string to the rest of the program, while the other one prints the leading `'` for the string and adds the other quote to the buffered output.

The top row is fed through a duplicator (`"`), one side of which is just pushed to output, while the other one has each character incremented by one (`+1`) to be transformed into the rest of the program before entering a queue (`&`), which already contains a `'`. Each character in this queue is delayed by 23 steps (`~23`), so that it only starts printing *after* the initial data string has finished being printed.

Answer (score 6):

## [Javastack](https://github.com/chunkybanana/Javastack), 64 bytes

```java
"34 char swap add 2 repeat print"34 char swap add 2 repeat print
```

No TIO yet, watch this space!

Javastack aims to combine the verbosity of Java with the stack-based paradigm  to create a truly horrible programming experience. I'm planning to make up for the verbosity with a truly immense library of functions, but it's all a work in progress.

Javastack doesn't have any way to get the character `"` aside from `34 char`, so that's what we start with. We prepend it to the string currently on the stack (which is part of the code) with `swap add`, double it with `2 repeat`, and print it, resulting in the source code.

-12 thanks to Aaron Miller - outgolfing me in my own language!

Comment: Doesn't look too verbose compared to Forth or Factor :P

Comment: Not that Java if everything doesn't have to be inside a class, you don't have to deal with any qualified names, and you don't have to declare the types of... stack positions? I'm going mad even trying to think about that last point

Comment: @UnrelatedString Ooh, good idea!

Comment: "I'm planning to make up for the verbosity with a truly immense library of functions." Sounds more like Factor than Java to me :P

Comment: You can get rid of the space before each `34 char` for 74 bytes: `"34 char swap add duplicate add print"34 char swap add duplicate add print`

Comment: You can also get replace `duplicate add`  with `2 repeat` for 64 bytes: `"34 char swap add 2 repeat print"34 char swap add 2 repeat print`

Comment: @AaronMiller Outgolfing me in my own language! Nicely done.

Answer (score 6):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), <sup><s>4182</s></sup>1869 bytes

```
+OU+++++++++OU++++++++++++++OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU++++++++++OU++++OU++++OU++++OU++++OU++++++++++OU++++OU++++OU++++++++++OU+++++++OU++OU+++OU+++++++OU+++++++++++++++OU+++++OU++++OU++++OU+++++++++++++OU+++++++++++OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+++++++++++OU++++++OU++++OU+OU+OU+OU+++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++OU++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++OU+++++OU++++++++OU++++++OU+OU+OU+++++++++OU++++++++++++++OU++OU+++++OU++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++OU+++++++++OU++++++OU++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++OU+++++++OU++OU+++OU+++++OU++++++OU++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++OU++OU+++OU++++++++++++++++OU+OU+++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++OU++++OU+++++OU++++++++++++++++++OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+++++++++++OU++++++OU++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++OU+++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++OU+++++OU++OU+++OU++++++OU+OU+++++++++OU++++++++++++OU++++++++OUOU++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++OUOU+E.+++++[]]]][]][{UO{^)]]-P++++++P:]+++PD-};N)}:++E.U)!-E:R[{UO):};{UOD+^(])R+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++P:};{N()UO:+E;}
```

Unfortunately there isn't a fancy TIO style interpreter for Headascii, just the same old replit hosted one. you can run that [here](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23) by running

```js
erun("+OU+++++++++OU++++++++++++++OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU++++++++++OU++++OU++++OU++++OU++++OU++++++++++OU++++OU++++OU++++++++++OU+++++++OU++OU+++OU+++++++OU+++++++++++++++OU+++++OU++++OU++++OU+++++++++++++OU+++++++++++OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+++++++++++OU++++++OU++++OU+OU+OU+OU+++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++OU++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++OU+++++OU++++++++OU++++++OU+OU+OU+++++++++OU++++++++++++++OU++OU+++++OU++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++OU+++++++++OU++++++OU++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++OU+++++++OU++OU+++OU+++++OU++++++OU++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++OU++OU+++OU++++++++++++++++OU+OU+++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++OU++++OU+++++OU++++++++++++++++++OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+OU+++++++++++OU++++++OU++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++OU+++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++OU+++++OU++OU+++OU++++++OU+OU+++++++++OU++++++++++++OU++++++++OUOU++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++OU+++++++OUOU+E.+++++[]]]][]][{UO{^)]]-P++++++P:]+++PD-};N)}:++E.U)!-E:R[{UO):};{UOD+^(])R+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++P:};{N()UO:+E;}")
```

Alternatively, [Try It In Headass!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@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), works the same way but outputs the character codes rather than the actual characters, which I personally deem unacceptable but whatever :P

#### Explanation

It's basically just the vanilla Encode, Print Encoding, Print Decoding style quine. Still on the hunt for a more clever trick to do it shorter but I thought this would be fun to start as a benchmark lol.

EDIT: was able to save quite a few (2313) bytes by writing a program to (mildly) optimize which characters were assigned which values, changed up the structure of code block 2 to have a loop (as discovered in previous revision), and removing a constant amount from each of the ascii values in the encoding and adding it back on in decoding later instead.

```
+OU…UOU+OU…+E.  code block 0 (heavily abridged / altered)
                (this block handles encoding)
                encode part 1: many of the following
+                 n +s: increment r0 by n, 1<=n<=20
 O                enqueue r0
  U               set r0 to 0
   …            (these encode which of the characters from
                encode part 2 are going to be decoded later)
    UO          enqueue a 0 to delimit parts 1 and 2
                encode part 2: 20 of the following
       +          n +s: increment r0 by n, n being
                  an ascii character code minus 33
        O         enqueue r0
         U        set r0 to 0
          …     (these encode the actual ascii character
                codes, and we'll add 33 to them later.
                we can call this little index of values
                our "table" of ascii values)
           +E   go to code block 1
             .  end code block

+…[]]]][]][{UO{^)]]-P+…P:]+++PD-};N)}:++E.  code block 1 (edited)
                                            (this block prints the encoding)
+…                                            5 +s: r0 = 5
  [                                           r2 = r0
   ]]]]                                       r0 = r2*4
       [                                      r2 = r0
        ]]                                    r0 = r2*2
          [                                   r2 = r0
+…[]]]][]][                                 r2 = 40
           {UO                    N)}:      for each value x on the queue
               ^                              r1 = x
              {^)       :     D-};            while r1--
                         ]+++P                  print ascii r2+3
                                              (r2==40, 43 is +'s ascii
                                              this loop prints x +s)
                 ]]-P                         print ascii r2*2-1
                     +…                       6 +s: => r0 = 49
                       P                      print ascii r2+9
                                              (these two print O and U to
                                              go after each string of +s)
                                      ++E   go to code block 2
                                         .  end code block

U)!-E:R[{UO):};{UOD+^(])R+…P:};{N()UO:+E;}  code block 2 (edited)
                                            (this block decodes the encoding)
U                                           x = queue.pop()
 )   :                                      if x==0
                                            (meaning we've reached the 0
                                            delimiter separating the two
                                            halves of encoded data)
  !                                           ACTUALLY print 
                                              (explanation below code block)
   -E                                         go to code block -1 (halt)
      R[                                    r2 = x
        {UO):};                             cycle through queue until
                                            we reach the 0 delimiter
                UO                          cycle to next x
               {  D+^(])    :};             while r1++ != r2
                UO                            cycle to next x
                        R+…P                R 33 +s P:print ascii table[x]+33
                               {N()UO:  ;}  cycle through remainder of queue
                                            (language quirk mandates this...
                                            i think these two loops can maybe
                                            be one loop, but its nontrivial)
                                      +E    go to code block 2
```

So in Headass, `P` just prints whatever number is in r0. In Headascii, `P` appends the ascii character for the value at r0 to a global "output" string, which can be printed with `!`. That's kind of wordy though and didn't fit in the little margin up there. #fermat

Comment: Apparently I [already wrote a quine in headascii back in 2021](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Quine). It's 2445 bytes, so it was shorter than the first attempt here, but longer than the most recent revision to date. Approach looks pretty different at a glance, hopefully I can reverse engineer and study it, maybe learn something to golf the whole thing down further.

Answer (score 5):

### C++ (350)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
int main(){std::ofstream f;f.open("f.cpp");
#define B(x)x;f<<("B(" #x ")");
#define A(x)f<<("A(" #x ")");x;
B(f<<("#include<iostream>\n#include<fstream>\nint main(){std::ofstream f;f.open(\"f.cpp\");\n#define B(x)x;f<<(\"B(\" #x \")\");\n#define A(x)f<<(\"A(\" #x \")\");x;\n"))A(f<<("f.close();}\n"))f.close();}
```

Modified version of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29#C).

Makes use of the C++ preprocessor.

Answer (score 5):

## CSS, 47 bytes

```
<style>:before,*{display:block;content:'<style>
```

Paste into a blank HTML page to avoid conflict with other tags.

Comment: Wouldn't this technically be HTML with embedded CSS in it? Also, what browser did this successfully quine in, because when I test this with an empty HTML file, it displays `:before,*{display:block;content:'<style>` on the window.

Comment: This doesn't work as HTML has implicit `html`, `head` and `body` tags.

Comment: @KonradBorowski But technically HTML still works if you leave out the tags on modern browsers.

Answer (score 5):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), 1 byte

```
Q
```

The interpreter evaluates undefined symbols as strings, and the result of the last expression evaluated is automatically printed at the end of the program. What's interesting is that *any* undefined identifier can be used; `I_am_a_quine!` is also a quine.

Comment: This does not satisfy [our rules for proper quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878/8478) as the `Q` only encodes itself (as does any character in `I_am_a_quine!`).

Comment: Agreed @MartinEnder, but the challenge does not specify proper quines.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

I present to you *the shortest* non-source-reading quine in JavaScript:

```
console.log(a="console.log(a=%s,uneval(a))",uneval(a))
```

How have I not thought of this before? Screw that, how has *nobody* thought of this before? :P

Here's a version that works in all browsers at the cost of 9 bytes:

```
q='"';console.log(a="q='%s';console.log(a=%s,q,q+a+q)",q,q+a+q)
```

Comment: If this works in the browser, you can make `console.log` be `alert`.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Nope. The `%s` in the string only works with `console.log`.

Comment: ahhh that's what that was.

Comment: Lolp I was trying to do that a while ago, I couldn't figure out string formatting

Answer (score 5):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 88 bytes

The byte count includes a trailing newline.

```
((q (g (c (c (q q) g) (c (c (q q) g) ())))) (q (g (c (c (q q) g) (c (c (q q) g) ())))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/19Do1BBI11BIxmMChUKNRXSNTG4miCgQLxSTa7//wE)

There are no strings in tinylisp, but a nontrivial quine is still possible because code is lists and lists are code. The above code is a list which, when evaluated, returns (and therefore prints) itself.

The idea is to pass the list `(g (c (c (q q) g) (c (c (q q) g) ())))` to a function which will wrap it in a list, tack a `q` on the front, and then wrap two copies of *that* in a list. Which is exactly what the function `(q (g (c (c (q q) g) (c (c (q q) g) ()))))` does. In-depth explanation available on request, but I wanted to post this before turning in for the night.

Answer (score 5):

### C++, 117 bytes

```
#include<cstdio>
#define Q(S)char*q=#S;S
Q(int main(){printf("#include<cstdio>\n#define Q(S)char*q=#S;S\nQ(%s)",q);})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJrm4JCUz345LOSU1LTMvVSFQI1gzOSOxSKvQVjnYOpgrUCMzr0QhNzEzT0OzuqAIyEnTUELXHZOHQ3tMXqCGarGmkk6hpnWt5v//AA)

Comment: What compiler does this use?  This does not appear to work on `gcc`.

Comment: It works on my gcc 4.9.2.

Comment: Ok. According to clang, this is not valid C++, since the return type of `main()` is missing. I fixed that now.

Comment: My version of gcc was 4.2.1 (I should update some time).  Now that `main` has a return type it works.

Comment: Suggest using `auto q` to make it standards compliant

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge-98 (`cfunge`), 8 characters

```
 'k<@,k␇
```

`␇` represents a literal BEL character (ASCII 7, or Ctrl-G). (Note also that the program starts with a leading space.)

Note that the `k` command, which is heavily used here, is somewhat imprecisely defined, and this code is outright exploiting several edge cases at once, making this an example of corner-case code. As such, this is somewhat interpreter-dependent; it doesn't work on TIO, for example. `cfunge` is the Befunge-98 interpreter I normally use locally (and has been tested to be highly conformant with the specification), and it handles this code correctly. (Update: I've been talking to some Befunge experts about this quine, and the consensus is that it's exploiting a bug in `cfunge`, not behaviour that's defensible by the specification. Still a valid answer, though, because languages are defined by their implementation and this is the sort of corner case that has no right answers, only wrong answers.)

This program would also work in Unefunge-98 and Trefunge-98, but I'm not sure if any of the pre-existing interpreters for those handle `k` in the way we need, so it may be noncompeting in those languages.

### Verification

```
$ xxd /tmp/quine.b98
00000000: 2027 6b3c 402c 6b07                       'k<@,k.
$ ./cfunge /tmp/quine.b98 | xxd
00000000: 2027 6b3c 402c 6b07                       'k<@,k.
```

### Explanation

#### General principles

We know that in fungeoids, it's normally easiest to [wrap a string around the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117550/62131), so that the code is inside and outside the string literal at the same time. However, another trick for shortening quines is to [use a string representation which doesn't need escaping](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115545/62131), so that we don't need to spend bytes to represent the string delimiter itself. So I decided to see if these techniques could be combined.

Befunge-98 normally uses `"` as a string delimiter. However, you can also capture a single character using `'`, and you can make any command into a sort of lightweight loop (in a confusing and buggy way) using `k`. As such, `k'` functions as a sort of makeshift length-prefixed string literal. And of course, a length-prefixed string literal has no problems in escaping its own delimiter, as it doesn't have any sort of string terminator at all, meaning that the entire range of octets (in fact, the entire range of cell values) are available to exist within the string.

We can actually do even better; we no longer have to stop the string at its opening delimiter (we can stop it anywhere), so we can wrap it multiple times around the program to grab not only the `k'` itself, but also the length of the string (which is in this case written as a character code, thus the literal backspace). The program will continue execution just after the end of the string, i.e. just after the last character captured, which is exactly where we want it. (Bear in mind that Befunge strings are printed in reverse order to pushing them; the most common form, NUL-terminated strings, are called "0gnirts" by the community because of this, and length-prefixed strings follow the same principle. Thus if we want the length to end up at the start of the string, we have to push it last.)

As an extra bonus, this also means that we can wrap multiple times around the program with no penalty; all that matters is that the last character we see is the string length (which is at the end of the program). By an amazing stroke of luck, `k'` specifies length-prefixed string (sort-of; `k` is weird), and `'k` (the same two characters in reverse order) pushes 107, which happens to loop round the program multiple times and end up in exactly the right place (this only had a 1 in 8 chance of working out). Because we have to reverse the program direction anyway (to read the string in the reverse of the natural reading order, meaning that it gets printed in the same order it appeared in the original program), we can use the same two characters for both pushing the length, and pushing the string itself, at no cost.

Of course, this now captures a risk of counting as a literal-only program, and thus not a proper quine under PPCG rules. Luckily, wrapping round from one end of the program to the other produces a literal space character, and spaces at the ends of the line (i.e. leading and trailing whitespace) aren't captured as part of a string. Thus, if we start the program with a space, we can encode that space (which isn't part of the string literal) via the implicit space that we get from wrapping the program (i.e. the leading space is encoded by the `'` next to it, rather than by itself), just sneaking within the proper quine rules. The easiest way to see this is to delete the leading space from the program; you'll get the same output as the program with the leading space (thus effectively proving that it doesn't encode itself, because even if you remove it it still gets printed).

#### Detailed description

```
 'k<@,k␇
 'k       Push 107 to the stack
   <      Set execution delta to leftwards
 'k       Push the next 107 characters to the stack: "'␠␇k, … @<ck'␠␇"
     ,k   Pop a length from the stack, output that many characters
     ,    Output the top stack element
    @     Exit the program
```

You can note that `k` has some odd ideas of where to start reading the string from (for the first `k` that runs), or where to leave the IP afterwards (for the second `k` that runs); this is just the way `k` happens to work (you think of `k` as taking an "argument", the command to run, but it doesn't actually move the IP to skip the "argument"; so if the command inside the loop doesn't affect the IP or the IP's movement, it'll end up being the next command that runs and the loop runs one more time). The literal BEL, ASCII 7, is interpreted by the second `k` as a loop counter, so the `,` inside the `k` will print the first 7 characters, then the `,` outside the `k` (which is the same character in the source) will print the 8th just before the program exits.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```
eval s="$><<'eval s=';p s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P7UsMUeh2FZJxc7GRh3KUbcuUChW4vr/HwA)

`$><<'...'` is equivalent to `print'...'` (outputs the string without a newline).

Note the newline at the end of the program.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer :)

Comment: doesn't `p` print a newline?

Comment: @Shelvacu You're right; it should be 27 bytes. Interestingly, I went back and looked around, and I couldn't find any Ruby quines that included a newline in their source to match the output. Most seem to add an extra newline in their output like this one did. I also have a vague memory of coming across a 25-byte Ruby quine somewhere, I think in a demonstration of a new-at-the-time feature, but I haven't been able to find it again.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

I've fantasized about a 9-byte Japt quine for years, and now it's finally snapped into place :-D

```
9îQi"9îQi
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Oe5RaSI57lFp&input=)

#### Explanation

```
    "9îQi    Start with this string.               9îQi
  Qi         Insert it before a quotation mark.    9îQi"
9î           Repeat until it reaches length 9.     9îQi"9îQi
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
-2*6<>:#,_@#:-5: _-p<"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X9dIy8zGzkpZJ95B2UrX1EohXrfARun/fwA)

Thanks to [jimmy23013's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159552/76162) for inspiring the idea to create the `"` before the wrapping string literal.

[Previous answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106791/76162) have usually relied on non-standard interpreter behaviour in order to wrap a string literal around the code and avoid the extra spaces. My quine however, is compliant with Befunge-93 specs.

Befunge-93 has a bounding box of 80x25 cells, which are initially filled with spaces. This means the wrapping string literal, a staple of 2D quines, usually fills the stack with a *lot* of excess spaces.

#### How It Works:

```
-2*6<  Create the " character
                     " Start the wrapping string literal
                 _-p<  Pop all the spaces until there are none left
                       Note that p is the put command, which basically pops 3 items from the stack
            :-5:  Dupe the 2 and subtract 5 to replace the - that was destroyed
                  Dupe that again to compensate for the _
     >:#,_@#  Print until stack is empty and terminate
```

Alternatively:

```
++9*5<>:#,_@#::_$#-< "
```

also works for 22 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 406 bytes

***DISCLAIMER:** This quine was not created by me, **it is created by Smithers**. Because this challenge was missing a Whitespace answer I decided to post his/her. If Smithers reads this and wants to post it himself/herself I will of course delete my answer.

Sources: [Smithers' website](http://cpjsmith.uk/) and [his/her Whitespace quine source code (note: it's missing a trailing new-line)](http://cpjsmith.uk/downloads/whitespace/quine-cs-3.ws).*

```
[S S S T    S S T   S T T   T   T   T   S T T   T   S S T   T   S S S T S T T   S T T   T   T   T   T   T   S T S S S T S S T   S S T   S T T   T   T   T   S T S T S S S T T   T   S S T   S T T   S S S S T   T   T   T   T   T   S S T   T   T   S T S T S S S T T   T   S S S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   T   S T S S T   S S S T S T T   T   T   S S S S S T S T S S S T S T T   S T S S S T S S T   S S T   T   T   S S S S S S S T T   S T S S T   T   T   T   T   S S S T T   T   T   S S T   T   S T T   S S T   S T T   T   T   S S S S T   T   S S T   T   T   T   S T S S T   T   S S T   S S T   T   S S S S T   T   S S T   T   S S T   S S T   T   S T S T S T T   S S S T T   S T S N
_Push_67079405567184005086107571748115383207539763039497665210559156555730234138][S N
S _Duplicate][N
S T S N
_Call_Label_PRINT_SPACE][N
S T S N
_Call_Label_PRINT_SPACE][S S S T    S N
_Push_2][S N
T   _Swap][N
S T N
_Call_Label_RECURSIVE_PRINTER][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10][T N
S S _Print_as_char][S N
N
_Drop][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3][S N
T   _Swap][N
S T N
_Call_Label_RECURSIVE_PRINTER][N
N
N
_Exit][N
S S N
_Create_Label_RECURSIVE_PRINTER][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_DISCARD_TOP(_AND_PRINT_SPACE)][S T  S S T   N
_Copy_1][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_1][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_1][T  S T S _integer_divide][N
S T N
_Call_Label_RECURSIVE_PRINTER][T    S T T   _Modulo][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_DISCARD_TOP(_AND_PRINT_SPACE)][S S S T  S S S N
_Push_8][T  S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
T   N
_Return][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_DISCARD_TOP(_AND_PRINT_SPACE)][S N
N
_Discard][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_SPACE][S S S T  S S S S S N
_Push_32][T N
S S _Print_as_character][N
T   N
_Return]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VU9BDsMwCDubV/hr01Rpu03apD0/wxiWNqkg2GDT7@P5Od6v2/1YiyT0QUcxC9CIQeXp2o3G0BBd9PiF5ubQIq1ihtttu5wGu0YLej/gLNKu3cpJQwyAWbXeUTdzhbJOAFlFrxX1iioxnA49DLVK@hKtXRn/Lv92lLnGIRFplvrwtGWGtX4) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Whitespace is a stack-based language only using three characters: spaces, tabs and new-lines. In Whitespace the stack can only contain integers, and there are two options to print something to STDOUT: "Print as number" and "Print as character". In the case of "Print as character" it will print the character based on the unicode value at the top of the stack. Because whitespace uses spaces, tabs and new-lines, it means it'll have to print numbers 32, 9, and 10 respectively as characters to STDOUT for this quine.

Smithers uses a pretty ingenieus piece of code with the magic number (s)he found.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
Push 67079405567184005086107571748115383207539763039497665210559156555730234138
Duplicate top
Call function_PRINT_SPACE
Call function_PRINT_SPACE
Push 2
Swap top two
Call function_RECURSIVE_PRINTER
Push 10
Pop and print top as character
Discard top
Push 3
Swap top two
Call function_RECURSIVE_PRINTER
Exit program

function_RECURSIVE_PRINTER:
  Duplicate top
  If 0: Call function_DISCARD_TOP(_AND_PRINT_SPACE)
  Make a copy of the 2nd top item of the stack
  Make a copy of the 2nd top item of the stack
  Make a copy of the 2nd top item of the stack
  Integer-divide top two
  Call function_RECURSIVE_PRINTER
  Modulo top two
  Duplicate top
  If 0: Call function_DISCARD_TOP(_AND_PRINT_SPACE)
  Push 8
  Add top two
  Pop and print top as character
  Return

function_DISCARD_TOP(_AND_PRINT_SPACE):
  Discard top
function_PRINT_SPACE:
  Push 32
  Pop and print top as character
  Return
```

It first uses a recursive-loop which keeps integer-dividing the initial integer by **2** until it's 0. Once it's 0, it goes back over these values and does modulo-**2**, printing either a space (if the modulo-2 resulted in 0) or a tab (by adding 8 to the modulo-2 result of 1). This first part is used to print the magic number itself, which only consists of spaces and tabs, because pushing a number in Whitespace is done as follows (and thus doesn't contain any new-lines except for the single trailing one):

- `S`: Enable Stack Manipulation
- `S`: Push a number
- `S`/`T`: Positive/Negative respectively
- Some `S`/`T`, followed by a trailing `N`: The number as binary, where `S=0` and `T=1`

After it has printed the spaces and tabs required for pushing the magic number itself, it pushes a **3** and will use the same recursive function with the magic number, integer-dividing and using modulo 3 instead of 2. Which will print the spaces (if the modulo-3 resulted in 0), or tabs/new-lines (by adding 8 to the modulo-3 result).

Comment: You may be interested in my [new Whitespace quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194067/76162)

Comment: @JoKing Very nice! Well done! :)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
echo(,quote)'echo(,quote)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/rv56SnoKSnoJ6mYGulrqCjUGulYKAAxP9TkzPyNXQKS/NLUjXVUThcYE2a/wE)

It's surprising that there's no proper J quine submission yet.

#### How it works

```
echo(,quote)'echo(,quote)'
            'echo(,quote)'  The string `s`
      quote                 Wrap `s` with single quotes
     ,                      Concat s to the above; `(f g)x` is equal to `x f g x`
echo                        Explicitly print the result
```

`echo` is needed because the result of a non-REPL line is not printed.

Answer (score 5):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), 834 bytes

```
(|11+"*"+"1+\1+/)("|1/()11+^)(2|\""++1+/()""+^)++<+/(#|\##"\+;1#()\^\1#)+<+()()(")(2)(2)()()(")()(2)(")(2)()(")()(")()()()(2)(")()()()(2)()()(2)()(")()()()()(2)(2)(")()()()(2)()()(2)()(")(2)()(")(2)(")()(")()()()(2)(")(2)(2)()(")()(2)(")()()()(2)()()(2)()(")(")()(")()(")()()()(2)()()(2)()(")(2)()(2)()(2)(")()(")(2)(")()()(2)()(")()(2)(")(2)(2)()()(")()(2)(")()(2)(")(2)()(")()()()()(2)(2)(")()(2)(")(")(")(2)()(")(2)(")()()(2)()(")()(2)(")()()()(2)(")()(2)(")()(2)(")(")(")()()()(2)()()(2)()(")(2)()(2)()(2)(")()()()(2)()(")(2)(")(2)()(")()()()()(2)(2)(")()(2)(")()()()(2)(")()()()(2)(")(2)()(")(2)(")()()(2)()(")()()()(2)(")(2)()(2)()(2)(")(")(2)(")(2)()(")()()(2)()(")()(2)(")()()()(2)(")()()()(2)()()(2)()(")()(2)(")()()()(2)(")(")()(2)(")(")(2)()()(")(")()(2)(")()()()(2)(")()()()(2)(")(2)()(2)()(2)(")(2)(")(2)()()(2)(")(")(#)@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVbj9pGFH7nV5wdP@BZGxt7t0pKFqnZSIlardBqmzxU4EXGHoJV3zIe9qLS307P2BjGGJwtIDNz5jvfuc5x/ipWWeputxqshMiLkW3nPg/iV@G/sNgS62QRcyvIEjvPCmG/fzd8/8s75/rK@dWOUsF4zhk@B8uMD5xBlA7ykq/X0y7sdcHtRZTaLH2CnVgDxwBFD9dwXx/dl3bhqzQMNvzBOEvkNjXBHTrXiLiLApYGDKICPn2C278Gf36Ea2uI4M8f78CxrnD1ZfINvtzfPV31oiTPuIDitegteZZAkMUxC0SUpQXszkL2Y816vcKEIoRxtdWpCf/82@uFbAlZyvJ4XegFYscwwS0d9QA/0RLSDLm5qPY7WcxSHe1ZPv/@ROFiDO7hWH5yjsED@Vb439kICBhQo6dDD3cEpssoZiAyWDBgLyxYCxZ6pEEiVdhLJHSHHmynOTqY5Yr9qeOZ0Of9A4j7zwhCqMWZH@oNbSuIs4LtZCwu0L0KjiGWsvKxSkx4MGFRCBNuTZjg@dST6TIPuRvirwRjT0AgK4xEjSwFMB5DX@83c3MLxhichgjtWH6OQYX6hLYZaIthcMzwMJUceZbr1JMVbBwi0S3cwLDJotTp92Thxz52XAgL7gd/M1FckBZ4Xw/3hI9aH/w0RDu4GY4wgScCmhwiL126GKs@vcmXYx/Kx8SEIJGNiyX57GNNS@nzSnbYBAOX3Yq1oQdbmewiFE0nnhqKbHVkGh1nT8IxRqc/gqKOS2nKqpUOOEPFFVVV5BWoVuf1Lk/pXf5cjzT0pgPHO4@1SyzPhC9YVwyzmQocdCAfSyB7EdL6dOesWXvd4cqN6vZQ5rmO@Wa/kjcUOoxryCFv5yqpLXtnsZZqz18UOvab7Is5joW10PspvgMYH@F9ox3JNlWWjIcqQ7DysWVFRYKTroNmhDRVx@/8Pov8IA1i2xcizNbCeuYRFmSdRsGK103SYWeK2tXl@MrX7CzseEiVY1Sk9S3B7nVGD3hbPAvfmiKSLxe9v@nTlhJSoh7OZHQ6nMrl0JMTSa5crwXfv3j22DalrO@DelPLsX3mjnr7eA@TQJk9CJzPUz9h87mEk/k88aN0PicVX@0O3W71jeMY5JIYxDFmjmFTnWwcW6cofaS6u5kRYhgo1ykuHqlh3OBa28w0jcyMD46m09njzNEoynWKX4JK5W@3KddkJyH7x@Fgv97/7YU11TmU8n@K2VX5OmjISddahlyVhqiMbjvWdgLaiWiF6NbunIitI5YTRsj/ieXo9C0@nizgT7w@QrkNb9t2u8M92TNtIDk2opb8DaG4jT1RbVYsGv1ta5Vj0cJh8R8)

Defines all the subroutines before the data section, then calls the `(#)` subroutine at the end of the data. Instead of using `1`s followed by totalling `1+`s, we define subroutines for initialisation (`(")`), which pushes a `2` to the stack, incrementing (`()`), and doubling plus 2 (ironically, `(2)`). All of these also push the characters used to call the subroutine to the top of the stack to print after printing the rest. We also offset the data by 32, since all values are above that.

This is most certainly suboptimal, especially since I've been steadily golfing it down from ~2000 bytes. I suspect it can be sub-500 eventually, or even lower with a different strategy.

Here's my [program encoder](https://tio.run/##NY7RbsIwDEXf@YrIQcSOaUJg2sM2@AlekJaBKo1NTB10zSYxNe2vF3fSZD/43GtfuT421f0wpPJXYcZU/TS1e6tOtftuynNCH5NX640CIHdpXpPaFas7mq8W5D7LGg0CmR6Q4GrJfVxOZzdrcXqYt9uH99YgjWUU/k/EnVorIXPF6aIIpHqhJZnOOWePX5aebRFeVCcxW/@X7sdD3/UjjK3JDAPmEBgsMASOgb04OcimqHua4DJHAGYx5DMQifmJ/QR1jlpD5MegkeI@Bk1i3AA), though it needs some post-fiddling with the first value to make sense.

Answer (score 5):

## *[Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)*, 270 bytes

```
936025123570680582070742833115365117904492153588422750562053064415808293823109091171562255866020953926270476903421472061856963432351191541604543106801928196867870451324872393884426634
Count a while a-183 {
Write 48+(_/10^(182-a))%10
}
Count b while _ {
Write _%128
_/128
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NSgNxEMPv@xR7KbRIcZL5@M@cfQhvLttSsCAKUvEgPvs6h@IxJL8k6/l8Om1baQgdVB8SKZ6UIcOYqoBrODBKzIqtPNPI4eJBcZUwg6ckS5MKKamOo126Z3SzlGsxOMRGlKgRNiiB9KhQ0x4GCm4IMbcu6RcoJioyRjboUFoOaq@kGaO56enj6/02r/P36/XtMq9HpM4/0/Pn9XaZLR/2yyPkZY/kcT0cdpDp946c7sjyH192YE4NMLftDw)

#### Explanation

```
...                          Set the accumulator to a large number
Count a while a-183 {        Loop from 0 to 182
Write 48+(_/10^(182-a))%10   Print the ath digit of the number
}
Count b while _ {            Loop while the accumulator is not zero
Write _%128                  Print the character of the accumulator modulo 128
_/128                        Integer divide the accumulator by 128
```

Comment: Does base95 (or 92 for that matter) save any bytes?

Comment: @emanresuA I still have to represent newlines, so i don't think i can without making the decoding section much longer. I can do base 126 instead, but that doesn't save anything

Answer (score 5):

### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax) (packed), 43 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å3o╞╝&∞╝7►JôyG♦◄╨s│*T→╢φY'┘ò☼≤⌠░▼e╓Δ█•Aφ/│.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdBPS8NAEAXwez/FOykIzv7NrpEqSKyiBBRaDz2V3exuLWgiJkIEv3tc2158h7kM84N53vWvU@MGzOeLpzv8YBwDzj9xjaYLceLHXOLCKAWTGgPfSIPY@AbKCg7tSgVbaguuhQBIdUQnRJYe6fueaHYQRDYCtwpeSYdCCwdvYkBRSotQlgV4SgpJe56Nns5WRLQ@pX2OhsyGSKZAMCkheG6hRTZk8goy4l8o/l3eECOa8muzutpUq/Xz4iq2m5clvblh1wq8d20H1n0MrB/cyJZ51K7dUlU/ML9r2W30X9v9juIY96UcSpp@AQ)

#### Doesn't work because for some reason latin1 does not accept the C1 control codes.

For this version, the interpreter needs to be forced to output in latin1. Stax Encoding is used. There is an extra trailing newline, but this appears to be accepted here (judging from many other answers).

#### Explanation:

The unpacked source is:

```
"r{32-m2+c+95|EVB|EB128+s+"r{32-m2+c+95|EVB|EB128+s+
```

- The first half simply pushes the string which is also the second half.
- The second half builds the full unpacked source out of it and packs it:

  ```
  r{32-m2+c+95|EVB|EB128+s+ Second half
  r{32-m                    Reverse and subtract 32 from each character (for packing)
        2+                  Append 2 (double quote - 32)
          c+                Concatenate with self
            95|E            Decode as a base 95 integer (for packing)
                VB|E        Encode as a base 256 interager (for packing)
                    B128+s+ Add 128 to the first byte (for packing)
                            Implicit output
  ```

### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax) (packed), 103 bytes (50 characters)

```
üö╖╞╖┘û■Å╣ß$æi7⌐ê↔T)ç¢┤,I_º>┐ó♫Z╪Æ≤◄▐0σ▓☻E.α╬TÅ¶7É
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8194b7c6b7d996fe8fb9e124916937a9881d5429879bb42c495fa73ebfa20e5ad892f311de30e5b202452ee0ce548f143790&i=&m=2)

Source and output are UTF-8 here, so they are counted as such. Much longer, but UTF-8 is a little nicer to look at.

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) `-r`, 32 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Sisyphus' insight!

The content of this quine is mostly unprintable characters using the stringwise NOT operator so the test link is to Bash to rebuild the file from an `xxd` hexdump.

```php
eval(~$_=.....................);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5LDoJAEET3c4pasIAFhO9AS/QqZpgeI4kgCigL49URovFDrEWlqlN56UK1@3EYGO4ZXlk3fed15REbnPqyNl6zb3Ihrhqu/rlo1X06bqg4afsqF3ObSJY9h/fA@VoIM5TdaC7qYN@t7dr7JycfR/@lFWSSSshAaoRZahDGyQ4RkwJpSkE@M0hlBCyh4kkIJgYZisBpFkBFXED5OgQXygdLHYN5spCiAlg@8gA)

### Explanation

In PHP it's possible to use the `~` operator to 'flip' all the bits in a byte to return a string that doesn't look anything like the original string, which works around the problem of having to encode, and then decode, things like quotes. This means it's possible to just call `echo` on the result.

[Visual example of how `~` 'flips' the values.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyCjQEG3SEG9oCgzr0RDyVFJ01q9pqIiRUE3iQtVrg5F8v9/AA)

This was built using the following approach:

```php
$quine =
    // plain beginning 
    "eval(~\$_=".
    // flipped code with $_ interpolated
    ~'echo"eval(~\$_=$_);";' .
    // plain end
    ");"
;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZCxCsJADIb3e4pQC21B6uR0ipPgINgHEM7ai/bgTGO9qpOvXs9qRQfNkCH/l@RPuOR2MmOfw2NjCGEqwMdoBGxzQ7DFvSEytIeuHuA5t/FtHappkPbkzhpm1FBUGuFiXAmhAkMOa65s7lB34C3Coqw@BoQqkYGMIP3eiPTkA68KKQTXflR8crVFip8mk0S@ytkiU/PVMuk5OOhxD/1i/uidud/yAHbGouLGqaLy95E7xVFHp/6D0RDerQN4HLu5XjW89Y0UbXsH)

Comment: 32 bytes - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5LDoJAEET3c4pasIAFhO9AS/QqZpgeI4kgCigL49URovFDrEWlqlN56UK1@3EYGO4ZXlk3fed15REbnPqyNl6zb3Ihrhqu/rlo1X06bqg4afsqF3ObSJY9h/fA@VoIM5TdaC7qYN@t7dr7JycfR/@lFWSSSshAaoRZahDGyQ4RkwJpSkE@M0hlBCyh4kkIJgYZisBpFkBFXED5OgQXygdLHYN5spCiAlg@8gA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sisyphus Of course! I'll update this later. Thank you! It's quite a competitive quine now!

Answer (score 5):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 22 bytes

```
E=s"O+'E=s'++A34sA34"
```

Includes trailing newline.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCey8FVt2cgUyUKKOgJZSG4/gC8IWQbVyrJPkmFZwv71XHfPi0Z@yV3ulqpY1szTPd3P9HT3OFH3Loq@vUqyKF1O4v2inCTz1/ejpjmSJre1oah8WsQroDzJ7mpDZTITmEk8TbKYpSlL59kdfTT16Kezzx9Yr3q9/HTB/Or1H4cXrF@9Hp@9Yz9VrxefWa8CH59eGtizz6cG9PPZh8PLv9sFZzZ@tNmfvb9xPXt4CcuKyeg@zJnDKwETBbZqFaMR61dzZ0e/4mQGk@TRV4bf9/dXMLgMYdBNwKQpR2AN8/b8/JRA@HFATg7QN8OQi/cCAPKGrQ9huow5v8rGvNkkP2BXrsbBRevo/Nj@dhQUrfOOBQ@r0znc6xfwr9X8xmGyNRR4BwTicMYClBw2m6B@EeZFbHP23GwkWcmSYbMBo7SUy5zpMotghIQjeC9nC7dYZFf@OHj2XO8FdDQSUEd4eHo48OYNqk8W7PE@KeNiEUZxswHf09iGcRC3hRkua12X19n19Dpnzy9XY5sPXrU4mdJIpszW1gbMemVxJlSo0R0Yvc5guNMRI2BnI06L2Bx4EeZE93H0G5vOc5YtZ7dxXkh7mJ0Uk@QuKZVWWB3d6bnaI/F0WM9jHeZIyzsdzrrM8ixYAi1NOMvjcplnTAWHEKP4GK7a8BDmSXibxsoKMCKdP8a5HcF6yhD29StTxkX0FhERXywu6Uk2uJ4EPRf2KNDDK9bhcZNhCZBsslzYuKVMctpl8LZusDj8hdAmzLi2rMqmliU2DYTBA20UAyWQLOA7WLYIi5KV9zEoC/MSwHIDHMUobmjE0RNlrHGGthoLnz1OG92oyCDzMXTLZJ6B2Rix3hhMixQjxXKxQMK5iio1YtJvxh/QbpCNOlQoLzKIY0hcGLnScsHKJ0ufbjFwjAOYxAaYvNBMFWSU94SrNtqNpoZpOo/svuf2ODqIw9oJcjBbpmmYP5mOVvtzYWzPR0tbRgtK@WW2Ik1L9HAJmRQ2eXp49PbdzS87pz@fGw6bam@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@DLIwb5NTUr3sCGshy4dUhSsEtZ1ljqWLOs@rMX@uwgwaKMrtYuELWLiuO4eMZ/O29/sU/yrkR0CCVsHRXVym0DTabdrLNu4QlshJkvHhZkvgwanIC21HQpvoC/GsS3e1NFIgM2Nlw9vKWoHXM@@qGZQ0CdSYG8DgXkN0BYv5Is5sY2G3lbeoEQCrgpmogxBtge/1f6Jx2TrYot@YgukTdAoaNAhIF7s3gENnQG@4BiytgseGQdYJqNHB8whILskEPbQWEYkanID5ZkdS0Vh58gt4Ev8OTRqe5TU/d2p7Sp3/DuapNeDp2ubDKmmdFwP@szWQXeCGMNV5TdaX1hk1vTZWGK5KzGjU51XbuJbslOgltX72boGC9VBfFwY6obEx14U8yVsVVE1g8YjDTKrdVqBkRTJ3QGYOycJ5xQKGvbjWIGliP2vUsXabrkvdLkLHoom9pma6oczafe0UYI8Nb5ypg5Qb5i/LQu2@jgnRyQmDOtogyoKQDTHhYmgZ2yN65UZ9t8XdE9HQ1TMVS77Yc@xu6TCIDSAUDmOqDpSXPt8cqlFYqofsKXudiiauvqMuDr2mS89S5gjpV3ctOo1ox0a8bq8Qcqrd2cDCavHdwIOzxoPY100szDa45hAmMJWQAFQYm8pcYF3DFQ5Bw26X9EmiqCCubrRgtKyd/jffJebNZmJ2vyu0u1non8RmzSFxMaAx3/RyKGkXrAes29MsExao78E56/bgjPVMsP@D6H1IjzVsECCU1h2oEU9RTkT7I09y7XNqRpyA@G@uHgiaJFfgBkAJFksMfMcLwX2cx1bBsjl0yElaJhl7DJ@ANzaZw42zjO/iHGQW8yzOyiTEOwKc5Dl7jNl9@BADUCpCeMlmYbaE8Hl6jaPo3S0yDlQQE8UyLfEnAVpcJzwF6ZoYteQKZaachqyoR33bkd52QzRsv4by6PYdplgbn8DrbJLGE3ZTmX2jtTzjN9F2GYtUzoxQWber3jnBGxLqGKa/6Dy4T8G6Uvgw6dXyYlDPigfMPPz75jFA0YH8Va3NBOCA1dpAGnSZkQ1RhyckVcn1RR1A7E4A1cbogkZwKDG05pP5gM3iWbTAMMvY6Obg/3Vl9Be4MlKu7GzwJZC@SFcOtrMvVt1gMk4fsBrA1whfFdCdTXZWL9o9lXlMBdq8dpX@0JdNteHAlJSpRMt//W/kZQ4y1Gj5oTUw0bU2dxUbVFm3Pv3D1xTV21b3FMQ1ancVnQoJgxrHQU3aSJMogYhOR4sJk38F98RvWmajWfOOmb2LFDupd@0INeQP/MGeQct7cWUIjA6rYxag9XtHJi8erj4Le7WG9lIQvaJ0uFry/E0lb4/rPsDX0n0a/A8NERqGT9yKSDf/uh0yeyMfPMRVOz1skqhBEPEvJulBiI48CbD6JJ6GkCTBM9VhJhlMJhP6iSiMSihT1m5kYc@JI5xtuaOiMl0DoRuUPxPMwiTDZpWF@V3kklLHge8PHH@Motsj/ieN7ZE19Wvcy7d/Aw)

Finally figured out how to do an `EVAL` quine, after definitely not adapting the Ruby quine example on Wikipedia.

It is pretty standard. Create a string containing code to print itself, and eval it. `A34` is used to generate a double quote.

I am keeping my original idea here as well.

---

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), no eval, <s>56</s> 45 bytes

```php
O S S=p"O S S=p7F=qA34 7F+q p"7F=qA34 7F+q p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCey4Gq3bGSKZCFFHYEsJLcfwJcIWQbVybIiybAsYf96rrvnRSPb5C53ywfLM3q6p/uZnu4eE/VvoujbiySL0uU03iurabJ4eTtumzNpct2YiqqHPF4BFUl205iqkrnATONZksUsTVm6yG7oo61nP5x@fMcG9fDiwznz6@E/Ds7Zbj08On3Dfq6H5x/ZoAYfnVwY2NOPJwb04@m7g4u/2yVnNn502Z@Dv3H99uAClhUvo9uwYA6vBUwU2KpVjMdst353evgbvszgJXn0leH3vb0VDC5DGHQTMGnKEdjAvD47OyEQfuyTk0P0zTDk/K0AgLxh612YLmPOL7MJb7fJD9iVy0lw3jk8O7K/nbELdhHkHfn86Sj4crCzy3466n1heac5bH/jINMZCTUO6InDOQtQ4ajdhlXzsChjm7PHdivJKpaM2i2YJQtc5syWWQQzJBzBuJrnbplnl/4kePRc7wl0tBJQR3h4ejjx6hWqT3J2f5tUcZmHUdxuwfc0tmEexG1hhss6V9VVdjW7Ktjj0@XE5sMXHU6mtJIZs7W1AbNeWJwJFWp2C2avMpju9cQM2NmK0zI2J56EOdFtHP2LzRYFy5bz67gopT3MTsppcpNUSiusju4MXO2ReDps4LEec6TlvR5nfWZ5FiyBliacFXG1LDKmYkaIUdiMVm24C4skvE5jZQUYkS7u48KOYD1lCPv6lSnjIhpFRMQni0t6kg2uJ8HAhT0K9PSKdXgKZbQCJJsucxu3lElO@wxG6waLnFAKbcKMK8uqbepYYtNAGDzQRjFQAjkEvoNleVhWrLqNQVlYVACWG@AoRnFDI46eKGONo/WssfA54LTRrZoMMh9Dt0oWGZiNEetNwLRIMVIu8xwJ5yqq1IxJvxl/QLtBNupQoZxnEMeQzzBypeWClQ@WPvRi4ggnMLcNMaehmSrIKB0KV220G00N03QR2bueO@DoIE5rJ8jBbJmmYfFgOlrvz7mxPe8tbRktKOWX2Yo0LTHAJWRS2OTpweHrN59/3Tr55cxw2FR7nWzU66/r3Woofnt88YzGKi5IZZhN2ZdlqIao9s5cYmd9CUHAW0tzcbyBCxLebQo3MU@UKotlhjs0kjnZqRalrXIlHQAI7SqJGL29Xs4u/d2JtENsdJfSgzagzOFYVTMboOD/dppOOyrvUE1yUcmqAjgUWoGodmL9Bm6PDXaafqLzGIv7rFMVy7gDMajnMSRhfhZCBsEXHYysTk0C@om@y7JEdHx6vVik8Oa6ycCzvtZufc8h58c9Ms28XjMzRRuzv9RGCNpqkaa2aarLPBcqxP9gcrZmMlbhdwfvT12sxSLQYHh8OfA8D8IJXIGhGpXJH/GniuFjZMSo4S0yACMXP3z63AkGqqRjhsOqjg/69MVjBwBHxyeHDptBchy1dGjL9TANR2HupnFGHYDBleqaBGdw7p4jY1UQaxOWNiw4dkK9BNTiPeJiBEUlwZc6b0TzfGUHiKRkUqcQpCmZ4DLlfVJFt7YDzKw1WcARk38R1inrwBoyXEUAAiQU2zTIwrxLTkn1slFshCwfURWuEdSNVgWWLmpILyf8sQ4zaKAot4uFz2Hhpu4CMp7Nu97vM/yrke8BCVoFRzdxlUIvaXdpL7u4Q1gip0nGR5stgQenIi@0HQptoi/Esy7d1dJIgcyMtQ2va2sFXr95U79BSZNAjfkMGNxriK4gX@RxZhsLu52iQ40AWBXMRR2EaAt8b/dnmpetgy36jRmYPkWnoEGDgHSxewM4dAY0wjVgaRU8NkyyXkCNDp5HQHJJJuihtYhI1OAEzDc7kprG2pNfwZP4d2jS8Cyv@bnV2FO6EGxhnloDnqxtPqySNnkx4L9YQ9kFbghTnddkfemcUtNrY4XhqsSMx7u8bhvXkp0SvaDWz94uUbAZ6uvCQCc0Nua6kCd5p4aqF1g84jCTap8rULIimTsgM4dk4axmAcNeXGuQNLGfDepYt0u3qH4foRPRxF5RM91SZm2/dEqwx4YRZ@ogFYb5y6pUu69jQnRywqCeNoiyIGRDTLgYWsb2iF651dxtcSVFNHT1TMWSL/Ycu1s6DGIDCIXTmKoD5aXPN4dqFFbqIXvKQa@miavvqItDr@nSs5I5QvrVX4tOI9qxEW/aK4Scenc2sLBafDfw4KzxIPZ1EwvzDa45hAlMJSQAFcamMhdYV3CFQ9Co3yd9kigqiKsbLRitGqf/1XeJebWZmO3vCm1vFvonsdlwSFwMaM43vRxJ2gXrAesPNMuEBeoHcM76AzhjAxPs/yB6D9JjAxsECKV1h2rGU5QT0f7Yk1z7nJoRJyD@26sHgl6SK3ADoASLJQa@44XgNi5iq2TZAjrkJK2SjN2HD8Abmy7gxlnFN3EBMvkii7MqCfGOACd5we5jdhvexQCUihBesXmYLSF8Hl7iLHp3jYwDFcREuUwr/EmAFtcJT0H6JkYtuUKZKachK@pR3/NI73lDNGyvgfLo9h2mWBsfwOtsmsZT9rk2@7PW8ojfRNtlLFI7M0Zl/b4ac4K3JNQxTH/SeXCPgnWl8GHSa@TFoJkV95l5@PfMY4CiQ/ljW5cJwD5rtIE06TIjG6IOT0iqkuuLOoDYrQCqjdEFjeFQYmgtposhm8fzKMcwy9j48/7/68r4L3BlrFzZ2uBLIH2Rruw/z75YdYPJ@HqfNQC@RviqgG5tsrMeaPdU5jEVaPO6dfpDXzbVhn1TUqYSLf/1v5GXOchQo@VH1tBEN9rcVWxQZ93m6x@@pqjetr6nIK7VuKvoVEgY1DgJGtJGmkQJRPR6WkyY/Bu4J37TMhvNhnfM7F2k2HGza0eoIb/vD3cMWt6KK0NgdFg9swCt3zsyefFw9VnYaTS0F4LoFaWj1ZLnbyp5O1z3Ab6W3qXJ/9AQoWH4xK2IdPOv2yGzN/LBQ1y1N8AmiRoEEf/iJT0I0ZMnAVafxrMQkiR4pjrMJIOXyZR@IgqjCsqUtR1Z2HPiDGfP3FFRma6B0A3KnwnmYZJhs8rC4iZySanjwPc7jj9G0e0R/3dje2RN8xr39O3f)

Updated for the new `ASCII` function.

Includes trailing newline.

Removing the quine string and expanding the keywords/variable names, this is basically the `printf` quine:

```php
OUTPUT
  : SUBSTITUTE(
        # insert closing quote for quine_str
     : SUBSTITUTE(
        : (= quine_str "...")
        : 7
        : 0 # we use FALSE to save a space
        : (= quote ASCII(34))
     )
    # insert opening quote + quine string
    : 7
    : 0
    : (+ quote quine_str)
: )
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 21 bytes

```
do s: "prin{do }?? s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z8lX6HYSkGpoCgzrxrIrrW3VyhW@v8fAA)

### Explanation

`??` is usually used when debugging, but it's also great for quines. Take the following code:

```
s: "foo"
?? s
```

It outputs `s: "foo"`. Let's see what happens when we combine this with a `do`:

```
do s: "?? s"
```

As expected, we get `s: "?? s"`. Ignoring the `do`, it's pretty much already a quine. We can easily fix this by adding a `prin{do }` before the `?? s`:

```
do s: "prin{do }?? s"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 12 bytes

```
`q\`:Ė\`+`:Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%60q%5C%60%3A%C4%96%5C%60%2B%60%3A%C4%96&inputs=&header=&footer=)

What differences this from the other quine is an `eval` quine so is easily payload-capable - that is, all the processing code you need can go after the `+` and only needs to be iterated once.

Will be [9 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%60q%E2%80%9B%3A%C4%96%2B%60%3A%C4%96&inputs=&header=&footer=) once parsing bugs get fixed.

```
`        `   # String of code to be executed
 q           # Quotify / uneval
  \`:Ė\`+    # Append a `:Ė`
          :  # Duplicate
           Ė # Run on itself
```

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

```
`0:"`0:"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P8HASgmEuf7/BwA)

Posted with permission from @Bubbler.

So, oK has this cursed <s>bug</s> feature where prettyprinting of the output still occurs even if you print something else. `` `0 `` is the output symbol, and calling print to it with `:` prints the string, but returns the string as well, which is implicitly prettyprinted, with quotes to show it's a string.

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 34 bytes

```
{a:"0x7b613a22,a,0x223b2e617d";.a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qOtFKyaDCPMnM0DjRyEgnUcegwsjIOMko1czQPEXJWi@x9n91rUOCgVVadOx/AA)

My attempt.

In K, hexadecimal literals represent byte values. `0x7b613a22` is `{a:"`, and `0x223b2e617d` is `";.a}`, both of which are added to the string. So we set the value a to a string that when evaluated, returns itself wrapped in the boilerplate, and evaluate it.

Comment: How is this not cheating?

Comment: @pxeger [All these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A69+javascript) seem to be valid...

Comment: All of those are invalid too IMO. Why are they accepted?

Comment: Technically, it's not reading it's own *file* in any way - it's using a feature of the language to stringify a function, which happens to produce its source code, like the Befunge-93 quine.

Comment: The spirit of the rules are clearly against reading your own source code in general. JavaScript in the browser doesn't even have a source *file*. And you can't just keep listing other invalid quines like it'll change my view

Comment: @pxeger Fine, I'll add in a proper quine. Gimme a bit of time to make it work

Comment: Is there a way to make these sol work with no implicit output?

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal 2.6.0](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
`I`I
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgSWBJIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Posting this as a separate answer because it's using overloads not available at the time of the other answer.

### Explained

```
`I`I
`I`   # The string "I"
   I  # prepend a quoted version of that to itself and implicitly print
```

Comment: The code-block in your Vyxal TIO doesn't seem to work. It does see it as 4 bytes and outputs correctly, but the code itself shows as a zero-width space.. Seems there is something wrong in the online compiler. (Your answer looks fine btw.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it works perfectly fine on my end. Having said that, it wouldn't surprise me if there are issues with the site...we only launched it yesterday because we finished a language rewrite we've been working on for a few months. Hopefully a PR I'm working on will fix this :p

Comment: Welp, [this is what I see on my end](https://i.imgur.com/5bxKbKP.png) (latest Chrome version), with [these errors in the browser console, and the `&ZeroWidthSpace;` when I inspect element](https://i.imgur.com/mNFkdgD.png). 

Answer (score 5):

## [Insitux](https://insitux.github.io/), <s>171</s> <s>103</s> 85 bytes

```clj
(#(join(char-code,34)[%,%(char-code,41)])"(#(join(char-code,34)[%,%(char-code,41)])")
```

Note: Commas are treated as whitespace.

[Try it!](https://insitux.github.io/repl/?precode=BQYmCsHsEsDtgMYAsCGAnAtAyATApgDQDMALAJQDaApAVYqptvgSQIxkC6ZARKBDPGTosuQqUo06QxqJbsu3MkA) (The Insitux REPL replaces commas with spaces, but it still works.)

### Explanation:

```clj
(
  #(join ;Function to process string
    (char-code 34) ;Join the following with '"'
    [
      % ;String (first half)
      % ;String (second half)
      (char-code 41) ;Code for ')'
    ]
  )
  ;Same as above, but in a string
  "(#(join(char-code,34)[%,%(char-code,41)])"
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <sup><s>333</s></sup> 330 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBBCoAwDDu3r8jXRAS9CQo@f7ZJ52bHaNI1CezZj3u7zmXdWgNgBmNjJU2eMIEVYuPrWMM3t6GWTB4/GWRdbgLlL1yOU25JMfnOyT2jytGpx7GgeTmOuWsU8kC5IbkaKWXy5LLE3v@EuV75lUOYduatvQ)
[Try the 333B version online!](https://tio.run/##TY5RDoQwCES/h1PM1TbGRP822U08fu0wFFVaGKAPruP877/vZ9vHIIlp85sesEpTBT6PaI8y1M0XAesR/M5drDqK8ozocVzz4HD5Jr5QYC9mrXxQRz8YeWWqVCRhRkqbbGeZvehmCRXENreWjtrG8yNDMRFj3A)

This is the same code [as I posted](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Quine/angel_p57_1669740458&ws) to "Anarchy golf" ( http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Quine )

To be a bit more readable, substitute space,tab,newline to "s","t","n" like below;

```
sssttstssstttttttsttsstsstttssstststttsssstttststtstttttsttssssssstttstttttttttstttssstssstsstssstttststtstssttsstttsssststttsstststtttttssttsssssstssstststtttststtsststttssstsststtssssssststsstssssssssssnssstsssssnsnstnsstnsssnsssstsnnstnsssttnnssnsntstsstntstssnsntssnsnsstsstsnnstnnsssnsnttsttsstttsssntsttssstsssssntssstnssntn
```

or disassembled code with my original interpreter/disassembler;

```
push +2636263872820036273590233982665123397718151559108318308901888(201b)  # 0000: sssttstssstttttttsttsstsstttssstststttsssstttststtstttttsttssssssstttstttttttttstttssstssstsstssstttststtstssttsstttsssststttsstststtttttssttsssssstssstststtttststtsststttssstsststtssssssststsstssssssssssn
push +32(6b)  # 0205: ssstsssssn
dup           # 0215: sns
putc          # 0218: tnss
putc          # 0222: tnss
dup           # 0226: sns
push +2(2b)   # 0229: ssstsn
call null     # 0235: nstn
push +3(2b)   # 0239: sssttn
mark null     # 0245: nssn
swap          # 0249: snt
copy +1(1b)   # 0252: stsstn
div           # 0258: tsts
dup           # 0262: sns
jzero +0(0b)  # 0265: ntssn
dup           # 0270: sns
copy +2(2b)   # 0273: stsstsn
call null     # 0280: nstn
mark +0(0b)   # 0284: nsssn
swap          # 0289: snt
mod           # 0292: tstt
push -24(5b)  # 0296: sstttsssn
mod           # 0305: tstt
push +32(6b)  # 0309: ssstsssssn
add           # 0319: tsss
putc          # 0323: tnss
ret           # 0327: ntn
```

The key idea is to decode the same encoded number as binary digit for the 1st time, and as ternary digit for the next, with recursive operations like a Python code below;

```
def decode(x,b):               # b=2 or 3
  x //= b
  if x != 0:
    decode(x,b)
  print("stn"[x%b], end="")    # "s" for 0, "t" for 1, "n" for 2
```

This code decode a number as a binary or ternary digit, then add 0 at the top and remove the last digit, finally substitute 0,1,2 to "s","t","n" respectively.

For example, if you want to encode a Whitespace code "sstn", use an even number 502=200121(ternary)=111110110(binary).
At the 1st decoding as binary, "stttttstt" is created, and the 2nd decoding as ternary, "snsstn" is created.
Finally, concatenate "ss" and these, the decoded code will be "ssstttttsttsnsstn", which is "ssstttttsttsn" ( "push 502" in Whitespace ) + "sstn" and thus what you want.

In addition, the conversion from 0,1,2 to s,t,n ( ASCII 32,9,10 ) is implemented with a formula y=mod(x,-24)+32.

Comment: Nice answer! Pretty similar approach to [this Whitespace answer by _JoKing_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194067/52210), but your formula to convert `0,1,2` to `32,9,10` seems to do the trick to make it slightly shorter. :)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, this formula is a bit favorite part of the code.

Comment: I think you can use log bytes with whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

## [Positionally](https://github.com/chunkybanana/positionally/), 1551 Chars or \$1551\log_{256}(3)\approx\$ 307.28 Bytes (cheating)

```
    >v      >        v                                              >v                   /  >   
                /      \/      \/ 1            \/      \        /      \                        
                                        >              ^                                        
                                        ^+     <                                                
            :           > .   $        v        >     $     :  v    :                           
v                                                       v   {  <     }                          
     g          \ s     \      /\      /                \              /                        
\   ^>      ^        > /                                        \   ^>                      ^   
                                /     \                  /     \                /     \         
                                                / 1    \        /      \/ 1            \ 0      
                                                >   9          ^                                
                                                         +                      ^+     <        
                        >      v      $                         > .            v>   :          v
                        v  ~   <              ;<                                                
                                \         s    /       /                                        
                        \             /                  \             /\      /\     /  \     /
```

\$\log_{256}3\$ is because each character is a space, newline, or command.
General outline (ignoring most control flow, represented in easy mode*):

```
g:s\.$1+$:{:}   >
   >~$s;19+.1+:0^
```

<sub>*Easy mode is a new test mode on my interpreter, using the s flag. It treats each instruction as what you tell it it is, rather than using the table and your coords.</sub>

### Explanation

The stack is set up before each running of `g` as follows:

```
x
y
y
x
```

`g:` gets the char code at `x`,`y` and pushes it on the stack twice.
`s\` will continue straight if the value pushed by `g` is non-zero (aka it's not yet at the end of that line), otherwise goes down to the next line.
`.` outputs the character gotten by `g` (if it wasn't null, otherwise control would have already moved).
`$+1$` swaps the remaining `y` and `x` on the stack, increments `x`, and swaps them back.
`:{:}` first duplicates `y`, rotates `x` onto the top, dupes it, and rotates one copy back to the bottom, restoring the stack format.
`>` is just used to allow the second line to rejoin the first.

Now for the other line:

`>` is to make control go along the second line.
`~` gets rid of the unoutputted extra `g` result.
`$s;` swaps `x` and `y`, checks if `x` is 0 (popping it in the process), and halting if so.
`19+.` outputs a newline (1+9=10, 10 is code for a newline).
`1+:` increments y and duplicates it.
`0` pushes 0, resetting/setting x to 0.
`^` merges back up to the first line.

Comment: I can't find a way to make this work? https://tinyurl.com/jfwnfjkdsjnkf on the official interpreter doesn't print the whole thing, and [your interpreter](http://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/positionally/index.html) doesn't even work?

Comment: @emanresuA in mine you need to press update first. Also can you tell me where it doesn’t work (using Step)?

Comment: @emanresuA I figured it out. It’s a bug I patched on my interpreter where some things are treated as strings when adding

Comment: Okay, would you mind making a PR to the repository so that it works on there?

Comment: @emanresuA I did

Answer (score 5):

## [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), 36 bytes

```coffee
console.log s='console.log s=%o,s',s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85PS0tNLU4uyiwoMfr/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dodhWHZWrmq9TrK5T/P8/AA)

This was intended to be a [Civet](https://civet.dev/) quine, but it turns out it's a polyglot with CoffeeScript and there isn't a CoffeeScript quine here yet.

This uses the `%o` formatting directive of JavaScript to print a value as JSON, wrapping the string `s` in single quotes. This would also make a [38 byte JS quine](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN9WS8_OK83NS9XLy0zWKbdVRuar5OsWa6kAMUQ3VBNMMAA).

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 104 bytes

Uses `eval` and `repr`

```
a = "print 'a','=', repr(eval('a'))\nprint eval('a'),\n"
print 'a','=', repr(eval('a'))
print eval('a'),
```

Comment: Since this is `code-golf`, you might want to include a byte count.

Comment: `repr(x)==\`x\``

Answer (score 4):

## [ShapeScript](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), 16 bytes

```
'"%r"@%"0?!"'0?!
```

[Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=JyIlciJAJSIwPyEiJzA_IQ==&input=)

#### Verification

```
$ shapescript quine.shape | diff -sq - quine.shape
Files - and quine.shape are identical
```

#### How it works

```
'       Push a string that, when evaluated, does the following.
  "%r"  Push this formatting string. %r gets replaced by a string
        representation of the corresponding argument.
  @     Swap the string that is being evaluated on top of the stack.
  %     Apply formatting to the string on top of the stack.
  "0?!" Push that string.
'
0?!     Push a copy of the previous string and evaluate it.
```

---

## [ShapeScript](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), 32 bytes

```
'"'"'"'1?3?+3*2?+@+@+@#"0?!"'0?!
```

This version does not use string formatting. It's not particularly short, but I find it rather interesting.

[Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=JyInIiciJzE_Mz8rMyoyPytAK0ArQCMiMD8hIicwPyE=&input=)

#### How it works

```
'"'     Push a double quote singleton string.
"'"     Push a single quote singleton string.
'       Push a string that, when evaluated, does the following:
  1?3?    Copy the second and fourth topmost stack items.
          This pushes a copy of the single, then the double quote.
  +3*     Concatenate both and repeat the result three times.
  2?+     Copy the third topmost stack item and append it to the string.
          We now have a string of the first seven characters of the source.
  @+      Swap with the string on the stack (the string that is being
          evaluated) and concatenate.
  @+      Swap with the original single quote and concatenate.
  @#      Swap with the original double quote and discard it.
  "0?!"   Push that string.
'
0?!     Push a copy of the above string and evaluate it.
```

Answer (score 4):

## TeaScript, 1 byte

```
1
```

Nothing too interesting. But if that's too boring...

### TeaScript, 3 bytes

```
[q|
```

and if that's to boring...

### TeaScript, 15 bytes

```
(ƒ`(${f})()`)()
```

Answer (score 4):

## SWI-Prolog, 22 bytes

```
a :-
        listing(a).
```

A surprisingly short and elegant solution.

The 8 spaces and the new line (the space in the last line is just to display the empty line, there is actually no space) are both required in SWI-Prolog because that is the formatting that `listing` displays in the interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

### J 4 bytes

I know this competition is probably dead but I wanted to put my answer in.

Just found this by accident

```
1 b.
```

### J 1 bytes

```
0
```

Comment: Nice... I think you found the shortest possible quine once again!

Comment: These basically rely on the repl state of J, and are rather trivial. But, if it's happening like this, `1&` is shorter than `1 b.`.

Comment: 28 Bytes for a full program: `(echo@,quote)'(echo@,quote)'`

Answer (score 4):

## [BaCon](http://www.basic-converter.org), 54 bytes

Without using the SOURCE$ variable, the smallest Quine is 55 bytes:

```
s$="s$=%c%s%c:?34,s$,34 FORMAT s$":?34,s$,34 FORMAT s$
```

Comment: please make the main part of the post the 55 byte noncheating quine

Comment: Done. I wonder why using 'SOURCE$' is cheating, looking at the other contributions?

Comment: The other answers are also cheating. This challenge is over five years old; most answers were posted before we had clearly defined rules. Since last month, [improper quines are officially forbidden](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10033/12012) in all challenges, even if the spec doesn't explicitly forbid them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this page, I was unaware of it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/), <s>68 63</s> <s>53</s> 54 bytes (newlines)

rewrote

```
@##'@r,r,r-{ +.r_}r{ +.r_}'#'@r,r,r-{ +.r_}r{ +.r_}'f
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#@@@grKzuUKQDhLrVCtp6RfG1RVBaHadEGtf//wA)

Explanation

```
@#         Set character variable to #. Useful because this cannot occur in string var     
  #                        #  Set the string var to...
   '@r,r,r-{ +.r_}r{ +.r_}'   This string (quotes included. coincidental)
                            '@r,r,r            Write out first three chars of program: @##
                                   -{ +.r_}r   Write out the string var, then #, move right
                                            { +.r_} Write out the string var again, write #
                                                   'f   overwrite last # with f
```

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, <strike>173 158 152 144 137</strike> 102 bytes

Tuples plus Rust's debug printing mechanism ( {:?} in a format string ) let me cut it down 30+ characters!

```rs
fn main(){let t=("fn main(){let t=", ";print!(\"{}{:?}{}\",t.0,t,t.1)}");print!("{}{:?}{}",t.0,t,t.1)}
```

Pretty-printed. It's so small there's little left to explain!

```rs
fn main() {
    // The space after the comma is necessary, because that's how
    // debug-print formats tuples
    let t=("fn main(){let t=", ";print!(\"{}{:?}{}\",t.0,t,t.1)}");
    print!("{}{:?}{}",t.0,t,t.1)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 bytes

```
2i2i
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MmkyaQ&input=)

Explanation:

```
2       " Two times:
 i      " Insert the following:
  2i    " The string '2i'
```

This is pretty straightforward. In fact, this *almost* works in regular vim. There is just one minor thing in the way: The string '2i' isn't inserted twice *until* you hit `<esc>`. In V, this is solved by implicitly ending every program with an `<esc>` (Really, that's an oversimplification, but it's close enough to the truth).

Old versions of V always added a newline to the output, which is why I didn't post this earlier. However, in commit [b6c238d](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/commit/b6c238d0cf0c0889fbfef2bb2b3f88a65e852721), this was fixed.

This answer works just because of luck. The approach doesn't extend well to general purpose quines/quine-variations. The shortest quine I'm aware of that can be trivially modified is

```
ñéÑ~"qpÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3944@GVhyfWKRUWHN7//z8A)

Explanation:

```
ñ           " Start recording into register 'q'
 éÑ         " Insert 'Ñ' (uppercase so that the recording doesn't stop here)
   ~        " Toggle the case the character under the cursor (the 'Ñ')
    "qp     " Paste the contents of register 'q'
       ÿ    " Stop recording and play it all back
```

The reason the `ÿ` is needed, is because it is implicitly added to the end of macros, a feature that is unfortunate for quines, but very convenient for golf.

The nice thing about this quine is that we can do almost anything inside of the recording and it is still valid since it will be pasted later anyway.

Answer (score 4):

## BotEngine, 4x1=4 bytes

```
TRUE
```

The `T` instruction deletes the active bot and prints `TRUE`.

Answer (score 4):

## Malbolge, 59851 Bytes

*I take no credit for this quine, all credit goes to [this person](http://www.matthias-ernst.eu/malbolgequine.html)*

Newlines are significant, Compressed into a code snippet because otherwise this wouldn't fit.

```js
var byteArray = pako.inflate(atob('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'));
var byteString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) byteString += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
document.querySelector("code").textContent = decodeURIComponent(escape(byteString));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.min.js"></script>
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

Comment: Please note that Community Wiki is not a rep waiver so there is no real need for you to have marked it as such.

Comment: Unless my clipboard is playing tricks on me, your snippet shows only 46485 characters.

Comment: @Dennis Snippet is compressed

Comment: Yes. I copied the *output* of the Stack Snippet. Copy-pasting from the original website works fine btw.

Comment: The problem is most likely because of whitespace and/or HTML escapes. `.html` won't work properly for a `div`.

Comment: @Dennis probably I'll look into it when I get to a computer

Comment: Took the liberty to make the output copy-pastable. According to the result on TIO, you need to count a trailing newline though.

Answer (score 4):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language,  <s>22</s>  15 bytes

```
q={"q={"+q+"}"}
```

**Call with:**

```
hint call q
```

**Output:**

[image: q={"q={"+q+"}"}]

**Old version (22 bytes):**

```
q={format["q={%1}",q]}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes

```
":1-or>o#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@69kZaibX2SXr/z/PwA) Exits with an error. Since the top answer reads from its source code, I present this program.

```
":1-or>o#
"........   capture these characters
 :          duplicate last character (`#`)
  1-        decrement it (`"`)
    o       output it
     r      reverse the stack
      > #   loop inner
       o    output
```

The `#` is a very repulsive mirror--anything that touches it will go the other way. In this case, it is functionally the same as `<`.

Comment: `#` is the same as `#`!

Comment: No problem. I figured that something was up :P

Comment: I like the trick of decrementing `#`. +1

Answer (score 4):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), 13 + 6 = 19 bytes

*Martin Ender has made a shorter Quine [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121511/56656)*

+6 from the `000` topology and the `-A` flag, (also works in the `001` topology)

```
<:3+@+3:<"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/1/exspY20Hb2MpGXonr////BgYG/3UdAQ)

## Explanation

Like described in my earlier not so Quine the `"` character cannot be made with a string literal so we need to make it by doing math on a similar character, in this case the unit separator character for reasons described later.  The difference between this Quine and earlier attempts is that this we can get around the restriction of having to read the string forwards by making the string itself a palindrome.  This way reading backwards is the same as reading it forwards.

So when the program starts it passes through a unit separator, then hits `<` which turns it around, it goes through the `"` and pushes the entire line.  `:3+` turns makes a `"` out of the final unit separator and `@` terminates the program causing it to print.

Answer (score 4):

## Awk, 64 bytes

```
BEGIN{c="BEGIN{c=%c%s%c;printf c,34,c,34}";printf c,34,c,34}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 45 bytes

Credit to Martin Ender for the use of `%`, `r`, and `y` to obtain the characters `"/\` without escaping.

```
/?.!eO%?.*y1?@~mtz!!4\
\"Y!Z1hrZRoY@*m*h%1Y{/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fXk8x1V/VXk@r0tDeoS63pEpR0SSGK0YpUjHKMKMoKig/0kErVytD1TCyWv//fwA)

This program runs entirely in ordinal mode.  Because of how ordinal mode programs need to be formatted, this is significantly longer than Martin Ender's [cardinal mode quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116278/69059).

In ordinal mode, the instruction pointer moves diagonally, and commands work on strings instead of integers.  The diagonal movement is what makes this tricky: there is even a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122367/alices-ordinal-formatting) specifically about formatting a program for ordinal mode.  While it's possible to sidestep the entire issue by putting the same string on both lines, this approach ends up slightly longer at 52 bytes.

```
\".!e1%r.Ryh?*.Ooo1m@z1!{
\".!e1%r.Ryh?*.Ooo1m@z1!{/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/z9GSU8x1VC1SC@oMsNeS88/P98w16HKULGaC6eM/v//AA)

### Explanation

This is a standard template for ordinal mode, with an additional mirror to allow the program to loop back to the beginning.  Linearized, the code is as follows:

```
".!e1%r.RyY?*~*t%!Y4?Y!ZOh?Z*o1@@mmhz1!{
```

As with many Fungeoid quines, the `"` wraps around to itself and puts this entire program in a string literal.  Since string mode treats mirrors as mirrors (instead of literals), the string that gets pushed is exactly the linearized code, excluding the `"`.

```
.!     Duplicate the string, and move the copy to tape
e1%    Split on "1", placing "@@mmhz" and "!{" on top of the stack.
       The other two parts are irrelevant.
r      Expand !{ into the entire range from code point 33 to 123.
.R     Duplicate and reverse this range
y      Modify the string @@mmhz by changing every character in the range 33-123 
       with the corresponding character in the reversed range.
       The result of this transformation is \\//4" .
       This allows us to get these characters without escaping them.
Y?*~*  Split this string in half by unzipping, and put the halves on either
       side of the original string.  The new string is \/"sourcecode\/4 .
t%     Extract the newly added 4 at the end, and use it to split on the single 4 in the code.
```

At this point, we have two strings corresponding to approximately half of the code.  The top of the stack has the second half of the program and the right side mirrors, and corresponds to these output bytes:

```
 ? ! O ? * 1 @ m z ! \
  Y Z h Z o @ m h 1 {/
```

The string below that has the first half of the program, along with the left side mirrors and quote:

```
/ . e % . y ? ~ t !
\" ! 1 r R Y * * % Y
```

Neither string currently contains the `4` that was used to split the string.

```
!      Move second half string to the tape.
Y      Unzip first half: the top of the stack now contains the characters
       from the first half that will end up in the first row of the output.
4      Append the digit 4 to this string.
?Y     Copy second half back from tape and unzip: the top of the stack contains
       characters from the second half that will end up in the second row
!      Move this onto the tape.
Z      Zip the two halves of the first row together.
O      Output this with a linefeed.
h      Temporarily remove the initial \ so the next zip will work right.
?Z     Copy the string back from the tape, and zip the second row together.
       This Z isn't the exact inverse of Y since the second half is longer.
       The resulting behavior is exactly what we want.
*o     Join with the previously removed \ and output.
1      Append 1 to the irrelevant string on the top of the stack.
@      Terminate.
```

The 52-byte quine works on exactly the same principle, except that it doesn't need the ordinal formatting section of the 45-byte quine.

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 8 bytes

```
#o<}-1:"
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XznfplbX0Erp/38A)

Copied the trick of copying and decrementing the # to get " from the [other ><> answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120991/76162), but uses both sides of the # to avoid needing to reverse the stack.

Edit: A much cleaner solution of the same length:

```
'rd3*>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X70oxVjLLt/m/38A)

Everyone forgets that a `'` acts exactly the same as a `"`, but has usable divisors. Another 8 byte solution, but considered cheaty by some, `'r00g>o<`

Comment: This is the same approach I used in the comments of the [Original ><> answer:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2148/62009) Funnily enough my comment and your post were 1 day off being exactly a year apart.

Comment: @Tealpelican. Wait, why didn’t we just use a [single quote?](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X70oxVjLLt/m/38A)

Comment: I always forget ><> can use ' or " but ' is so much more useful with having some usable divisors.

Answer (score 4):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 63 bytes

```swift
let s=[";print(\"let s=\\(s)\"+s[0])"];print("let s=\(s)"+s[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/J7VEodg2Wsm6oCgzr0QjRgkiEBOjUawZo6RdHG0Qq6kUC5WFSQLloFL//wMA)

Comment: ChatGPT roughly gave me a 84 characters solution: `let s="let s=%c%@%c;print(String(format:s,34,s,34))";print(String(format:s,34,s,34))`. So congrats, you're better than it. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pain-Flak](https://github.com/Cis112233/Pain-Flak), 2009 bytes

```
><))(())(())()(())(())()(())(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())(())(())()(())(())()()(())(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()()(())()(())()()(())(())()()()(())(())(())(())(())(())()(())()()()(())()(())()()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())(())(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())(())()()(())()()(())()()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()(())(())(())(())(())(())()()(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())()()(())()()()(())(())()()(())(())(())(())(())(())()()(())()()()(())()(())(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()()()()(())()(())(())(())(())(())(())(())(())()(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())(())(())(())()()()(())()(())(())()()(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())(())()()(())()(())()(())(())(())(())()()(())()(())()()()()(())()(())()(())()()()(())(())(())()(())(())()()(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())(())()()(())()(())()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())()(())()()()(())()(())(())(())()(())()()()()(())()()(())(())()(())()(())(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()()(())()(())()()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())(())(())()(())(())(())(())()(())()()()()(())(())()()(())()(())()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())()()(())()()()(())(())()(())(())(())(())()()(())()()()()(())()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())(())()()()(())()()((}><))))))()()()()((}{(}{(}{()((><))]}{[()(>})}{)((><)))}{])([()(((><{><})}{><(><{}{<())(}])([)>))}{)(>))))()()()()((}{())}{()}{(}{)((>))])}{([))}{()}{(}{)><((()}{()((<(<(()])(})()>}{<({[}{>})}{)(>}{<({<}{)}{>}}{{<}{(><(<({}{(}}{)}{><(><})>)(<({{><})}{><(><{}{{}}{{)))))()()()((}{)((}{)(><)}{(()()((
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVVLDgIhDN17Elh4A0LiOSYu3JgYjWOiu6ZXF/tgEj/TMmCMjuOUB@17hXa87A7n9f60O6YUg/fOTbdmPZH5Gt3j07ttxrKs37kuHdfVavrfOWqe8xz6/GvMPTkt52efYp8Si7GlDloY2@Jru66dg1XD@tnZ2ev7W6@xpbhLnaXVknW@v9PxTWfWe7StJqydtfZDZ/5X31s9VXsnLOVeY@vrpHr/9LO2vlV/WzeWvvxk/F3h80yKafqKjdkt0yB2ZM80QWJtvQOKMcWAuRhgMwUEZ8z76LNPnBEAdz7TIKSQYDC8whLOZVsWBLmcrHEsASIoaBDCoqiMg5iAmGCKEnEhRCo4tLHoAfqhl@DzugdFVA4dIKCAq5Tu4@V2GM/XtN48AA)

(Trailing newline because the interpreter outputs a newline.)

*-176 bytes by improving the Brain-Flak quine*

Basically a straight port of my [Brain-Flak quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144085/69059).  The only major difference is the `><` at the beginning, which is required in order to keep the data section out of the output.

```
><                 switch to right stack; effectively does nothing since both stacks are empty
))((...))()()((    data, same format as the Brain-Flak quine
}main loop{        same as the Brain-Flak quine, but with different constants
}}{{               clear current stack; this does nothing
)))))()()()((}{)((}{)(><)}{(()()((   push opening >< at beginning of code
```

Since this is Pain-Flak, the code also goes backward after it is finished going forward.  As such, I had to ensure that this does not mess up the output.

```
))()())}{(><)(}{))(}{))()()()(((((   push 70, 68, 5, 4 on right stack
}}{{               clear right stack
}pool niam{        do nothing because top of stack is zero
))()()((...))((    push constants on right stack in reverse order
><                 switch to left stack and implicitly output
```

Comment: The only Pain-Flak solutions I've seen are ones directly translated from Brain-Flak...

Comment: I will give the bounty but kinda lame that it is just a port

Comment: @Christopher it _is_ your fault that you made Pain-Flak so similar to Brain-Flak :P

Comment: @ascii painflak update is removing swap stack

Comment: @Christopher then it'll just be translated Mini-flak?

Answer (score 4):

## [2DFuck](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/2DFuck), <s>1352</s> 1289 bytes

```
!xv>>>>x>x>>>>>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>x>>>>>x>>x>>>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>x>x>x>>>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>>>>>>>>x>x>>>>>x>>x>>>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>x>>>>>x>>x>>>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>x>x>x>>>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>>x>>>>>>>>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>>x>x>>>x>x>>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>>>>>>>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>>>>>>>x>x>>>>>x>>x>>>x>x>^x!..!.!....!.!.!....!....!...!.!..!.![<r!]![vr[!.!....!...]..!.....!.>^r!]![<r!]![vr[!..!.!.!...!.]r![>r[!..!.!....!.!]r![>r[>r[!.!.!.!...!.!.!]r![!.!.!.!..!.!..!]<]r![>r[!.!...!..!.!.]r![>r![!..!.....!.]r[>r![!..!....!..]r[>r![!.!.!.!....!.]r[>r[!.!....!...]r![!.!...!.!..!.]]]]]<]>]]>^r!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLNDsMgCH4WXsDDzg0vYuhlyy67mazx7Z0TR7GFttME8QM/fuT2eL7vr1IgL1hXrht/SruoQ0B934Ib1SLBNUiXGS1jXh20xz6GlUFWxejK3Gh/p2J2QSWk@VQaNsG@QycEBp@bzgGr@W6jD827WJs/QMcERn/c1l59OozJ6dODj/EJLsynE8nu/YkcfwJ3Vm/i5wwhQN2Bj6500e5VxCkBQVxSVB7UHavEudmVl5BBoAQRBWPWjiETggRrBoFY0CQM7NZwxoBpQw80IFUIokqjtHJxHd1DyqXvmgiJWl2lfAA)

Shaved off 63 bytes with [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)! New explanation in progress.

Comment: Some thoughts; you can reverse the data encoding to avoid the second `![<r!]`, and you can save some bytes through reusing `.`s (for example all characters have a leading zero). [1131 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVI7DsMwCD2LL8DQOeIiFlladekWqRW3d/EvgRi3iRWMH/DA4Nvj@b6/Ugr8QZaF@c8btiPaYwNPHtZ6ljtro@4ZWHseNku/g8a3r4Nd142Ik9CLwX@yXgn1om0Jw32dUNNbr3@2wW4Led5ht1i/TebCcwJFcYplh4IHGv8F4nQGerQ/hnst22Dkof4xx@Sik6GzHimuHACCLKhbU5ooZxFx2QKF@Nmi8qDmKBLXw77TBIItR0bFG6hCFSkKiSagKNiN0NJCBULPWhANiBAADJKBygylgFIIyYe0EC250pS@). I think you might get better huffman encoding through multiple or partial characters

Answer (score 4):

## [Reflections](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/), 9228 bytes

As the program has 8620 lines, I won't put it here completely.

First line:

```
\
```

Then, for each character in the last part (below), there are *n* newlines for ASCII character *n*, followed by:

```
+
#
```

After it, the last part is (the `#` is actually already covered by the previous section):

```
#  /  \          /+\  /#_=0v\
>~ <       /(1:1)#@/       ~
\(0/      2)     \3)(2:2)(3^ 0#+#@
           \:(24):(4#_#_#_  /
      +               \*             (4\
      \*(1(2                          +/
```

[Test it!](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##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)

Working on explanation.

I had to fix a bug in the interpreter for this one. Does that count as adding a feature just for a challenge?

Comment: :| the URL encoding format is terrible

Answer (score 4):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 120 bytes

```
00000000: 21f5 76e5 2180 10e5 21cd 00e5 2180 7ce5  !.v.!...!...!.|.
00000010: 21cd 00e5 21e1 7de5 2106 14e5 2110 e8e5  !...!.}.!...!...
00000020: 2100 80e5 21e5 cde5 211b 3ee5 2100 80e5  !...!...!.>.!...
00000030: 211a cde5 2180 13e5 21cd 00e5 211b 1ae5  !...!...!...!...
00000040: 2180 1be5 21cd 00e5 213e 21e5 2106 14e5  !...!...!>!.!...
00000050: 0614 3e21 cd00 801b 1b1a cd00 8013 1acd  ..>!............
00000060: 0080 1b3e e5cd 0080 10e8 0614 e17d cd00  ...>.........}..
00000070: 807c cd00 8010 f576                      .|.....v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdFJDoMwDAXQfU9hLhDZhAzqgrswhG4qdceiKmenjh2GolpCMoNffsg74uP1nNYVS92hpslB8MlxFxEIpRtGQNyehYE7qMxsKmPK9TE3FUiM4/tEEEbp0AM10hFCimrk2WV3ilGLgQixGA4GNagHm1Qrb@HI0J4NKwZ122Tei73shTXqfo2fHI0YebK/TNqksY5dHUZbnQ3HBnpqOHdNHEZy54V7yaa3lnMwDsa0eXSvYvhsoOTghZOTHHo4UfFEYVSNDf4RWy27EdiIGIZ9TYTJBQ9/i48z17yuXw)

Verification:

```
$ ./z80golf a.bin | xxd
00000000: 21f5 76e5 2180 10e5 21cd 00e5 2180 7ce5  !.v.!...!...!.|.
00000010: 21cd 00e5 21e1 7de5 2106 14e5 2110 e8e5  !...!.}.!...!...
00000020: 2100 80e5 21e5 cde5 211b 3ee5 2100 80e5  !...!...!.>.!...
00000030: 211a cde5 2180 13e5 21cd 00e5 211b 1ae5  !...!...!...!...
00000040: 2180 1be5 21cd 00e5 213e 21e5 2106 14e5  !...!...!>!.!...
00000050: 0614 3e21 cd00 801b 1b1a cd00 8013 1acd  ..>!............
00000060: 0080 1b3e e5cd 0080 10e8 0614 e17d cd00  ...>.........}..
00000070: 807c cd00 8010 f576                      .|.....v

$ ./z80golf a.bin | diff -s a.bin -
Files a.bin and - are identical
```

Looks like no one tried to make a proper quine in machine code yet, so here is one.

Although the machine code is loaded to memory, it does NOT read any address occupied by the code. Instead, it uses the stack space to setup required data.

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  ld hl, $76f5
  push hl
  ld hl, $1080
  push hl
  ld hl, $00cd
  push hl
  ld hl, $7c80
  push hl
  ld hl, $00cd
  push hl
  ld hl, $7de1
  push hl
  ld hl, $1406
  push hl
  ld hl, $e810
  push hl
  ld hl, $8000
  push hl
  ld hl, $cde5
  push hl
  ld hl, $3e1b
  push hl
  ld hl, $8000
  push hl
  ld hl, $cd1a
  push hl
  ld hl, $1380
  push hl
  ld hl, $00cd
  push hl
  ld hl, $1a1b
  push hl
  ld hl, $1b80
  push hl
  ld hl, $00cd
  push hl
  ld hl, $213e
  push hl
  ld hl, $1406
  push hl

  ld b, 20
loop1:
  ld a, $21
  call $8000
  dec de
  dec de
  ld a, (de)
  call $8000
  inc de
  ld a, (de)
  call $8000
  dec de
  ld a, $e5
  call $8000
  djnz loop1

  ld b, 20
loop2:
  pop hl
  ld a, l
  call $8000
  ld a, h
  call $8000
  djnz loop2

  halt
```

At start, the stack pointer `sp` is zero, just like other registers. Pushing some values causes `sp` to decrease, so the values are stacked in the memory region `$ffxx`.

The combination `ld hl, $xxxx` and `push hl` seems like the best option to dump predefined values into some memory space. It takes 4 bytes to store 2 bytes; any other option I could think of uses 3 or more bytes to store only one byte.

The **first loop** prints the `ld hl, $xxxx (21 xx xx)` and `push hl (e5)` instructions for the data, from the bottom of the stack (the address, represented by `de`, is `dec`reased starting from `$0000`).

`ld b, $xx` and `djnz label` combined forms a fixed-times looping construct. It is only 4 bytes, which is optimal in Z80 (unless the loop count is already saved in another register).

But there is an endianness problem here, so simply sweeping the memory addresses in decreasing order does not work. So I had to add a pair of `dec de` and `inc de` at the cost of 2 bytes (plus 4 bytes to push the 2 bytes into the stack).

The **second loop** prints the main code by popping data from the stack.

#### Possible improvement ideas

Since the code is longer than `$38` or 56 bytes, we can't use `rst $38` in place of `call $8000`. Having `call $8000` 6 times in total, it's a great opportunity for golf. I considered placing `call $8000; ret` at address `$38`, but then I have to reduce the main code into 26 bytes or lower.

I also thought of moving the code to the front by adding some `jr`, so that I can embed the `call $8000; ret` in the code part. But then I can't use the efficient "pop and print" loop. It prints the data in reverse order of pushing, so it can't be used to print the push part; the "print" overwrites the stack with the return address, so it can't be used to print the first part either.

Finally, there is room for alternative encoding since some bytes frequently appear in the code. But Z80 itself is severely limited in arithmetic...

Answer (score 4):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```
q=:'q=:~p;:io.format q,[q]';:io.format q,[q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v@/0NZKHYjrCqytMvP10vKLchNLFAp1ogtj1TFE/v8HAA)

This is basically an existing quine taken from [here](http://elixirgolf.com/articles/elixir-quine-self-replicating-program/), but I managed to save another 2 bytes by declaring `q` as an atom instead of a binary.

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 9 bytes

```
ÿ_'ÿ¬_'ÿ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w/nj1w/sPrYGQ//8DAA)

#### Explanation:

```
ÿ_'ÿ¬_'ÿ¬
ÿ          Start string of length 4
 _'ÿ¬      Push "_'ÿ¬"
     _     Duplicate it
      'ÿ   Push the character "ÿ"
        ¬  Rotate stack so the "ÿ" is at the bottom
           Implicitly output "ÿ", "_'ÿ¬", "_'ÿ¬" join together
```

Comment: `ÿ'ÿ¬_'ÿ¬_` is another 9-byter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 30 bytes

```
_="_='_='+`_`+';__(_)'";__(_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3lYp3lYdiLQT4hO01a3j4zXiNdWVIDTX//8A)

Yet another eval quine. The lack of being able to do `%r` in Symbolic Python is made up for Python 2's backticks, which are an alias for the `repr` function.

#### Explanation:

```
_="                   ";       # Assign the string to the _ variable
                        __(_)  # Eval the string
   _=                          # Assign to the _ variable
     '_='                      # The initial _=
         +`_`                  # The Python representation of the string
             +';__(_)'         # And the final evaling part
                               # Implicitly output the contents of _
```

An alternative that doesn't use the rather long `eval` function comes to 31 bytes, but I actually like it more.

```
_=';_="_="+`_`+_';_="_="+`_`+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3lbdOt5WCYi0E@ITtONReVz//wMA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Golunar](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar), 951 bytes (394.25 bytes as an integer value)

```
19370043316195921194914466480856680152267470323963447024756684537596068724128114478400203537500358028693578705195025299449504112473728653294217406768139954805008550643064305270958743186186490023003785512463398359429631224818444304976679217098389450981926661910005004089131207223929032173888419619738722341444212432611576207643452266161684471788295034889655803444137372629364500165719019777515305922257911642994836581634099155833200157295629218533465854143898419293035289733581625252699105530843807023973345521520887128012736565874423200184723012755626596238647926406709693583878890472621210970350861368171259284533764490596207310864352873729240842719608391238098412446205860013948766486129442046252306334230243913196704614648889659870117069927719874852423159076941049170045933025772364248625729725500550726133134993128102614696728457139079375133324957922066270555810085574853273966267981675757808791933974619299446035844180580831907739236954600685575
```

Golunar is the decimal representation of the number of zeros that a [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) code would need.
It translates to this [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck) code:

```
->+>+>+>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>>>+>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>+>>>>+>+>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>+>>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>+>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>+>+>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>>>>+>+>>>>>+>>+>>>+>>>+>+>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>+>>>+>+>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>>>>+>+>>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>+>>>>+>>+>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>+>>>>+>+>>>>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>+>+>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>+>>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>+>>>+>+>>+>+>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>>>>>+>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>>>+>+>+>+>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>>>>>>>+>+>+>+>+>>+>>>+>+>+>+>>>>+>+>>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>>+>>>>>>>>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+[[>>+[>]+>++>+[<]<-]>>[>]<<-[<]<<+]+>+>-[>]++>++>++[[-<+]-<[-<[>++<-[>++<-[>++<-[>++<-[>--------<<[-]++>-[>++<-]]]]]]>[<+>-]+<<]>>[>>]<[>]<-[[-<+]-<<+>[>>]<[>]]<+]<[<<]>>[+++++++[<++++++>-]<.>>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPRDsIgDPygC35B0x8hPKiJiTHxwcTvxwMG0q06HywZrNf2rsB2ehyv98vzfMs5KOqYrLkYYwHdB6MA@u3BxI2BT07nsNJQJ2vuUq00PCoTMBK75E7DzsFgKsGPY9C9ebanDSOP7UZ3JsP7UfBfAd10uncdlkPd3btnYxJWX8DqIlYx/3bhlvutrXhg/5s@xcglauJr8SRJSKoERELxBCWkoaS0HJYEokG4RLrMc@awmDCtVC6BVE2jEEkQqVoUK4KhEzPYwURAYstDM9ZWI4EcuJ2U8ws)

I couldn't find an online Golunar interpreter, but you can use [this Golunar to brainfuck converter](https://tio.run/##RZPdquU2DIUfaE8G69@CkBfZ5KJTKJRCLwp9/tNPOWem3jtxbEtLWkvyj39@@/PvP/79/a@Pj@O6vr3P1zPe1/E1zuN@Xc/4dl/HdZzn@Xof5@u@3u/j4v86eTFd9/nm8GYeB2xmZnN8X78GJkCyNc9r/IH9gjzG@HOP5a@9477PZ7yf9/2ZDot7Qj9I/4OdD9jwuI7J6Jmvh9JnfFbsPjyvMeHrHLrn8R7QY/Y@V2PMe15fG8/q8X/QXz@t7s9xfX/P6YCS@ceHtNVabiYpHa0i7S3umb7Xjsy9JFSzvJapdZrzpV5z5GEVnSt3qYtuwbG2r6XL5mgx7aU726J2rSDE0tBud75cBCArDMK0XaV8ZeUW6w7iA7AjVro9T2itjl1uspO/N5GMIIUVUGnW2wIg0hRV37LdcfSuzIIc/tt2ezBLayakZa0J5Gu34LVKoakNWynbe7s0VnzOgcOQPNVNUyQqsSc1H4kSCdHES2pvhZ/53p2BBIjmYkM1tS2JvySjpBfIVSEBu1bVqBZJH4W2ZWxB79UtgJgpXlEgA6Kyw8wxCXKC0@QJNorrJlsbX6QOTdxXEGBjtqidzbFHKIVdexeFW6JFuBxxXZ9A2wtt2Q/CJVVWQ3FEzKnR6qkpWkK1lw8vUVlNk8SiOEYRAYbTNImhEcUakFUmGPikOXq0IrwrUuTa1kKUNVyUFtQVO0nFEKOmIVPoEtflw4yegAYTxZjKNVl5imP3yN40nFBx@GuBD7UdioNEU7R2oS9kmj/aQImCMNITRkflUloP4WgI@JiYd9s0@dKJQrjhVmS3iksU2JjS1kikK5NeDaomTwtPaEPiZp9GpDQV/Lhh1JvoXWTez73IuTN0C93PMbRW4Udm3AjEyEGL/wA) to get the brainfuck code and then execute it.

This code is inspired by [a brainfuck quine](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/392quine.b) of Eric Bosman and Daniel B Cristofani. First it reads a list of bits that represent the bit-codes of the code part, then it builds up a list of bits that represent the ">" and "+" characters needed to print the first list. Those lists are merged and hold the binary value of the Golunar code. In the last step, the decimal value of the binary number are computed and printed.

```
[ 
tape: [decimal digits], value start marker/VS(-1)(starting cell), [input bits], between binary marker/BB(0), [binary output data]

input bits are 0 or 1, output bits are in reversed order and have the values 1(used) or 2(used and set)
input must be given in reversed order

decimal digits consist of two cells per value (value, digit used marker(DU)(1))

bit values:
> 000
< 001
+ 010
- 011
. 100
, 101
[ 110
] 111

]

-                       set VS

                    set input bits
>+>+>+>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>>>+>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>+>>>>+>+>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>
+>+>>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>+>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>+>+>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>>>>+>+>>>>>+>>+>>>+
>>>+>+>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>+>>>+>+>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>>>>+>+>>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>+>>
>>+>>+>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>+>>>>+>+>>>>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>
>>>>>+>>>+>>+>+>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>>>+>>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>+>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>
>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>+>+>>>+>+>>>+>+>+>
>>+>+>>+>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>+>>>+>+>>+>+>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>>>+>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>+>+>>>>>>+>>>>>>+>>+
>+>+>>+>>+>>>+>>>+>+>+>+>>>>+>+>+>+>>+>>>+>>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>>>>>>>+>+>+>+>+>>+>>>+>+>+>+>>>>+>+>>+>>>
>>>+>>>+>>>>>>+>>+>+>+>>>>>+>+>>+>>>>>>>>>+>+>>+>+>>+>

                    list rebuilding loop: append bits for "greater than" and plus symbols to the right of input data
+[                      for each input bit
  [                     while bit is greater than 0
    >>+                 copy bit to out data
    [>]+>++>+           append bits for plus (used markers plus 010)
    [<]<-               decrement in value
  ]
  >>[>]<<-              change most right character from plus to gt (010 to 000)
  [<]                   return to BB
  <<+                   repeat if not on VS
]
+>+>-                   prepare binary to decimal routine: set VS DU and first 1

[>]++>++>+              append bits for minus (011)

                    binary to decimal loop: use "double and add algorithm" to calculate the digits of the decimal value
+[                      if not on VS then
  [-<+]-                restore current bit value and go to VS
  <                     go to first DU
  [                 digit doubling loop
    -<                  remove DU and go to corresponding digit
    [
      >++<-             decrement current value and add 2 to temp value four times
      [
        >++<-
        [
          >++<-
          [
            >++<-
            [                   if value was greater than 4 then
              >---- ----        subtract 8 from temp
              <<[-]++           set next digit temp = 2 (DU plus 1)
              >-                decrement current digit
              [>++<-]           set temp = remaining value * 2
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    >[<+>-]             set current digit = temp
    +                   set DU
    <<                  go to next digit
  ]                 end of digit doubling loop
  >>[>>]<[>]<           go to current bit
  -[                    if bit is 2 (used plus 1)
    [-<+]-              delete bit and go to VS
    <<+                 increment least significant digit
    >[>>]<[>]           go to current bit
  ]
  <+                    if not on VS then repeat  
]                   end of binary to decimal loop

<[<<]>                  go to most significant digit
>[                  printing loop: for each DU print corresponding value
  +++++++[<++++++>-]<.  add 48 to value (ASCII 0) and print
  >>>                   go to next DU
]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>49</s> 43 bytes

```
\^\(\\\\\,\:\&\^\&\^\,\)\^\#^(\\,:&^&^,)^#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/Ji5GIwYEdGKsYtSAPBDWidEEkspxQBkdK7U4tTgdzThlrv//AQ)

(note the trailing newline...)

*-6 bytes thanks to Jo King reminding me that comments exist*

This is a horrible mess, and I'm sure it can be outgolfed easily by someone comfortable with Keg's stack, and/or once `"`/`'` stop erroring. The first two thirds simply push each character from the last third to the stack in order (such that the last character is on top), and then the last third:

```
^                   Reverses the stack (such that the first character is on top),
 (         )        then does the following for each item CURRENTLY on the stack:
  \\,               print a backslash,
     :              duplicate the top of the stack,
      &             pop it to the register,
       ^            flip the stack,
        &           push the register,
         ^          flip the stack again,
          ,         and pop and print the top of the stack;
            ^       finally reversing what's left on the stack
             #\n    and commenting out the trailing newline,
                    so the stack is then implicitly printed bottom first,
                    with a trailing newline.
```

Essentially, it prints the first two thirds while copying itself onto the bottom of the stack, then flips the copy to be implicitly printed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 21 bytes

```
HBZLTXJMIC(":,48*-)#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fwynKJyTCy9fTWUPJSsfEQktXU5nr/38A)

The string of letters translates to the code section reversed and shifted up by 32. It's lucky all the characters used are in the correct range for shifting.

#### Explanation:

```
(       )    # Loop over the stack
 "           # Shift stack left
  :          # Duplicate the letter
   ,         # Print the letter
    48*-     # Subtract 32 from the ordinal value of the letter
         #   # Comment out the newline
             # Print the shifted characters with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p0513`, 29 bytes

```perl
s<><s<><@>;s/@/lc/e>;s/@/lc/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/Yxs4GhB3srIv1HfRzkvVTEaz////lF5Rk5ucV/9ctMDA1NAYA)

### Explanation

```perl
s<><               >;         # Working with `$_` by default, `s`ubstitute (`s///`, but using 
                              # `<><>` instead of `///` to allow nesting) the empty string...
    s<><@>;s/@/lc/e           # ...with the body of the quine.
                     s/@/lc/  # Then, again working with `$_`, replace the first `@` with `lc`...
                            e # ...and execute the result (calling the sub `lc` which returns its
                              # argument, or `$_` if no argument is passed) `l`ower`c`ased, which
                              # in this case is the body of the quine.
                              # `$_` is then finally `print`ed because of `-p`.
```

Comment: I can somewhat get the other quines, but somehow Perl always manages to elude me.

Comment: @Razetime This particular one is a little tricky because it breaks out of the (implicit) `while(<>){...}` from `-p` first and then uses nesting chars for `s///` (`s<><>` in this quine) and uses `@` as a positional argument (like `%s` in the `printf`style quines). The final piece is using `lc` for a reference to `$_` as everything would be unchanged by lowercasing. If I get time today I'll annotate this one properly too!

Answer (score 4):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 60 bytes

Thanks @JoKing for saving a whopping 55 bytes!

```
48923792915350878792773358929392915992930\%\[52WW\M!:\]\[;\]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=48923792915350878792773358929392915992930%5C%25%5C%5B52WW%5CM!%3A%5C%5D%5C%5B%3B%5C%5D&input=)

It's finally done!

### Explanation:

The quine is essentially split into three parts.
The first part is the data, and is represented by the big blob of numbers in the start (excluding a 0). It represents the ASCII codes of the rest three parts of the code.
The second part is the decoder that both turns the long stack of separate numbers into a smaller stack with multi-digit numbers and prints it as numbers without destroying it.
The last part loops over the stack and prints it as ASCII. Note that we don't have to preserve the data in stack any more.

Old solution:

## 115 bytes

```
481263753508787774753508787775350878777479153508787774793479133584793479159930~%52WWM/52WWM52WWM/[52WWM/]/[!:/]/[;]
```

Comment: @JoKing - the auto-pasting of the code in the link doesn't seem to work (at least for the Mac OS X browsers that I've tried), and it's difficult to extract the code from the link itself.  Could you include the code itself in a comment?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen could you possibly describe the issue with the auto-copy on the interpreter? I myself work on a Mac, but had no issues developing and testing everything, as so do others who use the interpreter.

Comment: @JoKing - Thanks!  @Dion - When I click on your link (or that of JoKing) in either Chrome or in Firefox, I get the 'MAWP version 1.1 (latest)' web page, but the 'code:' box is empty.  In Chrome I can manually copy-paste the code into the box, and it then works fine when I click 'Run code', but it's difficult to get the code out of the link because many of the characters are represented with ```%```s.  FYI, I just tried to generate my own link (using the 'generate link' button after pasting-in your code), and this link also opens an empty 'code:' box.  Hope this helps....

Comment: @DominicvanEssen if it doesn't trouble you, would you mind and telling me two things: a) are the query's in the links empty b) does the dev console show any errors on loading and/or link generating? Thanks!

Comment: @Dion - I'm not a developer so I'm rather out of my depth here, but I'll try to answer.  Let me know if I haven't told you what you need to know.  The link seems to contain the program (it ends with ```.../?code=481...b%5D&input=```, but the program doesn't end-up in the 'code:' box.  I don't really know what the 'dev console' is, but (in Chrome) I clicked on 'View>Developer>Developer tools' and selected the 'console' tab, and there are no errors displaying (either for loading or creating links).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks for the info, weird tho. What browser versions are you using?

Comment: Rather old (which may be the problem): OSX 10.8.5, Chrome 49.0.2623.112, Firefox 48.02

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
say<<""x2
say<<""x2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sdLGRkmpwogLweL6//9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MA)

Comment: Woah, not sure how I missed this. This is awesome!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 57 bytes

```
2996557859220556162530996767470:`0123456789+:`\\\`\τ+++τ+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=2996557859220556162530996767470%3A%600123456789%2B%3A%60%5C%5C%5C%60%5C%CF%84%2B%2B%2B%CF%84%2B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

The big number at the front is the rest of the program encoded using the key `0123456789+:τ\` with a backtick (dammit markdown). The rest of the program constructs the key,  decodes this, and concatenates the original number to the result.

Answer (score 4):

## Zsh, 37 bytes

```
s=s=%q\;printf\ \$s\ \$s;printf $s $s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3VYtti21VC2OsC4oy80rSYhRiVIrBBFRAQaUYiCCKoXpgegE)

Answer (score 4):

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), 66 bytes

```
SELECT PRINTF(s,s)FROM(SELECT'SELECT PRINTF(s,s)FROM(SELECT%Qs)'s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7MySxJ/f8/2NXH1TlEISDI0y/ETaNYp1jTLcjfVwMirI5XVjWwWFO9WPP/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), <sup><s>67</s> <s>53</s></sup> 32 bytes

```
PvxP,"DC!�$Vp~V*Z$
BE'"PvxP,\"
```

note: � in the 1st line is a NUL char ( ASCII 0 ), and in the 2nd line an ACK char  ( ASCII 6 ) exists ( but looks hidden ) between a single quote and a double quote.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P8/oKwiQEfJxVmRQSWsoC5MK0qFy8lVnU0JLB6jxPX/PwA)
[Try the 53B version online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P8/oExHKV5BQSc5KCnOwtjA2EChwsjMTL2cC6sYlP7/HwA)
[Try the 67B version online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P8/oExHKV5BwVUhWSfJ2NjcwMjI0sBSocLYyMjV0NCSC48MnPX/PwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Trilangle, <s>15858</s> 5562 characters, <s>15950</s> 5654 bytes

Nowhere near as short as the others but it finally works! Posting what I have before attempting to get it shorter.

Edit: I think that's the most extreme golf I've ever had in a single go.

---

The program consists of two interesting sections separated by 5329 periods (`.`):

```
\\!.(2."!L.2'7!..2j.++!"%_".#:_",oI#.!"%_"2..._",o+..S#\(,o+!":.,##,o."<!L*2/!..2,,<><#..(!(,oj)2_,o""<!L#"!B!!B!!B!!><#2"!B!!B!!B!!@"!!7!
```

and

```
"ᘠ""l""࠰"""⍋"㩇"""喨"⍎"㩇""㩐""""""䪤""""Ճ"""傤"ﮧ""""⏮""a"!"!"!"傤"p"!"!"!"~"ࠪ".
```

The second part contains unallocated Unicode codepoints, so I can guarantee that your font doesn't have them all. It's the first part encoded in base-95, three instructions per character, length-suffixed.

To scale, the full program looks like this when unfolded:

[image: A screenshot of vs code showing a very zoomed-out program. The very top is labelled "Decoder". The very bottom is labelled "Data". Most of the program is labelled "big-ass NOP slide".]

The decoder does three things, in order:

1. Decode the data from base-95 and print it. I use `!` for zero rather than   because the interpreter ignores spaces. In hindsight I could've done base-94 but that's still only 3 instructions per character, so it wouldn't make a massive difference.

```
               \
              . ( 2
             .     L
            . 2 ' 7  
           . . 2 j   +
          + ! " % _ " .
         # : _ " , o    
        . ! " % _ " 2   . 
       . _ " , o + . .   
      \ ( , o + ! " : .
```

2. Print 5329 periods.

```
                  7
                   .
                    "
                     I
                      .
                       S
                        ,
     # , o . " <   L * 2 /
                > < # . . ( !
```

3. Print the whole stack, alternating with `"` characters.

```
    . . 2 , , < >
   ( , o j ) 2 _ , o " " <   L
                          > < #
                         @
```

Most of the `!`s, some of the `"`s, and all of the `B`s are never hit. They're just what the decoder produces at those locations. `!` and `"` are used because they're 0 and 1 in base-95, respectively, and `B` is used because `B!!` is the smallest triplet that corresponds to a printable non-whitespace character.

This can obviously be compressed by making the NOP slide smaller. There's two ways to do this, one easier than the other:

1. Be a bit smarter about computing the size of the NOP slide. I gave myself very little room to do so and so the only thing I could come up with was `"I2*`, i.e. \$73^2\$. Rearranging some other things to give myself more room to compute this value means I could move the data closer to the decoder.

   - Partially addressed by edit 1: 15625 -> 5329. This is the smallest square that will work, but there's a smaller non-square number. I only got the absolute lowest-hanging fruit.
2. Be a bit more clever about how the stack is printed, so that it doesn't have to be all on one line. This brings the amount of NOPs needed from \$O\left(n^2\right)\$ to \$O(n)\$ if you do it right, I think. See [Bubbler's suggestion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=64037362#64037362) the other day. I can definitely do this, but it'd take a bit of thinking.

Like I said, I'm just posting this for now to be on the board. I'll have to revisit this to make it shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 38 bytes

```javascript
console.log(s='console.log(s=%o,s)',s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN9WS8_OK83NS9XLy0zWKbdVRuar5OsWa6kAMUQ3VBNMMAA)

This seems to be the shortest non-function-stringifying JavaScript quine. Unfortunately seems to be platform-specific: it works as-is in Chrome and Node.js, but in Safari requires the single quotes to become double quotes.

In a strict-mode setting like Deno, you need to declare `var s;` at the start:

```javascript
var s;console.log(s="var s;console.log(s=%o,s)",s)
```

Bun doesn't seem to support the `%o` directive in any form.

Comment: I just tried this on Safari, it works if you replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: This seems to be V8-specific; in Firefox/SpiderMonkey it uses spaces instead of quotes in the output.

Comment: @Bbrk24 That's what I thought before, but I tried it on Safari (JavaScriptCore) and it works with single quotes, so I think it's tied to the runtime rather than the JS engine itself.

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 14 bytes

```
&s&pf."&s&pf."
```

[Try it Online](https://uiua.org/pad?src=JnMmcGYuIiZzJnBmLiI=)

RTL evaluation made this way more easier than it could have been.

### Explained

```
&s&pf."&s&pf."­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
      "&s&pf."  # ‎⁡Push the string "&s&pf."
     .          # ‎⁢Duplicate it
  &pf           # ‎⁣Print without newline
&s              # ‎⁤Print repr version
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: Alternative 14: [`⊃&s&pf"⊃&s&pf"`](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4oqDJnMmcGYi4oqDJnMmcGYiCg==)

Answer (score 3):

## Java (229 Characters)

```
class Main{public static void main(String[]args){char q='"';String s="class Main{public static void main(String[]args){char q='%c';String s=%c%s%c;System.out.print(s.format(s,q,q,s,q));}}";System.out.print(s.format(s,q,q,s,q));}}
```

Comment: You can shorten it by naming your class a one character name (such as `q` for quine). Also, there is no need for `main(String[]args)`, just do something like `main(String[]a)` (total savings: 6 chars)

Comment: @Justin Technically, 12 bytes saving.

Answer (score 3):

### (ucb)logo - 28 chars

```
to q
po "q
pr "q
bye
end

q
```

Answer (score 3):

**MATLAB, 95 characters**

There might be shorter ones, but I'm happy that it works at all.

```
function d=g();d='gvodujpo!e>h)*<e>(<e>\e)2;29*.2-e-e)29;foe*.2^<';d=[d(1:18)-1,d,d(18:end)-1];
```

Cleaner approach, exact same length:

```
function d=g();d='function d=g();d=[d(1:17),39,d,39,d(15:end)];';d=[d(1:17),39,d,39,d(15:end)];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Mathcad, 94 characters**

```
f:(c{"f:(c{"")]concat(substr(c,0,6),c,substr(c,6,41))")]concat(substr(c,0,6),c,substr(c,6,41))
```

Watch out for quotation marks autocompletion in the editor!

This should create a parameterless function `f` which returns its own code.

This quine makes use of (another) weird feature of Mathcad: you can put as much quotation marks *inside* a string as you like. No idea how they handle it...

Answer (score 3):

### Burlesque - 1 byte

Technically, this is a quine:

```
1
```

Technically, this is also a quine:

```
{1 2 3}
```

Pretty much any literal is a quine.

This is also a quine which doesn't use a simple literal:

```
,#Q2 SH ~- ",#Q" \/ .+ sh
```

The comma is not necessary if you launch burlesque in no-stdin mode.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
jN*2]"jN*2]
```

Surprised this hadn't been posted yet :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
@Qw
```

This expects no input or output, i.e. `brachylog_main(_,_).`.

`@Q` is the string `"@Qw"`, and `w` is the write predicate.

#### A 34 bytes quine without a specific built-in for quines

```
"~c~s~cS:[34:S:34]rw"S:[34:S:34]rw
```

This is a basic quine strategy applied to this language:

```
"~c~s~cS:[34:S:34]rw"              § Create a string containing the source code
                                   § ~c~s~c gets replaced by the arguments of predicate w
                                   § in their respective order in the list
                                   § ~c prints the arg as a char code, ~s as a string
                     S             § Call this string S
                      :[34:S:34]rw § Write the format S to the output with args " (34),
                                   § S and " replacing ~c, ~s and ~c respectively
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>188</s> <s>157</s> 149 bytes

```cs
class A{static void Main(){var a="class A{{static void Main(){{var a={0}{1}{0};System.Console.Write(a,'{0}',a);}}}}";System.Con‌​sole.Write(a,'"',a);‌​}}
```

Basic quine, just contains a self-containing string.

Comment: More shorter version (149 bytes): `class A{static void Main(){var a="class A{{static void Main(){{var a={0}{1}{0};System.Console.Write(a,'{0}',a);}}}}";System.Console.Write(a,'"',a);}}`

Answer (score 3):

## Squeak Smalltalk - 91!

I just translated my [Factor answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/72040/39436):

`[:b|b value:b]value:[:b|Transcript show: '[:b|b value:b]value:[:b|' , b sourceString , ']']`

Just `DoIt!` in a Workspace, prints itself to the Transcript.

Blocks don't have a reference to *self*, so i used another block as a combinator.

I'm sure there MUST be a shorter Smalltalk quine! After all it's **Small**-talk :P

> No cheating -- that means that you can't just read the source file and print it.

At first I thought `BlockClosure>>sourceString` could be cheating as stated in the question, but looking at the Squeak implementation, doesn't seem to be reading the *sources* file<sup>1</sup>, but *decompiling* the block.

1: Smalltalk's image usually saves compiled code, and links to an external file with the original source.

Comment: It's cheating if `b` is your whole program. However, if `b` is a function or string literal, it's fine.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yeah `sourceString` looks like "read[ing] the source file and print[ing] it".

Comment: @MartinBüttner I just checked the implementation, and it _decompiles_ the BlockClosure, it doesn't use the sources file. The message-chain is: `sourceString` -> `self printSourceOn:` -> `self decompile`. Not sure if it's cheating in a general sense, but I think as stated in the question it's legit, right?

Comment: The second largest program I've seen. 91! = 1.352002e+140 :P

Comment: @zyabin101 That's weird, I get '`91! Argument expected ->`' if I `printIt`. What version of squeak are you using? :P

Comment: I'm using Google for that. :P

Comment: @fedes. Try: `USE: math.factorials 91 n!`, you get 135200152767840296255166568759495142147586866476906677791741734597153670771559994765685283954750449427751168336768008192000000000000000000000 :D

Comment: @cat is that a Monticello package? I can't find it on SmalltakHub... you guys make no sense!

Comment: @fedes. probably [needs more jQuery](http://needsmorejquery.com/)

Answer (score 3):

## Go, 115 bytes

```
package main;import."fmt";func main(){s:="package main;import.\"fmt\";func main(){s:=%q;Printf(s,s);}";Printf(s,s)}
```

Blowing the previous Go record out of the water!

Answer (score 3):

## [reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 9 bytes

```
"'34'coo;
```

This captures the string `'34'coo;`, then wraps around. After that, the number `34` is pushed the stack, converted to a character with `c`, finally being outputted with `o`. The next `o` outputs the captured string, and `;` terminates the program.

Other quines:

```
"'34'c~O;
"6@P2*c~O;
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), 30 bytes

```
;T...!59*\1=33*++o.9=\1=2*+(1"
```

The `T` should be replaced with a literal tab character.

#### About Ouroboros

Each line of an Ouroboros program represents a [snake eating its own tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros), with the beginning of the line being the head and the end being the tail. The only control flow operations are commands to eat or regurgitate characters of the tail. When the instruction pointer reaches the last part of the line that hasn't been eaten, it loops back to the beginning. If the instruction pointer is swallowed, execution halts.

While Ouroboros has some similarities to 2D languages such as ><>, its limited control flow options presented a challenge for quine construction. The only way to skip an instruction is to put it near the end and swallow it--which means instructions near the beginning basically can't be skipped. It took some experimenting before I found a quine structure that worked.

#### Explanation

The core idea is similar to a ><> or Befunge quine: with a wrapping IP, a single `"` mark can be used to stringify the code on one pass and execute it on another. Ouroboros automatically pushes strings to the stack in reverse order, which simplifies things. However, we have to put the quotation mark at the end so we can swallow it to avoid pushing the string multiple times. That means that the code must be executed first, then the string pushed, and then the code executed again until the output is complete.

On every pass, the code does two main things: output a character and swallow 0 or more characters of code.

```
...!59*\1=33*++o
```

On the first pass, the stack is empty and treated as zero. Logically negating and multiplying by `59` gives the character code for `;`, the first character of the quine. On the final pass, the `1` that was pushed right before the string (at the very end of the code) is encountered, to which we add `33` to turn it into `34`, the closing `"`. On other passes, the character code is output unchanged. In pseudocode: `output (!top)*59 + (top==1)*33 + top`

```
.9=\1=2*+(
```

There are two passes on which code needs to be swallowed. On the first pass after we push the string (when we print the tab) the quotation mark has to go; and on the last pass (after we've processed the whole string and the `1` is left on the stack) two more characters are eaten to swallow the instruction pointer and end the program. On every other pass, don't eat anything. In pseudocode: `swallow (top==9)+(top==1)*2`

One problem remains: since we output the first character of code on the initial pass, we have to drop it (`;`) immediately after pushing the string so it won't be output a second time. But we don't want to drop anything on subsequent passes. Fortunately, at the end of each iteration we push another `1` to the stack, which is immediately dropped at the beginning of the next pass.

#### Try it out

```js
// Define Stack class
function Stack() {
  this.stack = [];
  this.length = 0;
}
Stack.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.stack.push(item);
  this.length++;
}
Stack.prototype.pop = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack.pop();
    this.length--;
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.top = function() {
  var result = 0;
  if (this.length > 0) {
    result = this.stack[this.length - 1];
  }
  return result;
}
Stack.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "" + this.stack;
}

// Define Snake class
function Snake(code) {
  this.code = code;
  this.length = this.code.length;
  this.ip = 0;
  this.ownStack = new Stack();
  this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  this.alive = true;
  this.wait = 0;
  this.partialString = this.partialNumber = null;
}
Snake.prototype.step = function() {
  if (!this.alive) {
    return null;
  }
  if (this.wait > 0) {
    this.wait--;
    return null;
  }
  var instruction = this.code.charAt(this.ip);
  var output = null;
  console.log("Executing instruction " + instruction);
  if (this.partialString !== null) {
    // We're in the middle of a double-quoted string
    if (instruction == '"') {
      // Close the string and push its character codes in reverse order
      for (var i = this.partialString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.currStack.push(this.partialString.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      this.partialString = null;
    } else {
      this.partialString += instruction;
    }
  } else if (instruction == '"') {
    this.partialString = "";
  } else if ("0" <= instruction && instruction <= "9") {
    if (this.partialNumber !== null) {
      this.partialNumber = this.partialNumber + instruction;  // NB: concatenation!
    } else {
      this.partialNumber = instruction;
    }
    next = this.code.charAt((this.ip + 1) % this.length);
    if (next < "0" || "9" < next) {
      // Next instruction is non-numeric, so end number and push it
      this.currStack.push(+this.partialNumber);
      this.partialNumber = null;
    }
  } else if ("a" <= instruction && instruction <= "f") {
    // a-f push numbers 10 through 15
    var value = instruction.charCodeAt(0) - 87;
    this.currStack.push(value);
  } else if (instruction == "$") {
    // Toggle the current stack
    if (this.currStack === this.ownStack) {
      this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
    } else {
      this.currStack = this.ownStack;
    }
  } else if (instruction == "s") {
    this.currStack = this.ownStack;
  } else if (instruction == "S") {
    this.currStack = this.program.sharedStack;
  } else if (instruction == "l") {
    this.currStack.push(this.ownStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == "L") {
    this.currStack.push(this.program.sharedStack.length);
  } else if (instruction == ".") {
    var item = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(item);
    this.currStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "m") {
    var item = this.ownStack.pop();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "M") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.pop();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "y") {
    var item = this.ownStack.top();
    this.program.sharedStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "Y") {
    var item = this.program.sharedStack.top();
    this.ownStack.push(item);
  } else if (instruction == "\\") {
    var top = this.currStack.pop();
    var next = this.currStack.pop()
    this.currStack.push(top);
    this.currStack.push(next);
  } else if (instruction == "@") {
    var c = this.currStack.pop();
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(c);
    this.currStack.push(a);
    this.currStack.push(b);
  } else if (instruction == ";") {
    this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "+") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a + b);
  } else if (instruction == "-") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a - b);
  } else if (instruction == "*") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a * b);
  } else if (instruction == "/") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a / b);
  } else if (instruction == "%") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(a % b);
  } else if (instruction == "_") {
    this.currStack.push(-this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "I") {
    var value = this.currStack.pop();
    if (value < 0) {
      this.currStack.push(Math.ceil(value));
    } else {
      this.currStack.push(Math.floor(value));
    }
  } else if (instruction == ">") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a > b));
  } else if (instruction == "<") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a < b));
  } else if (instruction == "=") {
    var b = this.currStack.pop();
    var a = this.currStack.pop();
    this.currStack.push(+(a == b));
  } else if (instruction == "!") {
    this.currStack.push(+ !this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "?") {
    this.currStack.push(Math.random());
  } else if (instruction == "n") {
    output = "" + this.currStack.pop();
  } else if (instruction == "o") {
    output = String.fromCharCode(this.currStack.pop());
  } else if (instruction == "r") {
    var input = this.program.io.getNumber();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "i") {
    var input = this.program.io.getChar();
    this.currStack.push(input);
  } else if (instruction == "(") {
    this.length -= Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.max(this.length, 0);
  } else if (instruction == ")") {
    this.length += Math.floor(this.currStack.pop());
    this.length = Math.min(this.length, this.code.length);
  } else if (instruction == "w") {
    this.wait = this.currStack.pop();
  }
  // Any unrecognized character is a no-op
  if (this.ip >= this.length) {
    // We've swallowed the IP, so this snake dies
    this.alive = false;
    this.program.snakesLiving--;
  } else {
    // Increment IP and loop if appropriate
    this.ip = (this.ip + 1) % this.length;
  }
  return output;
}
Snake.prototype.getHighlightedCode = function() {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.code.length; i++) {
    if (i == this.length) {
      result += '<span class="swallowedCode">';
    }
    if (i == this.ip) {
      if (this.wait > 0) {
        result += '<span class="nextActiveToken">';
      } else {
        result += '<span class="activeToken">';
      }
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i)) + '</span>';
    } else {
      result += escapeEntities(this.code.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  if (this.length < this.code.length) {
    result += '</span>';
  }
  return result;
}

// Define Program class
function Program(source, speed, io) {
  this.sharedStack = new Stack();
  this.snakes = source.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(snakeCode) {
    var snake = new Snake(snakeCode);
    snake.program = this;
    snake.sharedStack = this.sharedStack;
    return snake;
  }.bind(this));
  this.snakesLiving = this.snakes.length;
  this.io = io;
  this.speed = speed || 10;
  this.halting = false;
}
Program.prototype.run = function() {
  this.step();
  if (this.snakesLiving) {
    this.timeout = window.setTimeout(this.run.bind(this), 1000 / this.speed);
  }
}
Program.prototype.step = function() {
   for (var s = 0; s < this.snakes.length; s++) {
    var output = this.snakes[s].step();
    if (output) {
      this.io.print(output);
    }
  }
  this.io.displaySource(this.snakes.map(function (snake) {
      return snake.getHighlightedCode();
    }).join("<br>"));
 }
Program.prototype.halt = function() {
  window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}

var ioFunctions = {
  print: function (item) {
    var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
    stdout.value += "" + item;
  },
  getChar: function () {
    if (inputData) {
      var inputChar = inputData[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
      result = inputChar.charCodeAt(0);
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  getNumber: function () {
    while (inputData && (inputData[0] < "0" || "9" < inputData[0])) {
      inputData = inputData.slice(1);
    }
    if (inputData) {
      var inputNumber = inputData.match(/\d+/)[0];
      inputData = inputData.slice(inputNumber.length);
      result = +inputNumber;
    } else {
      result = -1;
    }
    var stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display');
    stdinDisplay.innerHTML = escapeEntities(inputData);
    return result;
  },
  displaySource: function (formattedCode) {
    var sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display');
    sourceDisplay.innerHTML = formattedCode;
  }
};
var program = null;
var inputData = null;
function showEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "block";
  stdin.style.display = "block";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "none";
  
  source.focus();
}
function hideEditor() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    sourceDisplay = document.getElementById('source-display'),
    sourceDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('source-display-wrapper'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin'),
    stdinDisplay = document.getElementById('stdin-display'),
    stdinDisplayWrapper = document.getElementById('stdin-display-wrapper');
  
  source.style.display = "none";
  stdin.style.display = "none";
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.display = "block";
  
  var sourceHeight = getComputedStyle(source).height,
    stdinHeight = getComputedStyle(stdin).height;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = sourceHeight;
  sourceDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = sourceHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.minHeight = stdinHeight;
  stdinDisplayWrapper.style.maxHeight = stdinHeight;
  sourceDisplay.textContent = source.value;
  stdinDisplay.textContent = stdin.value;
}
function escapeEntities(input) {
  return input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
function resetProgram() {
  var stdout = document.getElementById('stdout');
  stdout.value = null;
  if (program !== null) {
    program.halt();
  }
  program = null;
  inputData = null;
  showEditor();
}
function initProgram() {
  var source = document.getElementById('source'),
    stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second'),
    stdin = document.getElementById('stdin');
  program = new Program(source.value, +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML, ioFunctions);
  hideEditor();
  inputData = stdin.value;
}
function runBtnClick() {
  if (program === null || program.snakesLiving == 0) {
    resetProgram();
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
    var stepsPerSecond = document.getElementById('steps-per-second');
    program.speed = +stepsPerSecond.innerHTML;
  }
  program.run();
}
function stepBtnClick() {
  if (program === null) {
    initProgram();
  } else {
    program.halt();
  }
  program.step();
}
function sourceDisplayClick() {
  resetProgram();
}
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.so-box {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .3em .7em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    border: 1px solid #c47b07;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: #f88912;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
}
.control {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
}
span[contenteditable] {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    background: #cc7801;
    color: #fff;
}
#stdout-container, #stdin-container {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
#reset {
    float: right;
}
#source-display-wrapper , #stdin-display-wrapper{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#source-display , #stdin-display{
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 2px;
}
.activeToken {
    background: #f93;
}
.nextActiveToken {
    background: #bbb;
}
.swallowedCode{
    color: #999;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--
Designed and written 2015 by D. Loscutoff
Much of the HTML and CSS was taken from this Befunge interpreter by Ingo Bürk: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40331/16766
-->
<div class="container">
<textarea id="source" placeholder="Enter your program here" wrap="off">; ...!59*\1=33*++o.9=\1=2*+(1"</textarea>
<div id="source-display-wrapper" onclick="sourceDisplayClick()"><div id="source-display"></div></div></div><div id="stdin-container" class="container">
<textarea id="stdin" placeholder="Input" wrap="off"></textarea>
<div id="stdin-display-wrapper" onclick="stdinDisplayClick()"><div id="stdin-display"></div></div></div><div id="controls-container" class="container clearfix"><input type="button" id="run" class="control so-box" value="Run" onclick="runBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="pause" class="control so-box" value="Pause" onclick="program.halt()" /><input type="button" id="step" class="control so-box" value="Step" onclick="stepBtnClick()" /><input type="button" id="reset" class="control so-box" value="Reset" onclick="resetProgram()" /></div><div id="stdout-container" class="container"><textarea id="stdout" placeholder="Output" wrap="off" readonly></textarea></div><div id="options-container" class="container"><div class="option so-box">Steps per Second:
<span id="steps-per-second" contenteditable>20</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 73 bytes (incl. tabs and newlines)

```
(f=function()
{
    cat("(f=function()\n")
    print(body(f))
    cat(")()")
}
)()
```

Shorter, less interesting quines are possible: `function()1` is 11 bytes. `+` (1 byte) is an arguable quine, since the command prompt for an unfinished line is a plus sign by default, and `+` on its own counts as an unfinished line.

Comment: It is necessary to format exactly this way (can't remove tabs or replace newline with ";"), otherwise the output will not exactly match the input.

Comment: A more trivial example is `function()1` (11 bytes) but that's kinda boring...

Comment: Your [14 bytes solution](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9PQ1OBy4Dr/38A)  is not easy to find. And I don't find it boring at all! Suggestion: keep the 73 solution but list this solution as 14 bytes one so it found more easily using the leaderboard.

Comment: I may be misreading some details of how programs are defined in R, but I think `list()` is a shorter trivial solution? I can't do command-line verification, but it certainly plays interactively and on TIO (though you might argue a newline is needed for the latter) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyezuERD8/9/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: yes, `list()` (and `numeric(0)` and friends) are all quines in R.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 36 bytes

```julia
(~=:@printf "(~=:%s)|>eval" ~)|>eval
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=KH49OkBwcmludGYgIih-PTolcyl8PmV2YWwiIH4pfD5ldmFs&input=)

#### Background

Unlike many other languages, Julia's *eval* doesn't work as expected with a string; for example, `eval("print(42)")` just returns the string **print(42)**.

To actually executed `print(42)` with *eval;*, we have to pass an *Expr* to *eval*. This can be done by invoking *parse* on a string (e.g., `eval(parse("print(42)"))`) or by passing an *Expr* literal to *eval* (e.g., `eval(:(print(42)))`.

Now, while `:` is a unary operator and `:print` works fine on its own, `:print(42)` does not, as it is parsed as `(:print)(42)`, making all parentheses in `:(print(42))` mandatory.

However, if we use the macro `@printf` instead, the parsing rules change, and `:@printf(42)` works as intended. Also, macro calls also do not require parentheses, and `:@printf 42` saves one byte over `:(print(42))`.

#### How it works

`:@printf "(~=:%s)|>eval" ~` constructs the *Expr* that calls `@printf` with the specified format string and additional argument **~**. Here, **~** is simply a variable reference; the name is arbitrary.

`~=<Expr>` saves the generated *Expr* in the variable **~**, which will be accessible when the *Expr* is evaluated.

Finally, `(<assigment>)|>eval` calls *eval* with the return value of the assignment, i.e., the *Expr* that was assigned to **~**.

Answer (score 3):

## Y, 2 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Y/)

```
Up
```

This is two commands. `U` is a capture link, and begins quoting the code, and has a `U` at the beginning of the result. It wraps around, since there is no matching `U`, and captures the string `Up`. Then, `p` prints it, and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <strike>41</strike> 37 Bytes:

<strike>`function q{"function q{$function:q};q"};q`</strike>

```
filter q{"filter q{$function:q};q"};q
```

> Thanks to TimmyD for saving 4 bytes

Comment: What interpreter / compiler does this work in? In [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell_terminal_online.php) interpreter, this submission doesn't work (it outputs `function q{End: { "function q{$function:q};q" }};q`).

Comment: @Loovjo Most online PowerShell interpreters use an open-source PoSH that's roughly equivalent to PowerShell v0.5 and lacking many features. The above works fine in an actual install on Windows.

Comment: At least in v4 on Windows 8.1, you can shave a few bytes using `filter` as follows -- `filter q{"filter q{$function:q};q"};q` for 37.

Comment: `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock` is 2 bytes shorter but almost definitely cheating?

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
'&DtU'
&DtU
```

(the code has a trailing newline).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X13NpSRUnQtEcv3/DwA)

#### Explanation

```
'&DtU'    % Push this string
&D        % String representation (adds quote marks)
t         % Duplicate
U         % Evaluate (removes quote marks)
          % Implicitly display each string followed by a newline
```

Comment: I take it that it would not be shorter to do `&D` after `t`, avoiding `U`?

Comment: @ETHproductions Not sure if I understand your suggestion correctly. I think `&D` needs to be after `t` because the second part of the displayed output needs to be without quotes

Comment: I mean that unevaling the string `&D` and then re-evaling `U` seems a little redundant. It's probably not shorter any other way, though, as you would likely need to use stack manipulation.

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh, now I see what you mean: [this](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J3QmRHcnCnQmRHc&input=), right? (`w` is swap). As you say, it's not shorter unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, and that's what I figured

Comment: Shouldn't this be 12 bytes, since there's a trailing newline in the output?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I think so, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 9 bytes

```
95 34
_"
```

Although writing functional programs in Pushy is sometimes difficult, the quine is relatively simple:

```
95   % Push 95 to the stack (ASCII code for _ )
34   % Push 34 to the stack (ASCII code for " )
_    % Print representation of the stack: 95 34
"    % Print stack converted to string: _"
```

Notice that, although Pushy ignores newlines, it is needed here because the default separator for printing is `\n` - and there needs to be a trailing newline, hence making it 9 bytes

---

Alternatively, an 11-byte solution that does not require a newline:

```
78 95 34N_"
```

Works similarly to the one above, but `N` sets the separator an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), 7 bytes

Yay, my first quine!

```
"34c,o|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#@69kbJKsk1/z/z8A)

#### Explanation

This is a standard 2D quine.

```
"           starts to push a string
34c,o|      part of the string
"           it wraps around and go to the beginning of this line thus pushing the string
34          push this number
c           output as character (ie outputs ")
,           discard this value
o           output the top of stack (ie 34c,o|)
|           end program
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes

```
0
0
```

Note the trailing linefeed. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/AZcD1/z8A)

This exploits a potential flaw in our [definition of proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878/12012):

> It must be possible to identify a section of the program which encodes a different part of the program. ("Different" meaning that the two parts appear in different positions.)
>
> Furthermore, a quine must not access its own source, directly or indirectly.

The stack of Actually is printed backwards, so the first **0** encodes the *second* **0**, and vice versa.

This can be verified empirically; the program

```
1
2
```

prints

```
2
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/IZcT1/z8A)

Answer (score 3):

## Logicode, <s>1368</s> <s>1241</s> <s>1096</s> 1086 bytes

```
var a=000101011000111101001111001011000110100000111000001010001100101010100101011010111110110001111011111101110110010001000001100101010110101111101000000010100011001010111100010101111001010111110011110001010111100101011111001111100111100010101111001010111110011111001111100111100010101111001010111110011111001111100111110011110001010111100101011111001111100111110011111001111100111100010101111001010111110011111001111100111110011111001111100111100010100101010111110000010100011001010111110011111001111100111110011111001111100111110010100101011111100101000101011011111110101111010001000001110000010100001100010110001011000101100000110001011000101100000110001011000101100000110000011000001100000110001011000101100010110001011000001100000110001011000001100000110001011000001100000110000011000001100000110001011000101100000110000011000001100000110001011000001100010110001011000101100010110000011000101010010101011110000101010111110000010100011000010101001
circ p(e)->cond e->@(e<+e><+e>><+e>>><+e>>>><+e>>>>><+e>>>>>><)+p(e>>>>>>>)/e
out p(111011011000011110010010000011000010111101)+a+p(a)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/logicode#pVPLDoIwELzzFRxpCHH2jo2/0mAPXsQQ9fexdftCUVqF0NlMO7OFKfNdTbXaAyB7ky3MZWrGSFqKZxnhaBaCggM9lQszT5ATIJgFeaID1jpw41hGweZc/pLilb8K/tQt5eEbfginyJNSz5QIOfk4w0lZPRrw23sHlJKrQNsdUEpmNMpYmb9Bes0P@JZmFFTDaRrqS6NFJ4fxfKx1Jw@N7lst7cODGz0ElL1ojZRrKXa6Gm9XY@Z@UNfJJY/0NX3molXGQYl5fgA)

### Explanation

This is pretty simple as far as Quines go.  The first line of the program assigns a very long list of ones and zeros to a variable called `a` this is the binary representation of the last two lines of the program with each character represented by 7 bits.

Then I define a function that takes in a binary string and returns it as a ASCII string.

This works pretty simply:

```
circ p(e)->                                  #Function header
cond e->                                     #If e is non empty
@(e<+e><+e>><+e>>><+e>>>><+e>>>>><+e>>>>>><) #return the ASCII character made by the first 7 bit
+                                            #plus
p(e>>>>>>>)                                  #p of the rest of the string
/                                            #otherwise
e                                            #return e (i.e. the empty string)
```

Then on the last line we print `var a=` the binary string and the ASCII representation of the binary string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Threead](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Threead), 24 bytes

```
">34co<o>o<o">34co<o>o<o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#@69kZ2ySnG@TbwfEyOz//wE)

I didn't think to do it like this until I saw [Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57100/riley)'s answer. I have no intention to self-award the bounty, so this is non-competitive for it.

### Explanation

```
">34co<o>o<o">34co<o>o<o
">34co<o>o<o"               # Encodes the right half of the program as a string, in the 1st buffer.
             >              # Move to the 2nd buffer.
              34c           # Put the string represented by ascii 34 (") in the second buffer.
                 o          # Write it to STDOUT
                  <o        # Move to the 1st buffer, Write the contents of the string to STDOUT.
                    >o      # Move back to the 2nd Buffer, write it.
                      <o    # Move back to the 1st Buffer, write it.
```

### Originally... 129 Bytes...

My plan was to use:

```
"\x0E\x0E\x0E78g\x0EBv$/s@$@c8$$$$$vB\x0Ep$/c6Bb_$f$vgs@$/Bba\x0E$$$c5$$$$$1c5$$$$p"

34c
>r +o< <_4     r>
l +_2>^[ b rco< +>^]
   _1     -_1    l
```

where `\x0E` is the literal `SOH`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#JYq7CoQwEAD7LfYbFtkuHMHHeRYSJL8hGszC2QhKhPx@jDrNFDOpQMRft6KNrM@BB@n4Jlo8WEtrveM/xzUnbf2COcn3OcrXRwFQNwImkNp76l1DN8HARspVZh7JU5CclJknyMmVz/F5vaVEFw)

The string is simply all the commands after it, but with a byte value 4 higher. This was because I can't store a `"` or a `\` in the string, without it getting *meta*. The rest of the script, acts kind of like my other solution, however manually iterates through the string, printing each character -4.

Comment: "I have no intention to self-award the bounty." You can't.

Comment: The README on github doesn't seem to mention that you can push string literals.

Comment: @Riley True, but you can figure that out by looking at the Threead "Hello, World!" program.

Comment: Question, how does string multiplication work? I was trying to get it to work on TIO (to solve your bounty), and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @mbomb007 Hopefully [this](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#@6/kkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqMSlgAq08rkMTf//BwA) will help you out. And Riley sorry about that, the readme was kind of poorly written.

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 17 bytes

*Thanks to James Holderness for pointing out that this relies on nonstandard interpreter behavior*

Slightly late to the party, but here goes!

```
<@,*2+98_,#! #:<"
```

[Try it here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), but you have to copy-paste the code. The program relies on nonstandard interpreter behavior, so it'll print a bunch of leading spaces on TIO. Oops. My bad.

`<`: sets the program direction to "left"; instruction pointer wraps around

`"`: toggles string mode (pushes ascii value of every character until next `"`, which it encounters only when it wraps around)

*(at this point, it pushes every character to the stack & wraps around. This is where it relies on nonstandard behavior - TIO and the reference interpreter would push a bunch of spaces to the stack)*

`:<`: sets the instruction pointer direction to "left" and duplicates top of stack

`! #`: negates the value at the top (important because of the upcoming `_`); `#` skips the next character

`_,#`: checks the value at the top of the stack & pops it: prints the  ascii value as a character of the new top and sets the direction of the instruction pointer to right if checked character was `0`; else sets the direction of the instruction pointer to left

`@,*2+98`: prints the `"` at the end of the program and quits.

Answer (score 3):

## [DipDup](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/DipDup), 6 bytes

```
[_:]_:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVRNj9owEL3nV0wjJBJRuPUSLXtBVKrUqqj0htKsN5hibWJbjilB6n@nM@N8LeVAxm/emy9PchbNm6yq@13V1jgPP2XrVzvhGuk2pn5VWnjjmtUPKY67KDoKL5DialjDBjZn4eAvbGHbWhdF/mYlm@g8ECmPIqUbL3QpYX8216C8nqWTEeCvISzZQJmSoswn4BYkgfEhhsUiYJKsOI8H1lfVeOQki0UKKyiNLoX/Jiz7Jpmp9MfMDrFm52SJehRinBlju8KbYs8mKQZul@qBEtruyZBlnGvHyUZ4TS0@zZ6hEV41pxskL9r4bSXrF@wvj9MUG1tQy0R6lf4qpYakpOHOD/O0N3M0@6xpSMvDHtJyOQO8hlro29hKuLu9F@Ub@oJymQUAh3VSrYNPBNHolA/EbCT0EN5UzsoBwps3dqDC8jlUQmDSMrWgu2y7Dfl80TT2gdzFkH9E1Y@Rn@gi6ujolyKRFDSdODYw/zUn11HZ93AR4MsD/IFhax7gjGFaiBEvEFHHUF8/b35O6@smfqqUxVU8mepY4UbxsQ8UIkzVPCUG10DDWo0CpkwGjH2RkvOR3c31xv8NFR3MQdtCg6rLRHUZVMwPZgdEkTUjleykGKnoppEMfj78XwFeD56gTfuYTnZb4ZT@HW6aLMaVthd6o0rRSDi0@BVJ2o8Qxyk8LcPbGSg5mBO/hYc2pxD8JZhxn7hQ5CgIls4ZB7Gl71Y4xFFUC6WpgC/fIUnDCa9Se@lE6TGJvd8PRZYX2T8)

#### Explanation

```
[_:]        push this list
    _       duplicate
     :      cons
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Threead](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Threead), 101 bytes

```
>91>60>93>62>91>105>54>50>99>111>100>111>62>93>60>91>60>93>62>91>99>111>62>93[<]>[i62codo>]<[<]>[co>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/threead#@29naWhnZmBnaWxnZgRiGxqY2pma2JkChSztDA1BAgZgGiRtDFaKqgGqDCwdbRNrF51pZpScn5JvF2sD5iYDWf//AwA)

My first thought for writing a Threead quine was to store the entire data section as one large number, in order to get a good compression ratio. This doesn't work because a) `%` appears to be broken, and b) Threead doesn't support bignum arithmetic.

Instead, I wrote this solution, which works along the same lines as a brainfuck quine, storing the characters of the code section of the program as individual tape elements. Then we just have to scan the list once in order to print it as data, and again to print it as code.

Although Threead allows for three threads, and requires their use when performing binary operations, this style of quine uses only unary operations and thus there was no point in using more than one thread, so I just did everything inside the first.

### Explanation

```
>91>60>…>62>93            ASCII character codes of the rest of the program
[<]>                      Return the pointer to the start of the data
[                         While the current data cell is nonzero:
 i62                        Place 62 (ASCII code of >) on a temporary tape cell
 co                         Output it as a character (i.e. >)
 d                          Delete the temporary tape cell
 o                          Output the current data element as an integer
>]                        then continue the loop with the next data cell
<[<]>                     Return the pointer to the start of the data
[                         While the current data cell is nonzero:
 co                         Output it as a character
>]                        then continue the loop with the next data cell
```

Comment: Nice. Basically the same as [mine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106640/57100) but with `>` at the beginning. I like it

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I used that trick in my new version :)

Comment: @Riley: That's OK, we're pretty much all cooperating to improve the quine at this point.

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 9 bytes

*Credits to Sp3000 for the idea of including the `!`.*

```
"!<@o&9h.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@kaOOQr2aZoff/PwA)

#### Explanation

This works much like quines in other Fungeoids with an unmatched `"` that wraps the entire code (except itself) in a string because the instruction pointer move cyclically through the code.

```
"!<@o&9h."   Push code points of the entire program except the " to the
             stack (irrelevant).
!            Store 46 (the code point of '.') on the tape (irrelevant).
<            Send IP back west.
!            Store 104 (the code point of 'h') on the tape (irrelevant).
".h9&o@<!"   Push code points of the entire program except the " to the
             stack in reverse.
.            Duplicate the 33 (the code point of '!').
h            Increment to 34 (the code point of '"').
             Now the top nine values on the stack correspond to the entire
             code in reverse order.
9&           Repeat the next command 9 times.
o            Print 9 characters from the top of the stack.
@            Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 24 bytes, 21 characters

```
.($s={".(`$s={$s})"})
```

I'm going to attempt to explain this, but be forewarned that I'm terrible at explaining myself.

This code sets $s to the following:

```
".(`$s={$s})"
```

This recursively sets the variable $s (the first $s is a plain string, but the second $s is the variable $s) in itself and then the block inside parentheses echoes $s, which at time of execution will be the following:

```
.($s={".(`$s={$s})"})`
```

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 16 bytes

```
[91Pn6120568P]dx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@x9taRiQZ2ZoZGBqZhEQm1Lx/z8A)

Nothing fancy, posting for completeness.

### Explanation

```
[91Pn6120568P]dx
 91P              # Print "["
    n             # Print the macro
     6120568P     # Print "]dx" encoded as a number
[            ]dx  # Run macro on its own code
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 131 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE("=SUBSTITUTE(@,CHAR(64),CHAR(34)&@&CHAR(34))",CHAR(64),CHAR(34)&"=SUBSTITUTE(@,CHAR(64),CHAR(34)&@&CHAR(34))"&CHAR(34))
```

Adapted from a program by Dave Burt.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 112 bytes

As far as I can tell, there's no Go answer here. Here's mine and I think this is the shortest possible.

```
package main;import.`fmt`;func main(){s:="package main;import.`fmt`;func main(){s:=%q;Printf(s,s)}";Printf(s,s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#@1@QmJydmJ6qkJuYmWedmVuQX1Sil5CWW5JgnVaalwwW1tCsLrayVSJapWqhdUBRZl5JmkaxTrFmrRIK7/9/AA)

Comment: [80 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjcDMnML8otK9BLScksSrNNK85IV0jQ0q4utbJVwyqgWWgcUZeaVpGkU6xRr1iqh8CDmbgKrB9kD1MIF1McFlViwAEIDAA) by turning it into a called function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 121 bytes

Nobody cared enough about Kotlin to post it so...

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){val s="fun main(a:Array<String>){val s=%c%s%1$1c;print(s.format(34,s))}";print(s.format(34,s))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM08j0cqxqCix0ia4pCgzL91Os7osMUeh2FaJkALVZNViVUMVw2TrAqB4iUaxXlp@UW5iiYaxiU6xpmatEg7x//8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 48 bytes

The language's pretty groovy too.

```
s="s=%c%s%c;printf(s,34,s,34)";printf(s,34,s,34)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/2Fap2FY1WbVYNdm6oCgzryRNo1jH2EQHRGgqYQr9/w8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Micro](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Micro), 5 bytes

```
{_BS}
```

### Explination:

```
{_BS}

{      start a code block (this block will be run due to implicit evaluation)
 _     push the item most recently popped. this pushes the code block which was popped due to implicit evaluation
  BS}  convert the code block to a string, and end the block. Micro's implicit evaluation is weird, because the evaluated variable may generate new items on the stack, in which case the program's execution will continue as if it hadn't ended. this second implicit evaluation displays the string which is left on the stack: "{_BS}", and ends execution.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 28 bytes

<sub>Note: This doesn't work on TIO. I guess it's because TIO doesn't store the command history. It works on the desktop version. I tried it in Octave 4.2.1.</sub>

---

```
printf('%s',[history(1){:}])
```

So, what's going on here?

[`history`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Commands-For-History.html) is a function that can be used to read and manipulate the command history.

`history(n)` shows the `n` most recent commands you have typed, numbered:

```
>> x = 1 + 2;
>> y = x * 3;
>> history(3)
    7 x = 1 + 2;
    8 y = x * 3;
    9 history(3)
```

As you can see, `x = 1 + 2` was the seventh command that was typed after the history was cleared the last time. The command `history(3)` is included in this list.

Now, `history(1)` is not a quine, since it gives:

```
>> history(1)
   10 history(1)
```

However, if you assign the output from `history(1)` to an output, you'll get:

```
>> x = history(1)
x =
{
  [1,1] = x = history(1)
}
```

It's still not a quine, but it's something we can work with.

Unwrapping this, and we're a bit closer:

```
>> [history(1){:}]
ans = [history(1){:}]
```

Notice that the entire command, including brackets are outputted.

Finally, if we print this as a string, using `printf`, we get:

```
>> printf('%s',[history(1){:}])
printf('%s',[history(1){:}])
```

Note: `disp([history(1){:}])` almost works, but it appends a trailing newline.

Comment: Wouldn't `disp([history(1){:}])\n` work for 27 bytes?

Answer (score 3):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 64 bytes

```c
main(t){printf(t,34,t="main(t){printf(t,34,t=%c%s%c,34);}",34);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z83MTNPo0SzuqAoM68kTaNEx9hEp8RWCbuwarJqsWoykK1pXasEof7/BwA)

could be one problem if compiler not use the stack based way of push arguments.
result of the print (tcc, gcc all in TIO today at last ok (not ok in clang)):

```c
main(t){printf(t,34,t="main(t){printf(t,34,t=%c%s%c,34);}",34);}
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122856/70664)

Answer (score 3):

#### Java 8 - 392 bytes

```
interface Q{static void main(String[]a){p("interface Q{static void main(String[]a){p(");q(");}static void p(String s){System.out.print(s+(char)34+s+(char)34+')'+';'+'q'+'('+(char)34);}static void q(String s){System.out.print(s+(char)34+s);}}");}static void p(String s){System.out.print(s+(char)34+s+(char)34+')'+';'+'q'+'('+(char)34);}static void q(String s){System.out.print(s+(char)34+s);}}
```

The main trick with this was using 34 cast to a character for the quotes that bound the string literals in order to not run into issues.

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), <s>69</s> <s>57</s> <s>53</s> 41 bytes

```
Printf[s:="Printf[s:=%s,Repr@s]",Repr@s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM68kLbrYylYJwVQt1glKLShyKI5VgjG4/v8HAA) Surprised I didn't think of this sooner.

---

```
Print!Format[x:="Print!Format[x:=%s,Repr!x]",Repr!x]
```

In the end, the standard quine framework was most efficient :( . The 57-byter below is significantly more interesting.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69E0S2/KDexJLrCylYJXUC1WCcotaBIsSJWCcbg@v8fAA)

**BUT** I found a cooler one, also for 53 bytes!

```
Print!Join[q:=["Print!Join[q:=", ",Repr!q]"],Repr!q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69E0Ss/My@60Mo2WgmVr6SjoKQTlFpQpFgYqxQLY3H9/w8A)

### 57 bytes

```
Print!Format<~_,Repr!_~>["Print!Format<~_,Repr!_~>[%s]"]
```

This uses sneaky curried functions with blanks. When a function is called using 
`f<~...~>` syntax, it denotes a curried function. `_1` represents the first curried argument, `_2` the second, etc. `_` is an alias for `_1`, so this saves us some bytes without duplicating our string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69E0S2/KDexxKYuXicotaBIMb7OLloJp4xqcaxSLNf//wA)

### 69 bytes

```
Save["Save[%c%s%c]Print[Format[_,34,_,34]]"]Print[Format[_,34,_,34]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/PzixLDVaCUyqJqsWqybHBhRl5pVEu@UX5SaWRMfrGJvogIjYWCWcMlz//wMA) The trailing newline is significant.

### Explanation

`Save` updates the abstract variable `_` with the string

```
"Save[%c%s%c]Print[Format[_,34,_,34]]"
```

Then, this string is formatted with the arguments `_`, `34`, `_`, and `34`. This prints the string, the character 34 (a quote), and then those two again, which is the program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 28 bytes

```
(()->print1("("self")()"))()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/X0NDU9euoCgzr8RQQ0lDqTg1J01JU0NTSRNI/P8PAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
sP#H"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/vzhA2UPp/38A)

Credit to Jo King.

#### How it works

```
sP#H"

s      +16
 P     +1
  #    Reverse direction
 P     +1
s      +16
    "  Start string literal
sP#H"  Push H, #, P, s and end string literal
   H   Print everything on the stack from the top, and halt
       The printed chars are s, P, #, H, 34 (")
```

### Previous solution, 6 bytes

```
"r2ssH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X6nIqLjY4/9/AA)

#### How it works

```
"r2ssH  Push the string "r2ssH" to stack, "r" being at the bottom
"       Close the literal
 r      Reverse the stack
  2ss   Push 34 (")
     H  Print all content of the stack from top to bottom as chars, and halt
```

There were a couple of alternatives to consider:

- `S"` prints the string right away (instead of pushing to stack), but then it gets harder to handle `"`.
- `` `" `` is an alternative way to push 34 to the stack, but the string literal also treats `` `" `` as escaped `"` which is not desirable.

Comment: An interesting [8 byter](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X0nD3jpJNz/4/38A) using `S"`

Answer (score 3):

## Noether, 30 bytes

```
"~a34BPaP34BPaP"~a34BPaP34BPaP
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=In5hMzRCUGFQMzRCUGFQIn5hMzRCUGFQMzRCUGFQ&input=)

Basically, this works by pushing the string and storing it in the variable `a`, printing quotation marks (`34B` where `B` pushes the character with ASCII code `34`) then printing `a` twice.

Comment: @OMᗺ That's only the Python/tio.run interpreter (which has a few bugs) . On the JS interpreter, there is no newline.

Comment: Alright, that's the one on TIO so I tried with that sorry! Nvm, in that case.

Answer (score 3):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 94 bytes

```
	9	f;	/*+{ ;{?06	0/9^[]={o)	*4_;=	9);];36   
:
g<
0+,|!<|@17
10:_\^>|p*
+5`<>
:*<  ^ <47!!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBEoIgEADQ8@5PsByFGnEyHVi0/qPE6qAXJxuv8O/be8u2f77vQwQ8LAy1sZk431wHrvbpMQ15r8C0Mw/gK1ZqUnzpiAgDrhGdPRUdy73psXFhfqax/Aza6yuOGEwkShTbXmstIufjDw)

There's some debate over whether the `g`et instruction counts as reading the source code, but in this case, I'm not using it to read the executed code, but a data array on the first line (except for specifically reusing just the `9` character).

This reads and prints the data section, then reads and prints each character incremented by one to represent the code section.

#### Explanation:

```
.
..
.....<|@..   Start at the @ going left
..........   We use the | to evaluate the code beyond it and come back here
.....
.............

:
g<
0+,|!<....   Print the character on the first line at position n plus 0
.0........   Then go down from the |
.....
.............

.9
.
..
...|!.....
..:_......   If n > 5*9 then go left at the _ and return !n
.5`<.
.*<..........

.
..
...|!<....   Else go right and increment n
1.._\^....   And loop again
+...>
:............

.
..           Once we've ended the loop we come back to the original | going down
.....<|.17   And we put a 1 at the (1,4) position and repeat the main code again
.1....>|p*   This time adding 1 to each character
.....
.....^ <47...
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
"'<~@>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19J3abOwe7/fwA)

Huh, a multiple pointer quine actually works pretty well.

### Explanation:

```
"'<~@>
  <  >   Start pointers going left and right
"'<      Left pointer pushes " to their stack
    @    And terminate the IP, printing the stack (")
     >   Right pointer wraps around
"        Start string literal
 '<~@>   Push as string
"        End string literal
 '<~     Push the < character, but pop it
    @    Terminate the IP, printing the stack ('<~@>)
         End the program as there are no IPs left
```

Edit: I realised you can replicate this with only one pointer

```
'<~@|"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/dps6hRun/fwA)

Comment: Ha, didn't even see prior to posting [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173130/47990) *and* you already beat me. Very clever use of the multiple IP feature.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
"r2ssH
```

Hopefully this is not a previously used quine, I was messing around for another challenge having to do with quines, and I ended up creating this!

**2nd program (the most recent), 7 bytes**

```
":P}rH!
```

Courtesy of [JoKing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king), who knocked an entire byte off the original!

**1st program (the original), 8 bytes**

```
":P&r&H!
```

I know this isn't the smallest, but it is my first quine in `Gol><>` (I did it entirely on my own!). Link to the interpreter in the title!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X6nIqLjY4/9/AA)

**Code Breakdown**

```
":P&r&H!
```

First, the `"` command collects all of the chars and rewraps around the program

Then the `:` command doubles the last symbol in the program, the `!`

Then this is incremented, and saved by the register

The stack is then reversed and the value is put back

Then the entire stack is outputted as characters and then the program halts

Comment: you can use `}` to rotate the stack instead of `&`, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X8kqoLbIQ/H/fwA)

Comment: @JoKing wow, that cuts one byte off, thanks, is it okay if I put that as the answer (with credit to you of course)

Comment: of course you can. PPCG is a lot about cooperative answers rather than competition and it's nice to help new users figure out shortcuts in their chosen language(s)

Comment: @JoKing Thanks, credits are also to you! Are you a Gol><> coder, if you have any experience, do you have tips, I really like it!

Comment: there's not really much Gol><> specific advice, but I would recommend getting familiar with its parent language, `><>`, first.

Comment: @JoKing Alright, thank you for the advice!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89348/discussion-between-krystostheoverlord-and-jo-king).

Answer (score 3):

## [Fueue](https://github.com/TryItOnline/fueue), <del>411</del> <del>391</del> <del>381</del> 376 bytes

```
(5(2(7(1(8(0(0(4(0(2(5(2(4(9(9(0(4(9(0(2(4(2(8(2(1(6(9(0(6(2(9(5(9(5(9(0(1(1(4(0(3(2(3(1(3(1(9(1(8(1(1(1(0(1(4(0(1(2(3(1(3(1(7(1(6(1(9(0(4(9(9(5(8(2(4(9(9(0(4(9(4(9(1(6(9(0(4(9(1(0(1(6(4(9(9(5(4(9(9(0(4(9(4(9(1(6(9(0(4(9(6(2(9(5(9(0(3(1(3(1(4(9(1(1(0(2(6(1(3(1(3(1(0(2(4(2(9(0(4(9(6(2(1(6(4(9(1(6[10(:91(H49~)~48<]):[[)+$7--32+*$5--10)~[<~)~~])~!]~[~)~~])~:[)--~+40--48)~:]~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU/BDcMgDPx3i0p5mEZINhACUQboDohnukG@rE4dh5Kqj8qy7Dufz/Dat32rFSYwMANBAORwnEY4B5EDpaJgwxrDSi@M5z6y8kxknmTbMm@5PzKKL0lgm9PXfBY36ncOr/Bz24mL7/h08l3/T3u9EfvNU0PyJ98427AT/bX7ucM1EcISCZ4uFlVcWLNaUlLjMGttzfgYJq0JVUkrj0tW5Z5Lau2SlNZldKi1Cwxzybda3w)

See also [Ørjan Johansen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162904/25180).

Basic idea (outdated):

```
(7(1(9(5(1(1(8(0...                  Data.
[9!(91[+(H~)]57<33]                  Begin the second pass and end the program on second pass.
):[                                  Duplicate and evaluate the block.
    [)+$7--32+*$5--10)~[<~)~~])~!]   On the second pass, print b*10+a+32 for each two digits a, b.
    )()[~)~~]~:~<                    Copy a digit and evaluate the next line between copies.
    [)----40+--~)48~:~~]             Print "("+digit and duplicate and evaluate the whole block on the next digit.
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
$_=q(print qq(\$_=q($_);eval));eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZQo6AoM69EobBQIwbMVYnXtE4tS8zRhFD//wMA)

Comment: Welcome! Please consider adding an explanation or a link to an online interpreter. Code-only answers tend to be automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: No problem. I didn't realize that tio.run has an area to copy/paste submission markdown for code golf. Very cool.

Answer (score 3):

### [Tir](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tir), 24 bytes

Abandoned languages are my favorite.

```
«⤇℘↔»
⤇℘↔
```

### Explanation

```
«⤇℘↔»       Push a string onto the stack. Stack: [⤇℘↔]
      ⤇      Duplicate TOS. Stack: [⤇℘↔,⤇℘↔]
        ℘    Make top of stack in its string-represented form. Stack: [⤇℘↔,«⤇℘↔»]
         ↔   Swap top two items in the stack. Stack: [«⤇℘↔»,⤇℘↔]
Stack will be implicitly outputted.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 287 bytes

```
var a="[118,97,114,32,97,61,34].each{|m|System.write(String.fromCodePoint(m))}
System.write(a+String.fromCodePoint(34)+String.fromCodePoint(10)+a)"
[118,97,114,32,97,61,34].each{|m|System.write(String.fromCodePoint(m))}
System.write(a+String.fromCodePoint(34)+String.fromCodePoint(10)+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/vyyxSCHRVina0NBCx9Jcx9DQRMfYCMQyM9QxNonVS01Mzqiuya0JriwuSc3VKy/KLEnVCC4pysxL10srys91zk9JDcjPzCvRyNXUrOVCUZaojVWhsYkmdglDA03tRE0lrkHkmP//AQ)

### Explanation

````
var a=                                                                         // Define the variable a
      "[118,97,114,32,97,61,34].each{|m|System.write(String.fromCodePoint(m))}
System.write(a+String.fromCodePoint(34)+String.fromCodePoint(10)+a)"           // As the string that processes the variable

                                                                               // A literal newline is inserted and can be decoded literally.

[118,97,114,32,97,61,34].each{|m|System.write(String.fromCodePoint(m))}        // Output the string "var a=" to the console
System.write(                                                                  // Output without a newline:
             a                                                                 // The string a
              +String.fromCodePoint(34)                                        // Plus a quote
                                       +String.fromCodePoint(10)               // Plus a newline
                                                                +a)            // Plus the string again
```
````

Comment: Why doesn't `fromByte` work in place of `fromCodePoint`?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @JoKing It does work ;)

Answer (score 3):

## **Javascript, 133 bytes**

```
a="\\";b="\"";d="throw b+'HELP!'+b+'a='+b+a+a+b+';b='+b+a+b+b+';d='+b+d+b+';'+d";throw b+'HELP!'+b+'a='+b+a+a+b+';b='+b+a+b+b+';d='+b+d+b+';'+d
```

Answer (score 3):

## [FEU](https://github.com/TryItOnline/feu), 56 bytes

At first, I thought it was impossible.

Then I remembered `__DATA__`.

```
s/(.+)/\1\n__DATA__\n\1
__DATA__
s/(.+)/\1\n__DATA__\n\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0st/f@/WF9DT1tTP8YwJi8@3sUxxDE@PiYvxpALxuHCoeD/fwA)

### Explanation

It's just your usual quine. `__DATA__` onwards is read and fed into the regex substitution, which takes the input, and puts it in this format:

```
input
__DATA__
input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/),  <s>44</s> 41 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170188/86301)</sup>

-3 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen

Works on R Version 3.6.2 and greater (thanks to Giuseppe for figuring out the versions).

```r
`+` <-
function(x)cat(dump("+",""),1)
+ 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7QcFGlyutNC@5JDM/T6NCMzmxRCOlNLdAQ0lbSUdJSVPHUJNLW8Hw/38A)

This is <s>3</s> 6 bytes shorter than the [previous shortest quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105759/86301) by JAD.

Note that TIO currently uses R version 3.5.2, and thus adds some spaces and newlines to the output, but my local install of R version 3.6.3 does not, and gives the exact correct output.

Comment: IIRC TIO calls R by using `Rscript` as seen [here](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/r), not sure if that's the difference.

Comment: Nice!  And you can even shed 2 more bytes to [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P03BRpcrrTQvuSQzP09DMzmxRCOlNLdAQylNSUdJSVNHSUNTSZMrTUFD8/9/AA) (also works on R installation but not properly on TIO or RScript).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Neat, thanks!

Comment: Some digging in R news shows that since TIO's R install (3.5.2), there's been a change to `dump` as of version 3.6.2: see [this edition of R News](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2019-2/ch.pdf). I have 3.6.1 on my machine and it prints the `function()` and its body on separate lines.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for working that out!

Comment: Both versions (original 44 byte and updated 42 byte) work fine on my installation of R 3.2.1, but add the extra spaces & newlines using Rscript (which calls same R version).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen The plot thickens! I have R 3.6.3 and I never get extra spaces, whether using R, Rstudio, or Rscript.

Comment: @Robin (after some thought) Are we sure that using ```dump``` like this doesn't fall into the the 'reading your own source code' category of ['cheating'](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#4878) quines?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It doesn't read the source code any more than `print(f)` would. With regards to your link, it is clear e.g. that the first set of `()` encodes the second set of `()`, so this quine falls within the rules.

Comment: @Robin I must admit that it seems Ok to me, too.  I was just reading [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13634/is-a-quine-that-reads-a-functions-source-a-cheating-quine) thread, and noticed that the 'bad example' seemed remarkably similar.

Comment: ...but I liked the distinction between *program* source code and *function* source code (Dennis' answer in that link), which seems to imply that ```dump```-ing a function that you define in a program is Ok, since you're not reading the program itself.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Indeed. Additionally, [this example](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1HBViFZw1DbwMpIR8HEykKTK6U0t0BDKVFJR0FJSfP/fwA "R – Try It Online") shows that `dump` does more than just read an object's source code.

Comment: Yes.  I like that example a lot.

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7QcFGlyutNC@5JDM/T6NCMzmxRCOlNLdAQ0lbSUdJSVPHUJNLW8Hw/38A) using ```+```.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 38 bytes

```
4K6j364K3645/1,3(!&$*)+(@)+(_+@)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fxNssS8zYzMQbiE31DXWM5bgZhDUU1VS0NLU1HICYO17bQfP/fwA)

Uses quite a few unprintables to abuse the behaviour of pushing the ordinal value of that character.

#### Explanation:

```
4K6j364K3645/1,3                           Push data section to stack   (0,data)
                                           Push zero, then the counter  (0,data,0,19)
                    (!&$*)                   Push the reverse of the data (0,data,0,atad,0)
                          +(@)               Print the data               (0,data,0)
                              +(_+@)        Print the data again, in reverse and offset by 11
```

Answer (score 3):

## [2DFuck](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/2DFuck), <s>963</s> 853 bytes

```
!x^x>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>>>x>x>x>x>>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>>x>>>>>x>>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>x>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>>>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>>x>x>>x>>>>>x>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>>>>x>x>x>x>>x>>>>>x>>>>x>>>x>x>x>>>>x>x>x>x>>>x>x>>x>x>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>v[<r!x]..!.!....!.<^x[r[!.!....!...]v.r!.!.vr^!....!.>r^]![r.v<r^]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVHLDgIhDPwWfqAHz6Q/QuCi8eKtiWT@HhdlkfIwqwfDBtpO2ekwp8v1fr6lZBDAjOfKXwlrUrEG4b0BbUMBmvy9vcD9l0fY0NM1PTxUj8TDzQXrTNecVVVX76H0Dsq/m/h3rV1VebM0TXmOCdf/Bv5wD9N5F950grQdBYrOioEnMtuifNgAJ66mRD6S5DRKKDWW4I0TinYLUnoA)

Just a plain binary encoding beats out the huffman style encoding.

#### Explanation

```
!x^           Leave a marker at the start of the data string
x>>x>x>...    Push a binary string where 'x>' is 1 and '>' is 0
v[<r!x]       Move to the start of the data string
..!.!....!.   Print the leading '!'
<^x           Add a leading 1 bit to the data string
[             Loop over the data string
  r[!.!....!...]     If the current bit is a 1, print 'x'
  v.r!.!.vr^!....!.  Print a '^' if the current bit is the first bit, else '>'
  >r^                Move to the next bit
]
![            Loop over the data string in reverse
  r.v<r^        Print each bit of the data string
]
```

And my previous longer but more interesting answer below:

## [2DFuck](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/2DFuck), 963 bytes

```
!xv>x>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>>>>>x>>>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>>x>x>>>>x>x>x>>>x>x>>>x>>>>>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>>x>>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>>>>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>>>>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>>x>x>x>x>x>>>x>>>>>x>x>x>>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>>x>x>x>>>x>>>>>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>x>x>x>x>>>x>>>>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>x>>>>>>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>x>>x>x>>>>>x>>>>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>x>x>>>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>>x>x>>>>>>>>x>>>x>x>x>x>>>x>x>x>x>>>x>>>x>>>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>>x>>x>x>x>>x>x>x>>x>>x>x>x>x>>>>>x>x>>>^x!..!.!....!.!.!....!....!...!.!..!.![<r!]![vr[!.!....!...]..!.....!.>^r!].![vr[!.!.!.<r!...!.>r!]r![<r[<r.>r..<r!..!.>r!.]r![<r[.!.!..<r.!.>r.!]r![<r[<r.!.>r.!]!...r![<r.!..>r].]]]<<^r.!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJJDsMgDHwLH/ChZ@SPIHJp1UtvSI38e2qWGJdFSZTIxJ5hxoY8Xu/v8xOjoR2JHyyR2oK5hi3V8SBKxMYkjaKwqKlJ3vuK0FJlonlThrpJz6W7dv@kB2zVxfUpVj4TK5oOJNenHal30Hc8GPUnJAcxHN3VBmbzjb/d9HaWfos9J921Ho5GNzIAhh8oS/2oIeccnA3GG7cHpxi@EjnixjgIwQDzC8D1kLbzywkUINehAsWE4VQFRa95Esq1RMPgwXtv7ZagGH8)

I'm glad I got this below 1000 bytes. I think it still could be shorter though, maybe through encoding multiple or partial characters rather than one character per binary string. In particular encoding `..` and/or `!.` as tokens but while that may make the data string shorter, the increases to the decoder may not be worth it. Here's the [helper program](https://tio.run/##TZDvaoMwFMW/5ymSbiUR5NbuwxjUhrLXcHHYrh0dWiXpxNH12d3NPx2Sq@ecX26u6Y66fh7H5ocuD3RLBaGUA6dbSfk646mVLMi1l9rLLOo86oCroCegmIxAyGhMTjk7YVM/OVlghtmxTLIhBKfeGZza1N@6g6uuLkas3szKgTyBQ9vsN@TBVJaDr/Z8mdVr9YkdgpISWv2BdV@Zo3hK4NRcxWKZvZhFio0QtBxnQy95ijd125m76wen@ty5c6CpOnHDKYfH93viQoF/mqS/O0PGsRwYAMMH/Ct8hOI0liLXTLGi18U/QgUQqywxB0ZIgTfS4/IgA9znAcyJ9ZklKM01tkQXPOEAUC6KiIP8BIhaApgKyczEViG3p02JZj7BSEXXd7DVrjwvESDqDw) to generate the program.

#### Explanation

```
!xv                Leave a marker at the start of the data string
>x>x>>>x>...       Create the binary data string where 'x>' is 1 and '>' is 0
                   Here we encode the characters of the program as
     '.' => 10
     '!' => 11
     '<' => 010
     'r' => 011
     '[' => 0010
     ']' => 0011
     '>' => 00010
     '^' => 00011
     'v' => 00000
     'x' => 00001

^x                 Leave a marker at the end of the data string
!..!.!....!.       Print '!xv'
!.!....!...
.!...!.!..!.

![<r!]             Move to the start of the data string
![                 Loop over each bit of the data string
  vr[!.!....!...]    Print an 'x' if the bit is 1
  ..!.....!.         Print a '>'
>^r!]

.!                 Print a zero bit for use in the first character
[                  Loop over the data string in reverse
  vr[                If the current bit is a 1, print 
    !.!.!.<r!...!.>r!  '.' if the next bit is a 0, otherwise '!'
  ]
  r![                Otherwise
    <r[                If the next bit is a 1, print
      <r.>r..<r!..!.>r!. '<' if the next bit is a 0, otherwise 'r'
    ]
    r![                Otherwise
      <r[                If the next bit is a 1, print
        .!.!..<r.!.>r.!    '[' if the next bit is a 0, otherwise ']'
      ]
      r![                Otherwise
        <r[<r.!.>r.!]!...  Print '>','^','v' or 'x' based on the next two bits
        r![<r.!..>r].
      ]
    ]
  ]
  <<^r            Move to the next bit in the data string
  .!              And print a zero bit for the next character
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 10 bytes

```
44186D15B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fxMTQwszF0NSJ6/9/AA)

This uses the same strategy as its [parent language 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186809/76162), but beats it by not having to join afterwards.

#### Explanation

```
44186      Push 44186
     D     Duplicate
      15B  Convert to base 15
           Implicitly print the stack
```

Answer (score 3):

## [pl](https://perl1liner.sourceforge.io/) – Perl One-Liner Magic Wand, 22 bytes

Very late to the party, just for fun.  This decades old Perl wrapper, was only released into the wild when Corona went viral.

The [3rd quine](https://perl1liner.sourceforge.io/Challenge-and-Golf/#f-qw-f-qw-s-x2-x2) in the blog is the actual golf.  Of interest here is the 2<sup>nd</sup> 1-letter alias variant.  It's essentially the same as the [Perl one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4827), which it beats by 6 bytes.  As on many examples on that page, hover the ▶ button, or the blue code box, to see the result.

```
&f(qw(&f(qw(%s)x2))x2)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! The "default" online interpreter we use on this site, [Try It Online!](https://tio.run), has pl listed, so I've edited your answer slightly so it's closer to our standard format. Please, feel free to check out our [main questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) page for more challenges you can attempt!

Comment: @caird-coinheringaahing Thanks, but that's a different pl.  It implements some weird undocumented highly specialized language.  It has nothing to do with Perl, other than being implemented in it.  It's a total coincidence that it spews out my quine ;-)

Comment: Huh, a very weird coincidence. My mistake, I've rolled back my edit

Comment: @caird-coinheringaahing Actually not such a weird coincidence.  Apart from the few (code golf only?) tasks that other pl language is capable of performing, everything you throw at it seems to be a quine.  Like calling `cat` a language.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
`:qp`:qp
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%3Aqp%60%3Aqp&inputs=&header=&footer=)

*-2 thanks to a stone arachnid*

### Explained

```
`:qp`:qp
`:qp`    # the string ":qp"
     :q  # surrounded in backticks
       p # and prepended to itself
```

Comment: 8 bytes: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%3Aqp%60%3Aqp&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Does [this](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0&inputs=&header=&footer=) count?

Comment: @user no, it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

## Jq `-rn`, 18 bytes

```
"|@json+."|@json+.
```

```
"|@json+."         # the string
          |        # through the filter
           @json   # json encoded
                +  # concatenated with
                 . # itself
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
"34çì«"34çì«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDaw6thjO4/v8HAA)

```
"..."34çì«  # trimmed program
"..."       # push literal...
        ì   # prepended with...
       ç    # character with codepoint...
     34     # literal...
         «  # concatenated with...
            # (implicit) itself
            # implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 40 bytes

```sh
s='s=\47%s\47;printf $s $s';printf $s $s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/2Fa92DbGxFy1GEhYFxRl5pWkKagUA5E6Cu//fwA)

[Until recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59975870#59975870), this was the shortest universally trivially modifiable quine. Uses no external commands (`printf` is a builtin).

(Lesson learnt: don't describe your answer as the shortest possible.)

Answer (score 3):

### Unix Executable, 10 bytes

```
#!/bin/cat
```

When run with something such as `./file`, it will actually call `/bin/cat ./file` (because of the shebang), which prints the file's contents.

Comment: This is not a proper quine, meaning it prints its own source code. Good try, though. With bash, I'd omit the sha-bang statement and jump straight to the cat. This would do: `cat $0`. In bash, sha-bang can be suppressed, and the script is treated as generic system commands. But this does not qualify as well. (I don't know if this works on other shells.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 87 bytes

```
import strutils;let s="import strutils;let s=$1$2$1;echo s%[$$'$1',s]";echo s%[$'"',s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEobikqLQkM6fYOicVyLFVwi6sYqhipGJonZqcka9QrBqtoqKuYqiuUxyrhBBSVwIJcP3/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) ([esolang-box](https://github.com/hakatashi/esolang-box#pxem) notation), 21 bytes.

I originally posted this as a cheating quine, which I noticed it disqualified for the problem.

```
.fak.-.f.p
.fak.-.f.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5khCckgKhKjUvBazlGq1rqsgK4QgoIhcJKgaOB89d49kyAQeruua2lmfvs5@zEPn4OnX58/25Zl79pOZ69X2C9Qy@o525Zd2rZ7RVrQqb1T0vec3UKv8ClwQqQ6E2MytIJnpOuFguFMxyM/RGfVh8rZmVk1cPg2dtCjE9ojr5fN8pk9Gg4tr0sOta7zonkT10WFwyzNZhPhi8r1V1MQccKH1PFCAScRMWIfuTyPB@pcWJj90ajfPny/rpkFXd9egBffvtdvz34@VL9dXZ1Ur01qNJEgRl8q378@3Jxcfa9/a5Tlt7mATPSG2tksX9UIjUdBfxrP5C@xyN3/kHCGE9cKHRQ8cf7ROITh68jvBmO3H2azltu3AqQ@IkmMqCyIx8JcMiX2lbLZxo@zs@p5zSxzG5jZ6xrBU78XGnyMGF8COPbTCImfCbNMmeUMGCqM3O5hFkL/YrlIyKCe5QaOMJut0rhqLj2dBU4XSYE21d40I4A/75rEFb6jNhPiXMCzELUxwSNIQsVD6ks4obPQR2o1QK2mru63kdRsebm2NHv0nTHKx8q1@@KuqEXliiF2jIahtTw@vwBz9/l8y9M0o1Mx5vG0ec/0UFoQtbFmhKtgSd/EKKWiNkqBe/ubGKUg7aUZS5sY1XdErZ9m3N7E9oHvIY2BZTuF7e5tYpSCcJBe3/YmRim4@JJm3N3EqA4R66Xd1jcxqkPEnLSP@5sYpUVR89OmC5sYpSD9mmbc28RgvxCh0FKMpU2MFsDHtzTj/iZGC@DPezoJ@m8wcMdKL3pnE6MUYhumLRc3MaqDO8N0vPc2MaqDO9206dImVoT0y2kMXFRT2DbwZdIYeC2mMXBmi2FzaYZtK9kuuiRpSt6vWnTKmnJqdKH/Tpl0C@dbpIVbHvubz7WIqLW2W4UW1YAr0PI56Nbpen@XXUPMRFrzdfr2bnXbWiZqGB0XFM6NN2h2DWmG1rxPqKzERQ11tTUdqoekxHzz/lhpg13wADfjIbhQOEbMhaeEJ8ZRPgck7llsHdYz5m6KmsLQDrgAKY5glokCGFW0sdG5BDRmU45BwQdj94Oxq9UWjGtsC0oSh7JviFFs7hgx1bDFcW5UWSBhhYdWzDSA0vKaSH1v57pMW@ivILAkHp92vFiNkyxgG/OcxouzYqk5eFu@/FCZ576Fl6k9N4nHV4hMrQJxmSbJ5ZFdxi2Oz2miif/GrsSeJFn/naCEFkfHSkK0fg@7VsdxTVNoUYFEfCW4OR55/Qc7eOk5fjiUM@KW2mbcLYqJoT3GPKweWxFVWnNGusAtmtCsVZeCSQcLLCGCwqSPYCyUhWNB4WbJPDG4zv8n5pqodXzHeuYTyFsFC@5oNEbeKERDK7Sf@t6jAKzSYrkyJloHU8L4VT5W40mGT3Q@FmH8TzLe4mPggT7kPSj1Rn4SJnDGMEgkGR8NKs0lQn79p1E5PzGlfM96zqv5Xn4sfap@a1yfNK7hKsSJwic89vte2EMJ0PLEhEWYvdpItQmc178C3zalLyen9UYEuZEDx@mSwId7FObDeW/i2WF/5KELXCPR9@az8jcmbbNmwLAty0v6CSaR74QT30MZGXiWlL@WFMAP6ZLy95LC1C0J12sEZlKlK@RbfEWiKxO4uBuqaiTMV0ueCa6SiEcAVZfoKb5S7j50wz3R7XvOoX4k6mV1xbGvsQGRGrw@7nnxyVAmgkDWIBRDm@Z/MPMTz1yxXcHnC4/OZwIkFOLP7qL9EK2YHsPSX5/6roMzEFIyWo0kTCIAZ7MJvgXakuDhunKj1BSXsCxywejGBB7DNV3Hewyf8A0xWFnV4UJbPzBdg0wwrpmwliD08Y1Sl2WFEvKvwNclHNXkYqlc3CHzpZE@WL/Ap2uGH/C5UlXulJ8kOjeF/EMZNaAvLNR17P4QLpiwWOfR8eE7noSCUTVB3LgDH5gvrLLB3eLeQTWbrR7slAjvNAOw6r/CfbG5vdMWYZO4M4tFtZoIx80ILLgUi9EiBKRqmtsFEsUscPcP@97EmbOIM9bqQbEEPIc7e4RBsfGl2Vgz@WninwRV1WLJYNkzLvBd7ufKWu1F9C/w9VoQggXhdjVZL5CTgXJDorqpc4sDk9cxhH/AylYZqGrbvGGJYrN6m4OQhzafD9orofeXpiGimPcnybEaWDH4umyaTW@m@FLhtjLQjizCGZhd8hK5MS8PGG8ie7MUevuj0OHvhd4/3GBS3A11zZVwsZgn6F1zjTQE0jMUC4Kn0QVm9BViB1sQ0LjE/2IVfoGtIxCXLRaJ8m0SEWO5Y@RMqhZy2DrQSY7lDL4rQf0nrW@QdMxtslg8yLkEKgbMCPktOBnyUI1CGd05PlyU@i/9ANQIrFBYUqyjwaF7NNhyy@7WoMzHGh9DjubxDguemXobygFec6ndWZjZRJCWzvUgEmtcH3v35uvqD48rMz6V4qsA3LTglGKPXNX3nunMnsCoKyEJqb3C4viCm8sFzhL2yltxx@HFHB@LERQuL@hnWTZkeXCA2SbMihZCHod/kExhQIzfL4Mtt@u4DjyEIc/QCsn2BA0iy/UDEJdp3BL8pKlzjTKFPok3fTmet@eSwU4q9h8AuCvZiP@XYMI6ZDRkb14A/Q1wGcNuEamN4hrDbIbH8P6uwKO@31WcsD90lLE9nigvwbvRhZc7Wc1B8c8vXBRafRfur8WVALM7dFRi9xh@W5Jm1usz6EKWqRZoca9Y2t4tlpAUWbIp6vOTRi05NSw4@oVP/3f@E61JdNhHgATAgS9wkiTqcAmDHwEFcXqwsDUSFFEn0mxq@Y8Qg/oUJZmbok@//gs)

### How it works

In this notation,

- 1st line is main routine.
- `.f` is for `push its own content from 2nd to final lines`.

`ak.-` is an idiom to push LF; `.p` pops each item to print them.

Answer (score 3):

## [Alumin](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Alumin), 350 bytes

```
hhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhh hhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhh h hhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhh h hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhh h hhhh h hhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhh h hhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhh hhhh h h h hhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhh h mdqhldthadtlaocpladadtdadoddaaamfof97
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8wpzc3M@/8/AxkowAlMYQwpHIpR1ROhCEkhmrQCMXoI2oFDgQKKAnQHKGCxEFlYITelMCMnpSQjMaUkJzE/uSAnMQXIBOL8lJTExMTctPw0S3Ou//8B)

Alumin is a stack-based language that only executes the lowercase alphabetical characters.

#### Explanation:

```
hhh...     Each series of `h`s represents a single alphabetical character. h=a, hh=b, hhh=c etc.

m          Map each element to
 d         Duplicate the element as a loop counter
 q         While that element is positive
  h        Push 1
  l        Push length of stack (3)
  dt       Square (3*3=9)
  ha       Add 1 (9+1=10)
  dt       Square (10*10=100)
  la       Add length of stack (100+4=104)
  o        And output ('h')
  c        And subtract the first 1 from the counter
 p         End loop
 la        Add length to the end result (0+2=2)
 da        Double (2+2=4)
 dt        Square (4*4=16)
 da        Double (16+16=32)
 do        Dupe and output (32)
 ddaa      Triple (32+32+32=96)
 a         And add to the original value to get the ascii character
m
fof        And print each value
97         The program prints the last remaining value automatically
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Joy](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/humanities/research/research-projects/past-projects/joy-programming-language), 32 bytes

```
[put "x." putchars 10 putch] x.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8qv/P8/uqC0REGpQk9JAchIzkgsKlYwNICwYxUq9Lj@/wcA)

Joy is a stack-based language. It has an interesting operation, `x`, which means executing a block without popping it. So `[P] x` is equivalent to `[P] P`. This is useful for writing quines.

Comment: The second time I've seen Joy, after the appearance in your article about Esolangs.

Comment: Let's see some DipDup answers too!

Comment: As a sidenote, are you still in the CGoL community?

Comment: @null I'm not active in the forum, just occasionally search the word "rlifesrc" to see if anyone has found a bug.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyxplot 0.8.4](http://pyxplot.org.uk/), 62 bytes

```
q="'";Q='"';s='pr"q=",Q,q,Q,";Q=",q,Q,q,";s=",q,s,q,";@s"';@s
```

This quine makes use of the macro expansion operator `@` to execute the code stored in the string `s`. Both quote characters have to be extracted to variables because there is no way to get one without the other (not counting backslash escapes, which don't help here).

Fun fact: replace `pr` with `print` and `@s` with `eval s` and you have a not-so-golfy Ruby quine.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$14\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 11.524 bytes

```
"
h+C34"
h+C34
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJcIlxuaCtDMzRcIlxuaCtDMzQiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Functional()](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Functional%28%29), <sup><s>904</s> <s>880</s> <s>846</s> <s>768</s> <s>716</s> <s>692</s> <s>684</s> <s>662</s> <s>605</s></sup> 602 bytes

```
),$,$$,($(8,( $(($(<,$(,,,)),($(4,$(9,,)),($(9,$(,,0,,)),($(0,$()),$ 4)(((0,9,,$)(((,)(( $(($($$,( 9((()(9($ <($ 4(8(, 4))))))$$),, $))(( $(,(,$),,(),, 9,, 0,, $,, 4,,(,())))))),(()($$())(8(9(9(8(4(4(8(9(8(8(<(9(9(9(9(9(9(9(8(<(8(<(<(4($,0(<(<(4(0(<(<(0($,0(<(<(9($,0(<(<(9(8(<(<(9(4(<(8(<(8(4(0(8(8(9(9(4(0(<(<(9(4(4(9(9(9(9(9(9(4($,0(<(8(8($,8(4($,0(4(8(<($,0(4(8(9($,8(9(8(8(8(9($,0(8(<(4(4(8(4(8(8(4(0(8(8(9(<(8(8(8(9(4(<(<(9($,<(0($,8(8(8(9(4($,0(4(<(9(9(8(4(<(0($,8(4(8(<(9(9(<(<(0($,<(<(8(4(<(9($,8(4(8(<(9(9(<(<(9($,8(4(<(4($,8(4(8(<(9(9(<(<(<(8(4(<(<($,8(4(8(8(4(0(8(<(8($,8(4(8(<(4(4(<(4(<(9(
```

[Try it online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 605B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 662B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 684B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 692B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 716B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 768B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 846B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 880B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 904B version online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)

This code comes from a generator code below;

```
),1,P,
:(h,
  & 1(
    :(l,1(>,>)),
    :(d,1(i,>)),
    :(i,1(>,`,>)),
    :(`,1()),
    1 d
  )(
    &(`,i,X)(
      &(>)(
        & 1(
          :(P,
            & i(
              &()(
                i(1 l(1 d(h(> d))))
              )
            )P
          ),
          > 1
        )
      )(
        & 1(
          >(X),>(),> i,> `,> 1,> d,>(>())
        )
      )
    )
  )
),
&()(
  P()
)(

h(i(
  i(h(d(d(
h(i(h(h(
l(i(
  i(
    i(
      i(
        i(
          i(i(h(l(h(l(l(d(1,`(l(l(d(`(l(l(`(1,`(l(l(i(1,`(l(l(i(h(l(l(i(d(l(h(l(
        h(d(`(h(
      h(i(
        i(
          d(`(l(
          l(i(
            d(d(i(
              i(
                i(i(i(i(d(1,`(l(h(h(1,h(d(1,`(d(h(l(1,`(d(h(i(1,
              h(i(h(h(
            h(i(1,`(h(
          l(d(d(h(d(h(
        h(d(`(h(
      h(i(l(h(h(
    h(i(d(l(l(i(1,l(`(1,h(h(
  h(i(
    d(1,`(d(
    l(i(i(h(d(l(`(1,h(d(h(
    l(i(i(l(l(`(1,l(l(h(d(l(i(1,h(d(h(
    l(i(i(l(l(i(1,h(d(l(d(1,h(d(h(
    l(i(i(l(l(l(h(d(l(l(1,h(d(h(
  h(d(`(h(
l(h(1,h(d(h(
l(d(d(l(d(l(i(
```

[Try the generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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) ( [Try the encoder script online!](https://tio.run/##dZHPToNAEMbv@xSThpAZM3ayBy9UNz6AB44ktYoRlE0QCVRNbHx2HAolFCPJst/3m3/LUudNedV1X4Uvc8BrR3AwAM/F@1u9UdHKA1yI9DLwN0E4sEhCK6@DjsVOOhHXa1CzbyR0gixDZJs@XX7v5NAG4Sl5CxaJdzIhLTkiSTM9zVh4EJ7at4KD/Kjawr/s4faOA79u8s@8aXMMHmm9uq9WG/Nj6sZXfXzTdcSWYzYRFqyloY7QDSDCki06dkQ8gkyBnwN/zEjnKFV0chYy3WnoF2rIczK63rtJz8YOT4Qxz2wf93gG@ga0RKBZFkpdGRboICN9FjnnnuKZpflMB9Ysa/4/sMOE2OnPcaA3BHolYHVlypTS307m9CajY8dviVEd/gI))
[Try the 605B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 662B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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) ( [Try the 662B encoder script online!](https://tio.run/##fZDbSgMxEIbv8xRDWcqMjJ3kwqtq8AF8A6u22NQNrLVsPIDFZ18nu5vaihgI@f45Z3ahbS667qOOTQC89AR7A/BYvzzv5gpJ7uFMJGMVr6rpYLtdrs4/72Sfqqk8DSYraVXYSVoX9pJCYZC0LLxASfVBkKRYBEtqCu@FXeE@p@e3barj5hWub7iKsza8hzYFrB5oNllsJ3PzZXZt3Gb/vOssOyY2iA1rKoNFfQAQ12wRwbMjYsSgyo28ZAs@w0rBEY8JtYZ4LgmxTxhUH5CduYIKGnocmilqrcCRij5xDtIdy9zPM4NHRjp1DMejg0bvGmu0YEnPrygif2IZxyxHf3akf5Lp36ks6E6QdC@6MIh5P3qt2tRKfxc0x28/FBkdZvyYR1VovgE) )
[Try the 684B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 692B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 716B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 768B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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) ( [Try the 768B encoder script online!](https://tio.run/##XZBNasQwDIX3PoVWRQINsi/gi7SFGBwygdCN202HOXv6LE/mpwajT9KTJbnN9bR8/ex7MyL7@LYlNHufyun30y5vV3ejteKQrFWHbG12IGuTA1s7O4i11UGtbQ4XJLu9miZx6nXdoh2aLvseNWlR1qqqolkD86SBiDmrUmZgP8oulMNHhCpnipoZZZRwC27FzYghKnLTDisZRmIQZe7K1AHy/rB0nsHJGTOcPXGkVk8d3jaKhlTZZ0K/4KAUx4wMjaJTepq5YM6782/DY095DfjTmjDQJB1o5YTNE21cKD@WfF71xvnuyKNrHJ8h/hl/) )
[Try the 846B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 880B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)
[Try the 904B generator code online!](https://hakerh400.github.io/tio/?data=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)

The core part of the code is encoded with `,d,h,i,l for space,1,(,),comma respectively.
Other characters &,>,:,P,X are treated as (,comma,`(1`,`11`,`,1`

The actual characters in the quine code,

- 1 is converted to  $
- `,d,h,i,l are converted to 0,4,8,9,<

The encoded string forms a long long call chain with encoding rules below;

- `Z` -> `z(`  e.g. 1 -> d(
- `z` -> `z(1,`  e.g. h -> h(1,

Answer (score 3):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>22</s> 16 bytes

```lua
(f%f)"(f%%f)%q"
```

Essentially the lua quine of `s="s=%qprint(s:format(s))"print(s:format(s))`.
Takes the function `f%f` (which acts as `f:format(f)`) and then calls it with the format string `"(f%%f)%q`, where `%q` escapes the provided argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/18jTTVNUwlIAinVQiWu//8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [(,)](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/in-parens-comma) <s>46114</s> <s>17682</s> <s>14022</s> <s>12123</s> <s>11403</s> <s>11183</s> 9947 Chars or \$9947\log_{256}(3)\approx\$1970.7 Bytes

Less than 10,000 Characters!! Still 2000 characters to go before I can fit it in a url :(

```
((),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()()())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(((),(())()),()())(()(),()()()()()()()())(()(),(()(),,,,(),,()()()()()))((()),()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())())(,,,(()())()()()())(,(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())()),,,(),,()()())(,,,(()())())(,(,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()())())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())((())(),())((())(),((())())(,,,(()())),,(()())(),(((())))(),((())()))(,,,(()())())(((())),((,,,,,()))(((()))))((()),((()))()),,,(()),((())))((()),()()())((()),((()))(),,(()())(((())),,,,(),,(((())))),(()),((())))
```

```js
let text = "(()(),()()()()()()()())(()(),(()(),,,,(),,()()()()()))((()),()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())())(,,,(()())()()()())(,(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())()),,,(),,()()())(,,,(()())())(,(,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()())())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())((())(),())((())(),((())())(,,,(()())),,(()())(),(((())))(),((())()))(,,,(()())())(((())),((,,,,,()))(((()))))((()),((()))()),,,(()),((())))((()),()()())((()),((()))(),,(()())(((())),,,,(),,(((())))),(()),((())))";
output = "((),()()())";
for (let c of text){
  output += "(((),(())())," + "()".repeat(c=="(" ? 1 : c==")" ? 2 : 3) + ")";
}
output += text;
out1.innerHTML = output.length + " Chars";
out2.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<h1 id=out1></h1>
<p id=out2></p>
```

Like most esolang quines, there is an encoder and decoder. The decoder is shown below:

```
(()(),()()()()()()()())(()(),(()(),,,,(),,()()()()()))((()),()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())())(,,,(()())()()()())(,(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())()),,,(),,()()())(,,,(()())())(,(,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()())())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())((())(),())((())(),((())())(,,,(()())),,(()())(),(((())))(),((())()))(,,,(()())())(((())),((,,,,,()))(((()))))((()),((()))()),,,(()),((())))((()),()()())((()),((()))(),,(()())(((())),,,,(),,(((())))),(()),((())))
```

And in pseudo-code:

```
a is var[1]
b is var[2]
c is var[a]
d is var[a]+1

b=8
b=b*5;
c=3
(str-output b)*2
str-output b+1, b+4
(str-output b, b+1)*3
str-output b+1
while a>/>=c{
  _=(
  (str-output b)*3
  str-output b+1, b+4
  (str-output b)*2
  (str-output b+1)*2
  str-output b
  (str-output b+1)*2
  str-output b+4
  d=1
  while var[c]+1>/>=d{
    d=d+_=(str-output b)
    str-output b+1
  }
  str-output b+1
  var[c] = var[c]+var[while None>/>=1] // while None>/>=1 is 0, var[0] is input, and EOF is -1, so this is equivilent to var[c] = var[c]-1
  c=c+1
  )
}

c=3
while a>/>=c{
  c=c+1
  str-output b+c*c
}
```

And the encoder is of the format below:
Once: `((),()()())`, and for each char in the decoder: `(((),(())()),?)` with ? being `()`, `()()`, or `()()()` depending on whether the char is `(`, `)`, or `,`, respectively.

[Try It Online!](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/)
You have to paste the code yourself, the url was to long otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 56 bytes

```
"%uUSE: formatting dup printf"USE: formatting dup printf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYsxDsIwEAR7XrFE4hOmBkRDE/IAE5/hhHOO7LsgXu9E9HSjGU30o@bS9ri/uGLKwRJhI5YxWaCAxxeBorekm4PQBwuVylkqcsT5t7vd0F9vF4c3FaGEY@sONvQnh5jL5FVZngg2Yy4sGrv/qbUV)

Inspired by [fede s.’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/72040/108687).

#### Explanation:

`%uUSE: forma…"` String with printf-directive `%u` to print an unparsed value (wrapping string in quotes) at start of string

`USE: formatting` Import `formatting` vocabulary to get `printf`; string is still on stack.

`dup` Duplicate the string; now there are two copies on the stack.

`printf` Print the string with its copy as a formatting argument; the copy is wrapped in quotes and inserted at the start due to `%u` directive.

Answer (score 3):

## [FALSE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FALSE), 34 bytes

```
["'[,34,$!34,'],!"]'[,34,$!34,'],!
```

### Explanation

```
["'[,34,$!34,'],!"] {quote that prints the program sources}
'[,34, {write `["`; ASCII code for " is used because FALSE has no escaping}
$! {dup the quote, then call}
34,'], {write `"]`}
! {call the quote again}
```

Comment: Note this works the same way as [this FALSE quine of the same length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263274/108687)

Comment: @noodleman I see. Is there a good way to order answers by programming language?

Comment: It’s not exact but if you go to the search bar while on the question you can search `inquestion:this false`. Unfortunately in the case of FALSE, it’ll also show any answers which include the word false which can be a lot on some challenges.

Comment: @noodleman thanks, will use this in the future!

Answer (score 3):

## [Positionally](https://github.com/chunkybanana/positionally/), 2273 bytes

```
QQ
        / 1    \/      \
>                      ^
^        +     <
>   :          v> P    v
                              ;<
        \      /
\      /

/      \
       ^        >     |
                ^      <
>   :  v>      v

  s    /\

            >  \
               \  1    \/      \               \   2   \/      \
                >  b           ^                >              ^
                ^+     <                       <^ -    <
        >   :  v        >      v>    ""      " v        > P    v

          s    /                \
            ^                                                  /

               \       \        /      \
                >    &                 ^
        ^                   %  <
                                >   :  v

                \      /                               /\


                                       \      5                \

                                                        ^   %  <
        > P    v

        \                      /  s                    /
            ^  /




P   P"!O␟␟␟O␉ ␉␉␉␉.␟␟ ]␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␉ .␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ r␟␟.␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟[␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␉␉u␟␟␟␟ O␟=␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␉;␟ ␟$␟␟␟]␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␉ ␉[␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟4␟␟ ␟␟␟␟[␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␉␉␉[. ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟.␟␟␟ ␟␟␟[␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␉ ␉u␟␟9␟␟ ␟=␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␉ ;␟␟$␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟]␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␉]␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟%␟␟␟␟ =␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␉[␟␟ ␟␟␟␟.␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟[ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ [␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␉␉.␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟] ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␉[ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟.␟␟␟␟ r␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␉␉u ␟␟␟␟O␟= ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟u␟!␟␟␟ ␟␟␟!!␟␟ ␟␟=u␟␟␟ ␟␟␟=␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟u␟ ␟9␟␟␟=␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␉;␟␟␟␟, ␟];␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟;␟ ␟␟␟␟*]␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␉]␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟=␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟] ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟a␟␟ =␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␉[␟␟ ␟␟␟␟.[␟ ␟␟1␟␟␟[ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟[␟␟␟␟␟ ␟.[␟␟␟␟ 0␟␟[␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␉[ ␟␟=␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␉␉[.␟␟ ␟␟r␟␟␉␉ u␟␟␟␟␟␟ =u␟␟9␟␟ ␟=␉;␟␟␟ ␟␟␟]␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␉ {␟␟␟␟␟= ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟]␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␉[␟␟␟ ␟␟␟.␉␉. ␟␟␟␟␟␟[ ␉.␟␟␟␟␟ ␟[␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␉;:␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␉u␟␟␟␟ O␟=u␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ 9␟␟␟=␉; ␟␟␟␟␟*␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ]␉]␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␟␟=␉[ ␟␟␟␟␟␟. [␟␟␟␟0␟ .␟␟␟␟␟␟ ␟␟␉
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@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)
[Encoder](https://tio.run/##nVLtbqMwEPzvp1hZamOLq9Nc1bsqTfIM7e8SJC64jU@pQQZFjdR3TxcbHMBJ@rEIjL3j2dmxi121zvXNfq9ei9xUUO5KQgqTv8AcaKyp@J8rzXBVlFWmtDAyzRgXZbFR1UZpWTL@NL2aLDlEFt/urQcEF5t0JRkV9BfQB8qPZ@/q7D/MEqlXeSYzRDyt1oblJmOrdWo4XMGEw3NuoJ6C0pZhSeRbZVJEN/tEkRfs2koBwDcKEyM68lWiz8vYAktC1DOkemeRisMF3MJ8DtcWqizOUXLAhRE@h6UpQSm1rUK@qYpNeG2v0hWTOptbOyJXBROezqT6RbKN1Kwl5o7nsLXbGec2iSIVavtba/vj8P09qIzv94@PPjWGST3EYzeNyQKORkKS9jey35lFTg@I7QKEHQmcjfuZB8SNBuJ/iNfR1m2xTtd7QN4AvJxt08CWILS0rDHp7Vp06DtK@j6Eefjd82moA1nvQlm9fN/PoJHG1xO2zRK8m7bRLmPd8KCCM4BSN6PdvPDGtOEMGtbqd5fAt2NMjhjcN/ackQCXRy7gOT0XXWNORWtYIM5fxM/awptEvmhBQ3kbekvgh5EMGw1PND4hvDnp8JwG/HhwGNYo@gE)

Note: Unprintable characters and tabs are replaced with symbols from the Unicode Control Pictures block for clarity. For functional code, use the "Try it Online" link.

### Explanation

The main idea is to maintain an encoded program string at the bottom, outputting its decoded version and pushing the encoded form onto the global stack, before ultimately displaying the global stack.

#### Caveats

- The encoded version must not contain spaces as the interpreter ignores them. For instance, the encoding used here reduces each ASCII value by 1, prohibiting the use of `!` since `! (33) - 1 = space (32)`.
- The encoded version needs to be spaced every 8 characters when including it in the program to avoid exiting string mode, as every 8 characters trigger the " command, which toggles string mode on and off. Spaces are used to maintain string mode continuously.
- Because the encoded version is spaced every 8 characters, logic must be added to output a space every 8 characters when printing the global stack.

Comment: Wow. When I created that bounty I wasn't even sure if this was _possible_, but you've proven me wrong and then some.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>93</s> 68 characters

```
s="\nmain=putStrLn$\"s=\"++show s++s"
main=putStrLn$"s="++show s++s
```

Answer (score 2):

## D, 85 bytes

```
enum c=q{import std.stdio;void main(){write("enum c=q{"~c~"};mixin(c);");}};mixin(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, <strike>125</strike> 84 chars

```
main(){char*p="main(){char*p=%c%s%c,c='%c',s[256];sprintf(s,p,c,p,c,c);puts(s);}",c='"',s[256];sprintf(s,p,c,p,c,c);puts(s);}
```

It turns out that my idea was [implemented](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm) much better:

```
main(){char*p="main(){char*p=%c%s%c;printf(p,34,p,34,10);}%c";printf(p,34,p,34,10);}
```

Comment: You could shave 9 chars off the shorter version by leaving out the trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 67/51 chars

```
f () 
{ 
    printf "%s\n${!1} $1" "$(local -f ${!1})"
}
f FUNCNAME
```

And 51 chars:

```
trap -- 'printf "%s\n:" "$(trap -p DEBUG)"' DEBUG
:
```

Answer (score 2):

### Erlang escript <strike>225</strike> <strike>164</strike> 140

```
$ escript quine

main(_)->[A|B]=["main(_)->[A|B]=[","],io:put_chars([10,A,34,A,34,44,34,B,34,B,10,10])."],io:put_chars([10,A,34,A,34,44,34,B,34,B,10,10]).

$
```

Apparently escript has to have at least three lines.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <s>17</s> 19

```
ToString[#0][] & []
```

Comment: Why Community Wiki?

Answer (score 2):

## [Zozotez Lisp](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/): 73

```
((\ (x) (c x (c (c (" ") (c x))))) (" (\ (x) (c x (c (c (" ") (c x)))))))
```

This requires one of the REPLs. For one bootstrap expression quine I need it to print: 81

```
((\ (x) (p (c x (c (c (" ") (c x)))))) (" (\ (x) (p (c x (c (c (" ") (c x))))))))
```

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 68

This uses mostly Brainfuck code except for the store string procedure.

```
>~"~!<<.[<]>.>+.-<[.>]<[<]>>+.->[.>]"<<.[<]>.>+.-<[.>]<[<]>>+.->[.>]
```

A 94 byte version that uses more EBF features:

```
{c|"{q$q.$p(-)}:q:p$q 34+$p|'{c|'&q&c&q|'}'(-)&c"}{q$q.$p(-)}:q:p$q 34+$p|'{c|'&q&c&q|'}'(-)&c
```

Answer (score 2):

## Go - 583

Just because d;

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
    a := string(byte(34))
    b := []string{
        "package main",
        "import fmt",
        "func main(){",
        "   a := string(byte(34))",
        "   b := []string{",
        "       ",
        "   }",
        "   for i:=0;i<5;i++{if i != 1{fmt.Println(b[i])}else{fmt.Println(b[i][:7]+a+b[i][7:]+a)}}",
        "   for _,v:=range b{fmt.Println(b[6]+a+v+a+string(','))}",
        "   for i:=7;i<9;i++{fmt.Println(b[i])}",
        "}",
        }
    for i:=0;i<5;i++{if i != 1{fmt.Println(b[i])}else{fmt.Println(b[i][:7]+a+b[i][7:]+a)}}
    for _,v:=range b{fmt.Println(b[5]+a+v+a+string(','))}
    for i:=7;i<11;i++{fmt.Println(b[i])}
}
```

Comment: this is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 65 bytes

```
set -o history
echo "set -o history"
history|tail -n 2|cut -c 8-
```

Bash disables the command-history function in scripts, but you can turn it on manually with '`set-o history`'.

This first command is obviously not stored in the shell's history file, so the second command prints the same text to the terminal.

The third command pulls the last two out of the history file and cleans them up for displaying.

The output matches:

```
set -o history
echo "set -o history"
history|tail -n 2|cut -c 8-
```

Comment: reads its source no matter what

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js REPL (22)

```
console.log(RegExp.$1)
```

Comment: ...this abuses the fact that (I guess) the Node REPL internally executes a regex on the received line? I want to upvote because of the cleverness, but on the other hand I don't want to since it relies on extracting its own source code as a string...

Comment: You need to specify the Node version this works in, because running in 7.5.0, this prints a single newline.

Answer (score 2):

### Julia, 101 characters

```
s="s=%c%s%c;@printf %c%s%c 34 s 34 34 s 34";@printf "s=%c%s%c;@printf %c%s%c 34 s 34" 34 s 34 34 s 34
```

It's the usual format string technique, but unfortunately you can't get the format specification string from a variable in Julia, so I have to include it twice in the code, which blows everything up.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp - <del>73</del> 35

Thanks to reader variables written `#n=` and `#n#`, with `n` an integer, Lisp code can be self-referential. Also, the printing functions can emit such reader variables when told to handle circular structures.
The [`WRITE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) function accepts a `:circle` parameter for that purpose. It also returns the value being printed, which means that we have to globally set [`*PRINT-CIRCLE*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) to T (the initial, standard value  is NIL), otherwise the REPL would report a stack-overflow exception when printing that value. Initializing the variable takes a lot of bytes and so the shorter solution is to return another value:

```
#1=(PROGN (WRITE '#1# :CIRCLE T) T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty certain you can't get shorter than this with Common Lisp. The first one I managed to figure out myself; all credit to http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine#Common_Lisp for the second one.

## Common Lisp - 9 (With REPL)

```
(write -)
```

In Common Lisp, `-` is a special variable that holds the expression currently being evaluated but only during a read-eval-print loop. If you're running from a script or you've disabled the REPL though...

## Common Lisp - 25 (No REPL)

```
#1=(write '#1# :circle t)
```

This references itself and then prints itself out. `:circle t` makes it detect the infinite recursion cycle and exit early.

Answer (score 2):

## AppleScript, 2 Bytes

```
1
```

It's a little cheaty, but it *is* following the restrictions of a quine.
If we don't count the trailing newline, then this solution becomes 1 byte - `1`.

Whenever AppleScript has a final *executed* line of code, it prints the result of the last operation (whatever it is) to the command line.

```
text
```

Any class name has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3 - 58 Characters

Since there is a Python 2 version, I suppose this is acceptable:

```
x='x={};print(x.format(repr(x)))';print(x.format(repr(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 190 Characters

```
class I{public static void main(String[]a){String s="class I{public static void main(String[]a){String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s));}}";System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s));}}
```

Comment: Since ye olde Java SE 8, you can put static methods (such as main) in interfaces - no public. Also print and format methods can be collapsed into printf.

Answer (score 2):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 51 bytes

```
0"0.[34,0[$;$][,1+]#]$!%%!"0.[34,0[$;$][,1+]#]$!%%!
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Well, DUP quines *are* possible, just really, really, long. I'll have to golf some more.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 and 3 - 32 bytes

```
s='s=%r;print(s%%s)';print(s%s)
```

From [Ray Toal's Quine Page](http://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/quineprograms/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

There are two [proper](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4878/53748) and [payload capable](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4924/53748) "built-in" quines of 6-bytes:

```
“ØV”ṘV - takes no input
“ØV”   - make the string “ØV”
    Ṙ  - print and yield left (prints “ØV”, yields “ØV”)
     V - eval Jelly code (the code ØV yields the string “ṘV”)
       - implicit return of the string “ṘV”, so the final output is “ØV”ṘV
```

and

```
“Øv”Ṙv - as above,  except:
         v evals with an input, which in this case is empty; and
         Øv yields “Ṙv”
```

A payload may be placed directly after the leading open quote in either.

Answer (score 2):

### [Straw](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), 10 bytes (non-competing)

```
(:%>>):%>>
```

Comment: Link to language is dead. Also, why is this non-competing?

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>123</s> 102 bytes

```
module q;import StdEnv;Start=(s,q,s,q);q=inc'!';s="module q;import StdEnv;Start=(s,q,s,q);q=inc'!';s="
```

Save as `q.icl` and compile with `-b -nt`.

Saved 21 bytes thanks to [Οurous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18730/%ce%9furous).

Comment: This can be improved to 102: `module q;import StdEnv;Start=(s,q,s,q);q=inc'!';s="module q;import StdEnv;Start=(s,q,s,q);q=inc'!';s="`

Comment: @Οurous nice idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Dart, 185 bytes

```
main(){var c=new String.fromCharCode(34);var l=["main(){var c=new String.fromCharCode(34);var l=[","];print(l[0]+c+l[0]+c+','+c+l[1]+c+l[1]);}"];print(l[0]+c+l[0]+c+','+c+l[1]+c+l[1]);}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Cheddar, 56 bytes

[Try this one online!](https://tio.run/#c7F4s)

```
let q='let q=%s%s%s;print IO.sprintf(q,@"39,q,@"39)';print IO.sprintf(q,@"39,q,@"39)
```

See the explanation below, except mentally replace `%` with `IO.sprintf`.

---

---

---

Well darn. @ETHProductions [came up with this solution before me.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/96580#96580).

This is the shortest I could come up with... Maybe some abuse of functional operators could help me.

```
let q='let q=%s;print q%@"39+q+@"39';print q%@"39+q+@"39
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#FK8m9) You can guess what the output is.

This code can be divided into two parts: the string and the output. The string part:

```
let q='let q=%s;print q%@"39+q+@"39';
```

is simply a formatting template.

The output part:

```
;print q%@"39+q+@"39
```

formats the string. `@"39` is char 39, or `'`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 94 bytes

```java
()->{String s="()->{String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.printf(s,34,s);}";System.out.printf(s,34,s);}
```

This is a lambda expression which prints its own source code to `STDOUT`. It uses a similar tactic to other Java quines here, but the lambda really helps cut down bytes.

If we wanted to be really cheeky and cut down two bytes, we could declare the lambda as `x->`, where `x` is an empty string, as according to meta, "taking no input" means [you can assume empty input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7167/what-does-taking-no-input-mean-for-a-program/7172#7172), and in function submissions input is given as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 38 bytes

There are already a lot of Python quines, but as far as I can see this one hasn't been posted yet. Technically it is a statement that evaluates to a string representation of itself, but other submissions do similar things.

```
'.__repr__()[:-1]*2'.__repr__()[:-1]*2
```

This works in a similar way to many quines in 2D langauges with "edge-wrap", where "string mode" is entered, the whole program is pushed to the stack, then string mode is executed and the program runs, printing the string mode character (usually `"`) followed by the contents of the stack (i.e. the program's source) then exiting.

A breakdown of the statement is as follows:

```
'.__repr__()[:-1]*2'                   # A string containing the body of the program.
                                       # .__repr__()[:-1]*2
                    .__repr__()        # The same string, but enclosed in single quote marks.
                                       # '.__repr__()[:-1]*2'
                               [:-1]   # A splice that crops off the last character.
                                       # '.__repr__()[:-1]*2
                                    *2 # Repeat the string.
                                       # '.__repr__()[:-1]*2'.__repr__()[:-1]*2
```

The reason I have used `.__repr__()` instead of `repr(string)` is because the quine relies on code following and not preceding the string. This is also why this is a statement and not a program; the `print()` function requires code before the string, which is not possible with this quine layout.

As you may have noticed, there's a much golfier statement that evaluates to this statement:

```
"'.__repr__()[:-1]*2"*2
```

But this isn't a quine, because it doesn't evaluate to *itself*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is valid, since it's an expression (and therefore a snippet) rather than a full program.

Answer (score 2):

### SmileBASIC, <s>66</s> 54 bytes

```
?MID$(("+CHR$(34))*3,19,54)?MID$(("+CHR$(34))*3,19,54)
```

This will work in most BASIC dialects.

Answer (score 2):

### AWK, 72 bytes

```
BEGIN{s="BEGIN{s=%c%s%c;printf s,34,s,34}";printf s,34,s,34}
```

In 6 years nobody had written an `AWK` solution :(

This can be run from command-line as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{s="BEGIN{s=%c%s%c;printf s,34,s,34}";printf s,34,s,34}'
```

or placed in a file, `FILE` and run as:

```
awk -f FILE
```

Note: no newline is printed so if storing in a file... the file shouldn't have an `EOF` in it... maybe? We can add an `EOF` by adding `print` statements but that adds 12 bytes.
This happens to be my first ever quine. :) It took me a bit to figure out how to get the quotation marks, since I first wanted to use `\"` but I'd have to escape the `\` and then escape that one... ASCII to the rescue :)

Comment: After I posted this I was curious if there was an extant `AWK` quine example.  Apparently so at https://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_awk.txt.  Given that, I believe this might be the shortest possible `AWK` quine.

Comment: No this isn't the shortest AWK quine ;)

Answer (score 2):

## k, 48 bytes

This is, of course, ignoring the trivial quines, such as `()` or `1`.

```
{}`0:(`c$34)/{(x;x;())}"{}`0:(`c$34)/{(x;x;())}"
```

[Try it out.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%20%7B%7D%600%3A%28%60c%2434%29%2F%7B%28x%3Bx%3B%28%29%29%7D%22%7B%7D%600%3A%28%60c%2434%29%2F%7B%28x%3Bx%3B%28%29%29%7D%22)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 540 Bytes

```
object Q {
  def main(a:Array[String]):Unit={
    val d=Seq(
      "object Q {",
      "def main(a:Array[String]):Unit={",
      "val d=Seq(",
      "val c=println(_:String)",
      "val b=(x:Int)=>x.toChar.toString",
      "d take 3 map c",
      "val a=d.zipWithIndex.map(x=>b(34)+x._1+b(34)+(if(x._2==d.size-1)b(9).drop(1)else b(44)))",
      "a.map(c)",
      "c(b(41))",
      "d.drop(3).map(c)",
      "c(b(125))",
      "c(b(125))"
    )
    val c=println(_:String)
    val b=(x:Int)=>x.toChar.toString
    d take 3 map c
    val a=d.zipWithIndex.map(x=>b(34)+x._1+b(34)+(if(x._2==d.size-1)b(9).drop(1)else b(44)))
    a.map(c)
    c(b(41))
    d.drop(3).map(c)
    c(b(125))
    c(b(125))
  }
}
```

Can probably be improved. I decided to call it quits for now as it is 5 in the morning. I think something that can be changed to make this smaller is to encode the `d` value in some other way other than a sequence of strings. I haven't thought of a cool way to do it yet, though. This would also add to the obfuscation part of the challenge.

Comment: This doesn't work as is due to indenting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Business Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880/business-cat)

```
"D34'DLaJL"D34'DLaJL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#@6/kYmyi7uKT6OWDYP3/DwA)

```
"D34'DLaJL"          # Push this string (everything after this)
           D         # Duplicate
            34'      # Push the character "
               D     # Duplicate
                L    # Print "
                 a   # Swap the top 2 elements 
                  JL # Print the string, ", then the string again.
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by replacing `LLL` with `JL` (in both occurrences).

Answer (score 2):

## ACL2, 41 bytes

```
(let((q"(let((q~x0))(cw q q))"))(cw q q))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 27 bytes

```
ii^V^V^V^[BDuplxbbpp^[BDuplxbbpp
```

`^V` being <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> and `^[` being <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

The other one is beating mine, but it took a while and I didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 8 bytes

```
?A+@?A+@
```

I was trying to do [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125053/golf-an-anagram-quine), but I accidentally golfed an actual quine. Whadda you know?

### Explanation

```
?           Print
 A            A$
  +         concatenated with
   @       a string literal containing
    ?A+@   "?A+@"
```

When `A$` is used the first time, it might not seem to have a value yet, but it already contains the string literal `?A+@` because the QBIC interpreter first scans the code, sees the `@`, looks up what the first available string variable is (it's `A$`, because it hasn't been used by other QBIC language features yet), and it then extracts the definition `A$ = "?A+@"` to the top of the file, and inserts `A$` at the place where it found the literal.

Answer (score 2):

## JScript, 175 bytes

```js
WScript.Echo((k="WScript.Echo((k=\"%Z\").replace(/%[Z]/,k.replace(/[\"\\\\]/g,function(e){return\"\\\\\"+e})))").replace(/%[Z]/,k.replace(/["\\]/g,function(e){return"\\"+e})))
```

JScript is Microsoft's implementation of the JavaScript language. On a microsoft console, you can invoke the program as `<name>.js`, and this will output to a popup. To output to the console, one must use:

```
cscript //E:JScript //nologo <name>.js
```

and add a trailing CRLF to the source code.

Answer (score 2):

### Zsh, 17 bytes

```
sed p<<a
sed p<<a
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Foam](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/foam-lang), 15 bytes

```
[. <' |: ~|]: ~
```

This prints itself with a trailing newline. Without a trailing newline:

```
[. .' |: ~|]: ~
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 10 bytes

```
“:ṙpp”:ṙpp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1HDHKuHO2cWFDxqmAth/P8PAA)

#### Explanation

```
“:ṙpp”      Push this string.
      :     Copy it.
       ṙ    Get the string representation of it.
        p   Print the string representation.
         p  Print the string.
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 50 chars

```
<?printf($s='<?printf($s=%c%s%1$c,39,$s);',39,$s);
```

I realized I could save four chars by enabling short tags (`<?=sprintf` becomes `<?printf`)

I saved four more bytes by reusing one of the values in my printf.

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to ppperry.*

```
s='s=%rprint(s%%s)'print(s%s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/@/2Fa92Fa1qKAoM69Eo1hVtVhTHcYu1uT6/x8A)

<sup>I swear, if I get a bounty for this...</sup>

Comment: Hey, I promised a bounty, so if nobody beats it, good for you I guess :P

Comment: You can save two bytes by deleting the semicolons

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus) `-i`, 14 bytes

```
L,"L,%rd%%"d%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR8lHR7UoRVVVKUWV6///f/kFJZn5ecX/dTMB)

Takes advantage of Python string formatting with the `%` command. Uses the `-i` flag to run the function without having to call it.

Answer (score 2):

## [MaybeLater](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/MaybeLater), 74 bytes

```
x="write(('x='+chr(34))+x+(chr(34))+x)"write(('x='+chr(34))+x+(chr(34))+x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02sTErNSSxJLfr/v8JWqbwosyRVQ0O9wlZdOzmjSMPYRFNTu0JbA8HWJEbN//8A)

Answer (score 2):

### [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 9 bytes

```
"#34#9&o@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fSdnYRNlSLd/h/38A)

#### Explanation

This is a fairly standard Fungeoid quine. However, as opposed to most other Fungeoids, Wumpus's grid doesn't wrap around, so the IP actually bounces back and forth through the code:

```
"#34#9&o@o&9#32#"
     This pushes the individual code points of this string to the stack.
#34  Push 34.
#9   Push 9.
&o   Print 9 characters from the top of the stack.
@    Terminate the program.
```

There are several other ways to do this in 9 bytes, e.g. this one which generates the `"` from the `#` instead:

```
"#9[(~&o@
```

I haven't yet found a way to get it down to 8 bytes though (it might be possible: if there's a way to generate the 34 in three bytes that *doesn't* end in a digit, we could get rid of the `#` in front of the `9`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
$_=q{$_=q{0};s/0/$_/;say};s/0/$_/;say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rawGkwY1FoX6xvoq8TrWxcnVqJwuP7//5dfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/AEAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 108 characters

```
macro_rules!f(()=>("macro_rules!f(()=>({:?}));fn main(){{print!(f!(),f!())}}"));fn main(){print!(f!(),f!())}
```

This is a suboptimal solution, but it's so close to the [current shortest solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97833/3103) that I wanted to post it anyway as it uses a completely different strategy. I think it can be optimized by using `macro` keyword instead of verbose `macro_rules!` when it becomes stable (which would reduce this to 96 characters).

Answer (score 2):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 10 bytes

```
",-#) %8-$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/19JR1dZk0HVQlfl/38A)

This should be a quine, <s>except for a small bug in the interpreter which causes the `(` command to throw an error. For completeness' sake, here's [a version](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/19JR1dZU0HVQleFCwgUFBSU//8HAA) where a `#` is placed in the position the `(` is accidentally calling. Note that the space is actually a NUL character.</s> Bug is fixed, yay!

`"% (#-,0-$` also works with just one pointer.

#### How It Works:

The `%` creates two pointers, going left and right (the ones going vertical don't matter). The right pointer is delayed by the `8` for three steps, which lets the left pointer execute `,-#)` which changes the active value to `#`, decrements it and prints the `"`. Then the right pointer starts again, decrementing the active value to `-1`. `$` sets the pointer location to 0,-1, which then runs `"` over the rest of the code, printing it.

Comment: You can download fixed and recompiled version (including source code) of the interpreter from my Github repo: https://github.com/m-lohmann/Cardinal. The original interpreter had several errors that needed fixing.

Comment: I don't think your last edit worked properly, the URLs are identical.

Comment: @Orjan lol, it seems I had already made the exact change in a previous edit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 95 bytes

```
import strutils;let s="import strutils;let s=$#;echo s%s.repr[^49..^1]";echo s%s.repr[^49..^1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEobikqLQkM6fYOicVyLFVwi6somydmpyRr1CsWqxXlFpQFB1nYqmnF2cYq4RDnOv/fwA)

After scrolling through the leaderboard snippet, I was surprised to see that Nim hasn't been represented here yet. So, let's fix it!

This follows the standard pattern of constructing and printing a string with a quoted representation of itself inserted in the middle. Unfortunately, Nim has a few features that make this golf-unfriendly:

- String interpolation with `%` is not available unless you `import strutils`.
- `repr` not only quotes strings, but also prepends them with a hex number (seemingly, memory address), like this: `0x40a6d0"my string"`. Therefore, we have to extract the right part.

Still, not so bad overall, as it is significantly shorter than the version currently posted at [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine#Nim), which actually doesn't even work without tweaks in recent versions of the language.

Comment: `var x="var x=;echo x[0..5],x.repr[14..^1],x[6..^1]";echo x[0..5],x.repr[14..^1],x[6..^1]`

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 17 Bytes

In cell A1...

```
=FunctionText(A1)
```

I discovered this yesterday by accident. Feels a bit cheaty somehow though. I appreciate [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/122974#122974) much more, but this does seem to be a quine :D

Comment: Wouldn't this count as reading its own source?

Comment: I guess that depends on what the 'source' of excel formulas is, if it's the formula text, then yes, otherwise it could be the source code of Excel? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 21 bytes

```
"#v{<@^:[ba+0v|{$:o[}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/19JuazaxiHOKjopUdugrKZaxSo/uvb/fwA)

This is my new 1D language Backhand. It's a little bit more complicated than the typical wrapping string literal quine.

#### Explanation:

The program initially starts with a step count of 3.

```
"      Start string literal, stepping 3 places at a time
       This pushes the source code, but all jumbled up :(
```

See my [Hello, World! answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172266/76162) to see what you have to do to push a string normally.

```
"      End the garbage string literal
  v{   Step left and decrease the step count to 2
    <  Change direction to left
  v    Decrease the step count to 1
 #     No-op
"      Start string literal
       Now the step count is 1, so it actually pushes the source code
 #v{<@^:[ba+0v|{$:o[}    Push to stack going right and bounce off the end
 #v{<@^:[ba+0v|{$:o[     Push to stack going left
"      End string literal
  v    Decrease the step count to 0
  v    Decrease the step count to -1
       Now the pointer is technically going right, but with a step count of -1
"      Push the source code again...
  v    Decrease the step count to -2
    <  Change direction to left (step count is still negative, so it goes right)

      ^           Increase step count to -1
       :[         Dupe the top of stack (# 35) and decrement to 34 (")
         ba+      Add 10 and 11 to push 21 as the counter
            0     Push 0
             v    Decrease step count to -2
               {  Step left
              |   Pop 0 and continue moving left
                $ o    Swap the top two items and print the character
                   [}  Step right (against the wall so it bounces) and decrement the counter
              |{ :     Duplicate the counter and reflect if it is non-zero
                       Repeat this 21 times to print the source code
        [ a 0  Garbage
      ^        Increase the step counter to -1
     @         Terminate program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 103 bytes

```pascal
const s=#39'const s=#39;begin write(s[2..12],s,s[10..50])end.'#39;begin write(s[2..12],s,s[10..50])end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/Pzk/r7hEodhW2dhSHYltnZSanpmnUF6UWZKqURxtpKdnaBSrU6xTHG1ooKdnahCrmZqXoqdOtMr//wE)

`s` is the string that the output is generated from. In Pascal, subtrings can be easily extracted with `[from..to]` syntax. `#39` is replacement for `'` using its ASCII codepoint. As seen in this program, sequences of character codepoints can be glued together with the rest of the string delimited with `'`s at any time. `s` consists of characters before and after `'`s concatenated together. `#39` occurs immediately before first `'` and after second `'` so it can be put in `s` only once and used in both substrings in the output.

The version that may be more suitable in modified, quine-like programs is at 106 bytes:

```pascal
const s='const s=;begin write(s[1..8],#39,s,#39,s[9..52])end.';begin write(s[1..8],#39,s,#39,s[9..52])end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/Pzk/r7hEodhWHcawTkpNz8xTKC/KLEnVKI421NOziNVRNrbUKYaQ0ZZ6eqZGsZqpeSl66qQo/v8fAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog v2](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
"~k;?w₁";?w₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X6ku29q@/FFToxKE@v8fAA)

Full program. Essentially a translation of Fatalize's (non-builtin) Brachylog v1 answer, although it also uses different [SWI-Prolog formatting sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2), or rather, a single different one, which saves about 20 bytes (both `[34:`s, both `:34]`s, and both `~c`s). It seems to have existed back in 2016, but it was probably bugged or something. The last two bytes saved come from using the implicit input, which Brachylog being Brachylog is useful even when the program receives no input, because it's a variable (so instead of explicitly unifying the string with `S`, we just let it be implicitly unified with `?`).

```
          w     Print
"~k;?w₁"        "~k;?w₁"
                which is the input
           ₁    formatted with
        ;?      the input.
 ~k             (so that the ~k is replaced with the input's canonical representation, i.e. in quotes)
```

We don't actually need to use implicit input--[`"~kgjw₁"gjw₁`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X6kuOz2r/FFToxKE@v8fAA) works just as well (and might even translate back to v1)--but doing so regardless manages to both more closely mirror the structure of the original and feel cleverer.

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl, 47 bytes

```
puts [join {p \{ \}]} {uts [join {p \{ \}]} }]
```

Based on [Joe Miller's quine on this page](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Quines).

Answer (score 2):

## **Java, 515 bytes**

In order to make this quine, I made strings representing every part of the code that needed to be printed. Then, I created and printed a string representing the code by adding the strings together.

This is my first time playing code golf, let me know what you think of my quine!

```
interface a{static void main(String[]a){String ce="interface a{static void main(String[]a){String ",e="=",c="\",",q="\"",cq="\\",ec=";System.out.print(ce+cc+ee+e+q+ce+c+ee+e+q+e+c+cc+e+q+cq+c+c+qq+e+q+cq+q+c+cc+qq+e+q+cq+cq+c+ee+cc+e+q+ec+c+ee+qq+e+q+eq+c+ee+ee+e+q+ee+c+cc+cc+e+q+cc+c+qq+qq+e+q+qq+q+ec+eq",eq=");}}",ee="e",cc="c",qq="q";System.out.print(ce+cc+ee+e+q+ce+c+ee+e+q+e+c+cc+e+q+cq+c+c+qq+e+q+cq+q+c+cc+qq+e+q+cq+cq+c+ee+cc+e+q+ec+c+ee+qq+e+q+eq+c+ee+ee+e+q+ee+c+cc+cc+e+q+cc+c+qq+qq+e+q+qq+q+ec+eq);}}
```

in readable form:

```
interface a
{
    static void main(String[] a)
    {
        String ce = "interface a{static void main(String[]a){String ",
            e = "=",
            c = "\",",
            q = "\"",
            cq = "\\",
            ec = ";System.out.print(ce+cc+ee+e+q+ce+c+ee+e+q+e+c+cc+e+q+cq+c+c+qq+e+q+cq+q+c+cc+qq+e+q+cq+cq+c+ee+cc+e+q+ec+c+ee+qq+e+q+eq+c+ee+ee+e+q+ee+c+cc+cc+e+q+cc+c+qq+qq+e+q+qq+q+ec+eq",
            eq = ");}}",
            ee = "e",
            cc = "c",
            qq = "q";
        System.out.print(ce+cc+ee+e+q+ce+c+ee+e+q+e+c+cc+e+q+cq+c+c+qq+e+q+cq+q+c+cc+qq+e+q+cq+cq+c+ee+cc+e+q+ec+c+ee+qq+e+q+eq+c+ee+ee+e+q+ee+c+cc+cc+e+q+cc+c+qq+qq+e+q+qq+q+ec+eq);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to try shortening this further, have a look into using the `printf` function

Comment: I tried that, but I found print easier. I guess I'll try again.

Answer (score 2):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 26 bytes

```
"34cktptptptp"34cktptptptp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/1/J2CQ5u6QAAlE4//8DAA)

Explanation:

```
"34cktptptptp"             (The instructions)
              34ck         (Load 34 (") into destination string)
                  tp       (Print it)
                    tp     (Print the instructions)
                      tptp (Repeat)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
Y\"O"Y"ORPyy\"O"Y"ORPyy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MkbJXylSyT8ooLISifn/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 85 bytes

```c
#define q(k)main(){puts(#k"\nq("#k")");}
q(#define q(k)main(){puts(#k"\nq("#k")");})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VoVAjWzM3MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEM5Wykmr1BDCUhrKmla13IVahCrVJPr//9/yWk5ienF/3WLS1Jsky0sAQ)

The `q()` macro expands into a program that prints out its argument on the first line, and prints out the argument called by `q()` itself in the second line. So:

```c
#define q(k)main(){puts(#k"\nq("#k")");}
q(foo)
```

would expand into:

```c
main(){puts("foo""\nq(""foo"")");}
```

and after string literal concatenation, becomes:

```c
main(){puts("foo\nq(foo)");}
```

And executing and running the program would produce:

> ```c
> foo
> q(foo)
> ```

Replacing `foo` with the macro definition itself results in the quine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Corea](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Corea), 11 bytes

```
<0C>;"<0C>;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84vSk38/9/GwNnOWglM/v8PAA)

Alternatively, `<0C>>"<0C>>`

```
<0C>;"<0C>;
<0C>;            set the contents to that literal string
     "           start command sequence
      <          push a copy of the contents to the stack
       0C        push a quote "
         >       append that to the contents
          ;      and append the original copy and stop command sequence
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 299 bytes

```
_->14733272090064622117723033634640281434301133345502153207896692199003336573010981052872005814325038964478266287468505274190371239580629370336756929651609657090021232407437472153714372752689076920028135a+Out_"_->"+Out_a+d
d+0e->118b
a+b->o
118o->c+d
0a+0e+c->Out'o+e
e+b->e+o
e+d+c->e+d+a
0c+e+d->d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY9LbsMwDET3PkY2XQgC@Ke08RV6hECxDSRAWhWIc/2qVDfSgPM4JNtzux9fj9c5xjWvKM5MTlABTIwI0Z0YmI3FBKigsDAgMrOoAqEygZdqVglrtIVh6oFALQhKJdJAZx8pcIAiXsgsDLGiQbhgBXYkrlrAqLLPga4RWU3RIF6fK1EwJODCLj5He8Q6uZKVCh48zBVZW/p8n9dLXHT5Vy3ty57giAux3JaWbnntS@ie1y08aGGmLa8Bf/R0LMckjtRD7LM@v7bAlkLkdR/jt/@cj/79Gnn/Aw)

I'm posting this as a separate answer to my [existing one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179298/76162) since it uses newer features (character output). This functions much the same but with less logic regarding the modulo values, countered partially by the number being in base 118 instead of base 9. [Here is an encoder](https://tio.run/##HYsxCsMwDEV3n6JkyaAq2EspHXSFHqCUoFjaAgp2Uwj07q6c6T/@@3/Tst5aq3xcHindX@n6q@tetsmK1KnoV0vVd2sMz/0zDzPScBKDBIGoSP5aAsOCZMHZkLK7yC4hI/l4NNCgfaFgDtL7HhxiBgck@QM) that can be used to encode the large number up front.

Answer (score 2):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), <s>2100</s> 1896 bytes

*-204 bytes by using ASCII 255 and 1 instead of ASCII 122 and 123.*

```
ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿ ÿÿ
```

(All of the space characters are actually ASCII code 1, or SOH. StackExchange doesn't seem to like unprintables all that much.)

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?3VXbCoAwCMVPLfrPHvyw1UuxwPuWSQwC0@k5nrnhjueC@4OXDWjxdL@ViGh@zqdV9FeTM0ZxjPUmynI@2ne6k4c/D6NF88gsfMF9Pvs4vxF/De2rTEn9u7GCllW6@JfJz5yoSq9B5h2TNQNBnXvbnJ0LJaKYajwIKhbkQjbcT9uTKSomcUQ8hEHpGLcdWKnBE0yfIL2BFH6JZWvrsh0)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

This isn't a terribly *Poetic* program (it's only two distinct characters), but it's the most compact solution for writing commands that I was able to come up with.

Basically, the core of the program is code that takes tape values corresponding to Poetic commands in a line, adds values to the beginning that would put these values on the tape when executed, and then outputs the values as Poetic commands. The initial values on the tape are, of course, an encoded version of that code. (Standard stuff, surely, but it took me a while to wrap my head around it.)

Comment: Unless Poetic uses a custom code page/encoding, this is actually 3312 bytes as `ÿ` is 2 bytes in TUF-8

Answer (score 2):

## [Symbolic Raku](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Symbolic-Raku), 36 bytes

```perl6
$_={$_~"<$_>)"}(<$_={$_~"<$_>)"}(>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18l3rZaJb5OyUYl3k5TqVbDBl3ATpPrvzWXXnFi5X8A)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
$_=                                   # Set the output to
   {          }(                  )   # The result of the code block
                <                >    # With this string:
                 $_={$_~"<$_>)"}(        # The first half of the program
    $_~                               # Concatenate this string with
       "<$_>)"                        # The quoted string, and the extra bracket
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ral](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ral), <s>1389</s> 1043 bytes

```
1111111101011101011101010101111101011101010101111101010101111101011101010101111101010101111101011101010101111000111000111000111000111000110101010000110101110111011101011101010101111101011101010101111101011101010101111101011101010101111101011101010101111101011011010101111111111101011101010101111101011101010101111101010101111101011101010101111101011101010101111000111000111000111000110101010000111011010101010000110101111111010111011101011101010101111101010101111101010101111101010101111101011000111101011000111000110101110101010101111101011000111111111101011101010101111101010101111101011101010101111101011101010101111000111000111000110101010000110101111011010101011011010000111000111000111011111011111011010000111000110101111011110000110101111101010101111011011101010101111101010101111101010101111101010101111101010101111101010101111101011101010101111101011101010101111000111000111000111000111111:++:++:+:+:+:+:+:+-:+:0=:10-==110-*-:0*111:++:++:+:++?1+:*:11+1+:+:+:+:++./:0*-0*1111:++:++:+:++:++?:-+:++:++:++:++:++.:0*11111:++:+:++:+:++:+++?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVTBitswEL37K4b0INmSHIne1Kqhx5yylN5CKIrtEIOdCHu7bSn99nQUK7FMNxDCVraH8ZunmadnsPv1vD8e3p/ewWf4YhuoD89V57oKI@yOHXxdrpKlaWy7La2WySqk8KJdh1xa7Dv6kvLqUBpC0qSsdtB9P9Ai1QkUvOY9b826OLcqsLkPu3NGpGJCzzPD88U3suGSrzf8958E3Diiz61z2BonJPB0UdHn7uhoin16qJq@ApnAj33dVFB/bKowG2pempopXqzrjX/dQTlMJdpRr7xM04AbQ5hHn2jK8IlgEWAxhTXR1iD0wVE7hLE2xxrf@iqPGNuIkY2727XdIGq9M204TMQ0F6bn@WQsca9sOVGVE72iU6EL4q0AG/Z6GLNPUtemtT@p5Kg88d9rNpudVFgSrzgO2S3kwaqU8nYMvGuuouc@VQ8i19njehsf7jl7fOpRydSHuN89Sm4qHKbE@cTtW3z1nxx45aSRAyF/xbfQfuT/c5brwMjDWIl62MO3/fp@acbO93gJDNJoJYUxSBSZ0DKbMNlCMZ1ppZi67mL5HGnizIypnq0FuyDhzoeWgRlx2eKE/4X09Bc)

**Explanation**

All characters in Ral (except the no-op) are in the range 32-63, which is `001xxxxx` in binary. By omitting the leading zeroes, every character in the code can be stored as a group of 6 bits. (A hexad? hextet? Hextet will do.) The one is still included in the payload to make decoding easier.

Here is a short summary of what each part of the code does. I have omitted the value juggling on the stack and inner workins of the loops from the explanation, as they would make the explanation too complicated:

```
111111...100011                Push the payload data to the stack.

1111:++:++:+:+:+:+:+:+-:+:0=   Load the value 894, which is the length of the payload
                               and is used as a base pointer for the jump destinations.

:10-==110-*-:0*111:++:++:+:++? Move the payload data to memory.

1+:*:11+1+:+:+:+:++.           Loop through the payload, printing 48+n for each value
/:0*-0*1111:++:++:+:++:++?     and push each value to the stack again.

:-+:++:++:++:++:++.            Decode and print each hextet.
:0*11111:++:+:++:+:++:+++?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 190 <s>216</s> bytes

```python
s='s=\\\'\'+s.replace(\'\\\\\',\'\\\\\\\\\').replace(\'\\\'\',\'\\\\\\\'\')+\'\\\'\\nprint(\\\'\'+s+\'\\\')'
print('s=\''+s.replace('\\','\\\\').replace('\'','\\\'')+'\'\nprint(\''+s+'\')')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCoAwDEPv/kgsEy@e9ye9iAwUZA7nxa@frZsy7al5IUk4j3nzQ0rRIlpmBsPEfndhHSfXitRDV55b0NdGbYsgUzD7sC/@aJ/WwglN5jqIeg26hN@GRDOENIt4WzWqgEBNShc)

An old solution of mine following the standard pattern. It only uses the most common commands though.

Comment: Nice answer! I have edited in a link to the online interpreter, in case people want to test out your code.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by removing the redundant spaces. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCoAwDEPv/kgsEy@e9ye9iAwUZA7nxa@frZsy7al5IUk4j3nzQ0rRIlpmBsPEfndhHSfXitRDV55b0NdGbYsgUzD7sC/@aJ/WwglN5jqIeg26hN@GRDOENIt4WzWqgEBNShc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 66 bytes

```
£"24«cs%55«3+cp24«2+cdpsdpsppn"24«cs%55«3+cp24«2+cdpsdpsppn
```

Kind of a classic quine, but having to deal with a few quirks of Aceto to make it work. I had attempted this in the past but had failed.

This mostly follows the good old "source code in quotes, followed by printing a quote character and the source code twice" method.

#### Explanation:

```
£"24«cs%55«3+cp24«2+cdpsdpsppn"24«cs%55«3+cp24«2+cdpsdpsppn
£                                                            # (1)
 "24«cs%55«3+cp24«2+cdpsdpsppn"                              # (2)
                               24«cs%                        # (3)
                                     55«3+cp24«2+cdpsdpsppn  # (4)
```

Because of the development process of a quine, I decided to ignore the Hilbert curve in this case, because otherwise I'd need to scramble the source code to match the formatting. Therefore we write everything in a single line, exploiting the fact that it will be well-ordered still (just walk over a bunch of nops (spaces) in-between).

1. I just realized getting an empty string is not really trivial in Aceto (oops). Character literals (starting with `'`) are always 1 character long. You could use string literals, but just doing `""` will only work *sometimes*, depending on where on the hilbert curve you are currently. Since we're trying to avoid the curve for this (as described above), this will usually just turn into a string containing a couple of spaces. But when the stack is empty (such as at the beginning of the execution), we can "implode" (`£`) the stack into a single string, which will then be the empty string.
2. This is, as usual, just the remaining source code after this, as a string literal.
3. I will need to remove all spaces from the source code that have agglomerated there due to the Hilbert-curve. I can't use a space literal for several reasons (Hilbert curve, and it should be trimmed later), so I instead construct it (and other characters later) using arithmetical operations. An ASCII space is 2, bit-shifted to the left 4 times (`24«c`). We then use the regex substitution operator `%` to remove the spaces.
4. Now we're ready to print things: We construct the pound symbol (`55«3+c`) and print it, followed by a double-quote (`24«2+c`), followed by the space-trimmed source code, a quote, and the source code again. Finally, we print a newline (`n`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), <s>18</s> 12 Bytes

```
⌡^♦►◙►⌡^♦►◙►
```

[Try it not on TIO!](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=9V4EEAoQ9V4EEAoQ&input=ICAgICAgICA)

Comment: Can you update this? A resolution is in the issues on the GitHub.

Comment: [`⌡^♦►◙►⌡^♦►◙►` (12 bytes)](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=9V4EEAoQ9V4EEAoQ&input=). Same length as your previous 12-byter, but with the "bug" fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), 254 bytes

```
s:="s:=?q:='\"'n:=cuid@s(0,9)o:=cuid@s(9,fad@s)scriobh(athchuir@n(\"?\",q+athchuir@(athchuir@s(\"\\\\\",\"\\\\\\\\\"))('\"','\\\\\"')+q)+o)"q:='"'n:=cuid@s(0,9)o:=cuid@s(9,fad@s)scriobh(athchuir@n("?",q+athchuir@(athchuir@s("\\","\\\\"))('"','\\"')+q)+o)
```

[Try it here!](https://try-setanta.ie/editor/EhEKBlNjcmlwdBCAgICg5reICg)

This was pretty long, mainly because Setanta doesn't have any string formatting builtins. Probably could still be improved.

**Edit 2021/2/4:** It seems that you now need to spell the function to print a value as `scríobh` (previously, you could use `scriobh` without the accent on the `i`). Making that fix adds 2 bytes to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [(())](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(())), 3560 bytes

```
Let
(
=()
Let
)
=(())
Let


=(()())
Let
L
=((()))
Let
e
=(()(()))
Let
t
=((())())
Let
=
=(((())))
(((()(()))(()))(()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()()(())()(())(())()()()()(())(())(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())()()()(())(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()(())()(())()()(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())(())))(((((()))((())))()))((((()))())(()(())((()))))((((()))(()))(()()(())(())((()))))((((()))(()(()))((())())(()())()(()())(((())))()(())(()())((()))(()(()))((())())(()())(())(()())(((())))()()(())(())(()())((()))(()(()))((())())(()())(()())(()())(((())))()()(())()(())(())(()())((()))(()(()))((())())(()())((()))(()())(((())))()()()(())(())(())(()())((()))(()(()))((())())(()())(()(()))(()())(((())))()()(())()()(())(())(())(()())((()))(()(()))((())())(()())((())())(()())(((())))()()()(())(())()(())(())(()())((()))(()(()))((())())(()())(((())))(()())(((())))()()()()(())(())(())(())(()())()()()()(())()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()((()))(()(()))(())((()))(())(())()()()()()()(())(())(())()()()(())(())(())(())()(())(())(())()()()()()(())(())(())()(())(())()()(())()()(())(())()()()(())(())(())(())(())()()()()()(())(())(())()()(())(())(())()()(())()(())()()(())(())()()(())(())()()()(())(())(())(())(())()()(()(()))(())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVdLEoMgDN1zkrDoEbyB12DZTmfKpqenAkGwED6Cn3F0EpI88hIUFM@3/D5e4iOVmoVkwCbgTEt8kYBbmRnZabPWFsVqwtpWXaLVeU9G12bOjGBk9zAXcH87PTUearH/1pYaj1Fj/1zs6DzLM9LZUgjn5z@WxT14UZhtvGq4XNGvMez2rcmr@nh0N@/CN8Wih29rT/Pf5LGraJ9/S@XL/cpn1VPP/i70zLW3tm2dao3tWY1H9KXHv78a51es/KbgrZ947MPDH7gxK4OLMUZv8efCFS3y8LAIhBlab5wNvC0XF3q5yJBJOZ5GaMJZiW9x/itbkQ@BlO5UTV5QyKwND1dHAi/ekVxv69deNHuQz3b3y@@0KW50ZG4voZjl8qD379w7S88S/nVxpX4)

This probably isn't the optimal strategy (since it was the first one I thought of), but I've golfed this down enough that I feel confident posting it. I wrote a [helper program](https://tio.run/##bVE9b4MwEN39KywrCXcSgq1DEZ3ajalZkSqSWC1VMcg4Q4Xsv07PYCiJsiC9r/O7o5P652lsfvn@/FXpnud8DyyCiOcvPAKMYhZhAIAeilKJAGciKhad8ETINbBSZuMJsXylvMlTmDFGTQ5GU41hLjQk57Y52eS7rZWd5N2lMtXRVNqQy2gQhaCgF2rVS21eSQ6KxEXymTd12SZCpPZjBGCpCmlyMT2XNFUHgyCiVLuPUuXCJdTK4lQD/AnQ0Rdg8yaCCEP766k3tbmaulX@ogKRAXDYNF8KIQfkiJyxW32gmvQX0CLn4EHAaDf7U/JRDO9i@CDm@4jkMByfP9OyT1MbqsvlRtNl0P2n3GZVt9R33nmzLt74aHORLYPfZafDcEKYjZ2ulZn/Qbw64rv7zUo2jn8) to generate this program

`(())` is a string re-writing scheme designed to only use parentheses. The top lines of  `Let x = (())` are to assign characters to the sets of parentheses so that input and output can make sense, but otherwise the entire program is that 3400 byte string at the bottom. Essentially it boils down to a series of string rewrite rules:

```
"e)" -> "large data string"
"LL" -| ""         (terminate on this substitution)
"L(" -> "()L"
"L)" -> "(())L"
"" -> "Initialisation (((()(()))(()))(Le)L))(((((()))((())))()))((((()))())(()(())((()))))((((()))(()))(()()(())(())((()))))((e)"
```

First we start with the input, which is empty. Only the last rule matches the empty string, so we replace the current string with the result from that:

```
Initialisation (((()(()))(()))(Le)L))(((((()))((())))()))((((()))())(()(())((()))))((((()))(()))(()()(())(())((()))))((e)
```

The first rule to match this string is the `e)` rule (which is constructed to avoid matching anything in the initialisation section). This matches twice, and we substitute the first and then the second, since none of the other rules before it apply:

```
Initialisation (((()(()))(()))(L large data string L))(((((()))((())))()))((((()))())(()(())((()))))((((()))(()))(()()(())(())((()))))(( large data string
```

The large data string is the parentheses representation of the original empty string substitution, which means that this is almost the final product, except that the first copy of data string needs to itself be translated to the parentheses version. We use the `L(` and `L)` rules to turn each character into it representation. Once we run out of those, the output looks like:

```
Initialisation (((()(()))(()))(large data string representation LL))(((((()))((())))()))((((()))())(()(())((()))))((((()))(()))(()()(())(())((()))))(( large data string
```

So we finally execute the `LL` rule, replacing `LL` with nothing and terminating the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 14 bytes

```
"#ooooooo;!-1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/19JOR8CrBV1Da3@/wcA)

*><> doesn't offer much more than its parent language ><> apart from file input and some new movement commands, neither of which are useful here. In fact, this is longer than the ><> quine, since *><> outputs the error to STDOUT, meaning we can't exit with an error.

#### Explanation:

```
"                   Wrapping string, pushing the code to the stack
 #                  Mirror, reverse directions
"                   Pushing the code to the stack in reverse
           -1:      Duplicate the top of the stack (#) and subtract one to get "
         ;!         Skip over the terminate
  ooooooo           Print seven characters
 #                  Mirror
  ooooooo           Print the other seven characters
         ;          And terminate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code-page)

```
"'%r:%%1⊢":%1⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU0sSfz/X0ldtchKVdXwUdciJSswxfX/PwA)

Commata is a very underdeveloped golfing language. This makes use of the string formatting command to format the data with double quotes.

#### Explanation

```
"'%r:%%1⊢"       Push '%r:%%1⊢ to the stack
          :      Duplicate the string
           %     Format one string with the other
 '%r             Python's string repr with double quotes
            1⊢   And drop the leading '
```

Answer (score 2):

## [ABC](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/abc/), 89 bytes

```
PUT {"0INa"; "1WRITE 'PUT',a"; "2FORbINa:WRITEb@2/"} INa
WRITE 'PUT',a
FORbINa:WRITEb@2/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xK/v8/IDREoVrJwNMvUclaQckwPMgzxFVBHSiqrgMWMXLzD0oCylqBZZIcjPSVahWAfC4UlVwYqrj@/wcA)

This is one of those weird old languages, this one being "originally intended as a good replacement for BASIC". It has a few strange quirks, such as lists are iterated in sorted order, and you can only print newlines using a `WRITE`. At least the object to string conversion works well, and tokens can be placed right next to each other.

#### Explanation

```
PUT {"0INa"; 
     "1WRITE 'PUT',a"; 
     "2FORbINa:WRITEb@2/"}
INa                            Set a to the list of strings
WRITE 'PUT',a                  Print "PUT" and the list
FORbINa:                       Iterate over each string in the list
        WRITE                  Print
             b@2               The string excluding the first character
                /              And a newline
```

I don't think this ir quite optimal, but I think it's pretty close. You can't have a two line quine, since both lines would have to encode themselves, and I can't think of a way to do a one line quine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Adapt](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/adapt), 19 bytes

```
`@96cs+.+`@96cs+.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJLCj5/z/BwdIsuVhbTxvO4Pr/HwA)

#### Explanation

```
`@96cs+.+`               Push string "@96cs+.+"
          @96            Push 96
             c           Convert it to the character "`"
              s+         Swap the two and concatenate "`@96cs+.+"
                .+       Duplicate and concatenate "`@96cs+.+`@96cs+.+"
                         Implicitly output
```

Comment: Bloody hell, I had no idea Adapt was actually usable, that's super cool!

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 52 bytes

```
411096280599923751453245172184368156!
_
2/:@
" .
71_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fxNDQwNLMyMLA1NLS0sjY3NTQxNTYyMTU0NzI0MLE2MzC0NRMkSuey0jfyoFLSUGPy9ww/v9/AA)

Just beats out the [previous Labyrinth quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55741/76162) by one byte, through using the modulo behaviour of `.`, and an unorthodox divisor.

#### Explanation:

This uses a similar setup to the other answer, but where that used a divmod of 98, this divides by 172 and modulos by 256. This first saves on the decoder section because the `.` instruction already moduloes by 256 before printing. But this alone [isn't enough](https://tio.run/##DcU7EkAwEADQPqdAj93NZzcqhXsYKpkxYUjj8pbXvH1ZnyvlsqmSDSyEIoKenQfxzJYiA0VBInEEMUhwANZhbdAM3Wyaikwf/P@o@h5nSUe@tZ0@), so I started looking for a smaller divisor.

This is possible by brute-forcing the required number through rearranging the source code until it works, and only when the encoded string is really small (in this case 16 bytes). I wrote a [Raku script](https://tio.run/##dZBNbsIwEIX3PsUQuchOhfODQKIWiG3PgGjkUlwiBSeyU6kQhaun45iWVVeeN/PmG/k1R1sth/MFqKu@bANrGF9JCPamGnVHALDeKqyDSbRWGceiLJ9HsN7AjdE3xbnQVdmI2n44GVboN66kXujaeoBHgW/HiFJyVN5n0MdoATOc8ad8sQyjUvvRBq33TQjIV6PlXVfKtaHuyS/8GeHGN3vitST98HckS1MhstWKi097bFg3SVKa9Fy42rasE1Mdi0N9ft/Fs2zf8126l8Spy8jzjKtnaEYNj6l5OMPXb/@mYzjHQEfQVRxOymJCjS1Ni1oOw4QUZJ68bEkEguRZ8QM) to help brute force these variations of the code, with minor tweaks needed for different layouts.

The code itself is a simple loop

````
.....!  Push number and print it
.....   Then reverse direction, pushing the number in reverse

_       Enter the loop by
2/`     Integer dividing the initial number by 2
` `
```

``:     Duplicate and print value modulo 256
` .
```

2/`     Integer divide by 172
" `
71_

```@    If the division results in 0, terminate
` `
```
````

The above code ended up being one of my first attempts at this method, and I only ever found a couple of others that were the same size, [this one](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fxNTcwtLAyMTA0NTC2NjAwsTIwMTS0MTMyMAMKGhiYWBqYqTIFc9lpG/lwKWkoMdlrqT8/z8A) and [this one](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fxNjI1NTCzMLCwsDUzNDU1NLCxMLU0MzQyMTIAihhYmFmYKzIFc9lpG/lwKWkoMeVYK7z/z8A), both with divisor 172. I'm not sure why this is the magic number.

Some thoughts on further golfing through this method:

- You can push `0` through `?` or `{` (replacing `_`)
- You can push `1` through `#` or `` ,` ``  (replacing `_1`)
- The wall in the center can be anything that isn't an instruction
- `"` can be replaced with `'` or some other no-op and can be placed pretty much anywhere in the loop

I'm honestly not sure if this format *can* be golfed. It seems unlikely that there's a format that supports a smaller divisor than 172, but then again, I'm not sure why 172 was an island of stability in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
#define a(b)*s=#b;b
a(main(){printf("#define a(b)*s=#b;b\na(%s)",s);})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIVEjSVOr2FY5yTqJK1EjNzEzT0OzuqAoM68kTUMJi6KYvEQN1WJNJZ1iTetazf///yWn5SSmF//XLQcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Assembly (NASM, 32-bit, Linux)](https://www.nasm.us/), 620 bytes

```
section .text
mov di,1
mov ebx,1
m:mov esi,a
l:mov ecx,esi
mov edx,1
mov al,[esi]
add ax,di
cmp al,10
jne p
mov ecx,b
mov dx,2
p:mov eax,4
int 128
mov al,[esi]
inc esi
cmp al,96
jne l
dec di
jz m
mov ecx,c
mov dx,3
mov ax,4
int 128
mov ax,1
int 128
section .data
c db 44,57,54
b db 92,110
a db`section .text\nmov di,1\nmov ebx,1\nm:mov esi,a\nl:mov ecx,esi\nmov edx,1\nmov al,[esi]\nadd ax,di\ncmp al,10\njne p\nmov ecx,b\nmov dx,2\np:mov eax,4\nint 128\nmov dl,[esi]\ninc esi\ncmp dl,34\njne l\ndec di\njz m\nmov ecx,c\nmov dx,3\nmov ax,4\nint 128\nmov ax,1\nint 128\nsection .data\nc db 44,57,54\nb db 92,110\na db`,96
```

*-149 bytes by using backqoutes*

*-26 bytes by simplifying jumps*

[Try it online!](https://jdoodle.com/a/2sRO)

Comment: [-156 bytes using some dirty tricks](https://tio.run/##ZY8xT8NADIV3/wqLtVep11IE3S5xh4sSElGEIuSBIrFRL5n49cG@S9oghpPs5/fs@87D8HX5/P5Zy3m4jGPTviFF58GKY9FbdUj1Kbqw2kOdu7J3qmQXmatu6VRA@4KhdxShbDoMtfMbqAJ2MGfCagfxuUTqoTtMnqeHPNbgvQ5f0W8foSqwBjqqM0L1js1tg93Qi7ukaPyWoWgCVE233kNAKu50t76t837jPmY0liublks4lj90k5GSMfGxzIAsV0IWQ5zMmZElQ7IsKCeHYdo8/VmzCsqSSbVT1MWmdM9gs2a0i2jm1ZABs/wn1mYcfwE "Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 5](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/), 202 bytes

While much longer than the shortest Swift submission, this has important aesthetic points for me since it avoids numerical ASCII references as well as any declarations at all, using an anonymous function, resulting in a single-statement solution.

```
import Foundation;({print($0+"("+String(data:try!JSONEncoder().encode($0),encoding:.utf8)!+")")})("import Foundation;({print($0+\"(\"+String(data:try!JSONEncoder().encode($0),encoding:.utf8)!+\")\")})")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

```perl
print<<""x2
print<<""x2
```

24 bytes without any options.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvxMZGSanCiAuZ/f8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## <s>Pxem</s> [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) ([esolang-box notation](https://github.com/hakatashi/esolang-box#pxem)), <s>162</s> <s>113</s> 109 bytes.

Eventually as in [meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23467/100411) I had to change the language. The following program equals to filename with same name and empty content in original notation.

```
Be!?BzBc!!B+BzXXFBaBcFBzBsXXFBBaBsBtBvBmBvBcAcB-BaBsBp".e!?.z.c!!.+.zXXF.a.cF.z.sXXF..a.s.t.v.m.v.cAc.-.a.s.p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lRhrd9q48nt/hfDykLCNbAJ5IEQ2kKRLm9Jsku1NC26OY0xwYszDJiEh7l/fO5LNI@2ec@9@wJJG89ZoZsRDOPz7N1S57e@4xl5133WrdsUo39p7Zds92HP7ZWPPMQ9ujUHV3N0ZvAvdCOnunM1HdviADKNcZu5iMp5F6Kx1c3R2xlsMR88TF925kTMOBvm8XDnj0cgO@qRB@@4jDea@j8qNvJnPp8TnR1d/cCWLUzykT1YM5Nbr62TmBdEA5cJeL0BKVgAVkl2KUa3FyUSPlZUyf3Xa1zeXV8e8bBg7K@D558v29dnXm9bni4uT1hU3WRfpgtuyeXT5x82Xk4vL9udODdggK59fImnrGE3GobdgYqE2Wbym@fZPJO5o7tuRi8KhIBhPIpg9jWf9cOJ7EbN9zw6RfocK2aWpKtnflbjAC2IssM5fZ2etT8e8BiJwFwRgIbHPwqE3iKT0PhKYKcB1hmOU/Y0oiCMTWa@vOIPcR9tHSgYNbD90FULyeQEUiOGwPPb7jXyZMMlaAhevodtHhZAu6DNlIXxeaEEyfFkxlLQQAytiMMh/5AcHDM5p4vkuJnjADebYoQtsTQV5AcKDIkEDcC5zQ9thdjgSBzuGMz0KkP4Yzc3XaIb0VogKXUM/sAow9oKiVXi9m7kTVHq1nx5QoXnyvt1Ztro7OxaD76787olvRUIqVfE9gO9gPMPMq5d3madyU814KvY4r5JiWU72SXEHJj@UUrd6YIFXLrs@b3U9dbdqqWI82LOseAlQVbV41mDeAMNCL1ucV3bz@awhjGqRpa/zMjvDhCWhqOScXqBoataI45PO8RJ24sE8cCJvHCBYLIGPT5Ypsq@wp6FwmE9SCFLQZVfXfSvhh67juCAcU@ge6d@kU2z9BZwivKE/ojE4UXpfEasmL5S6T4vnFws90TEq2QUBbfGCY0dwUEBtNHCgcpogUZ3aNNVFKdmoWUEpufLagtvhRciMswZYj3BCYlv0UEG/g5KBCrS1a8L0cZH2qTArExBJY7A5D3QztSxozKXRcG99L3Dr3EglouZGyE86xYlKdirJlJ4EHsGGVElMUlYcYghR9lM2gBhTVo4KwVHCu4m36uWEEQvcRRSHRTBvMg6c8HEWWbSI7bpJVNpVM9mcnqzLhCwlLp3QpQ2xHXIzDusmg1@yMYTJEMyIaNGOlyHP0O7ATX3GbGGfd2NRlfrAr3OqgwBsNwwCoh2wuTsOQhANwKEA0hHVYduE2UqL2ExsWVmws22BUlieQ8waMlInXMxV3bTiSeYHxFiquU8FkojgCTq9ROH8NoxmOGtoO4SdQ8x5Fr@OzTrucJmW8ESztdNLkS9AxSWgYyWrAATZ3Y6lJawI67u@C5ktYRB36juAHgpJCcM150RRsSU5oe53ZKnA73rNaa1Dp1GGHCUsB7sh49BuNmfRfF7ILcIHLIPjWHCxZs88gYgLuqg/k4XKn3X8zBdwI7m4YCIR3MMdva8DGiOTxHq7ew8Xm207BLyJaU@lhwv1uQZncrjQYczAWIQxB2PuuQZJ8WebRXAmQgwQ4rHkKsOukAC3V6ZTM6Tfs9QdTaJnWlhlWIjvUjFL6TrHpfAEjbKI0e8@Ao9RKjKxcFmRnuM8YfQO1ojCcAuFIZTh691AAA/cWTQCZ0FCEvTh6lollxHAZJnA4ZYlkz6FUiNLyyCtGlB@RYYviKuFDVJ4fU3WfWA6c6P5LIDLVkj5Qx7o99fSdBreRutVhkLdW696Wdr3HtfLHB2NN4SlIv3P1SlW8gpACq8/6YPXPqRJBbjsPnCIdriHMlQVRRtqSk3QsmxIs2BbgUDkbMjWOdjFTbJ8UFUGLCwOHxE74viawK1ZF1DWVFWoBw9aM0WAyYoxaCx4E8LCmcPTehTOoDnBYX8r1Z/jYyK01D5iYvFjKU1VN/snUAoSX2Y@bpeID2s4AnjD3Ox83OwIZpuNqzcbQqC4@uvta3xBlhccsKQSup6eIbrY4MxxK02tWDfrrXy@VS9Xd8lhq6YoG6z3ghNcs3nwg5aoYDoP2DzgirJhmU7SbN8wDrNGTd@y4i8hCWhaG9AR/rQqQkc1RfskczsyZXZPwJl1ml8TTcDoJKYz4Eoyx9fw3WyPk0r7j3sBbmtT7VjzNyjLKQcc5nPfDe6iIZ4SGRJtaFfade6zNgTEHONjnibNqdbWTEJ@KLJVUQ6P1cp@rVIl8UaKBxqc4/dvJN/gT1pL@6Z9JctPXCnd1FBnHIm84965M4W1OKCzbyBUNi9M6lfZS86juk9uZ679IPJc64fyvdLdqVpZhSy/8UpFb6XEEiUGFLyfkJkVqCktzndEBUtwoH2OvGDuxsLxErdVr@wLtEZ1jxABTRTYiE64k6/8K8ItHZCZOEd2jr8Vv27Z52x5/RxfvbE93Nq73o74RziOe@0LkTkUXG6Q@j2XQQy@vwcnfBGXUGtbTA6iHROT@2R9r@sW/7Ll99mWHDGZQZ8@DvznfB70Ed3HEVZKsxqCqSIsEDEvry8pijDZPsKnzcUCbpBOACEDHDYYC/ynNk3kwcUlKbLJ/pThlARVCvyzPt3QPf8LusaUbQhf1irhhHSlVaL7Gi/a8sJQJLo3Lh8luw@ihR3CSQmMre2@OJFtjLTeCTT2AAlkfVKNey4TZlvkTRUSKRxPEcpeMUl3JDkoLjfhBDciZM0QEj7IUAHt1LeXVJSR9hoDbhLIAwxdYNWNQ71da28flawzb/gV3/ITlWeaXvkPaWhg6WhowXw58jQ4sjVkAPo6OqYN/3BK/ZpPp2/CQ5Sv/5NlboulZJcDdrkpcBO19@/TztGnEygmbuaw@dJ0Mpmm2ny5vj5t2k3nFCChmMMibEbNx@YIfs6R09QlZKKUgKz0UgKykloSZCW75JwCRJCVYBGWotJjaQQ/ICvpEjIpvGt97lyddK54oZAqAKr81EFLuCLbElGwczl6B232ivBX/HRH2fTiax7p0xANNjsr7PWe8@5nqicH6Q5Ugne/Ev26ldBsg9ZnNYDoWGu7xeTfvj/hNdS5EM1i1oAuTvx7oD8gM5hp5qp3@14qoh4uFXskC61azxTtDImFR8I@l42W7iD5d8dcpJ3xSPQ3AJz9Atzo1q8gvVN5gwD3fhLC/hhNvL7mRt7I1SbOZK49hi@sb0cu2bat8j9si2zPR3pQKa@sAP1xqbfc78XCjp5Jmeyi9LJZ2avs7@xW9lVoiDKiI1J7PWjYbh2w8F96UzzLhE/CvniYQT@1fq1NeU8@XT9fXPLVo18kHQ96NE@0JvCoV4nThedCmBwqVnq93FjRPGjPMvI5GqZ9@BRdXMJzzUh7iaSRSBqKuHORqxqcm@mzMkTKKkTQFGgEaZzuOd2sYa0eotu8RYc/RHr4938B)

### With comments

```
XX.z
# represents programs from first .m
# every dot has to be replaced with B, for example,
# because dots are syntaxically special
# append " to it
.aXX(long)".z
# essentially double entire stack
.a.eXX.z
# loop begin
.a!?.zXX.z
  # move every character to bottom
  # HOWEVER B is replaced with DOT
  # when exiting from loop, the stack will be:
  # "(original data)"(modified data)
  #
  # push dummy F if B is not top
  .a.c!!.+.zXXF.aXX.z
  # replace B with dot, and push F if F is not top
  .a.cF.z.sXXF..aXX.z
  # remove dummy
  .a.sXX.z
  # move to bottom
  .a.t.v.m.vXX.z
# get out if "
.a.cAc.-.aXX.z
# finally; discard top
.a.s.p
```

### Previous version

- 113 bytes: `Bm!?BzBcBoBc!!B+BzXXFBaBcFBzBsXXFBBaBsBtBvBmBvBcAcB-BaBp".m!?.z.c.o.c!!.+.zXXF.a.cF.z.sXXF..a.s.t.v.m.v.cAc.-.a.p`

  - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lRhrd9q48nt/hfDysPBDNoE8ECIbSNKlTWk2yfamBTfHMSY4MTZgk5AQ96/vHcnmkXbPuXc/YEmjeWs0M@IhGv39G6reDnZcY6@277o1u2pUbu29iu0e7LmDirHnmAe3xrBm7u4M30VujDR3TudjO3pAhlGpUHcxCWcxOmvfHJ2dsTaV4@eJi@7c2AmDYbEoVk44HtvBADfJwH0kwdz3UaVZNIvFjPj86OoPJuXlDA9pkxUDsfX6Opl5QTxEhajfD5CU50AJ55d8VOpJOtESaaXMX93O9c3l1TGrGMbOCnj@@bJzffb1pv354uKkfcVM2kMa57ZsHV3@cfPl5OKy87lbBzbIKhaXSNgaokkYeQvKF0qLJmuab/9E4o7nvh27KBpxgnASw@wpnA2iie/F1PY9O0LaHSrll6Yi5X@XkhIr8bFEu3@dnbU/HbM6iJB7IEDmEgc0GnnDWEgfII6ZAVxnFKL8b1hCDJnIen2Vc8h9tH0k5dDQ9iNXwrhY5ECOGI0qoT9oFiuYCtYCuHiN3AEqRWRBngmN4PNCSoLhy4qhoIUYWBGDQf4jOzigcE4Tz3dlLA@ZQR07coGtKSEvQPKwjNEQnEvdyHaoHY35wYZwpkcB0h7jufkaz5DWjlCpZ2gHVgnGflC2Sq93M3eC9Ff76QGVWifvO91lu7ezY1H47orvHv9WBaRa498D@A7DmUy9RmWXegozlZynyB5jNVyuiMk@Lu/A5Iek92oHFnjlsuezds9TdmuWwseDPctKlgBVFIvlDeoNZVhoFYux6m6xmDe4UW289DVWoWcypmkoSgWnH0iqkjeS5KR7vISdZDgPnNgLAwSLJfDx8TJD9iX6NOIO83EGQRK67Gmab6X80HWSlLhjSr0j7Ztwiq29gFO4N7RHFIIThfclvmqxkt57Wjy/WOiJhEi3SxzaZiXHjuGggNpoyoHCSIpENGKTTBdJt1GrijJy6bUNt8OLkZnkDbAeySmJbZFDCf0OSgYK0NavMdXCMhkQblYuwILGoHMWaGZmWdCcC6Ph3vpe4DaYkUlErY2Qn3RKUpXsTJIpPAk8gg2plJokrTgkEKL0p2wAMSatHBWBo7h3U281KikjGriLOInKYN4kDJzocRZbpCzbDRMrpKfk8gUtXVcwXgpcMiFLG2I7YmYSNUwKv3RjBJMRmBGTsp0sI5YjvaGb@Yza3D7vxiIK8YFf91QDAbLdNDCIdsDmXhhEIBqAIw4kY6LBtgmzlRaJmdqysmBn2wKptDyHmDVEpE4YnyuaaSWT3A@IsUxzn3AkHsETdHqJovltFM/kvKHuYHoOMedZ7DoxG3KXibQkT1RbPb3k@QJUXAK6LOUlgCC717XUlBWmA9d3IbOlDJJuYwfQIy4pZbjmnCrKtwQn1PuOLAX4Xa85rXXoNiuQo7jlYDdkHNLLFyxSLHK5ZfiAZXAcC8bX9JmlEH5BF41nvFDYsyY/swXcSMYvGE8E93BH7xuARvEktd7u3cPFptsOAW/KpK@Qw4XyXIczOVxoMOZgLMNYgLHwXIek@LPNPDhTIQYI8Wh6lWGXS4DbK9KpGZHveeKOJ/EzKa0yLMS3Xs4Tss5xGTxFIzSm5LuPwGOE8EzMXVYm53IRU3IHa0RguIXCEInw9W4ggIfuLB6DsyAhcfpoda3SywhgvEzhcMvSyYBAqRGlZZhVDSi/PMOX@NWSDVx6fU3XA2A6c@P5LIDLVsr4Qx4YDNbSNBLdxutVjkDdW6/6eTLwHtfLAhmHG0K9TP5zdSpLRQkgpdef9JHXPiRpBbjsPTCIdriHIlQlSR2pUp3T0nxE8mBbCUPkbMjWOdiVW3j5oCgUWFgMPjx2@PG1gFurwaG0pShQDx7UVoYAkxVj0JjzxphGM4dl9SiaQXMiR4OtVH8uH2OupfpRxhY7FtIUZbN/AqUg9WXu43aJ@LCGI4A3zc3Ox80OZ7bZuHqzwQXyq7/evpYv8PKCAZZQQtOyM0QXG5y53M5Sq6yZjXax2G5Uarv4sF2XpA3We84Jrtk8@EF0wpnOAzoPmCRtWGaTLNs3jcO8Ude2rPiLSwKa9gZ0JH9aFaGjuqR@ErkdmSK7p@DcOs2viSZgdBrTOXAlnsvX8N1sh2ml/ce9QO6oU/VY9TcoyykDHOoz3w3u4pE8xSIkOtCudBrMpx0IiLksH7MsaU7Vjmpi/EMSrYp0eKxU9@vVGk42UjzQ4Fx@/0byjfxJbavf1K94@YlJ@k0ddcOY5x33zp1JtM0AnX4DoaJ5oUK/6l56HrV9fDtz7Qee59o/pO/V3k7Nykt4@Y1Vq1o7IxYoCaDI@ymZWYWa0mZsh1ewFAfa59gL5m7CHS9w243qPkdr1vYw5tBUgY3olDv@yr4iua0BMuXnSM/lb@WvW/Y5W14/l6/e2B5t7V1vR/wjHMe9@gWLHAouN3DjnokgBt/fgxO@8EuodiwqBt6O8cl9ur7XNIt92fL7bEsOn8ygTw8D/7lYBH1493EkS/qsjmAqcQt4zIvri8s8TLaP8GlzsYAbpBNAyAGHDcZC/lOdpvLg4uIM2aR/inBKgyoD/tmYbuie/wVdc0o3hC9rleSUdKVVqvsaL97ywognujcuH6e7D7yFHcFJcYyt7QE/kW2MrN5xNPoACWR9Us17JhJmh@dNBRIpHE8Zyl45TXc4PSgmNuEENyJEzeASPohQAe2Ut5eUl5HOGgNuEsgDDI1jNYxDrVPvbB@VqDNv@JXf8uOVZ5pd@Q9ZaMjC0dCC@WJkWXDk68gA9HV0TJv@4ZT4dZ9M34QHL1//J8vCFkvBrgDsClPgxmvv36fdo08nUEzGucPWS8tphS0nl2sprZfr69OW3XJOARrxOSyiVtx6bI3h5xw5LQ0gE0kHQv1Fd/RQB0Jd0TmhbuvOKUA5oQ6LSI/1R30MPyDUNYBMSu/an7tXJ90rViplSoA6P3XRAi6J1oQX7UKB3EGrvSL8FT/bkTb9@JpH9jxEw83OCnu957z7merJQZoD1eDdr0S/bqU026D1eQ0hQtbabjH5t29QeBF1L3jDmDegk@P/IGgPyAxmqrnq377rZdSX9XIf56Fd65u8pcEJ90g0YKLZ0hwk/vKY89QTjnmPA8DZL8CNboMq0rrVNwhw9ycR7Ido4g1UN/bGrjpxJnP1MXqhAzt28bZt1f9hW2x7PtKCamVlBegv6/3lfj/hdvRNQkUnpVXM6l51f2e3uq9AU5TjXZHS70PTduuAhf/Sm/xpxn0SDfjjDHqq9Yttyvri@fr54pKtHv488XjQp3m8PYGHvYKdHjwZovRQZanfL4SS6kGLlhNP0ijrxafo4hKebEbWT6TNRNpUJN2LQs1gzMyelhGSViGCpkDDSZNsz@nlDWv1GN3mzbv8EdKiv/8L)
- 162 bytes: ``` XXx\è\ô\Ú\î\Ú\Þ\Ú\Þ\Ú@\V\Þ``\Z\Â\Æ\Æ\Þ\è\ì\Ú\ì``\Z\è¢\Â\ì\æ\ì°\î\Æ\Æ\ô\È\Â\H\Þ°\ÂQ.t.z.m.w.m.o.m.o.m .+.o00.-.a.c.c.o.t.v.m.v00.-.tQ.a.v.s.vX.w.c.c.z.d.a.$.oX.a ```

  - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrVyK58vv8ipBFSIB@Ab6I0VV0dtlVxlF31hlgPW3TDK1tN9INosD89bmVpJuH4727e48Hk1Qq9U5Vpbt21P/@E9py3e3tTbe33du2KxXHrpZve7t213Sd3q6zWam4t7u97Vu7@y5yY6S5IzZ6sKN7ZJrlMnMng3AYo9P6zeHpKa8zEj8PXPTVjZ0w6OVycuWEDw920KX7RtcdG8HI91F5P2flcsnh88OrXznOkgQPaYOUgNyi2akYirW5mmhznLL9o9m4vrm8OuZl06ykwPMPl43r08839Q8XFyf1K26xFtIChLPTo8PLX28@nVxcNj40a0AGdXK5KZJahWgQRt6EiUXxiM0XZ768dcR9GPl27KKoLw6EgxhmT@GwGw18L2a279kR0r6ifHZqFXH2ZzzP87wY86z5x@lp/eyY1yQLUFow7LKo7/ViybyLBGICcJ1@iLI/UYw4sgRrIiFR3wUbxmGIQr@7nxNe8GJkUeaObR/hDOrZfuTi2ewNdLSKLyWQOJNZ5HZRPjImxrPBIvj3YuQl3xfUmc1AZUkJcH5gC5qABfwx391l4MKB57uEkh43mWNHLnCwMPICRHoFinrgDeZGtsPsKHIfbv1n4fgQfH4YIG0cj6xZPERaPUKmVa5UN7e2d3ZRvtUOCp387OvQHSB9Zj/do/zRyS@N5tQHJl1e3WJgXTIYekHcQ/nBefghaHqNG6ceXY4/9d67J8OLpz8n18@fX77Yh/HVw1n3uKhlshsb@dn/wTprclxvYZQ1Ee7wNsZgEj98cockUiIQvOHgUtakFOE2ZpiBIfMyNAjGpcsSrmHKhOg9HnGMWS8cEgYR73uBi3r7JqNTr0dSQLTHTSrxABgJS9ZzuR7nXTo9IZRJlqjeijps7oLXkcCSu0994Qk1PyU9Ktix14TVjiAknWmy@XzB5kcGkoM6ckoiCgCBMe@NAif2wgCdEkfK7mRAXhrFtnPf8ovFDndWkOCIwPHpVJkL@4kJfFDd1zSagBFGCQXN6igxwAjzeV66QRujEGJHRh5O40GpnCi4D9oFRW60nibPLx1DM2xDqB/smQlnrNvoqIp0hYBn2LEhnCGw8SKyJR44migqdsc4wOhnkCwoArkaKClIhlIho2vkcpmAJoZUEDod8UCzmJIs2B@t@lY6IBFFCYGejBDp9puyvNZFCYftRB7AkL4L/gXJ1OcQoCy5PhtRuy0SX3o/8Yy0kDIz0vwYlUUaAkqz1As2N8UAEZoFn8GsD4B8VACTDcLAicbDuGMUiL1n0aLRKsK109S6TME/7iRmc2NgTIEMiyA7zKM9i8Ev2erDrA@Kx0Yhk7HZfBrxjNHquYk3mC2M4t10jKLhA9Xmew3YEBt8DwI4YKhWGEQgAAD7Amg8GBpsWzBLZWFzC27oKzUra2rmp@ctr2h2eBb8WiyyAYe1VoYbMfgG4ZvLAfOpAvEBkpE7uo3iIcmapQplXdd3oVqctzTN6zClGBz8y0etv1CnKM47xhSOECwBWVzCOZTDJUXybwlkBYXImHoaL7/C/S8n/eSE5IkWTP8xx6XgqRUh9MHj2Q0xA0SCzBkyFRrNYjoNhe0gdQ7YhGeb7xl65lnlLrYixKooAyrwQ3GRJnvPdFLkzxp55hPKFpZ@fwmJKiZGu2gcTIrPNfD3wUSDMQNjAcYNGDeea1DU3lbppHk8FbnnDqLvbs9jd8WiSj@AdtcRFyOti3DL9ELWMBa1QMINMAhY0TBEzRSyF4xzkqPM@AprZMBwC@VR3gTvBu5Czx3GDx2wvJGDxGmwmKVXGkAqR8AGncodWwDnctoVU1HkRMXuLdoBWZTz4hYTk@ZnM7XuAumhG4@GgSg8iktRELC73ZSrJtbRbZyuM2INXU26bmcFoOuNU8CGRAhTApGhF4w/r94TnIMcCFZ5JdmiGqvEfNm653B94IqnZbCvymAemoQ4zT15Ye/Z4uiiYrjkiE7v4d4BmQ6Hf6IgCLcdAcWjPQFlR@A5mJSOEgSYvCIuRAcGVJb5LoI0Rxlc7sgZeoOYJ4KK4ue63W9Yh/o1hG5ULldr3Dk5pkKf0u@EdvixlAlEW69vyvyZ39eq42@LDQQb@9bK1u/LLanNcudqbUcwFcov96/JBZ1ecECTkmha4np0sYI0IvWkKhDN2oP@ob5X3tyiB/WaqKgLtF8ELbDAKPhm6IYgOwrYKBC9x5JoMlsU2YOsWdNWdflDMINT9RXYITlLy9LhLTTpNUiRZ6sVSe1lMFvUpsXZAUl7mQyYlo7INfxf2Q9VP/H2ZkAapcfScclf4kwfOSBBA@a7wde4Tx6pjKUGFJ/GHvdZAyJpRMgxT3L4Y6lRsij9hlumttvBB8fF6k6tuim6nwUbD2Q4J7@s874hZ6V66UvpM52ecazf1FAzjEXCcr@6Q8zqHPDZF2Arux/V9VW3lXs2d@jt0LXvRfarQ96ttiqbHZFHv/BqVasnhxWKqPpkR52zqlDp6pxXRHVVSPCQir1g5LK58ILCru9VdwTi/uY2pRIsZVhyVwzoZ/4ZkboGyEy4lZ2TL4XPqzo6K8Y/J1frBohWNq/XrsIY3HJX@kRl8gXTm3Dv77gMbnDCHdjik7jGpUaHyUH0kGJyp9Z3mtbhn1YdMFxhJSZDeM6Fgf@cy4FMos86JFgf1hBMsVBDXAV5vWlBRMyaM5@WVw7IQUICjAyQWJF/Qj6WHhVHuNU0wbbYRxlaKsAS4Me9x5WDz//i4P7qwZeFUEQdTeVKxF8gxiuW6It8uW75B7V9Lzr8PrhMoKzud4VnVlGSsinw2D2klzWPyWTVEBm4CFmJiKtTIHfyv8qLlCq3cYki/LlkJcuR4PSbDB6Qs/jq9ooC1VigwA0DxoCiCbQ980Br1BprnpMFbI1i4RVFUdEek2zwWxIrRJodRPblyJNoydbQF3cYZhbx8rjvHzwafs03Hild5QpV8R/S3HiT5gbQ3JA0RYn//r55eHbC89fXk7ZVqbYrm6Yat6pqrJQT@Nb6uvI/1qaiYZW3lntVU/0EPD1jpuPW@pjSSmXZfC1L9W16gF@uvqKdnq1uLdblLXNdp9f8U90tc0HLNBXMSmEg44KOWf6ox/qL/qA/wS9UP6QX9dA0dU23dQf@QkAZw9ZYwuKPAB7rkT6@hkNi/0Xv6jbwKetZPbzW7fy7@ofm1Unzin9Pmgqclc7Cs@TDB@q9W99pBxjq2xKYEFgecN69JvXkIM15@9APW4sY7EHcLz6BrJz4/75vNC/kIwY69vwsEt/UtHtkBcOSlXbDf8laWEBtohfaNAtNb9sSbSCdY3hKipaJy2ZVc5D86DcSuTZ8EJ0hAIc/AJdidqtIa1bXEERLGMF@iAZet@TG3oNbGjiDUWkcvbCuHbt0Vc3q36sZ256PtKBaTtUBJYjenu6050KZtmXkl69brWxVt6s7EIE78A6E9yZYRb4b1DvBVq/nf29n8WZWdhIDFk/utBnFKcIjb@fF@OHikufzaTMtMrAHna8nmjjxHqVOy@vwxdendnsjxCUP0h609bKjTd40jwhDPMIz20z6LdVrqe8BbN682Ng0ObcSzSKE03hCj3AoOT1Ptp1W1uwoS/zIYg5x00da9P0/)

Comment: This isn't a quine. It's a program that outputs its own file name. A quine would require the filename to not be important; which I'm not sure is possible in Pxem. This is like submitting a 35 byte Python solution with code `exec(__file__)\n` with filename `print'exec(__file__)'`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BPbUiNVkjPj4tMyc1Pl6TS91OqaAoM68ETVxdybqgsiQjP89IAYf8//8A "Python – Try It Online"). Even though this is not in direct violation of any rules here, it clearly breaks their spirit. But what you're doing here is against the rules.

Comment: @Makonede but Pxem matters filename first and content is matter if and only if `.f` and `.e` are in filename; would I just undo frilom 109-byte version to 113-byte version to remove `.e`? Or should have I just clarify that a Pxem program consists of filename and optionally its content? In this case I would claim that its filename is the only source code; then I would satisfy the definition of quine: *produces a copy of its own source code*.

Comment: A Pxem program may run based on filename, but that does not automatically make it need to output its code instead of its content. A quine is still a quine, no matter how a language is implemented. Remember that you can't just make it output its content, by the way. A quine has to have part of its code that encodes the entire program. And even though I originally thought this isn't breaking rules, I'm 99.9% sure this is a rule somewhere, I just can't describe it in search-friendly keywords. I'll ask TNB about this answer for their opinion, I'm highly doubtful that this is a valid answer.

Comment: @Makonede; the programs output their filenames; not content.

Comment: Or should the 109-bytes version be represented in plain-text notation, such as in [esolang-box](https://github.com/hakatashi/esolang-box#pxem) or nk.'s [text2pxem.pl](https://vivibit.net/remember_pxem/#i-8)?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the program is. It must output its own content, not filename, regardless of if the program runs off of filename. Quine exceptions have not been made for Pxem and cannot be assumed until somebody sets a default.

Comment: @Makonede [Posted on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22424/100411)

Answer (score 2):

## [Adjust](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/adjust), 21 bytes

```
`@96c$+.+O`@96c$+.+O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVbbcts2EH0WvwJm6Ukr@SLl4sS0ZUu@qe4ksadp/OKRQ4qEZDQUyfCiOuOxH/oj/YH@Rf@kP@KeBQmAStTJxDrnLLDYXQAL@mGYpk9Pe2wY/l7mBRNxwbM04/hr7Vl77DiZz/04zF3JBmyTXZb5LeuCHCpS3HIW87uC@dkM@tp3uojTsmDBrV/5vKQBmZhzVvC8gHAB4aIsMAgkIZKFQAHQsZzEMsAPvGCZH4o7cAF@jlBnFCbLyVpkIp5J/x3QYRiKQiQxaBv0XRkVIo2@gm7S4HJSZH5Ay22DnoiFCDnIDcjpXZrEPCbbOs1MwjJKQA5ARhn3URlk5pPnfUhveZ4r3qfpX0o/Ao6B3ycF4xWH4tDCf/gp4CNVICG0RcuXaSQCOAZ3wX/lC57lXE46ETNRUH7DNOVxyIqEYXcWIilzFpfziczf29ra8hjVDWO2gyjJOcvrerBzKtUU4AzgLKHxp1La5hEtwoYyaR4wP6eydToWpdLvq73fjETMq4Mx9QMuTXuWNY38mWsHtmUF81CTqYh4RaawnNemPv3ZsFpBEnL3ELoapgweWfBLunsIMEalQ2IqmFGUTPyILfwsVxHIw@D2ulZe@MFn93psAYUidm27AnTiNBFxyO/crmXhlC7cT/JHayd6PAXTJOMZL5Z0gI4egJkbIbaYYh/g/9GlZXnk2XKkfCBxncJ7Efkhm5ZxQCdTp3GyEZPBL8hHG3@6k3HHyNlM6Z4O2auJ59LQpqGnqDd5u261bG2xP2qX8jpqp6Y4nmLKbcPU07x2bGzkuUrwXRKvTnBOhpSuPC37SOteHo21JanCkfrRbdOQhdpw0dDrDakMxw2DPBLaYkuK@FqNITjIeoBo6LgwWr8HeSBbldfJV6S1Kq8QBj80MXYqfyTP0XG03jZ6Xk60/MnIoVhoedvI/C7V8k3DeWLWXDfyzKx4YNRGHPsNz1@02jdq3JTXTAU@0A1bVQF59XJ0NT3NqbxJQ5oYPW3oYWn0sKGjs2l9YFZ/myTpyvrzSEz1hLWrybXVGjku9m/ui/iBrqP8JxfgaHHmZHwIMpEWPz579sx2cLRtgA12Pf7JBjm6qmZMkyxKGhm0l9zKIWKKuAs@541Dtbb23cA6DYEHdlUa1GLmYU5L0I105C31mOfIg0mA9oZ@ZZXIgxTl2@DVHkg1LjKwuZyS4imuHgNi0CknNYmwmVQnTOMaiRGl4slfFNxT@chH43/7GdVDdpiA1Rn50pXqahrLduQx1Kk1dAbOFfbQHth91msTOgR63u4QXAN8QbD3yXGdydixWo/6@i4tZ/qNrmJSFgZnprrUStD4mOKyZWiriM0sFPGbKC91lBcmykRFOcJ72GcvK5gBvqqgANypYA74ekVGtN1LCdWNRh0Fai4Ko6EoiCaiIBpHnVXdLzyFZ4WGkYH8i4Yx4aU8OzrPtslz0@S5bfK8MXmumzwPVJ4jex/wTQX7gLsVjO1@r7uiEPq8L1VDNx19JdLEYDQXjdFQvsnF0bk8mly2TC6uyuXbLZGXTYYhb/kCBq86LDTa3PKfefQ/zQrXpUg@87j@VvBkhB78dB13d@e4jzZ0fjY8tYfcasnA7tW1fkBPGwwn1zIYensxsXrQ5/5n3ny54If62dXk44jMKT6XuHrqyVbAtfPbBE8iNbnWv3/@fV@7QLuiSa2js3/@mgg5WXcOXf0r2c/QZOUHStVkpPEHaUVsg8M1e8RbLaqxfXmRoM/mJMiE7E57c/tm/WCfFFlw29l6dInJmtu95y9evtp5/Wa3S9qrah@qQlCHpDo4qa/2pG5mSwGM7DO736p2@Byo3uEhYL3Dp4Avm55lE5Susd31sctU0X7RHzdo6Y0vGl@ofbyXRX6oiqk3GTyodxifhHEZRZZDkw4Yfeo@PT15g92dwOlsdS4Msv4D)

Basically just a port of the [Adapt quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211397/66833), but updated with Adjust's swap command (`$` vs Adapt's `s`) and no longer implicit output

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 56 bytes

```
BEGIN{printf a="BEGIN{printf a=%c%s%c,34,a,34}",34,a,34}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzryRNIdFWCY2vmqxarJqsY2yikwgkapXgrP//AQ)

Outgolfed [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/122627#122627) [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/111090#111090).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 48 bytes

```python
s='print(f"s={s!r};{s}")';print(f"s={s!r};{s}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9hWvaAoM69EI02p2La6WLGo1rq6uFZJU90aqzDX//8A)

#### Python 3, 74 bytes

```python
s=r"s=;print(f'{s[:2]}r\"{s}\"{s[2:]}')";print(f'{s[:2]}r\"{s}\"{s[2:]}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9i2SKnY1rqgKDOvRCNNvbo42sootrYoRqm6uBZERBtZxdaqayoRVMH1/z8A)

First two attempts... I think this is the basic approach, just used Python's f-strings.

Answer (score 2):

## [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda), 160 bytes

```
open import IO;open import Data.String;main = run(putStr(r ++ show r))where r ="open import IO;open import Data.String;main = run(putStr(r ++ show r))where r ="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xPSfz/P78gNU8hM7cgv6hEwdPfGpnrkliSqBdcUpSZl26dm5iZp2CrUFSap1FQWgIU1ChS0NZWKM7IL1co0tQsz0gtSlUoUrBVorZ5//8DAA)

Agda is an interesting Haskell-like language with some interesting ideas and a lot of imports. Luckily I've managed to avoid most of those (though my [early attempts](https://tio.run/##S0xPSfz/P78gNU8hM7cgv6hEwdOfC5nrkliSqOeckViEKRpcUpSZl44p7pNZXKJQWgyU04iOj9XkqlCwVUgrys8Fi0eDmX6JJQrGJgqxXLmJmXlA6aLSPI2C0hKgiRpFCtraChUgAsLS1CzPSC1KBfJslYaKO///BwA) weren't so successful). The version on TIO is a bit out of date, which led to some frustration with the docs, but I think this code should still work with the latest version.

#### Explanation:

```
open import IO           -- Import the IO library for `run` and `putStr`
open import Data.String  -- Import Data.String for `++` and `show`
main = run(putStr        -- with main, print the string
       (r ++ show r))    -- r appended with the string representation of r
       where r =         -- where r is
                 "..."   -- the string of the rest of the program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [OCaml](http://www.ocaml.org/), 66 bytes

```ml
(fun x->Printf.printf"%s%S"x x)"(fun x->Printf.printf\"%s%S\"x x)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y09OzM35/18jrTRPoULXLqAoM68kTa8ATCmpFqsGK1UoVGgqYZWPASuIgaj4/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/), <s>34</s> 24 bytes

*Thanks to Jo King for saving 10 bytes*

```
S'R1+,$:@:?.S'R1+,$:@:?.
```

No trailing newline.

### Explanation

```
S'R1+,$:@:?.S { Put the rest of the program in a string: ("'R1+,$:@:?.") }
'R1+,         { Add a one-element string containing `S`: ("'R1+,$:@:?." "S") }
$:            { Swap & concatenate: ("S'R1+,$:@:?.") }
@:            { Duplicate & concatenate: ("S'R1+,$:@:?.S'R1+,$:@:?.") }
?.            { Print & halt }
```

ErrLess is a stack-based language I made for fun over the last few months. You can read the docs [here](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/), and I also started a [tutorial](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/tutorial.md).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VvpdtvGFf7Pp5hYsQFIJEU6S1PadOJ4q05sS7XVnjYUwwMCQxI2CCAzQ4uU4/zsA/QR@yLuvbMAg4WU7FhNqnNECYOZe7@7zp2F2UYs0uSLbzL2fo88piJY0JDMWLokCyEyPjg8nEeiy1l3IQ5/ZSs/mWSHlLGYcj5hdMYPBaP0cOlHyWEk6PJwGs2jRExWSRSkIT3MFHkzpJttiC/IFz1yHIh0Shm53bvdb0XLLGWC@Gye@YxT88w33PwroiVttYLY55xESTZoEfgJ6YxMJlESicnE5TSeeaodf/CxG/rCJ0PiOK28/5yKOEpotTujYsUSa9QBcu9yEUZJl1E/lIO80aDTH5eISUJtwqMLOuz0LYrRTDaSu6Q3uJy86xVQAHHecTRAIuM7JXmKt/hyMK5KwerksWMnponLPK@EP6pqIqFzYPHYj8EONUgocL@Aer6IYkpYN@I88wPQT0Fm1zBQDbwCu3ScgeZ3ylb0ziV8klQQNgIDFPyIn4R5WwiuJ@oYDppp2gqVFFBppq0kOVNWN02CbSoslNbB7UG7KBwCRbEo6JB0VHs@gq4Dmgnydz9e0UeMpayR2Ai8DPwcuMMnOEcLzRVnaebGbRIVngbcIh4lXPgJ6APexREX3pkhiepx3YjcG5KefIjAH9ENYs8jKSMuPqs3bifyyN2heVuPjbiL7CMliQVTIaP09e8IbRSNG2FxsDmiapP1/xAVwgHLrS1ICs8s9oWQ3XMw6CsNgPKUMYq1ZEBwpP6dAQ4KfkFiSxFdugbKoWtYUK9kKKYABGm2sbk3ca4qdyQHUc/iW1J2rEiH6WTlmkQihZ246zq1GTQ2yL3W3FXMjGDsRjHcIMN1ieFsknMMaxzbZGMx9dtkijFUZ9S2Gze60c5QvjTytDk6gdNFm5wriPgforyIMsW/yBU0Rkq7aGgxLywx84HbmQObC2vgZtygZqRdVZuaQJ9TkHsa04Fxp3OfhaCmtzkV5wIys/Oj0y5a3mLLO7vFxRbPblliyzPd8k5@Tv3gdZ38Bjv@0x76Dlve2i0etrh2yzNsWebkpRPw11E2CdLlkkKazVg6b5NMsLaRig9xZjEOnwQAo4/WNa91ju7L98HCxzBDKiMgopSagLJkGg7kIxcsSnDGws5qJtWzE/Qr7AXDceIxo0zTTZUukEPhbI1sLV4HmpnlnGrIUFql5CMSLQzolz0p7/@uqX8H@9uu4gKMA8Du3czRtjUaS@tah7bWkRx0GsryoU0gIQ2fp4nR/1b9TsAfg9eY4bDLuEHRWm6KGRkcGGgO5MMwd@auhqNJVCyjONTs078W67haDThhGM0XIEa9sapb5CuI3qoEZQvtsrYG3iYTLJwaI8GrDShwT2rvgjQB4Cta8xEFvetnGU4yCMgre5iLmit6euQzW7vF5FoVVpZllnKg0mpL@3oosWQ02IYG65EKjCqKIcZ7rmx4AviX0KsFQn93GJgM90eJA4Pn6oHQ@aMFghFheyS8@/BIaKtFzR82IIzQ/9cRIVYZMP3gGhOHUdcMXqvSZi1rTSWOFKVMSY5pWAs01KYsFb6Qg9Ls8tK7mWJ9QJqZohXAoj6AOC4I@lsoiCWu5/KlUpphAOQVfYTSMj@ZU7ffNuQsMFDPKQLw2S5RicaFyc2KRzbjqqdVae2NJR2vQUtz5k9dDrQtNZn2iZs3yZAxjm@WpIhVDcBlgBzh4RCt/5VylgH6igzGAS6X0XUwGUktQsm2SviAhFEAGu3cww66QF0lpbwjG/f2yMvT@w9@IMcnj17cPz06fv6yZewkB0CSGEC9uEcepEkA1k/gt1gXSEMAdBUUeft0S7vMZWXr@9r4allYeTk1L8uRVcoZI@jkj@1o5XRQ7jIlB8T3qmKtpVj3ZZdLJYq3S3Sp/9chxw2QS91j09X3tpOJayLdkSK9pBllVzFTHbzfCB7Hj3x7pkIUeqXsW5nF4PhM4jhJs0J/Ffal7t/J7g8xbQU2blwwqKW2DFM13Gs1KkM00J1Luk8givIxabbTwAWb/IUKZ2wzIV1n9CRnpPZ8ZffLedqk9Z9G8rEk/5Qmc7Eo7Z9V/AG3RGxN1XbLTjeZ3iwrj@z0G7g@tbiSdFYRqsbZtk6JDpN0Xsi5o6yTfB@n0M0W65qZp@ho5coStxcWtyY77OSp2eyyRVvSx2qjtSW2C8LjhvGfqxA997OPzqKl8MOQnZrNaMjmTyMBwR/zVpk1TIpOr3/7iy@/@vpP3/zZnwYwnyhJVsspZbxZGNxzhdFt0v@6SddnjpoZoALyA2FTMevCO9vr4BKjVNf9cmZqYvVSqe30xdHzJ61SpcpNpdqwjtbrBhi9he8IGQeqTgpQSXzUx11qKznryR3o5Tq@zzZisfRFFLTqSA/UtBKGv9G@GqHcnYv95TT0sXaBmF8fbDycGf0mPXWUnlZTgSa5NgidHRAmOkLmdrxXCa5yggPSWXulcGyguS9pPlvFIsrizbWJtb9DrEM1SUVvovDjCyC52vVnNIzeVPdY85yuHW59eLgpvdQ5/EfKUkTBozTRuVyP6O2QUzPdLt5NpeE0XMXpbxZvmYaXinfzE0sHPLdLd3ZmrAfdPoX1riCh3esDRW1fxZa2wCYzPUiXmc8iniYNmWkodfDo55UfR@LagqjT33fXw@HG226Nu7qy4JyIhZ9cK5K7u4Dc03UbhVTFrh/LPQuLsdj3kTiPOCWH5Gk6h/I3Jseyegen4A02/FUl1@PTK2XWXy/PrLfUdPX84bUl1Vs7kuovkvvxi2tj/ssO5j9J5v@4Ru4/bWr2PhYLyhoMK1RMRELElJxeFyIs6Nb7/d7@/q6wOJVYvo/m5GpuhlSR5tq71N0yW8yT6xXz9m4pT3IpT64s5e0mIYvkmwiWxuRxnJ43WLgr@f3Fj0W1ttTnZqXeF7L3Y3O@9iQVaam63l70ypO6UW/cVMHW2GyUEvSe6XY@TbvzH8TorWR0ep52zv0NmW9hUz93uSr9kSp8gUiutHzcq@W2FXiGWwzlbXjb6q8AwzATA5J1JxNOBV7NmkxcmJ9d3ALsvLI2cMEtXpkNwUKqTFxVgHEhQG6Oa5fg4DdIYNz@hKUBDVeMcnKLPPMDljZNXK7aEjJ9y2s4YB9ctowrcOEG5yjfIbdCcaz2NwO1hruS1pcSls24jGzpfypgLh65AzkFzrsSuhtqMwOecsUdSg0XLLe4hSxEEXoJ08y@U6Gq0B/oRhefgQEJmaogtKzdYiufIAT1EwR54INbdyPLCIYWJg2bVLF1hBKrK0G4KbmsbFGNLJXxbXt19Q1Nbs4WCrq79mVrezeXssS47FVu2GXy3lOZEfbD/XvQV4abFhrqUt2c0DtOaCwPLL6UUURStY9L0gRqU7ObZcLu6Lghyr7VUQZzVc59rzKPZfjWDRZMXyFaFycmvXW/34MffX/IOes56tTVcSqzXkGdnAK0WRrDpIfHf36wiOgbyhVif0kh1/txW2tmSrHPzOdQb1uHpxKR43RfpVFyZWTF4VbTnp6XA7egHpFoCb6KUwwNAWHE1QdMSW3AFvgroC3RIEwKsgD5EJf8sGay6ARmx4sI/zXI@vMK8iqJ0wQSw3QlLBJvKO4VScUIsGNA8bx5uQoWFjWlji6g2w/SVRzuFygJT0GDHK/upjMgPZupdYrAO6eKDQqSWtS4CFOAwKL5QoBMoCS8bJZBU8qkUTB/MX@J6uEK7hFMGYkjUBfJa@xjkaOzGXJHJcFf0IeQekdCICHM5D7EGmCfkU26AkUCZpGCJ1MakxmjtAyuEAzowACGV0U/q/vxXuHHuEPZss6R32AkKmfm8iDM5d6uwFf@4jrkgDjEuBiQKW/7efjacyouKfvZXlV2qhLkv0rIR6jpIrdDwENMtnFFX0ouOtSvuCkJ5uuaC9eNm8o/F7xL6vo4/ppd5DZVzZHF6oF9T6G2n6vJuP3GhcBRhQ5vLF/Wg6upBhLGuJqhTKJ8FvGmfdqHakeITlfz39W9zHHGDPLjUF83p4xdcl1AHzWD5LMEkqyefZm6pS9noghPbUBpqkMbz2FgFuSSz6B0MRtb7Nvz5pY9yM6Kk@cJ8nXx2wiV42ecAEtH0HiLJk2ofRKdN4Wob3WfR2MuLqUr2hlerYRZJQUlQfrEfLLADAYpEhow58ojtoD5XOZVmBwvKEvxVj4eVMlUx83BqLoIlF/xye8Fja2TU168l09D8vadUv7R88fHsqREKaGzBK8srl1kf9Im@/uTyUASKEa5zpmAsINKSn/oqqHaQVaRjGZMKladfqgCMT8RdP7zr3875byjqwwoz8t1hirYZZUB1DR1u7TIeyoIFVxaJVLKgfyqSJfHlGZut9evDv1I9NKZ8FsuGiFMj9OUU3PBq@4de/KbLCiW@VZL9z6br3AKOZFvzL0a3bHrh@HE1z3cG503N9rkRqej@cDDgsbZ8Eb@rMaShh@Y36M0Gd7gAmbQiYCy9Ya3i1OoOEkRcj40wTtJ2nGWIPKn4@hg2DqakSOLMPQKvGkF@pXFh/qykIwrx6gJxqOLa4ryD9LkRo/gAFo5tfqs0@lA4iQPjh8@IpBC4dGxlzFcntaH4DSw2IDuZ4n1Or/0Dv0qhbEiDg4FOZKOBl/erpTeFOjS0Ze3B@XFhAqCWN7Rb7jEpqgScL8zQcg22lvolwR@8ejl356elgQupUPjtvITtCjdmzmO8/6l86J/0P588N3g2679/3t4qZeB779q/Rc)

Answer (score 2):

## [JsonLogic](https://jsonlogic.com/), 631

```
{"reduce":[[1],{"cat":[{"reduce":[{"var":"accumulator"},{"cat":[{"var":"accumulator"},{"substr":["\\\",:[]1abcdelmnorstuv{}",{"var":"current"},1]}]}]},{"var":"accumulator"},"]]}"]},[21,1,16,11,10,19,9,11,1,3,4,4,6,5,2,21,1,9,7,18,1,3,4,21,1,16,11,10,19,9,11,1,3,4,21,1,20,7,16,1,3,1,7,9,9,19,13,19,12,7,18,15,16,1,22,2,21,1,9,7,18,1,3,4,21,1,20,7,16,1,3,1,7,9,9,19,13,19,12,7,18,15,16,1,22,2,21,1,17,19,8,17,18,16,1,3,4,1,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,1,2,21,1,20,7,16,1,3,1,9,19,16,16,11,14,18,1,22,2,6,5,22,5,22,5,22,2,21,1,20,7,16,1,3,1,7,9,9,19,13,19,12,7,18,15,16,1,22,2,1,5,5,22,1,5,22,2,4]]}
```

Try it online by pasting it under "Rule" [here](https://jsonlogic.com/play.html). (Note: the "Output" section is JSON-encoded. The raw unquoted string is logged in the console which can be viewed with F12)

Answer (score 2):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 77 bytes

Quines are one of the things that aren't that hard in OIL, because of the whole "unified memory" thing. The quine exists since a long time, but I hadn't posted it here yet.

The following code needs to be stripped of the comments to work:

```
0  # do nothing, these two fields are just placeholders
0
1  # copy the line above to itself
1
1
4  # output line 1
1
11 # and a newline
4  # and output line 1 again
1
11 # and a newline (now we printed 0 and 0)
1  # copy line 2 to line 2
2  # *
2
1  # copy
12 # line 12 (the one marked with the star)
18 # to line 18 (marked with $)
10 # ^, if the next line (currently 2) is equal to the line afterwards (1)
18 # $
1
32 # jump to line 32 (essentially quitting, because it's out of bounds)
22 # otherwise to the next line:
1  # copy from 18 ($) to 26 (&)
18
26
4  # output from the cell with the number in the next line
26 # &
8  # increment line 18 ($)
18
11 # newline
6  # jump to line 17 (^, beginning of the loop)
17
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Scratch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_(programming_language)), 542 bytes

```
when gf clicked
set[s v]to[when gf clicked/&set[s v]to[/&set[i v]to(0/&set[q v]to[/&repeat(length of(s/&change[i v]by(1/&if<<(letter(i)of(s))=[/]>and<(letter((i)+(1))of(s))=[&]>>then/&say(q/&set[q v]to[/&change[i v]by(1/&else/&set[q v]to(join(q)(letter(i)of(s/&end/&if<(i)=[28]>then/&set[q v]to(join(q)(s/&
set[i v]to(0
set[q v]to[
repeat(length of(s
change[i v]by(1
if<<(letter(i)of(s))=[/]>and<(letter((i)+(1))of(s))=[&]>>then
say(q
set[q v]to[
change[i v]by(1
else
set[q v]to(join(q)(letter(i)of(s
end
if<(i)=[28]>then
set[q v]to(join(q)(s
```

[Try it on Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/702456958/) (link is to a project that uses lists as output for better readability.)

This uses a classic method of storing the data in a container and uses it to make a quine. Because Scratch doesn't allow to initialize a list in just a single block, I have to use a variable of string and encode `/&` for a newline.

Explanation:

```
when gf clicked // when green flag is clicked (the start of the program)
set[s v]to[when gf clicked/&set[s v]to[/&set[i v]to(0/&set[q v]to[/&repeat(length of(s/&change[i v]by(1/&if<<(letter(i)of(s))=[/]>and<(letter((i)+(1))of(s))=[&]>>then/&say(q/&set[q v]to[/&change[i v]by(1/&else/&set[q v]to(join(q)(letter(i)of(s/&end/&if<(i)=[28]>then/&set[q v]to(join(q)(s/&
// the above variable `s` is used to store the content of the whole code, apart from the content of itself, which we'll try to tackle using the below code.
set[i v]to(0 // set the counter to 0
set[q v]to[ // this is like a buffer for what we'll say on a line
repeat(length of(s //repeat for the length of s
change[i v]by(1 // increment i by one
if<<(letter(i)of(s))=[/]>and<(letter((i)+(1))of(s))=[&]>>then // if we hit the newline
say(q // then say what is in the buffer
set[q v]to[ // clear the buffer
change[i v]by(1 // and increment i, to avoid parsing &
else /// else
set[q v]to(join(q)(letter(i)of(s //add the letter to the buffer
end // end the if-else
if<(i)=[28]>then //if we hit the 28th character, which is right after the initializion part of the variable s
set[q v]to(join(q)(s // then we add the whole content of s onto the buffer
```

Comment: Instead of using `/&`, why not use `//` and do `<(letter(i)of(s))=(letter((i)+(1))of(s))>`?

Comment: @UndoneStudios Unfortunately `letter` have double `t`, so when the code runs it treats the double `t` as a newline.

Comment: What about using a single character that the code doesn't have (like `$`?)

Comment: @UndoneStudios you also can't, because it will mistake the `$` in `<(letter(i)of(s))=[$]>` in `s` as a newline.

Comment: We could add another condition `and<not<(i)=(whatever position this $ is)>>`. Probably that would work?

Comment: This is invalid because the Scratchblocks output is wrong, you need to escape each `]`

Answer (score 2):

## [RASEL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/RASEL), 11 bytes

```
<@,Yj5#?:,"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$26\log_{256}(95)\$ ≈ 21.35203072707557

bytes

```
"D34CXx+xs+s+"D34CXx+xs+s+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuha7lFyMTZwjKrQrirWLtVE4EAVQdTD1AA)

[It's one of those ones which has one of itself.](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxglN_9283x5IVr6oEcFAFaZ0nU-XW99lX)

### Explained

```
"..."D34CXx+xs+s+
"..."              # Push a literal string 
     D             # Duplicate that string
      34CX         # X = chr(34)
          x+       # append " to the string
            xs+    # prepend " to the string
               s+  # prepend that to the original literal string
```

Comment: I thought it was \$\log_{256}(96)\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 9 bytes

```
"ᵉĝ,"ᵉĝ,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FuuVHm7tPDJXB0pxLSlOSi6GysHUAAA)

```
"ᵉĝ,"ᵉĝ,
"ᵉĝ,"       Push the string "ᵉĝ,"
      ĝ     Wrap the string in quotes
     ᵉ ,    Join it with the original string
```

Since Nekomata always prints the result with a trailing newline, I have to add a newline to the code to make it a quine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
"DṘ"DṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSUyMkQlRTElQjklOTglMjJEJUUxJUI5JTk4JmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JmZsYWdzPWo=)

##### Explanation

```
"DṘ"DṘ  # Full program
"DṘ"    # Push the string "DṘ"
    D   # Duplicate it
     Ṙ  # Get its representation
        # (Surround by quotes)
        # j flag joins the stack
```

Comment: You have “explanation” written twice, and maybe that screenshot should be a Try It link now

Comment: @noodleman good spot lol

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore C64 machine code (6502) using the Kernal (non-competing/just for fun), 42 bytes

From memory location 0x033c, enter the following machine code in your monitor:

```
>C:033c  a2 00 bd 3c  03 48 4a 4a  4a 4a 20 59  03 68 48 29
>C:034c  0f 20 59 03  68 cd 65 03  f0 0e e8 d0  e5 c9 0a 90
>C:035c  02 69 06 69  30 20 d2 ff  60 01
```

Now call with `g 033c` or `SYS 828` from the BASIC prompt.

Each byte of the machine code is written to the screen with the `CHROUT` routine in the Commodore Kernal, so this will likely work with all Commodore 8-bit machines, though it is untested on all but the Commodore C64.

How it works:

The routine starts from the base address at 0x033c, and reads each byte by loading its value into the accumulator; the accumulator is pushed to the stack, and then the value is logically shifted right so to get the high nybble (so `d2` becomes `0d`), and the high nybble is converted to its PETSCII equivalent (0 - F inclusive) and outputted to the screen.

We pull the value back from the accumulator and then mask out the high nybble, leaving the lower nybble (so `a9` will become `09`) and again we convert this to its PETSCII equivalent and output it to the screen.

Finally, we check the value of the current memory location of 0x033c offset by the X register (our counter); if it is equal to our terminating byte (in this case is `01`, the last byte of the quine) we're done. Otherwise, we increment our X register by 1 and go again.

For some hints, you may disassemble this by using `d 033c` in your monitor; this will show you the 6502 assembly equivalent to the machine code bytes.

For further guidance and reference, consult [C64 Wiki](https://www.c64-wiki.com/) or [CodeBase 64](https://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=start).

[image: Commodore C64 Quine]

Answer (score 2):

## [(,)](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/in-parens-comma), <s>8167</s> <s>7594</s> <s>7402</s> 7242 Chars

```
((),()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())((()),((()())))((),()()())(()(),(()())(())()(),,,(),,(())(())()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())(())())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,(()))(,,,(()())())((,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,((())))((),(())(),,(()())()),,,,((())))((),()()())((),(())(),,((()))(()()),((())))
```

*Thanks to some golfs (and help from Dadsdy himself) [now fits in a link!](https://inparencomma.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=((),()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),()()()())(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),)(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())(((),(())()),())((()),((()())))((),()()())(()(),(()())(())()(),,,(),,(())(())()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())(())())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,(()))(,,,(()())())((,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,((())))((),(())(),,(()())()),,,,((())))((),()()())((),(())(),,((()))(()()),((())))&stdin=&)*

I wanted to golf [Dadsdy's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261549/62393) but I couldn't really understand the implementation of the decoder, so I've ended up writing a new submission from scratch.

*Edit: reverted one golf because the interpreter changed and broke it; I've managed to nest some print statements however, which ended up in a lower bytecount anyway!*

*Edit: new golf suggested by Dadsdy cuts 160 more bytes!*

### Explanation

A typical quine strategy, the first part encodes the second part of the code, and the second part prints the encoded version followed by the unencoded one.

I'm using the variable at address 1 (`var1`) as a pointer, going through the characters of the quine one by one. `var2` will contain the ascii code for an open bracket (`(`, 40), while closed bracket (`)`, 41) and comma (`,`, 44) will be printed by adding 1 and 4 respectively to that number. Variables from 3 onward will contain the encoding of the quine.

```
((),()()())
Set var1 to 3

((),(())())....(((),(())()),())
Encode all the code after this part: 
  (((),(())()),) is an open bracket
  (((),(())()),()) is a closed bracket
  (((),(())()),()()()()) is a comma
this sets each memory address in order to 0, 1, or 4 to match the following code.

((()),((()())))
Set the memory address after the end of the data to -1

((),()()())
Reset var1 to 3

(()(),(()())(())()(),,,(),,(())(())()())
Set var2 to 40 (5*8)

(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())(())())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,(()))(,,,(()())())
Print ((),()()()), the first instruction of the quine which was not included in the encoded part

((,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,((())))((),(())(),,(()())()),,,,((())))
For each variable in memory print the corresponding encoding
(this will print the encoded part of the quine)

((),()()())
Reset var1 to 3

((),(())(),,((()))(()()),((())))
For each variable in memory, print the corresponding character    
(this will print the unencoded part of the quine)
```

```js
text = `((()),((()())))((),()()())(()(),(()())(())()(),,,(),,(())(())()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())(())())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,(()))(,,,(()())())((,,,(()()),(),,()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()())())()()()())(,,,(()()),(),,()())(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()()))(,,,(()())(),(),,()())(,,,(()())()()()())(,,,(()(),,,(()()))(),(),,((())))((),(())(),,(()())()),,,,((())))((),()()())((),(())(),,((()))(()()),((())))`;
text = text.replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
output = "((),()()())";
inc = "((),(())())"
for (let c of text){
  output += c=="(" ? `(${inc},)` : c==")" ? `(${inc},())` : `(${inc},()()()())`;
}

output += text
out1.innerHTML = output.length + " chars"
out2.innerHTML = output
```

```html
<h1 id=out1></h1>
<p id=out2></p>
```

Comment: I cannot belive I didn't try that encoder. Edit: I did, I just didn't realize I didn't need to set it to anything

Comment: For -7 Chars each, the ()(),() can be removed. This is because ungiven condition arguments default to -1.

Comment: Also it turns out outputting the 40 + variable**2 and replacing `(((),(())()),()()()())` with `(((),(())()),()())` is worth it, as is replacing `((),(())())` with `(((),(())()),)`, getting it down to 7645 chars. https://codepen.io/Onilily/pen/zYMvjMO

Comment: I was sure I had tried that first golf, but apparently it got lost somewhere ^^" I'll need some time to understand your second idea though... Thanks!

Comment: Turns out that after another golf using a new flag, the first golf is no longer more efficient

Comment: You can replace all instances of `()()()` in the code that outputs `((),()()())` with `(())` because you had rear var 1 beforehand

Comment: And same for the code that set var2 to 40! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Thue++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue++) 39 Bytes

```
.+::=~$0\n::=\n$0
::=
.+::=~$0\n::=\n$0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 34 <s>39</s> bytes

```
["$91,34,!34,93,!"]$91,34,!34,93,!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/z9aScXSUMfYREcRiC2NdRSVYtEE/v8HAA)

This is a "standard" quine program as outlined here: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Quine. What makes this program interesting is its use of FALSE's lambda (`[]`) command. FALSE doesn't have string literals, so I had to make an anonymous lambda function that prints a string, rather than returning it's value. This can then be executed multiple times by duping it (`$`).

Answer (score 2):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 24 bytes

`"34#.(,#)~:?"34#.(,#)~:?`

prints the string `"34#.(,#)~:?` twice

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=IjM0Iy4oLCMpfjo_IjM0Iy4oLCMpfjo_)

## Explanation

```
"34#.(,#)~:?"             \ push the string 34#.(,#)~:?
             34#.         \ print a "
                 (,#)     \ print the string
                     ~:?  \ 1st iteration: go back to the start of the program now with an additional -1 on the stack
                     ~:?  \ 2nd iteration: jump to address 0, terminating the program
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 45 bytes

Simple format approach. We can use `%q` for conciseness.

```lua
s="s=%qprint(s:format(s))"print(s:format(s))
```

Comment: Same as https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47143

Comment: @noodleman Heh, I had assumed that our quines had to be different given that it ranked higher. Turns out they are probably off by one byte: `print` prints a newline, so their solution needs a trailing newline, which puts it at 45 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 93 bytes

Note the trailing newline.

```python
f=lambda x:chr(34).join([x,x,'))']);print(f("f=lambda x:chr(34).join([x,x,'))']);print(f("))
```

Inspired by Vyxal’s `I` builtin.

This quine isn’t winning any challenges, but it’s still a quine!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocIqOaNIw9hEUy8rPzNPI7pCp0JHXVNTPVbTuqAoM69EI01DiSTFmppc//8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## HTML+JS (data url), 142 bytes

```
data:text/html,<pre id="a"></pre><script>!function f(){a.innerText=`data:text/html,<pre id="a"></pre><script>!`+f+"()</scr"+"ipt>"}()</script>
```

This requires no "extra environment", just paste it into the browser address bar.

### common version, 112 bytes

```html
<pre id="a"></pre><script>!function f(){a.innerText=`<pre id="a"></pre><script>!`+f+"()</scr"+"ipt>"}()</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You don't have to include the `data:text/html,` if you don't want to, a plain HTML answer is fine

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 90 bytes

```
`s='s=\\\';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*2';s[0..1]+s[3]+s[0..1]+s[2]*6+s[3..-1]*`2
```

**Edit**

Works in GroovyConsole

Answer (score 1):

### Ada, <strike>274</strike> <strike>258</strike> 257 Characters

```
with Text_IO;use Text_IO;procedure Q is M:Character:='"';T:String:="with Text_IO;use Text_IO;procedure Q is M:Character:=';T:String:=;begin Put_Line(T(1..54)&M&T(54..65)&M&T&M&T(66..126));end Q;";begin Put_Line(T(1..54)&M&T(54..65)&M&T&M&T(66..126));end Q;
```

pretty printed:

```
with Text_IO;
use Text_IO;
procedure Quine is
   M : Character := '"';
   T : String := "with Text_IO;use Text_IO;" &
     "procedure Q is M:Character:=';T:String:=;" &
     "begin Put_Line(T(1..54)&M&T(54..65)&M&T&M&T(66..126));end Q;";
begin
   Put_Line(T(1..54)&M&T(54..65)&M&T&M&T(66..126));
end Quine;
```

this program actually produces the short version (output can be redirected to q.adb).

Answer (score 1):

## F♯# - 349 Characters

```
let s="\\\"\nnlet s=let z a b=s.Substring(a,b)System.Console.WriteLine()z 4 6+z 1 1+z 0 1+z 0 1+z 0 1+z 1 1+z 0 1+z 3 1+z 3 1+z 4 169+z 1 1+z 2 1+z 10 26+z 2 1+z 36 25+z 62 111+z 61 1" 
let z a b=s.Substring(a,b)
System.Console.WriteLine(z 4 6+z 1 1+z 0 1+z 0 1+z 0 1+z 1 1+z 0 1+z 3 1+z 3 1+z 4 169+z 1 1+z 2 1+z 10 26+z 2 1+z 36 25+z 62 111+z 61 1)
```

My first attempt at a quine - probably an easier (or shorter) way to do it, but not a bad first attempt I don't think

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 61 chars

```
set c {set c {$c};puts [subst -noc \$c]};puts [subst -noc $c]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 143

```
class P
    def main
        s='class P{2}   def main{2}     s={1}{0}{1}{2}      Console.write(s,s,39to char,10to char)'
        Console.write(s,s,39to char,10to char)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 76 characters

```
s="s=%c%s%c;print(string.format(s,34,s,34))";print(string.format(s,34,s,34))
```

Another one with the usual format string technique.

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.9](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 10 bytes

This language *was* made after this challenge, but was not made for it.

```
"66*2-(O).
```

Like other 2D languages, the `"` makes everything between it and the next `"` a string. `66*2-` adds the not-included `"` and `(O).` prints everything out and stops.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, 84 bytes

```
val d="""
print("val d=\"\"\""+d+"\"\"\""+d)
"""
print("val d=\"\"\""+d+"\"\"\""+d)
```

Kinda straightforward, but putting it out there for completion.

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 2 bytes

```
1
```

Pushes the number 1, implicit print with trailing newline. Since this is fairly trivial, here is the smallest non-trivial quine which can contain arbitrary characters (12 bytes):

```
`è";ƒ"@+`;ƒ
```

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.1.3, 7 bytes

[Try it out here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

```
"rYao;~
```

`"` begins a quote string, and reads all of those characters. `r` reverses the stack, and `Y` pushes the char code of `"`. `a` begins a one-way mirror loop, `o` outputs the character, and `;` mirrors while the stack is truthy. After the zero is met, we advance to `~` and the program ends.

## Reng v.2, 8 bytes

```
{n6G*o}`
```

This one is a little more interesting. `{...}` is a code block, and `` ` `` executes a code block. `n` outputs the codeblock already on the stack, `6G*` makes a `` ` `` character (6*16 = 96), and `o` output's *that*.

Answer (score 1):

## Java <s>2146</s> 2118 bytes

A legitimate attempt at a quine. This was automagically generated. I could have robbed someone elses quining technique but decided against it.

```
interface q{static void main(String[] args){char[] s={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};System.out.print("interface q{static void main(String[] args){");System.out.print("char[] s={");for(int i=0;i<s.length-1;i++){System.out.print((int)s[i]+",");}System.out.print((int)s[s.length-1]+"};");for(char c: s){System.out.print(c);}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 36

```
printf |(q<printf |(q<%s>xx 2)>xx 2)
```

Based on the [Perl 5 quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4827/14109).

Answer (score 1):

## Aubergine, 21 bytes

```
-a1+a1=oA=Bi-BA:bB=ia
```

This program ends with a trailing tab character.

Comment: Tab character?.

Comment: I wrote this program in November 2015. I could have sworn I'd posted it here already. Anyway thanks for posting it and no thanks for not giving me credit.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you didn't post it on here, so how would I know you already wrote it lmao

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 56 bytes

```
val s="val s=%c%s%c;printf(s,34,s,34)";printf(s,34,s,34)
```

First defines `s` as `val s=%c%s%c;printf(s,34,s,34)`, then prints it formatted with double quotes (ascii 34) and itself.

Answer (score 1):

## Dip, 10 bytes

```
"N+|+"N+|+
```

**Explanation:**

```
"N+|+"      Push string
      N+    Add " on the left side of the string
        |+  Duplicate and concatenate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zetaplex](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Zetaplex), 13 bytes

```
"Sr34SZOsDrFe
```

Zetaplex is a variant of [gammaplex](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gammaplex). In it, commands are pairs of chars and act on an infinite stack.

Answer (score 1):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 16 bytes

[Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

```
[put ':!' put]:!
```

`[put ':!' put]` is a func, which is pushed to the stack. `:` duplicates it, and `!` executes it, which prints the function, then `:!`.

Answer (score 1):

## Forth (gforth), 21 bytes

```
: x
latest name-see ;
```

This prints the decompiled source of the latest word, thus only works if `x` is the latest defined word.

Test:

```
x 
: x  
latest name-see ; ok
```

This one works without that condition, but replaces the constant definition with it's value (since that's the only thing that actually gets saved to memory)

```
: x
[ latest ] literal name-see ;
```

Test:

```
x 
: x  
  140121195205104 name-see ; ok
```

Comment: If it prints with a newline in the middle, but the original doesn't have it, it's not a quine.

Comment: Fixed. It's because there's no way to tell where spaces/newlines are as it's only compiled code

Comment: It's not a proper quine anyway, because it reads its own source.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 90 bytes

```
((lambda (x) (display (list (~a x) (~v x)))) '(lambda (x) (display (list (~a x) (~v x)))))
```

Comment: You can remove unnecessary spaces to golf bytes. I'm not sure what spaces you can remove (cause I use Clojure), but there's definitely spaces that you can remove.

Comment: Not in this case, because the input has to match the printed output

Comment: Oh... yeah, whoops. I'm just looking at the spaces and thinking that they can be golfed somehow. Well, TIL.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
V Y"`V Y`.RPy"
```

The code includes a trailing newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x@mEKmUACQS9IICKpW4/v8HAA)

#### Explanation

```
  Y"..."  Yank this string into the y variable
V         and evaluate it
```

which executes this:

```
`V Y`      A Pattern literal (for our purposes, a string-like object without "")
     .     to which we concatenate
      RPy  repr(y), which wraps y in ""
```

The result is autoprinted with a trailing newline.

#### Bonus submission, 18 bytes

The above is the shortest Pip quine that I've found, but unfortunately it doesn't do so well when you try to modify it for other quine challenges. I have found [this one](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x@pFKlQGVQcFFCpBKG4/v8HAA) to be more payload-friendly:

```
Y"Y yRsRPy"yRsRPy

Y"Y yRsRPy"        Yank that string into y
           yRsRPy  Take y and replace space with repr(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Hack 60 bytes

```
<?hh printf($p='<?hh printf($p=%c%s%c,39,$p,39);',39,$p,39);
```

Only language I could think to do it in that I didn't see on the list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 404 bytes

```
->++>+++>+>+>+++>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>++>+++>++>>+++>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+>+>>+++>>>>+++>>>+++>+>>>>>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>+++>+>+++>+>+++>+>++>+++>>>+>+>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>>>>>+>+>>>+>+>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>+++>+>+++>+>++>+++>++>>+>+>++>+++>+>+>>+++>>>+++>+>>>++>+++>+++>+>>+++>>>+++>+>+++>+>>+++>>+++>>+[[>>+[>]+>+[<]<-]>>[>]<+<+++[<]<<+]>>>[>]+++>+[+[<++++++++++++++++>-]<++++++++++.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#hU8JDsAgCHsQcS8gfITw/2e4aj03l6FALKWpOZkILtLYj8EheaCQ/xeV0yTZ1r0hN2jNxVb7Yj/T62KWopvHD9H5g6NY9/eWsU2IEIt7KRbAXUNTmOGlohgXQAVIgeqqA5NHWIoFuzRyvgE)

I found this quine [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itchyny/brainfuck/master/quine3.bf); I didn't write it myself. I'm currently trying to understand how it works exactly to add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 105 bytes

```
S" 2dup 34 83 emit emit space type 34 emit space type" 2dup 34 83 emit emit space type 34 emit space type
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@x@spGCUUlqgYGyiYGGskJqbWQIhigsSk1MVSioLUkFSaELk6Pn/HwA)

#### Explanation:

```
S" 2dup 34 83 emit emit space type 34 emit space type"      \ push a string
   2dup                                                     \ duplicate string
        34 83 emit emit space                               \ print 'S" '
                              type                          \ print string
                                   34 emit space            \ print '" '
                                                 type       \ print string duplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 60 bytes

```ml
";str(chr 34)^it;print(it^it);";str(chr 34)^it;print(it^it);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sml-mlton#@69kXVxSpJGcUaRgbKIZl1liXVCUmVeikVkCZGta45f9/x8A)

I previously thought this kind of quine would only work when interpreted, e.g. by the [Moscow ML interpreter](http://mosml.org/). However, MLton happily compiles it to a standalone executable, so I guess it's fine.

#### How it works

Usually one writes `val x = <some expression> ;` in a SML interpreter to bind the identifier `x` to result of the evaluation of `<some expression>`. If the `val x =` part is omitted, the result is bound to the implicit result identifier `it` instead.

The quine consists of three declarations:

```ml
";str(chr 34)^it;print(it^it);";
```

A single string, so `it = ";str(chr 34)^it;print(it^it);"`.

```ml
str(chr 34)^it;
```

`chr 34` yields the 34th ASCII-character, which is `"`. `str` converts the character into a string and the `^`-operator performs string concatenation, thus `it = "\";str(chr 34)^it;print(it^it);"`.

```ml
print(it^it);
```

`it^it` now yields an escaped string version of the source code which is printed to STDOUT with `print`.

Answer (score 1):

## x86/DOS assembly, 4619 bytes

```
bits 16
org 256
mov ah,64
mov bx,1
mov cx,720
mov dx,b+16
int 33
mov cx,90
mov si,b+16
c:push cx
mov ah,64
mov bx,1
mov cx,6
mov dx,b
int 33
mov cx,7
a:push cx
mov al,[si]
shr al,4
add al,48
cmp al,58
jb g
add al,39
g:mov [b+8],al
lodsb
and al,15
add al,48
cmp al,58
jb e
add al,39
e:mov [b+9],al
mov ah,64
mov bx,1
mov cx,5
mov dx,b+6
int 33
pop cx
loop a
mov al,[si]
shr al,4
add al,48
cmp al,58
jb h
add al,39
h:mov [b+8],al
lodsb
and al,15
add al,48
cmp al,58
jb n
add al,39
n:mov [b+9],al
mov ah,64
mov bx,1
mov cx,4
mov dx,b+6
int 33
pop cx
loop c
mov ah,64
mov bx,1
mov cx,5
mov dx,b+11
int 33
mov ah,76
int 33
b   db 13,10,' db 0x  ,',13,10,'end'
 db 0x62,0x69,0x74,0x73,0x20,0x31,0x36,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x6f,0x72,0x67,0x20,0x32,0x35,0x36
 db 0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61,0x68
 db 0x2c,0x36,0x34,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76
 db 0x20,0x62,0x78,0x2c,0x31,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d
 db 0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x63,0x78,0x2c,0x37,0x32
 db 0x30,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x64
 db 0x78,0x2c,0x62,0x2b,0x31,0x36,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x69,0x6e,0x74,0x20,0x33,0x33,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x63,0x78,0x2c,0x39
 db 0x30,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x73
 db 0x69,0x2c,0x62,0x2b,0x31,0x36,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x63,0x3a,0x70,0x75,0x73,0x68,0x20,0x63
 db 0x78,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61
 db 0x68,0x2c,0x36,0x34,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f
 db 0x76,0x20,0x62,0x78,0x2c,0x31,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x63,0x78,0x2c,0x36
 db 0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x64,0x78
 db 0x2c,0x62,0x0d,0x0a,0x69,0x6e,0x74,0x20
 db 0x33,0x33,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20
 db 0x63,0x78,0x2c,0x37,0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x3a
 db 0x70,0x75,0x73,0x68,0x20,0x63,0x78,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c
 db 0x5b,0x73,0x69,0x5d,0x0d,0x0a,0x73,0x68
 db 0x72,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x34,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x61,0x64,0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x34
 db 0x38,0x0d,0x0a,0x63,0x6d,0x70,0x20,0x61
 db 0x6c,0x2c,0x35,0x38,0x0d,0x0a,0x6a,0x62
 db 0x20,0x67,0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x64,0x64,0x20
 db 0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x33,0x39,0x0d,0x0a,0x67
 db 0x3a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x5b,0x62,0x2b
 db 0x38,0x5d,0x2c,0x61,0x6c,0x0d,0x0a,0x6c
 db 0x6f,0x64,0x73,0x62,0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x6e
 db 0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x31,0x35,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x61,0x64,0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c
 db 0x34,0x38,0x0d,0x0a,0x63,0x6d,0x70,0x20
 db 0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x35,0x38,0x0d,0x0a,0x6a
 db 0x62,0x20,0x65,0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x64,0x64
 db 0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x33,0x39,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x65,0x3a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x5b,0x62
 db 0x2b,0x39,0x5d,0x2c,0x61,0x6c,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61,0x68,0x2c,0x36
 db 0x34,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x62
 db 0x78,0x2c,0x31,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76
 db 0x20,0x63,0x78,0x2c,0x35,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d
 db 0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x64,0x78,0x2c,0x62,0x2b
 db 0x36,0x0d,0x0a,0x69,0x6e,0x74,0x20,0x33
 db 0x33,0x0d,0x0a,0x70,0x6f,0x70,0x20,0x63
 db 0x78,0x0d,0x0a,0x6c,0x6f,0x6f,0x70,0x20
 db 0x61,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61
 db 0x6c,0x2c,0x5b,0x73,0x69,0x5d,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x73,0x68,0x72,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x34
 db 0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x64,0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c
 db 0x2c,0x34,0x38,0x0d,0x0a,0x63,0x6d,0x70
 db 0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x35,0x38,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x6a,0x62,0x20,0x68,0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x64
 db 0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x33,0x39,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x68,0x3a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x5b
 db 0x62,0x2b,0x38,0x5d,0x2c,0x61,0x6c,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x6c,0x6f,0x64,0x73,0x62,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x61,0x6e,0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x31
 db 0x35,0x0d,0x0a,0x61,0x64,0x64,0x20,0x61
 db 0x6c,0x2c,0x34,0x38,0x0d,0x0a,0x63,0x6d
 db 0x70,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x35,0x38,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x6a,0x62,0x20,0x6e,0x0d,0x0a,0x61
 db 0x64,0x64,0x20,0x61,0x6c,0x2c,0x33,0x39
 db 0x0d,0x0a,0x6e,0x3a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20
 db 0x5b,0x62,0x2b,0x39,0x5d,0x2c,0x61,0x6c
 db 0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61,0x68
 db 0x2c,0x36,0x34,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76
 db 0x20,0x62,0x78,0x2c,0x31,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d
 db 0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x63,0x78,0x2c,0x34,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x64,0x78,0x2c
 db 0x62,0x2b,0x36,0x0d,0x0a,0x69,0x6e,0x74
 db 0x20,0x33,0x33,0x0d,0x0a,0x70,0x6f,0x70
 db 0x20,0x63,0x78,0x0d,0x0a,0x6c,0x6f,0x6f
 db 0x70,0x20,0x63,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76
 db 0x20,0x61,0x68,0x2c,0x36,0x34,0x0d,0x0a
 db 0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x62,0x78,0x2c,0x31
 db 0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x63,0x78
 db 0x2c,0x35,0x0d,0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20
 db 0x64,0x78,0x2c,0x62,0x2b,0x31,0x31,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x69,0x6e,0x74,0x20,0x33,0x33,0x0d
 db 0x0a,0x6d,0x6f,0x76,0x20,0x61,0x68,0x2c
 db 0x37,0x36,0x0d,0x0a,0x69,0x6e,0x74,0x20
 db 0x33,0x33,0x0d,0x0a,0x62,0x20,0x20,0x20
 db 0x64,0x62,0x20,0x31,0x33,0x2c,0x31,0x30
 db 0x2c,0x27,0x20,0x64,0x62,0x20,0x30,0x78
 db 0x20,0x20,0x2c,0x27,0x2c,0x31,0x33,0x2c
 db 0x31,0x30,0x2c,0x27,0x65,0x6e,0x64,0x27
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## 80x86 TASM, 561 bytes

```
MODEL TINY
.CODE
.STARTUP
DB 177
DB 076
DB 186
DB 044
DB 001
DB 172
DB 180
DB 036
DB 179
DB 004
DB 191
DB 080
DB 001
DB 079
DB 136
DB 037
DB 212
DB 010
DB 004
DB 048
DB 134
DB 196
DB 075
DB 117
DB 244
DB 180
DB 009
DB 205
DB 033
DB 178
DB 071
DB 226
DB 228
DB 178
DB 038
DB 205
DB 033
DB 195
DB 013
DB 010
DB 069
DB 078
DB 068
DB 036
DB 077
DB 079
DB 068
DB 069
DB 076
DB 032
DB 084
DB 073
DB 078
DB 089
DB 013
DB 010
DB 046
DB 067
DB 079
DB 068
DB 069
DB 013
DB 010
DB 046
DB 083
DB 084
DB 065
DB 082
DB 084
DB 085
DB 080
DB 013
DB 010
DB 068
DB 066
DB 032
END
```

Comment: @Downvoter I can kind of understand the downvotes on all the quines I posted from RosettaCode, but this one, really?

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), <s>38</s> 28 bytes

```
AR_="AR_=%c%s%1$c,34,_",34,_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fMSjeVglEqCarFqsaqiTrGJvoxCuByf//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [ABAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP), 515 bytes

`````
REPORT R NO STANDARD PAGE HEADING.DATA:A TYPE TABLE OF STRING,B(8).APPEND:
`REPORT.FORM F TABLES T.NEW-PAGE LINE-SIZE 78.WRITE:'REPORT R NO',` TO A,
`'STANDARD PAGE HEADING.DATA:A TYPE TABLE OF STRING,B(8).APPEND:'.LOOP` TO A,
`AT T.REPLACE ALL OCCURENCES OF'``' IN T WITH'````'.WRITE:/'``'` TO A,
`NO-GAP,T NO-GAP,'`` TO A,'.ENDLOOP.WRITE:AT 78'.','GENERATE',` TO A,
`'SUBROUTINE POOL A NAME B.PERFORM F IN PROGRAM (B) TABLES A.'.ENDFORM.` TO A.
GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL A NAME B.PERFORM F IN PROGRAM (B) TABLES A.
`````

Should work on on any SAP system with `SY-SAPRL >= '700'`.

<sup>[source](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine)</sup>

Comment: is this an error quine?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon No, why do you ask?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the serial downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

## [Bob](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/bob-a-tiny-object-oriented-language/184409401), 1221 bytes

```
c=","; n="\n"; q="\""; s="\\";
v=\[
"c=\",\"; n=\"\\n\"; q=\"\\\"\"; s=\"\\\\\";",
"v=\\[",
"define prtQuote(str) {",
" local j,t,v;",
" stdout.Display(q);",
" for (j=0; j<str.size; j++) {",
"  t = str.Substring(j,1);",
"  if (t==q) { stdout.Display(s); }",
"  if (t==s) { stdout.Display(s); }",
"  stdout.Display(t);",
" }",
" stdout.Display(q);",
"}",
"for(i=0; i<2; i++){ stdout.Display(v[i]); stdout.Display(n); }",
"for(i=0; i<v.size-1; i++){ prtQuote(v[i]); stdout.Display(c); stdout.Display(n); }",
"prtQuote(v[v.size-1]); stdout.Display(n);",
"stdout.Display(v[v.size-1]); stdout.Display(n);",
"for(i=2; i<v.size-1; i++){ stdout.Display(v[i]); stdout.Display(n); }",
"];"
];
define prtQuote(str) {
 local j,t,v;
 stdout.Display(q);
 for (j=0; j<str.size; j++) {
  t = str.Substring(j,1);
  if (t==q) { stdout.Display(s); }
  if (t==s) { stdout.Display(s); }
  stdout.Display(t);
 }
 stdout.Display(q);
}
for(i=0; i<2; i++){ stdout.Display(v[i]); stdout.Display(n); }
for(i=0; i<v.size-1; i++){ prtQuote(v[i]); stdout.Display(c); stdout.Display(n); }
prtQuote(v[v.size-1]); stdout.Display(n);
stdout.Display(v[v.size-1]); stdout.Display(n);
for(i=2; i<v.size-1; i++){ stdout.Display(v[i]); stdout.Display(n); }
```

<sup>[source](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## COBOL, 18808 bytes

This was posted to the [mvsHelp forum](http://mvshelp.net/vbforums/) in 2004. Spaces necessary.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. GRICE.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       CONFIGURATION SECTION.
       SPECIAL-NAMES.
           SYMBOLIC CHARACTERS FULL-STOP IS 76.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT OUTPUT-FILE ASSIGN TO OUTPUT1.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  OUTPUT-FILE
           RECORDING MODE F
           LABEL RECORDS OMITTED.
       01  OUTPUT-RECORD                     PIC X(80).
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  SUB-X                             PIC S9(4) COMP.
       01  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-AREA.
           02  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-DATA.
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       PROGRAM-ID. GRICE.               ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       CONFIGURATION SECTION.           ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       SPECIAL-NAMES.                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           SYMBOLIC CHARACTERS FULL-STOP".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               " IS 76.                                 ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       FILE-CONTROL.                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           SELECT OUTPUT-FILE ASSIGN TO ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "OUTPUT1.                                ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       DATA DIVISION.                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       FILE SECTION.                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       FD  OUTPUT-FILE                  ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           RECORDING MODE F             ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           LABEL RECORDS OMITTED.       ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       01  OUTPUT-RECORD                ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X(80).                         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       01  SUB-X                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC S9(4) COMP.                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       01  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-AREA.       ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-DATA.   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               03  FILLER               ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X(40) VALUE                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-TABLE RE".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "DEFINES                                 ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                   SOURCE-FACSIMILE-DATA".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               ".                                       ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               03  SOURCE-FACSIMILE OCCU".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "RS 68.                                  ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                   04  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "ONE  PIC X(40).                         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                   04  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "TWO  PIC X(40).                         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       01  FILLER-IMAGE.                ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  FILLER                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  FILLER                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X     VALUE QUOTE.             ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  FILLER-DATA              ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X(40).                         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  FILLER                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X     VALUE QUOTE.             ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  FILLER                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X     VALUE FULL-STOP.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           02  FILLER                   ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "     PIC X(22) VALUE SPACES.            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       PROCEDURE DIVISION.              ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       MAIN-LINE SECTION.               ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       ML-1.                            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.     ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE 1 TO SUB-X.             ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       ML-2.                            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (SUB-X)".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               " TO OUTPUT-RECORD.                      ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           IF  SUB-X < 19               ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               ADD 1 TO SUB-X           ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               GO TO ML-2.              ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE 1 TO SUB-X.             ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       ML-3.                            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (20) TO".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               " OUTPUT-RECORD.                         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE-ONE (SU".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "B-X) TO FILLER-DATA.                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE FILLER-IMAGE TO OUTPUT-R".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "ECORD.                                  ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (20) TO".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               " OUTPUT-RECORD.                         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE-TWO (SU".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "B-X) TO FILLER-DATA.                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE FILLER-IMAGE TO OUTPUT-R".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "ECORD.                                  ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           IF  SUB-X < 68               ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               ADD 1 TO SUB-X           ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               GO TO ML-3.              ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE 21 TO SUB-X.            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       ML-4.                            ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (SUB-X)".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               " TO OUTPUT-RECORD.                      ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.         ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           IF  SUB-X < 68               ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               ADD 1 TO SUB-X           ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "               GO TO ML-4.              ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "       ML-99.                           ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           CLOSE OUTPUT-FILE.           ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "           STOP RUN.                    ".
               03  FILLER                    PIC X(40) VALUE
               "                                        ".
           02  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-TABLE REDEFINES
                   SOURCE-FACSIMILE-DATA.
               03  SOURCE-FACSIMILE OCCURS 68.
                   04  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-ONE  PIC X(40).
                   04  SOURCE-FACSIMILE-TWO  PIC X(40).
       01  FILLER-IMAGE.
           02  FILLER                        PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
           02  FILLER                        PIC X     VALUE QUOTE.
           02  FILLER-DATA                   PIC X(40).
           02  FILLER                        PIC X     VALUE QUOTE.
           02  FILLER                        PIC X     VALUE FULL-STOP.
           02  FILLER                        PIC X(22) VALUE SPACES.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-LINE SECTION.
       ML-1.
           OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.
           MOVE 1 TO SUB-X.
       ML-2.
           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (SUB-X) TO OUTPUT-RECORD.
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.
           IF  SUB-X < 19
               ADD 1 TO SUB-X
               GO TO ML-2.
           MOVE 1 TO SUB-X.
       ML-3.
           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (20) TO OUTPUT-RECORD.
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.
           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE-ONE (SUB-X) TO FILLER-DATA.
           MOVE FILLER-IMAGE TO OUTPUT-RECORD.
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.
           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (20) TO OUTPUT-RECORD.
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.
           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE-TWO (SUB-X) TO FILLER-DATA.
           MOVE FILLER-IMAGE TO OUTPUT-RECORD.
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.
           IF  SUB-X < 68
               ADD 1 TO SUB-X
               GO TO ML-3.
           MOVE 21 TO SUB-X.
       ML-4.
           MOVE SOURCE-FACSIMILE (SUB-X) TO OUTPUT-RECORD.
           WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD.
           IF  SUB-X < 68
               ADD 1 TO SUB-X
               GO TO ML-4.
       ML-99.
           CLOSE OUTPUT-FILE.
           STOP RUN.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

<sup>-2 thanks to Ørjan Johansen</sup>

```
a=\' b='a=\\$a b=$a$b$a\;eval echo \$b';eval echo $b
```

Comment: The spaces after the semicolons seem unnecessary.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh, I completely forgot to golf that part! Thanks :D

Comment: You forgot to include the new length.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Is there any limit to how helpful you can be :P

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 42 Bytes

```
'r3d*>l?\ao"/o \     "ooooooooo;
     \ o/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X73IOEXLLsc@JjFfST9fIUYBBJTyYcCaCywQo5Cv//8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 3 bytes

```
«Ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/5/r0OrDM/7/BwA)

This code does nothing with the first line, then, pushes the function `«Ø`. As `«` is unmatched, it falls through and executes the contents. `Ø` then pushes an empty string. The implicit printing behaviour first prints the empty string, then the function, giving our source code.

## 4 bytes

```
«•.
```

(With a leading space)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///Q6kcNi/QU/v8HAA)

This uses the fall through behavoir of the last quine, but ensures "quine" behavoir a different way. `•` pushes a space, `.` concatenates it, which gives our code.

## 6 bytes

```
{`{.}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/786oVqvtvr/fwA)

This uses a different fallthrough behavoir. `` {`{.} `` pushes a funciton, then `{`, with an unmatched `}`, fails and moves the IP back to index `1`, which skips the function definition, and runs its contents instead. (backtick)`{` pushes `{` as a string, then `.` appends it to the function, stringifying it. `}` then terminates the program, and the string is implicitely output.

Answer (score 1):

## [OML](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/OML), 20 bytes

```
"lK(34Tos)"lK(34Tos)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/N@f9fKcdbw9gkJL9YE8H6/x8A)

This was an interesting process. I initially started off with the classic data-decoder method of quining. That is, one devotes one section of the program to encoding the decoder, and another section to generate the data representation and decode the data. This came out to look like this (**51 bytes**):

```
'\'l'K'l'2'/'['('''''o'o')']'('o')\lKl2/[(''oo)](o)
```

Where the data section looks like:

```
'\'l'K'l'2'/'['('''''o'o')']'('o')
```

which pushes each character after a `'`. The decoder looks like this:

```
\lKl2/[(''oo)](o)
\                  reverse stack
 lK                duplicate stack
   l2/[            copy the duplication into a new stack
       (    )      while there are characters on this stack:
        ''o          output a single quote
           o         and the character
             ]     return to the original stack
              (o)  output all characters on this stack
```

This can be improved slightly by replacing `(o)` with `ls` (**48 bytes**):

```
'\'l'K'l'2'/'['('''''o'o')']'l's\lKl2/[(''oo)]ls
```

However, OML also has a length-encoded string construct. Let's say the string is `"xyz"`. This is effectively `'x'y'z3`, since there are three characters in the string. We can use `s` to print this string, but we still need to generate the quote characters. With all this in mind, I was able to devise the following approach (**26 bytes**):

```
"lK34Tos34Tos"lK34Tos34Tos
```

Simply put, this puts the "string" `"lK34Tos34Tos"` to the stack, then performs the following actions:

```
lK34Tos34Tos
lk            duplicate the stack (in this case, the string)
  34To        output a quotation mark "
      s       output the string
       34To   output another quotation mark "
           s  output the string again
```

We obtain our final version by noting that the structure `34Tos` is repeated twice. We can use a while loop to produce the current answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 21 bytes

```
f=@write`f=[f]f()`f()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z/N1qG8KLMkNSHNNjotNk1DMwGI//8HAA)

or, if Functions are allowed...

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 9 bytes

```
f=@'f='+f
```

The second of these defines a function `f` which returns the string `f=@'f='+f`, the first however is a full program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z/N1kE9zVZdO@1/QVFmXolGmoam5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Locksmith](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Locksmith), 201 bytes

```
070405000400080701090704000102010702070000080006030109000107020001020106070707040507040001020107020700000800060301090001070200010201067450408719740121727008063190172012167774574012172700806319017201216
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nYw7DsIwEESv9NZxPPF50gRBREHu74wtU9JQ7Gjn@3rvz8/5uI7WEJkVjLCZBXVo@Es@GQXDhcIyEkznmypmmlt/tJVXlzZFVSZSKKk3yhIVky4Vyanfdms3)

Formatted:

```
0704050004000807010907040001020107020700000800060301090001070200010
2010607070704050704000102010702070000080006030109000107020001020106
7450408719740121727008063190172012167774574012172700806319017201216
```

This consists of two parts: the data section and the decoder. The data section is simply each byte of the encoder prefixed with a `0` (which is the command to push that number). The decoder is:

```
74              // push stack length
5               // that many times:
   0408719      // output a 0
   74012172     // bring bottom of stack to the top
   700806319    // output this without popping
   0172         // swap top two (brings length to top)
   0121         // decrement
6               // close loop    

7774            // pop counter, push length again
5
   74012172     // bring bottom to top
   700806319    // output
   0172         // bring length to top
   0121         // decrement
6               // close loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 120 bytes

```swift
import Foundation;let q="import Foundation;let q=%c%@%c;print(String(format:q,34,q,34))";print(String(format:q,34,q,34))
```

[<s>Try</s> See it online!](https://asciinema.org/a/b779uumH8eHu7M3JR6Eq5tT9N)

Since this code `import`s `Foundation`, and the Swift corelibs can be a little quirky in non-macOS environments, you might not be able to run it (it doesn't work in TIO, or IBM's Swift Sandbox). If, however, you have a macOS environment, then you should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), <s>136</s> <s>111</s> 96 bytes

I'm surprised to see that there's no Foo quine here yet!

```
>&41>&60>&99>&36>&40>&60>&41>&62>&105>&36>&34>&38>&62>&34>&40>&62>&41>&60>&40(<)>(">&"$i>)<($c<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP///fTs3E0E7NzMBOzdLSTs3YDMg3gPDB4kZ2aoYGphAJYxMgtoAIgthghUYIA0wMNGw07TSU7NSUVDLtNG00VJJtNP//BwA)

### Explanation

This is pretty simple as far as quines go. There are two sections: the data and the decoder. The data is encoded on the array, and is decoded as such:

```
(<)>(">&"$i>)<($c<)
```

Which basically iterates once over the tape, outputting `>&` and the integer value of the cell, then iterating once again over the tape, outputting each character. The tape, then, is just the character codes of this decoder.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript REPL, 21 bytes

```
(_=$=>`(_=${_})()`)()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 103 bytes

An anonymous Yabasic quine

```vb
c$=Chr$(34):q$="c$=Chr$(34):q$=:?Left$(q$,15)+c$+q$+c$+Mid$(q$,16)":?Left$(q$,15)+c$+q$+c$+Mid$(q$,16)
```

Includes a trailing newline

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/P1nF1jmjSEXD2ETTqlDFVgmNb2Xvk5pWoqJRqKJjaKqpnayiXagCIn0zUyCCZppKRKjh@v8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 8 bytes

```
"34 8ko@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/1/J2ETBIjvf4f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 76 bytes

```
40Kjiiiiiiiiiiij,306j,6641,iK31,i,6j,,!!_+!^!&(@^!&)++!_+%(!_^^^^^^^^^^^_@%)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/fxMA7KxMBsnSMDcyydMzMTAx1Mr2NgYQOkKujqBivrRinqKbhACQ0tbWBXFUNxfg4BIh3UNX8/x8A)

The code can be decomposed into two sections: the data and the decoder. The data is this:

```
40Kjiiiiiiiiiiij,306j,6641,iK31,i,6j,,
```

Each character pushes itself, and corresponds to a command (shifted up by 11).

The decoder is this:

```
!!_+!^!&(@^!&)++!_+%(!_^^^^^^^^^^^_@%)
```

This can also be divided into two parts, one which prints the data raw, and one which decodes the data. This part prints the initial data segment:

```
!!_+!^!&(@^!&)++!_+%
!!_+                     push 0 (duplicate twice then subtract)
                         this is our delineator
    !^                   push 1 (duplicate and increment)
                         this is our pointer
      !&                 push the entry at that index in the stack
        (    )           until the dilineator is found:
         @               output the stack entry
          ^              increment pointer
           !&            refresh entry at index
              ++!_+      pop top two (add twice, duplicate, subtract)
                   %     push 0 underneath stack
```

Then the decoder:

```
(!_^^^^^^^^^^^_@%)
(               %)    For each character:
 !_           _           subtract
   ^^^^^^^^^^^            11
               @          and output it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Muriel](https://github.com/catseye/Muriel), 36 bytes

```
A:"\";.\"A:\\\"\"+|A+A";."A:\""+|A+A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy0tykzN@f/f0UopRslaL0bJ0SomJgbI1q5x1HYEioAElCC8//8B)

<s>Since Muriel isn't on TIO (yet!), I've included the interpreter in the link.</s> Thanks Dennis!

Quines are the base component of any complex Muriel program, since they're a requirement for any sort of loop.

#### Explanation:

```
A:        Assign to A
  "       ...         "; An escaped version of ";."A:\""+|A+A
                        .          Print
                         "A:\""          A:"
                               +|A       Escaped version of A
                                  +A     Then A itself
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aubergine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aubergine), 16 bytes

```
-a1+a1=oA:bA=iB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxNSi1Kz8xL/f9fN9FQO9HQNt/RKsnRNtOJ4f9/AA)

The program has a trailing null byte. Works similarly to [my hello world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164289/39244).

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 57 bytes

```cs
var s="var s={0}{1}{0};Write(s,'{0}',s);";Write(s,'"',s);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LLFIodhWCUJVG9RWG9YCSevwosySVI1iHXUgR12nWNNaCSGkBBb4/x8A)

There is [another C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68891/8340) that uses a console application with a `Main` method. This approach seemed a little outdated given most current C# answers use the Visual C# Interactive Compiler. This compiler allows for a much shorter variation using the exact same technique.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (REPL), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

[someone else posted this first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/189075#189075)

```
(_=x=>`(_=${_})()`)()
```

paste into chrome console or equivalent to test

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

@NieDzejkob saved 1 byte on both versions

```javascript
console.log((_=x=>`console.log((_=${_})())`)())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQyPetsLWLgFNSKU6vlZTQ1MzAUT8/w8A)

Comment: Save a byte like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQyPetsLWTh1NSF07XltdU0NTE0z8/w8A "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: Would ```print((_=x=>`print((_=${_})())`)())``` count too? [JavaScript (V8) 35 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EQyPetsLWLgHOUamOr9XU0NRMABH//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

### C, 353 bytes

```
char q[]={125,59,109,97,105,110,40,41,123,112,114,105,110,116,102,40,34,99,104,97,114,32,113,91,93,61,123,34,41,59,99,104,97,114,42,112,61,113,59,119,104,105,108,101,40,42,112,41,112,114,105,110,116,102,40,34,37,100,44,34,44,42,112,43,43,41,59,112,117,116,115,40,113,41,59,125,};main(){printf("char q[]={");char*p=q;while(*p)printf("%d,",*p++);puts(q);}
```

Comment: With some golfing, including changing it from hexadecimal to decimal, this can be [354 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDLCsIwEEX3foUUhKaO0ElSNYR@ibgo9dGCSlorLkq/vc4kWnEjZMhjzp17Sbk6l@U4llXRzpvdPu9RZpAZwNSA2dCWAWIKmhYCSkU3SaWnDuKazpIJpcGwUnslMYpRBQbBKFgHPUE0iRx@US39ZIZIwQEw9L1PuqVCnyJwHOZvEMXZCdfecJqvlV8YHPhtE4SYsZC93036hsFei/oWi9619a07xdH3lyJh@ZK4vLHPqr4c48SJD7Y4QASJWy6FdY/uHjfCDrNxfAE)

Comment: Wait Jo, I tried your solution in the gcc compiler and it unfortunately gave an error for the second quine program compiled from the first.

Comment: The link itself is a gcc compiler and it works fine. Are you sure they aren't just warnings?

Comment: Its not just warnings, Jo. There is unfortunately error called "initializer element is not constant" due to what gcc perceives as a formatting error. Yes, in my compiler, they were just warnings at the first compilation stage. But you see, I actually tested each of the offspring quine programs in succession, and I unfortunately ran into the following errors according to gcc for the second offspring quine program:ken_quine2.c:1:274: 
ken_quine2.c:1:274: error: initializer element is not constant

Comment: If only the output is erroring, then what is the difference between the two programs? What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc 7.4.0 in CYGWIN. The difference is that the second generation quine program fails to compile and print.

Comment: ... What is the difference between the *code* of the two programs, not their behaviour. I already know that the second one fails. The version TIO uses is 8.3, and that works fine.

Comment: Then this clears why we were disagreeing with each other. I simply was using an older compiler. So I guess I should use the most up to date compiler for code golf then.

Comment: For curiosity's sake, what was the older compiler outputting?

Comment: The warnings and errors were so huge that there is not enough space to paste what the compiler said here. It said the following error messages:ken_quine2.c:1:274: error: initializer element is not constant
ken_quine2.c:1:274: note: (near initialization for ‘q[75]’)
ken_quine2.c:1:280: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘{’ token

Comment: *I don't care about the output of the second generation quine. I would like to know the output of the **first** program, the one that **didn't** fail and produced something that **did**. I don't want to know about the errors that you have commented about several times already. I would like to know the difference between the program I have given you and its output. You can put the program in an online compiler like I have and link it in a comment below.*

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##fZDLCsIwEEX3foUUhKaO0ElSNYR@ibgo9dGCSlorLkq/vc4kWnEjZMhjzp17Sbk6l@U4llXRzpvdPu9RZpAZwNSA2dCWAWIKmhYCSkU3SaWnDuKazpIJpcGwUnslMYpRBQbBKFgHPUE0iRx@US39ZIZIwQEw9L1PuqVCnyJwHOZvEMXZCdfecJqvlV8YHPhtE4SYsZC93036hsFei/oWi9619a07xdH3lyJh@ZK4vLHPqr4c48SJD7Y4QASJWy6FdY/uHjfCDrNxfAE)

Comment: That appears to be no different to the first program. Why would it not error the first time, but error the second time?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference when using the TIO compiler. Jo, the real reason why this argument started was because we were using different compilers in the first place. That started the confusion. I think we should end the discussion here.

Comment: I just want to know why the second program would error, but the original doesn't, as you said `it unfortunately gave an error for the second quine program compiled from the first`. I would understand the original program throwing an error, but I see no reason for it to work, but cause the second generation one to fail.

Comment: Good question, I honestly do not really get why gcc 7.4.0 was acting like this either. Everything honestly looked syntatically correct and indistinguishable even in the error messages.

Comment: Can you please edit in the corrections to the program/score? Otherwise it may get deleted as not a valid answer. You can also use my improved version or try improving it yourself, since I'm not that familiar with C.

Comment: Sure. I'll add in the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>8</s> <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
`④`④
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/4dHExSD8/z8A)

### Answer History

#### 8 bytes

```
`:.,`:.,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wUpPB4T//wcA)

Why did it take me so long to figure out how to write a quine in Keg? I really should have picked up on this sooner.

Basically, it pushes the string `:.,`, duplicates it, prints the string `repr`'d and then prints it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

### [tq](https://github.com/A-ee/tq), 8 bytes

New high-level language! (Technically inspired by Jo King's [Symbolic Raku quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/197574#197574).)

```
etq'etq'
```

### Explanation

````
   'etq' # Define the second item of the list
         # As a string
  q      # Surround the string with quotes
 t       # For the first item of the list,
         # Access the last (tail) item in the list,
e        # and un-quote the accessed value.

# The list becomes etq, 'etq' (comma is for readability)
# , which then becomes foreach-printed without any separator.
```
````

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 13 bytes

Print the data string & prepend quote.

```
p34CS+"p34CS+
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](https://common-lisp.net/), 58 bytes

Lisp is perfect for quines because of using code as data, but terseness is not its strong suit.

```lisp
(FORMAT T "(~{~S ~}~:*'~S)" '(FORMAT T "(~{~S ~}~:*'~S)"))
```

Excellent expert explanation.

```
(FORMAT T  -- print
"(      )" -- between parentheses
" ~{  }~ " -- looping over the list argument
" ~S_    " -- each item followed by a space
"   ~:*  " -- use the FORMAT sublanguage's *very* fancy
             -- "~*" directive (skip argument) with the ":"
             -- modifier to back up and reuse the argument
"    '~S " -- print the argument again with a quote before it
    '(FO.. -- the argument is the same thing but with a quote
             -- in front to show that it is data
```

[Ideone it!](https://ideone.com/TWWq32)

### Alternative 9 bytes, that only works in the REPL

```
(prin1 -)
```

(use `print` for a trailing newline)

This prints the value of '-', which [is the current expression being evaluated](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__.htm). You can try it [here](https://jscl-project.github.io).

Answer (score 1):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 24 bytes

```
"34cke12ketp"34cke12ketp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/1/J2CQ5O9XQKDu1pACZ/f8/AA)

#### Explanation:

```
"34cke12ketp"               Push the string 34c0ke13ketp to the source string
             34c            Put 34 in the accumulator
                k           Push a " to the destination string
                 e          Append the source string to the destination string
                  12k       Push a " to the end of the destination string
                     e      Append the source string to the destination string
                      t     Swap the source and the destination string
                       p    And print the source string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 3101 bytes

```
3.611102101111601492000010000000160111200001000000016010020000100000001601002000010000000160139200001000000016019520000100000001601842000010000000160199200001000000016019920000100000001601092000010000000160190200001000000016010920000100000001601912000010000000160111200001000000016019920000100000001601992000010000000160121200001000000016011020000100000001601092000010000000160193200001000000016010020000100000001601892000010000000160101200001000000016011020000100000001601102000010000000160130200001000000016013020000100000001601002000010000000160100200001000000016019920000100000001601002000010000000160100200001000000016010920000100000001601202000010000000160100200001000000016010220000100000001601312000010000000160199200001000000016019920000100000001601282000010000000160199200001000000016019920000100000001601902000010000000160111200001000000016019920000100000001601992000010000000160127200001000000016019920000100000001601992000010000000160191200001000000016011120000100000001601892000010000000160179200001000000016012120000100000001601192000010000000160198200001000000016019320000100000001601992000010000000160110200001000000016019920000100000001601102000010000000160119200001000000016019920000100000001601922000010000000160101200001000000016011020000100000001601992000010000000160131200001000000016010820000100000001601042000010000000160100200001000000016011020000100000001601092000010000000160190200001000000016013020000100000001601302000010000000160160200001000000016019920000100000001601602000010000000160110200001000000016013020000100000001601302000010000000160151200001000000016010320000100000001601032000010000000160105200001000000016011020000100000001601302000010000000160130200001000000016010220000100000001601822000010000000160103200001000000016010120000100000001601182000010000000160129200001000000016012220000100000001601312000010000000160152200001000000016018220000100000001601252000010000000160110200001000000016012520000100000001601222000010000000160151200001000000016015120000100000001601022000010000000160120200001000000016011320000100000001601152000010000000160112200001000000016011120000100000001601012000010000000160131200001000000016012920000100000001601452000010000000160194200001000000016015920000100000001601452000010000000160194200001000000016015820000100000001601452000010000000160194200001000000016015020000100000001601552000010000000160184200001000000016015920000100000001601452000010000000160194200001000000016015920000100000001601452000010000000160145200001000000016015120000100000001601052000010000000160115200001000000016015420000100000001601542000010000000160156200001000000016011520000100000001601152000010000000160160200001000000016015020000100000001601562000010000000160194200001000000016019420000100000001601682000010000000160148200001000000016014620000100000001648486494965050651516545455150155454954954954855054954854954954954921310112151310220151522520152282513229281103028200303015030301503030106990603030990010040801399011029999101990199398991129798111999997299991109999982999913200002900000990000030301011098003990011299991119900990999948599300001194
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVbtbgQhCHyjBlBceP8Hu6K2aVPnx8Rc3buoc4h8DNz216t9DFUVU6lJh2hPkxoqe0xI9YBEGKidutIPKPoplQwkQEooKWV85IwwoIszojEhDOA2dSOAGgVxqUXp4HSBEHIH7bT@OmlxeRDw6545z60RFH0Bcx6OvuDGYOgLTFW5lFIuEnZZHUAXIJOcbktnuEp2gNsSHZRD441NwUFwGgX5GzvTme0wygjAiTO1BqqD6jlO2WVUJIAUMAKkA2XImFarZ7wUmGrUa4Ey8QKB7ueNeVaaXx@M24OgFKg3GP9fHwGECOBMar1T0KBo4kwbQlEdTHAANEBqAfRXfY8eo2fP4eIyvMI3vNdTq5njWub3J7xk9uIHTCtqz7qok22VWi2qE7ithhBWsBXTo6q8etk0qdVT2n9PMjJlrHUtpn1dYr445@oOWUNnc5/fllG7qp4nS6nO3/LZIvXvMkfs3S5oy@Vq7mnfNgWjNusu/To71U@xuSsX66IVogr26/UJ)

#### Explanation

```
3.           Required boilerplate
6 11 10      Set cell 11 to 10
2 10 11 11   Set cell 10 to cell 11*cell 11 (10*10=100)

-- Data Section --
Every pair of digits in the program are represented by
6 01 49      Set cell 01 to the two digits joined together
2 00 00 10   Multiply cell 00 by 100
0 00 00 01   Add cell 01 to 00

This essentially makes cell 00 the rest of the program after the data section

6 48 48      Set each of the cells 48,49,50,51,54 to their respective values
6 49 49
6 50 50
6 51 51
6 54 54

551501554549549549548550549548549549549549  Print the initial section ('3.611102101111')

2 13 10 11   Initialise various powers of 10
2 15 13 10
2 20 15 15
2 25 20 15
2 28 25 13
2 29 28 11

0 30 28 20   Create the number '1000000010000200106', which is each data part backwards
0 30 30 15
0 30 30 15
0 30 30 10
6 99 06
0 30 30 99

0 01 00 40   Copy cell 00 to cell 01

8 01         Loop while cell 01 is not zero

  3 99 01 10    Integer divide cell 01 by 100 and store in cell 99
  2 99 99 10    Multiply cell 99 by 100
  1 99 01 99    Subtract cell 99 from cell 01 to get cell 01 modulo 100

  3 98 99 11
  2 97 98 11
  1 99 99 97
  2 99 99 11
  0 99 99 98    Swap the two digits of the modulo result
  2 99 99 13    Multiply it by 1000

  2 00 00 29    Multiply cell 00 by 10**19
  0 00 00 30    And append a copy of a data part
  0 00 00 99    And insert the modulo result in the correct place
  
  3 01 01 10    And divide cell 01 by 100
9            End loop

Now we print the number in cell 00 in reverse

8 00         Loop while cell 00 is non-zero
  3 99 00 11    Get the last digit of cell 00
  2 99 99 11
  1 99 00 99

  0 99 99 48    Add the digit to '0'
  5 99          And print

  3 00 00 11    Divide cell 00 by 10
9            End loop
```

Comment: I should write a SEDE query to see how many of the 362 quines you've written.

Comment: @Razetime A search for [`inquestion:69 user:76162`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=inquestion%3a69%20user%3a76162) currently puts it at 32

Comment: 8% of all the answers. I'm waiting for the day 50% comes.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 11 bytes

```javascript
a=_=>'a='+a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/0Tbe1k490VZdO/F/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGooam5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Agony](https://github.com/royvanrijn/JAgony), 243 bytes

```
<[.<]>[{(<(<){*}*{(>)}~)<(<){-.+(*}*<{)>(>)>}]${(@]@){,{.{[{*{]{)+*<}>[>*+)+]{@$${<{<<$+(@[{({.{({,>]@(>]+[>){,{({.+(@[+({,+(@(+({]+({)+({.<$@[<${-+({<@[+[>]{.>]{->]{.+(>){,+[{,{-{({]{[+({.>){->){.+]+[{.>]{-+({,+[{,+({.>){->){-+(@(>]@[>){]@(>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4xbkQxCEQv4wLM2idAyPdAFKnSbepo9Pfqf4eNlGI09gAPvr5/nr/37bm9IiEurpjXhIReL/181zZh5NBgGlcNyKmjeGAjMVFQm35FxjS1whkDDvdhcshkl@ARdSTKMnqOWdeMOV3oRSm1fZz0gcW3syOjsKnVbtLTliQsMgpN2MwWtY30v94PN5v9X129hzf0/r5E7/sN)

This looks like a bit of a mess, but this language is actually a brainfuck derivative, similar to [SMBF](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/). The self-modifying part is not used to read the executed code though (especially as each instruction is not mapped to one character). Agony splits up each brainfuck cell into 4 bits each (with two cells being a "character"), with special instructions to manipulate individual cells.

#### Explanation:

The code is split up into three sections; Code, the printable list of characters (offset by one to avoid the zero cell in `@`) and the data section (which is the printable version of the other two sections backwards).

##### Code

```
<[.<]      Print out the data section printing the code and the list of chars
>[         Loop over each 4 bits of the data section
  {(         While the current cell is not zero
    <(<){      Go to the start of the character list
    *}*{       Move it over one cell to make the next character the new start
    (>)}~      Go back to the current cell and decrement it
  )
  <(<){      Go to the start of the character list
  -.+        Print it offset by one (`@` is 0010 0000, so we store it as 0010 0001)
  (*}*<{)    Move over all the other characters by one to restore the list
  >(>)>}     Move to the next cell in the data section
]$         End the loop and halt
```

This section is modified or read (except the `$`, which separates it from the character list section).

##### Character list

The character list is the section between the `$` and the `$$`

```
{( @] @) {, {. {[ {* {] {) +* <} >[ >* +) +] {@
$  }  {  >  <  @  ~  +  -  .  ,  (  )  [  ]  *
```

Each pair of characters represents 8 bits each, which is the ordered list of the 15 instructions in Agony (offset by one).

##### Data section

Similar to the character section, each pair of characters in this part represent a single character in the code section. You can have it more efficient by just duplicating the code section entirely (thus being one to one), which is actually how the [reference quine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Agony#Quine_in_Agony) works. However, I think that even golfed, this would still take more code to handle duplicating the data section than it would save (but I'm not too sure about that, so feel free to prove me wrong).

Answer (score 1):

## [ALGOL 68 (Genie)](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/algol.html), 70 bytes

```
STRINGa="STRINGa="";print(a[..9]*2+a[9..]*2)";print(a[..9]*2+a[9..]*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJz88xs0j//z84JMjTzz3RVgnOULIuKMrMK9FIjNbTs4zVMtJOjLbU0wMyNHHL/P8PAA)

It's fascinating how modern feeling the syntax of this language (or at least the parts I've used), despite being over 50 years old. I wrote this without looking at any documentation, simply guessing at the features like string indexing (with ranges even!) and string multiplying.

#### Explanation:

```
STRINGa="STRINGa="";print(a[..9]*2+a[9..]*2)";  # Assign this string to `a` #
                                                # This escapes the " by doubling it #
print(a[..9]*2             # Print STRINGa=" twice #
     +a[9..]*2)            # Followed by ";print(a[..9]*2+a[9..]*2) twice #
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 2 bytes

Very simple quine, and (one of) the shortest possible quine(s) in tinylisp. All top-level statements implicitly output whatever they evaluate to, and integers evaluate to themselves. Any 1-digit integer from `0` to `9` works fine for this, and a 3-byte quine is also possible using `()`.

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/9@Q6/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 35 bytes

```
O S=s"O S=s5F++A34sA34"5F++A34sA34
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyJPIFM9c1wiTyBTPXM1RisrQTM0c0EzNFwiNUYrK0EzNHNBMzRcbiIsIiJd)

Expanded:

```
OUTPUT SET
    : = s "O S=s5F++A34sA34"
    : 5
    : F
    : ++ ASCII 34 s ASCII 34
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript <strike>6 Characters</strike> 13 Characters

### Working Version

```
f=_=>`f=${f}`
```

Previous Bad Version

```
f=_=>f
```

This quine is only 13 characters long

This code defines an anonymous function that outputs its own source code to the console when it is called. The source code of the anonymous function is defined as a string inside the function, and this string is used to output the source code of the anonymous function when it is called. This means that the code outputs its own source code, but it does not just read its own source code directly.

Comment: I think this would be considered invalid for a few reasons. First, its output isn't a string, and even if it was turned into a string, it would be `_=>f` without the `f=`). Second, it reads its own source code, if implicitly.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms I've updated it with one that actually meets the requirements for slightly more characters but still smaller than the versions I have found on here I think

Comment: `"f="+f` is shorter than a template string containing `f=${f}`, but then you've just got the classic JS cheating quine, `f=_=>"f="+f`

Comment: Y'all downvoting yet this one with 51 upvotes also reads its own source https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60148/53343

Comment: That was 7 years ago though, our standards have changed a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## SQL - Snowflake, 26 bytes

Using [CURRENT_STATMENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_statement.html) function:

> Returns the SQL text of the statement that is currently executing.

```
SELECT CURRENT_STATEMENT()
```

Output:

```
SELECT CURRENT_STATEMENT()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `KJ`, \$ 16 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.17 bytes

```
"D34CDZs"D34CDZs
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSt5dS7IKlpSVpuhYblFyMTZxdoophNEQYKrsASgMA)

Sort of like lyxal's Thunno answer, but uses flags and the stack instead of the `x` variable.

##### Explanation

```python
"D34CDZs"D34CDZs  #                                    STACK:
"D34CDZs"         # Push the string to the stack       D34CDZs
         D        # Duplicate this string              D34CDZs, D34CDZs
          34C     # Push chr(34), the double quote     ", D34CDZs, D34CDZs
             D    # Duplicate this string              ", ", D34CDZs, D34CDZs
              Zs  # Swap the second and third items    ", D34CDZs, ", D34CDZs
                  # The flags join the stack           "D34CDZs"D34CDZs
                  # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 117 bytes

```
_()9(?=.*\/)/\//_()8(?=.*\/)/\\/^\/(.*)/$1\/$1/\/_()9(?=.*_8_9)_9_8_9_9_()8(?=.*_8_9)_9_8_8_9^_8_9(.*)_9$1_8_9$1_9_8
```

As with many quines, works by unpacking and decoding the data. The data is `_()9(?=.*_8_9)_9_8_9_9_()8(?=.*_8_9)_9_8_8_9^_8_9(.*)_9$1_8_9$1_9_8` (Everything after the last regex), and the decoding is done via 3 regexes.

```
_()9(?=.*\/)/\//    # Replace instances of _9 with /
_()8(?=.*\/)/\\/    # Replace instances of _8 with \
^\/(.*)/$1\/$1/\/   # If the data starts with a /, copy everything behind it.
```

`_()`s are included in the first half of the number regex to ensure they aren't replaced when they represent the regexes themselves. `(?=.*\/)` asserts that it only replaces numbers behind a /.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYuxDsAgCET3foeDOHhxk6HpjxCZTHen/j2FoTWE4w54a655z8dMM3G@zloEBAE8950FQ5BrIaQm3v7xA9qVSTmG14ftrZsRErhyauFd/XSYvQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Shasta <sup>v0.0.9</sup>](https://github.com/jacobofbrooklyn/shasta/tree/c2e295776bc5497fcc0d787c46098bcc9c32edcd), 67 bytes

```
q='"'a="q='%s'a=%s(printf a[q,(wrap a q)])"(printf a[q,(wrap a q)])
```

There is no online interpreter for Shasta yet, but there are installation instructions at the GitHub link and I have verified that this works on my machine.

There is likely a much shorter quine possible, but I'm new to writing these.

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb machine code + Linux syscalls, 14 bytes (non-competing)

Hexdump of source:

```
0210 2ffa 1040 22e0 7240 fd00 7407
```

Disassembly:

```
00: 2001       movs r0, #1      // stdout
02: f2af 0104  subw r1, pc, #4  // address of start
06: 220e       movs r2, #14     // 14 bytes
08: 2704       movs r7, #4      // write()
0a: df00       svc  #0          // syscall
0c: 4770       bx   lr          // return
```

Is this against the rules?

Comment: I would say that this would count as reading your own source code, yes

Comment: ok should i delete this then?

Answer (score 1):

## [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/), 23 bytes

```lisp
(insert(buffer-string))
```

Execute it with [`C-x C-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html). The normal `C-j` key binding runs it in debug mode, so the `nil` return value of `insert` will also get printed afterwards. (Also, if an error appears, make sure the cursor is at the end of the buffer.)

---

### Explanation

Emacs uses buffers to edit, read or write text/code. By default, the current buffer is used for most operations. To get the contents of the current buffer, we can use `buffer-string`. We can then insert the contents back into the buffer using the handy-dandy function `insert`.

### Output

On the first execution, it sets the buffer to:

```lisp
(insert(buffer-string))(insert(buffer-string))
```

Since `C-x C-e` only executes the last S-expression, running the program again will copy its contents:

```lisp
(insert(buffer-string))(insert(buffer-string))(insert(buffer-string))(insert(buffer-string))
```

*Have a fantastic week!*

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 18 Bytes

```
history|tail -c18
```

### Bytes:

```
echo 'history|tail -c18' > quine
wc -c quine
18 quine
```

### Explanation:

`history` gets the bash history from memory and `tail` grabs the last 18 characters.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Unfortunately, since this solution reads its own source code, it's not a valid quine on this site (see the rules of this challenge)

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s Type System, 115 bytes

```typescript
type Y="'";type A='type O=`type Y="${Y}";type A=${Y}${A}${Y};${A}`';type O=`type Y="${Y}";type A=${Y}${A}${Y};${A}`
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAmgvAIgOQINyklAgnJHoDycABvrIgCQDeMAvmmTtXdVrc7aq7cUuuIRJl4CDgwHY4Hbhy5U2xALAAoFWQD6UOFAJQA9HqgALAPYA3CACco5q1GBHo6lUA)

This beats [tjjfvi's 149 byte quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214326/108687).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 4 bytes

```
"Ṅ"Ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJcIuG5hFwi4bmEIiwiIiwiIiwiMy40LjAiXQ==)

new name same old quine element

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 1 byte

Note: CJam was made after this challenge was posted, I am posting this answer as documentation as opposed to a serious entry.

```
0
```

Pushes a `0` to the stack, and CJam automatically outputs the stack after program execution.

Comment: Don't forget newlines.

Comment: One part of the program does not encode another, so this program is invalid

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Am I missing something about the definition of a quine? The challenge simply states "A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output." This seems to do that.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 the rule is it has to evaluate its code, not that it has to encode its code.

Answer (score 0):

## ForceLang with [this module](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang-JS), 87 bytes

Noncompeting, language postdates the challenge

```
set j require njs
j var f=function(){print("set j require njs\nj var f="+f+";f()")};f()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Idris, 88 bytes

```
q:String;main:IO();main=putStr$q++show q;q="q:String;main:IO();main=putStr$q++show q;q="
```

It’s like Haskell with more enforced top-level type signatures. I had to put `q`’s type first, because Idris’s type checker is a little weird? I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
"34.Cp\D\Es"DE
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2234.Cp%5CD%5CEs%22DE&warnings=0)

```
"34.Cp\D\Es"   - "34.Cp\D\Es"
            DE - eval(^, stack=^)

 34.C          -   '"'
     p         -  print(^)
      \D\Es    - sum("34.Cp\D\Es", ^, "D", "E")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 56 bytes

This is a template engine language I've made for fun.

It was written in PHP and run by compiling the weird syntax to PHP.

This answer is a translation of [Aurel Bílý](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73/aurel-b%C3%ADl%C3%BD)'s [**amazing** PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/534/14732)!

```
{@setF"{@setF%c%s%c}{@printF,34,F,34}"}{@printF,34,F,34}
```

Weird, right?

This works with the commit [d1d3e2c43bd98da2bd38f884ee5ac7b39cb8c579](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate/blob/d1d3e2c43bd98da2bd38f884ee5ac7b39cb8c579/SimpleTemplate.php) on my Github and you can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cca9ed3b9c87abad61159725f159285e5daf9bb9.

In there, you will have the existing code on that commit, plus showing the result and the generated PHP.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

```r
f=function(){cat('f=');print(f);cat('f()')}
f()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@59mm1aal1ySmZ@noVmdnFiioZ5mq65pXVCUmVeikaZpDRHS0FTXrOUCUv//AwA)

Can be extended to contain any set of operations by adding those before the first `cat` statement.

Printing a function `f` returns the content of that function starting with `function(){`. I then added `cat` statements to handle the rest of the output.

Comment: should probably be [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP09DU6GaizM5sURDPc1WXZOLs6AoM69EI00TJqihCRSt5QLS//8DAA "R – Try It Online"), as `print` will add indentation and weird brackets placement.

Comment: @Giuseppe hmm, on TIO there also appears to be trailing spaces. If counting those we'd end up at 64 bytes

Comment: [:| too long](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9hWqdhWtRgIDVWKrZMTSzSKC4oy80rSNIp11EFi6jrFmppK6DJKYOH//wE)

Comment: Alhough TIO adds spaces and newlines, my local install does not. The same thing occurs with [my 44 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209082/86301). I haven't found which option is different between the two installs. Also, I accidentally downvoted your answer instead of upvoting it, and my vote is now locked. Sorry about that. If you edit your answer, I'll change my vote.

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 11 bytes

```
$(value $0)
```

When called as a function, returns its source code.

And here's a complete makefile that doesn't *return* its code, but rather prints it:

```
Q=$(info Q=$(value Q))$(info $$(call Q))
$(call Q)
```

### Explanation

The second line just instantiates the variable, the first one defines it:

```
$(info Q=$(value Q))$(info $$(call Q))
         $(value Q)                     # Get unexpanded value
                           $$           # "$" escaped
$(info Q=          )$(info   (call Q))  # Print the remaining parts
```

Answer (score 0):

## Babel, 161 bytes

```
{ "{ '{ ' << dup [val 0x22 0xffffff00 ] dup <- << << -> << ' ' << << ' }' << } !" { '{ ' << dup [val 0x22 0xffffff00 ] dup <- << << -> << ' ' << << '}' << } ! }%
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ceylon, <s>173</s> 154 bytes

<sup>Saved those bytes thanks to Challenger5</sup>

```
shared void run(){print(let(x="""shared void run(){print(let(x=$)x.replaceFirst("$","\"\"\""+x+"\"\"\""));}""")x.replaceFirst("$","\"\"\""+x+"\"\"\""));}
```

<sup>[source](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine)</sup>

Comment: You can golf off some whitespace. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ceylon#@1@ckViUmqJQlp@ZolBUmqehWV1QlJlXopGTWqJRYaukpIRfgYpmhV5RakFOYnKqW2ZRcYmGkoqSjlIMGCppV2jDmJqa1rVAw0hQzfX/PwA "Ceylon – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Challenger5 Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

### ColdFusion, 276 bytes

```coldfusion
<cfset u=Chr(34)><cfset q="<cfset u=Chr(34)><cfset q=%s%s%s><cfoutput>%screateObject(%sjava%s,%sjava.lang.String%s).format(q,[u,q,u,Chr(35),u,u,u,u,Chr(35)])%s</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#createObject("java","java.lang.String").format(q,[u,q,u,Chr(35),u,u,u,u,Chr(35)])#</cfoutput>
```

I've never used ColdFusion, but after seeing @Danninta's post on [Self-growing code codee codeee codeeee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/158429/9365) I thought I'd play around. This could almost certainly be golfed down by someone that actually knows the language, so feel free to add a new answer.

Tested locally on lucee-express-5.2.6.60

Answer (score 0):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 4 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
£↕26
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.2/JstxGWT.html?code=wqPihpUyNg%3D%3D)

Comment: You might want to include an explanation, I'd be interested! Also I believe you'll need to include a newline in your code since the output of this program seems to include one as well.

Comment: I assume you are the created of Jstx and the GitHub? In your documentation you mention all the possible commands/operations/functions, but not which character represents it. Since I couldn't find it in the documentation, what commands/operators/functions do these `£` and `↕` represent?

Comment: It's not a solid association between opcodes and bytes, and it changes from version to version of the interpreter and compiler. In fact some opcodes can actually remap every opcode to byte association at runtime. Fortunately you don't need to worry about which bytes correspond to which instructions because all the programming is done directly through instructions using the Jstx compiler, then the resulting bytes can be interpreted with the same version  of the Jstx interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 147 bytes

```php
<?php $c= <<<'s'
	$n='<?php $c= <<<\'s\''."\n";global $c;echo($n.$c."\ns;\n".'$e=create_function("",$c);$e();');
s;
$e=create_function("",$c);$e();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcpBCsMgEEDRdTxFkIFRKF5glFxEKOkwrYUwSkzPb9NlVt3@91tpY8SllTYDpznGiB3NBJrwUjP2jBhsVkuvrT7W7RQSLtWBBuCfdDo1IEjiXdZD7s@P8vGu6qy9AXsCcZ7Qk@lk/lxjfAE)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 77 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window quine.

```vb
c=Chr(34):q="c=Chr(34):q=:?Replace(q,Chr(7),c+q+c)":?Replace(q,Chr(7),c+q+c)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 7 bytes

```
"'<~S@|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19J3aYu2KHm/38A)

#### Explanation

```
  <        Entry
"'         Push the " character (loop around)
      |    Mirror (loop around)
"          Begin string mode
 '<~S@|    Push the string '<~S@|
"          End string mode
 '<~       Push and pop a < character
    S      Swap stack the following also work, r: reverse, q: concatenate, +: add
     @     Print and terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 71 bytes

```
q:=34|chr|str;a:="q:=34|chr|str;a:=%swrite(a%%(q.a.q))"write(a%(q.a.q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8lMqfz/v9DK1tikJjmjqKa4pMg60cpWCUNEtbi8KLMkVSNRVVWjUC9Rr1BTUwkmAhP4/x8A)

`q:=34|chr|str` gets a quote character, and `a:=...` defines the format string. Finally, `write(a%(q.a.q))` formats `a` with `a` surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tamsin](https://github.com/catseye/Tamsin), 67 bytes

```python
main='->T&$:repr(T)->U&\'main=\'+U+T.'->T&$:repr(T)->U&'main='+U+T.
```

Ungolfed (isn't a quine, but outputs a quine):

```python
main =  '→T&$:repr(T)→U&\'main=\'+U+T.' → T
     &  $:repr(T) → U
     &  'main=' + U + T.
```

Tamsin has a builtin that formats strings correctly, which makes this fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

## [anyfix](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix), 29 bytes

```
“8221"’OƥO«"ƥ«”8221"’OƥO«"ƥ«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8yrTMus@P//UcMcCyMjQ6VHDTP9jy31P7Ra6djSQ6sfNczFIsr1/z8A)

Another half finished golfing language. This is rather longer since the string quoting uses different starting and ending quotes, both with large ordinal values. There's probably a shorter way that I'm missing.

#### Explanation

```
“8221"’OƥO«"ƥ«”                    Push string
               8221                Push 8221
                   "’              Duplicate and decrement
                     Oƥ            Convert to character and print (starting quote)
                       O«          Convert to character and swap with string
                         "ƥ        Duplicate string and print
                           «       And swap end quote back to top of stack
                                   Implicitly print from top of stack to bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Atari BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_BASIC). 4 bytes

```
1 L.
```

Well known since the release of the language, and the result of two quirks of this BASIC dialect.
Most BASICs only let you run outside commands in immediate mode, but Atari BASIC allows a line number here.
Secondly, there's a full list of abbreviations for the common commands.

Comment: I thought about entering this in common 8-BIT basic, but I am not sure about this rule: "No cheating -- that means that you can't just read the source file and print it", so my entry is non-competing and just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyret, <s>72</s> 61 bytes

```python
a="\nprint('a=' + torepr(a) + a)"
print('a=' + torepr(a) + a)
```

No, I can't remove the spaces surrounding the `+`

I'm learning a little Pyret because my brother is taking a coding class where this is being taught and he wanted me to help him learn.

Answer (score 0):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
¶ąőÖ‹ĄU¶ąőŘ␖×>şŃtŞ¶×>ş
```

Decompressed:

```
[.>]4.JU[.>]@[.>]4.JU[.>]
```

```
[.>]4.JU[.>]@[.>]4.JU[.>]
[  ]    [  ]              while loops
 .>      .>               print char and go to the next cell
    4.                    set the cell to @ (64 = 4*16) and print it
      JU                  go to the first cell and remove the last
            @             end the program
             [.>]4.JU[.>] initializer data
```

Answer (score -2):

## [Conway's Game of Life](https://copy.sh/life/), 7 bytes

```
!
**
**
```

Uses [Plaintext](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Plaintext) format.

Comment: 5 bytes, you missed the newline. Alternatively, in Standard Plaintext: `**\n**`

Comment: What interpreter are you running this in?

Comment: @WheatWizard This is not necessarily run in an interpreter, it simply means "a 2x2 square of live cells in an empty grid".

Comment: Languages are defined by their interpreters, if you don't have an interpreter that can take this as a source file then you can't submit this to a challenge.

Comment: @WheatWizard Fixed.

Comment: @Riker Nope, that's talking about the *final* line. This is the *initial* line and AFAIK it's necessary.

Comment: -1 this method of IO is very limited

Comment: @ASCII-only since when do quines need input?

Comment: Well this method of output mostly

Comment: The output of a CGoL program is some kind of storage, escaping glider streams, or even via a 7-segment display, almost anything but the next generation. Care to try hello world with this method? And since when are we using plaintext? RLE is much more canocial.

Comment: This is no different from the answer `1` in most languages, because it doesn't do any computation or have intermediate states.